# O que fazer com perguntas no estilo "Como fazer X?"

Tags: debate, fechamento, voto-contra, qualidade

Estava dando uma olhada na [fila de revisão/análise de primeiros posts](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts), e notei várias perguntas que eu votaria contra no StackOverflow, porque o autor não demonstrou esforço de pesquisa, nem de solucionar o problema por conta própria. Basicamente, são perguntas do tipo "Como fazer X [na linguagem ou ferramenta Y]?"

Alguns exemplos:

- [Sobre menus em sites](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23860/sobre-menus-em-sites)
- [Enviar imagem ao selecioná-la e mostrar miniatura sem dar refresh na pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5581/enviar-imagem-ao-selecion%C3%A1-la-e-mostrar-miniatura-sem-dar-refresh-na-pagina)
- [Como verificar se uma string possui apenas letras maiúsculas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/como-verificar-se-uma-string-possui-apenas-letras-maiusculas)
- [Capitalizando nomes em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247/capitalizando-nomes-em-c)
- [Como obter a última data de um dia da semana num determinado mês no SQL Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328/como-obter-a-ultima-data-da-ultima-semana-num-determinado-mes-no-sql-server)
- [Como usar Packages no Laravel 4?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327/como-usar-packages-no-laravel-4)
- [Django: Como agrupar registros utilizando o ANO a partir de um campo FieldDate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316/django-como-agrupar-registros-utilizando-o-ano-a-partir-de-um-campo-fielddate)
- [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferenca-entre-duas-datas)
- [Dúvida sobre px, dp, dip and sp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295/duvida-sobre-px-dp-dip-and-sp-no-android)

Como eu disse, eu tenderia a votar contra em boa parte delas, se não em todas. Porém, estou tentando rever meus procedimentos, considerando que este é um site novo, onde devemos criar regras novas. Estou disposto a acatar o resultado das decisões que tomarmos em conjunto, mesmo que venham a ser contrárias às minhas opiniões.

Então, como vocês acham que devemos lidar com essas questões? Deixá-las como estão? Editá-las? Votar contra? Votar para fechar?

A propósito, existe uma [discussão recente sobre a questão do esforço](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort) lá no "metão" (em inglês).

Comment: O que me preocupa mais é a proporção exagerada delas. E isso parece ocorrer mais, em alguns casos, pela empolgação de postar algo do que por uma dúvida genuína. Também prefiro ouvir os demais, eu tenho opiniões muito enraizadas e pelo menos nisso não vou tentar influenciar. Só observo que a edição não deve ser o caminho. Não dá para terceiros arrumar uma questão ruim p/ o autor. A edição é boa p/ resolver pequenos problemas que melhore a compreensão ou facilite a busca futura mas o conteúdo não pode ser alterado.

Comment: O que a maioria de nós considera como parte do esforço mínimo, pode não estar ao alcance daqueles que não conseguem compreender um texto em inglês.
Em muitos casos só conseguimos encontrar as respostas para perguntas desse tipo na documentação da linguagem/framework, ou no stackoverflow em inglês...

Comment: @Guilherme Provavelmente cada um tem mesmo seu próprio critério para decidir o que é esforço "mínimo". Mas será que quem pergunta não deve ao menos tentar demonstrar o que sabe, o que pesquisou, o que encontrou (ou não), e o que já tentou? Senão fica difícil respondermos, não sabemos o ponto de partida da pessoa.

Comment: @bfavaretto, acho esta pergunta importante, bom você ter colocado aqui. Já agora, qual é a sua opinião nesta matéria?

Comment: @Sergio Minha opinião é de que precisa mostrar esforço. Mas tenho questionado isso até mesmo no SO, nem sempre é um requisito absoluto. "Como fazer X" pode gerar ótimas respostas. E as respostas não seriam o filé do site? Não é atrás delas que vêm os googlers?

Comment: Sim, e no caso de conteudo em português o SOpt pode mesmo ser uma "meca" de conteudo. Btw, onde está a medalha "reversal" no SOpt? ela podia ser uma boa razão para dar um incentivo a boa resposta e penalizar uma pergunta muito má.

Comment: Acho que tá lá, @Sergio, não chama "reversão"?

Comment: Aha, sim. Não tinha visto, obrigado. Assim já há um incentivo para penalizar a má pergunta e produzir boas respostas...

Comment: Boa pergunta, acho importante discutir isso cedo antes que se torne um caso quase irreversível como esta o SO agora.

Answer (score 39):

Creio que para determinar se o autor de uma pergunta demonstrou esforço ou não, temos que levar em consideração ao menos 3 fatores:

1. Existe documentação [oficial ou não] acessível [i.e. em português] que responde a essa pergunta? (i.e. jogando ela no Google retorna logo um post falando sobre o assunto)
2. Se trata de uma *feature* obscura e/ou pouco utilizada que exigiria **experiência** para se conhecê-la, ou talvez uma grande familiaridade com a ferramenta (ex.: buscar as respostas no código fonte)?
3. Se trata de um comportamento inesperado (bug, exceção ou resultado incorreto) que o autor não consegue entender a razão, e precisa de ajuda para depurar?

---

O primeiro caso é simplesmente uma questão de "fez ou não fez o para-casa"... o único cuidado que é preciso ter é que o público-alvo aqui no SO-PT é justamente quem não tem o domínio do inglês, e portanto algo que seja "óbvio" para quem tem pode ser de difícil acesso para quem não tem. Apontar essa aparente falta de documentação pode ser uma demonstração razoável de esforço (ex.: procurei por "PHP maiúsculas" e "PHP capitalização" e não retornou nada de útil).

Eventualmente, muitas buscas no Google de "como fazer X" vão acabar direcionando para esse site - assim como já acontece no SO em inglês - e com frequência isso é útil por apresentar uma resposta **direta** e **condensada** em contraste com uma completa e elaborada, cheia de discurso, que é o que se espera de uma documentação bem-feita.

(a propósito: meu comportamento no SO sempre foi o de não estimular essas perguntas simples quando eu as encontro **enquanto utilizo o site**, mas quando estou trabalhando e uma dúvida minha é respondida por uma pergunta desse tipo eu "retribuo" votando a favor de ambas a pergunta e a resposta que me ajudou - pois se foi útil pra mim pode o ser para outros)

---

O segundo caso é, na minha opinião, um dos principais benefícios de se existir um site como esse. Digamos que você tem um objetivo [incomum], quebrou a cabeça com ele por vários dias, e eventualmente chegou a uma solução após muita pesquisa e testes. Em algum outro lugar alguém está precisando fazer a mesma coisa, e resolveu buscar ajuda aqui. Com sua experiência passada você é capaz de dar uma solução direta e sucinta em poucos minutos, enquanto outra pessoa teria de fazer o mesmo caminho tortuoso que você.

Nesse caso, eu diria que simplesmente citar por que as soluções "óbvias" não se aplicam já seria uma demonstração satisfatória de esforço. Por exemplo, se o autor [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316/django-como-agrupar-registros-utilizando-o-ano-a-partir-de-um-campo-fielddate) tivesse acrescentado algo como "num campo normal eu poderia usar um `group by`, mas como ele é uma data e eu quero agrupar por **uma parte** dessa data eu não sei o que fazer" isso já demonstraria um conhecimento básico do problema e por que uma solução vai além desse conhecimento básico. Sem isso fica difícil saber o que o autor já domina, e ficamos nos perguntando coisas como "ele sabe o que é `group by` ou não?".

A ausência de documentação envolvendo os *corner cases* também pode justificar uma pergunta desse tipo. Embora um bom programador deva ter a habilidade de **ler códigos fontes** (já respondi muita pergunta sobre tecnologias que nem domino - inclusive ganhando *bounties* - simplesmente buscando a resposta nos fontes), em geral esse é o último recurso utilizado - mesmo porque alguns códigos costumam ser intrincados e de difícil compreensão por quem não o escreveu. Some-se isso ao fato da maioria dos códigos estar em inglês, e temos uma situação semelhante à do caso 1 acima.

---

O terceiro caso também se beneficia de uma referência rápida (deu uma exceção? copia e cola no Google e já vem uma pergunta/resposta que a explica de forma sucinta), e muitas vezes esse formato é mais **conveniente** que a documentação tradicional (muitas ferramentas não documentam bem os casos excepcionais ou, quando o fazem, apenas dão uma lista de "esse método pode lançar essa exceção" mas sem explicar bem quando e porquê, e quase sempre sem mostrar exemplos).

(isso é um pouco mais geral que "como fazer X", mas tem pontos em comum: se você sabe como/a documentação explica como fazer `X`, e você quer fazer `X'` muito semelhante a `X`, e inesperadamente ou devido a alguma particularidade o método não funciona)

Nessa situação, a demonstração de esforço consiste largamente em apresentar um exemplo completo - de preferência reprodutível - e demonstrar por que o autor acredita que o código está correto de acordo com as especificações. Ficar citando coisas como "já tentei depurar fazendo isso ou aquilo" na minha opinião é desnecessário, pois se o código parece correto a uma primeira leitura então o problema por definição está em algum detalhe obscuro (por outro lado, se o autor não está confiante que o código está correto e quer simplesmente que alguém o corrija pra ele, sem nem tentar, aí já não considero aceitável).

---

Em suma, eu particularmente considero perguntas do tipo "como fazer X" bastante úteis ***a posteriori***, mas à primeira vista fica difícil julgar se uma pergunta específica é desejável ou não, de modo que uma mínima demonstração de esforço é desejável. Mesmo para "afunilar" as opções que o respondente pode considerar como viáveis para se resolver o problema ("ajude-nos a te ajudar").

Quanto ao que fazer com uma pergunta de má qualidade [e que não se enquadrem nos critérios de fechamento] eu sugiro votar contrário, de preferência **comentando por que fez isso** e **dando a chance do autor se redimir**. E se possível ficando de olho na pergunta por mais algum tempo, pois se o autor editou a pergunta de modo a aumentar sua qualidade, você ainda possa retirar seu voto contrário e/ou até mesmo dar um voto positivo.

Comment: Sua análise é perfeita! Estou marcando esta resposta como aceita, não porque ache que ela encerra a discussão, mas porque ela merece toda a distinção possível neste momento.

Comment: "Saber o que o autor já domina" é fundamental para uma pergunta "respondível" (existe isso?); acho que procurar situar quem responde quanto a isso é uma demonstração suficiente de esforço para legitimar a pergunta.

Comment: Eu estou com o mgibsonbr. É fácil perceber quando o autor fez alguma pesquisa antes de postar a pergunta. Se a pessoa está na empolgação de contribuir (como bem colocado pelo bigown), o segundo passo é moldar essa empolgação. O formato do site também requer certa pesquisa (seja dentro do proprio SOpt seja portando perguntas de outros sites). Eu sou 100% por ensinar usuários novos a usarem o site, e isso, ao meu ver, passa sim por votar contra ou mesmos fechar a pergunta com um comentário esclarecedor. Ao menos foi assim que eu aprendi nos golden years do SOen.

Comment: E eu queria dar +10 para o último trecho em negrito: Deixem um comentário antes de fechar a pergunta. Se você for o voto número 4 de 5 em uma pergunta sem comentário, mesmo que a mão esteja coçando para fechar a pergunta, se force a postar um comentário antes de fechá-la. Toda vez que uma pergunta de um usuário novo é fechada sem comentários um boto-cor-de-rosa-programador morre :).

Answer (score 15):

No começo ocorreram problemas que não estão ocorrendo mais. Se eles voltarem ocorrer, precisaremos tomar providências.

---

## Atualização de 2018

Voltaram ocorrer e em volume expressivo. É a tal coisa, quando tínhamos cuidado deu para segurar, começamos fazer o que alguns queriam de deixar tudo mais solto e o que aconteceu foi isso. Pessoas que queriam mais liberdade foram embora e deixaram a bomba para outros lidarem.

Agora nem sei mais o que fazer. Tenho fechado quase tudo que vem dessa forma "Como fazer X". Não mudei de opinião, só que agora essas perguntas não demonstram interesse em aprender ou qualquer esforço. As perguntas só pedem um tutorial, ou uma receita de bolo, de algo pronto pára ele usar, e sequer tem informação suficiente.

Estamos vivendo uma era de programador que pede para outras pessoas fazerem e recebem os créditos, inclusive financeiro, em cima do trabalho dos outros.

Não temos gente com capacidade (conhecimento, tempo e disposição) para lidar com tanta pergunta ruim. E temos pessoas sem a capacidade tentando fazer alguma coisa, talvez só querendo pontos, ou nem isso, mas com muita ingenuidade. A qualidade indo pro ralo. Tenho preferido fazer um fechamento sumário. Não sei se estou certo, mas é o que parece mais adequado no momento. Espero novas soluções.

---

Algumas vezes se discutiu neste tópico sobre a qualidade das perguntas. Pergunta cujo conteúdo é ruim, mas aceitável para o site deve ser votada negativamente para facilitar que outras melhoras tenham mais destaque. Isso sempre foi assim e sempre será.

Vou tratar do fechamento ou tentativa de salvação da pergunta.

#### Exemplo específico

Fiz a pergunta [Quais as principais vantagens e desvantagens de se usar um parser LL ou um LR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2044/quais-as-principais-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-se-usar-um-parser-ll-ou-um-lr) ([veja a edição original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2044/1)) que pode passar como [subjetiva](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) e a deixei um pouco vaga ou com possibilidade de resposta relativamente ampla.

Todo mundo deixou passar (até houve quem disse que poderia ser ampla demais), ou porque acham que não é ampla, ou porque viram meu comentário na pergunta que eu estava testando os limites da comunidade ou porque acham que eu sou bastante ativo aqui e não erraria e então temeram fazer alguma coisa errada (e não deveriam, posso errar tanto ou mais que qualquer um aqui, sem falsa modéstia).

Também ajudou ter uma resposta boa e que talvez não foi mais votada porque as pessoas não voltam nas questões que já passaram e não são tão interessantes para ela ou por não saberem se a resposta realmente está certa, já que é um nicho desconhecido pela maioria dos desenvolvedores.

#### Conhecimento prévio antes de perguntar e agir sobre as perguntas

A única coisa que não se discute é que qualquer um que se disponha a responder a pergunta, **deve** ter conhecimento sobre o assunto.

**Você só pode tomar uma atitude com uma pergunta, *se* você tem [conhecimento razoável sobre o assunto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/482/como-lidar-com-perguntas-com-certo-grau-de-subjetividade/483#483)**. Seria temerário alguém achar que a pergunta deva ser fechada se ela própria não entende o que está se tratando ali. Claro que existem casos mais fáceis do que outros.

No caso específico, eu tenho conhecimento sobre o assunto e mesmo que não tivesse, [eu sei a resposta para essa pergunta específica](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19541/what-are-the-main-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ll-and-lr-parsing).

No texto [Gorila vs Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark) fala muito sobre isso.

Eu escrevi a pergunta como se não soubesse nada sobre ela, como se eu não entendesse do assunto e não tivesse feito pesquisa prévia para tentar perguntar melhor. E a pergunta não segue bem a diretriz (e não política compulsória) colocada no texto explanatório do Jeff Atwood. Por outro lado o [Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) diz que [aqui pode ser diferente].[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQG1F.png).

Muitas vezes aplicamos regras sem questioná-las. **Talvez** estamos errando e nem nos damos conta.

Precisamos entender que muitas vezes a pergunta não está boa, dá margem para subjetividade ou deixa ampla por acidente. O autor não sabe como perguntar melhor. Mas pior do que o autor da pergunta não saber, é os outros membros que sabem menos ainda sobre o assunto acharem que podem determinar se aquilo pode ou não ser respondido adequadamente. Ok, ele deu margem tanto para a amplitude como para a subjetividade, mas não foi sua intenção.

Devemos aceitar amplitude e subjetividade acidental então? Não, mas não podemos avaliar o que também não entendemos claramente. E **se entendemos bem sobre aquilo**, então temos capacidade de ajudar o autor, **editando** a pergunta ou **questionando** ele para tentar compreender onde ele quer chegar e ajudar a ter mais subsídios para uma edição melhor. **Tentar salvar a pergunta é a primeira ação**. Contudo, milagres ainda não são possíveis.

**Fechar a pergunta quando tudo foi tentado é a última ação**. Ela deve ser tomada quando não há colaboração suficiente para salvar algo potencialmente útil.

Exageros não serão tolerados, claro. Perguntas intencionalmente fora dos padrões também não.

#### Pergunta melhorou mas as respostas não

Existe o caso em que a pergunta foi mal formulada e foi melhorando. Só que nesse meio tempo respostas foram sendo colocadas. E elas já não dizem respeito à pergunta atual. Se essas respostas não forem apagadas espontaneamente pelos autores, a pergunta precisa ser fechada, ela está toda comprometida.

Provavelmente seria ideal o autor reverter as edições e abrir uma nova pergunta, agora da forma correta. Não vejo isso ocorrendo em outros sites, talvez porque comecem julgar que o assunto não deveria estar ali depois de tantos erros. Mas acho que podemos fazer isso aqui. Temos que nos esforçar para aceitar conteúdo bom e útil.

#### Outros exemplos

Não vejo problemas na maioria das perguntas citadas na pergunta deste debate e em outras do site.

- [Django: Como agrupar registros utilizando o ANO a partir de um campo FieldDate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316/django-como-agrupar-registros-utilizando-o-ano-a-partir-de-um-campo-fielddate)

  A pergunta está bem ruim, difícil de entender o que se quer, mas ela foi respondida e aceita. Vai fazer alguma coisa? Eu ainda não consigo me decidir nisso. Normalmente fecharia a pergunta sem pensar. Mas é a atitude mais correta?
- [Qual a diferença entre px, dp, dip and sp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295/duvida-sobre-px-dp-dip-and-sp-no-android)

  Ficou bem aberto mas obteve uma resposta aceitável. E aí? Eu sei lá do que está se falando, nem posso dizer se é muito amplo. Tenderia dizer que sim, mas parece que não foi. Talvez, às vezes, queremos ser mais realistas do que o rei.
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-programming
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91350/what-should-every-programmer-know

  O que fazer com listas desse tipo? São amplas mas são úteis.
  A primeira eu obviamente conheço bem. Ela foi feita no começo do Programmers onde valia tudo. Ela está extremamente mal feita e mesmo assim está aberta porque é útil e tem algum limite de escopo.
  A segunda veio do Stack Overflow porque lá a pergunta passou ser *off-topic*. Na verdade uma delas deveria ser fechada como duplicata, mas tem algum problema em fazer isso também. Ela tem diversas respostas duplicadas e isso deveria ser tratado, não foi. Mas é outro problema que precisamos evitar aqui. Ali claramente houve exagero. Essa pergunta é mais longa que a minha mas é pior, porque claramente ela deixa ampla para dizer sobre o que quiser. Perguntou sobre Gorila vs Tubarão.
  Nenhuma das duas são boas, mas se fossem um pouco mais bem feitas, basicamente a mesma pergunta pode ser feita aqui? <sub>(devo abrir um pergunta para isso?)</sub>

## Perguntas não respondidas

**Vamos pender mais para a diretriz do Jeff ou do Gabe** (ambos falam pelo Stack Exchange). Um falou há alguns anos de modo geral como a rede deveria se comportar. O outro fala, agora, como nossa comunidade deveria se comportar. Em outras palavras, **é preciso pesquisa prévia?**

Veja o que diz o próprio *engine* quando vai se votar negativamente na pergunta:

[image: tooltip]

Precisamos achar uma decisão definitiva sobre isso agora que temos mais subsídios.

Para ajudar traga outros exemplos que mereçam ser debatidos, mesmo que sejam em inglês. Vou tentar trazer outras depois, visitem aqui quando ela tiver atualização.

Vou começar fazer algo que me esqueci completamente de fazer. Adicionar ao favorito para receber notificações das perguntas que devo monitorar de perto.

Comment: Sobre a pergunta dos parsers, eu ainda não entendo por que você acha que podem achar subjetiva. Eu achei que podia ser ampla demais – em parte por falta de conhecimento sobre o assunto, a resposta provou que é possível responder àquilo sem se alongar demais. Estranhei também porque parecia alguém que não sabe nada sobre o assunto perguntando sobre algo que supõe diversos conhecimentos prévios (até para perguntar, não só para responder). Nem depois da edição ficou claro qual seria o conhecimento prévio do seu "personagem". "Será que para responder precisa ensinar a criar um parser?", pensei.

Comment: Pontos de destaque, que valeria a pena até negritar na pergunta: **Você só pode tomar uma atitude com uma pergunta, se você tem conhecimento razoável sobre o assunto.** /// **Fechar a pergunta quando tudo foi tentado é a última ação. Ela deve ser tomada quando não há colaboração suficiente para salvar algo potencialmente útil.** /// **Vamos pender mais para a diretriz do Jeff ou do Gabe?**

Comment: Retomando a questão do esforço que estava na minha pergunta: quem pergunta precisa se esforçar para deixar bem claro a quem responde qual é o tipo de resposta necessária. Precisa no mínimo dar elementos para que possamos inferir o que a pessoa sabe e o que não sabe. Tendo isso na pergunta ou comentários, cai a chance de eu considerar subjetiva demais, ampla demais, pouco clara, ou off-topic/lista de X. E sobre as duas listas citadas, podem ser úteis mesmo. Mas se esse tipo de pergunta for liberado, teremos mais conteúdos úteis ou inúteis no site? Acho que inúteis, mas topo esperar para ver.

Comment: @bfavaretto Perguntas assim videm sendo fechadas no SO. No Programmers não. Só que a regra deveria ser a mesma para todos os sites. Cada um tem seu tópico, cada um afina um pouco, mas se ela não é subjetiva aqui e nem no Programmers, porque ela é no SO? Ela pode parecer subjetiva porque muita gente achar que pediu comparação, é subjetiva. Agora você conseguiu mostrar bem o problema dela, poderia ter comentado lé para melhorar nesse ponto. Claro que isso não é uma crítica, apenas reforçando o que disse do que devemos fazer em qualquer situação. Comentar "eu não entendi esse ponto, esclareça".

Comment: @bigown Na minha opinião, as últimas edições na pergunta dos parsers saíram pela culatra: ao tentar expor um conhecimento prévio a pergunta caiu no [problema XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), e ao listar itens na tentativa de "afunilar" as respostas ela se tornou ampla demais (pois para "responder a pergunta" teria-se que abordar cada um daqueles itens, que são muitos). Eu não "deixei passar" a edição original, eu gostei da pergunta e "upvotei", e por mim esse tipo de pergunta seria on-topic no SOPT. Agora, "unupvotei" e **respondi**, pois o aumento do escopo me permitiu fazê-lo...

Comment: @bigown Sobre a comparação entre o SO e o Programmers, eu entendo que um é sobre "problemas encontrados na frente do IDE" e o outro sobre "problemas encontrados na frente do quadro-negro" (i.e. problemas conceituais/de projeto), mas não gostaria que essa distinção rígida se aplicasse aqui. Nesse ponto concordo com [aquele primeiro post do Gabe](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com), onde ele sugere "permitir alguns outros assuntos relacionados a programação" e não "antecipar problemas". Sou a favor de questões conceituais - desde que objetivas.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Concordo, certamente não deve ter distinção. A dúvida é o quanto a pergunta precisa ser bem feita, deixar em escopo menor (por exemplo, limitar a um tópico ou deixar falar da programação como um todo) e principalmente se vamos aceitar perguntas que potencialmente gerem lista de conteúdo útil e permanente (inútil ou localizado no tempo, claro que não). Se uma pergunta que gere uma lista enorme tem essas características e ainda for *objetiva* ou *subjetiva boa*, deve ser aceita ou não? Já adianto que eu acho que sim.

Comment: @mgibsonbr E concordo que as edições não foram tão boas assim. Bem observado. Embora dê para responder. Eu editei e a pergunta válida (tem outra com outro problema que vou abrir discussão) continua válida depois de toda discussão. Nem uma nem outra edição estava boa. Esse é uma caso em que eu deveria fazer 8 perguntas (ou próximo disso)? Vou ver o que dá para melhorar sem estragar mais ou tornar inválida. Boa experiência aqui. Precisamos determinar se vamos ter essa rigidez ou não.

Answer (score 9):

O que vai acontecer com o tempo, são essas perguntas não serem respondidas, apenas ignoradas.

Agora eu pergunto: **você se empenhou antes de votar negativo?**

Porque eu ainda não descobri como usar packages no Laravel 4. Até hoje, nem sabia o que era Laravel, parece um Ruby on rails para PHP. Descobri como criar packages, mas também não sei como usá-las exatamente.

**Complemento:**
Agora eu sei como usar o Laravel, alguém respondeu a pergunta no StackOverflow.

Comment: Gostei do "você se empenhou antes de votar negativo?". As vezes nós achamos uma pergunta muito óbvia ou simplista e a tendência é já chegar com a mão cheia de pedras. Em minha opinião a primeira coisa a fazer é *esperar um pouco* antes de criticar, pois o autor pode reformular a pergunta ou alguém que entenda melhor a situação terá tempo de atuar. A segunda coisa é avisar o autor da pergunta sobre qual é o problema, pois até quem já é mais experiente às vezes não enxerga. Depois, quem sabe no dia seguinte, se nada evoluir, *downvote* neles!!!

Comment: Eu votei contra algumas das perguntas da lista, em outras me contive. Geralmente não voto contra quando não sei a resposta - ou ao menos onde encontrar a resposta. Em alguns casos, voto para fechar. Nessa do Laravel, não fiz nada. Quando eu acho que sei como ajudar o autor a melhorar a pergunta, deixo um comentário a respeito, independentemente do meu voto, ou mesmo de ter respondido.

Comment: @utluiz Tem pessoas costumam deixar para depois, correndo o risco de deixar passar algo ruim e aquelas que preferem agira já, correndo o risco de não reverter a situação quando a pergunta foi melhorada. Nunca consegui descobri qual é a melhor, eu mesmo acabo adotando ambas em situações diferentes. Acredito que isso vai da personalidade de cada um e seja difícil "impor" uma única forma de agir. De qualquer forma as boas perguntas sempre contém bastante informação do que o autor já fez, e diga claramente onde ele está esbarrando, tem que facilitar a vida de quem vai responder...

Comment: ... Quem está precisando de ajuda é o autor da pergunta, a não ser que a pergunta tenha sido postada artificialmente. Por isso perguntas artificiais são problemáticas, elas tendem a produzir conteúdo ruim. Ela não explica muito porque já sabe a resposta. Claro que existem outras vezes que a pessoa é tão leiga no assunto que não consegue formular a questão compreensivelmente, mas e aí é responsabilidade dos outros se virarem para responder? O SO ajuda mas não torna o mundo perfeito.

Comment: Curto e grosso, se a pergunta é desse tipo mas não tem como achar no resto da net, pertence aqui sim, não acham?

Comment: "você se empenhou antes de votar negativo?" - um voto negativo pode significar que o autor da pergunta é quem tem de se empenhar mais. Quem tenta responder está dispondo de seu tempo para ajudar os outros, e tem um certo direito de exigir clareza e um referencial sobre quem está perguntando (quanto o outro sabe?)

Answer (score 9):

Estamos falando em upvotes e downvotes, mas estamos esquecendo no no-vote.

Upvote traz uma série de benefícios a quem pergunta uma boa pergunta, da mesma forma pra quem responde uma boa resposta.

Um downvote traz uma medida disciplinadora, que instrui a quem perguntou uma pergunta ruim (ou respondeu com pouca qualidade) a tentar melhor da próxima vez.

O no-vote é uma situação que vem da própria comunidade: uma pergunta com poucos votos é pouco relevante, uma resposta com poucos votos, da mesma forma.

Entendo que tenhamos que nos preocupar com a dinâmica inicial do SOPT, e talvez devamos começar por esclarecer quando, exatamente, usar o downvote. Viu uma pergunta que não considera *relevante* e deu um downvote? Não concordo. Estando dentro do tópico do SOPT, cumprindo a proposta, pode ser que venha a ser relevante pra outras pessoas.

Entendo o SO e o SOPT como um lugar para respostas rápidas (ainda que devam ser muito bem elaboradas e embasadas), mas um caminho mais curto do que ler a documentação ou passar horas ligando os pontos.

Entendo o valor do esforço de disciplina para os novatos **dentro do beta**, e acredito que esse esforço será relaxado, uma vez que a comunidade como um todo começar a ignorar perguntas irrelevantes e valorizar perguntas pertinentes.

Comment: Então você acha que em última instância o botão de downvote nem precisaria existir, e tudo se auto-regularia? Pelo que andei lendo, no início do SO isso foi bastante discutido, e decidiram que ele era fundamental (mas com perda de pontos também para quem vota contra, em perguntas).

Comment: Não, eu acho que o downvote é disciplinatório. Assim, existem coisas boas, coisas ruins, e coisas sobre as quais não posso aferir qualidade (ou mesmo tenho opinião formada). Existem coisas certas, coisas erradas e coisas que ficam, moralmente, numa zona cinzenta. O upvote é para premiar as boas perguntas, as boas respostas. O downvote é para punir más perguntas/respostas ou comportamento indevido no SOPT, mas as coisas que estão entre um e outr serão regulados automaticamente.

Comment: É claro que isso é a minha humilde opinião. Será que cola um MHO? =P

Comment: MHO é perfeito! E é (quase) igual em inglês!

Comment: O downvote é importante para colocar p/ baixo as perguntas e respostas ruins, separando das boas. No caso das respostas isso é mais óbvio porque em em cima vir as respostas que estão corretas, são relevantes ao que foi perguntado e não está atrapalhando o entendimento do problema. No caso das questões, downvotes ajudam destacar as melhores perguntas (já que as piores vão para baixo) e ajudam as pessoas decidirem se vão investir nela ou não. Hoje isso pode não parecer importante, mas quando tiver muitas questões isso será fundamental. Não tem porque não começar separar já.

Comment: @bigown, eu entendo seu posicionamento a respeito dos down e upvotes. Mas entendeste meu argumento a respeito do no-vote? Tens alguma consideração?

Comment: Entendi, acho que tem casos que para tudo, não vou sair votando em todas questões que aparecem, não sei de tudo e não tenho posição definida sempre. Ainda vou escrever sobre isso, mas não acho tempo.

Answer (score 6):

Acho que é importante haver regras, especialment agora que o site é novo. Porém acho que pode ser aqui que está a diferença entre este Stackoverflow e o original em Inglês.

Partindo do princípio que uma das necessidade principais em existir um br.stackoverflow.com é compensar a falta de recursos de quem não sabe falar Inglês, então, justifica-se ser mais tolerante, uma vez que esses utilizadores terão dificuldade de encontrar essa informação em português.

No caso então de sermos mais tolerantes com o conteúdo, devemos também ser claros em votar negativo e fechar perguntas "secas", sem explicação; e também perguntas onde seja óbvio o desconhecimento total sobre a pergunta colocada.

Comment: Cada vez concordo mais com essa posição, mas sempre com um pouco de medo de ficar igual a tudo que tem de ruim por aí.

Comment: @bigown concordo. É importante o SO ser um site para respeitar, e não vir aqui perguntar como aprender sem saber nada ou sem tentar respeitar as linhas da comunidade.

Comment: @Sergio Eu acho que seria bom por isso tentar de todo tipo de pergunta "sem saber" ter uma resposta boa como referência para depois antes de fechar, para daí poder fechar esse tipo de pergunta a vontade. Se é pergunta boba mas não tem resposta no site, acho que ao menos essa resposta explicando pq a pergunta é boba, e como obter resposta a isso, deveria estar presente como exemplo.

Comment: @LaPingvino, concordo.

Comment: Quando a pergunta não diz muito, fica difícil saber por que a pessoa está perguntando. Pode ser por não saber inglês e não ter achado a resposta, mas também pode ser porque o cara está com preguiça de pesquisar/estudar. E aí, alguém aqui quer ficar gastando seu tempo com preguiçosos, ou gente que quer terceirizar seu trabalho ou lição de casa para o site? Esse é o meu medo.

Comment: @bfavaretto, verdade. No SO original, aparece muita gente a querer fazer o trabalho de casa sem querer pensar/aprender. Nesses casos a pedagogia melhor pode ser commentar sem responder. Hmmm... dificil prever que tipo de AP  e perguntas vão aparecer aqui.

Comment: Daí curiosidade minha, desculpe a minha ignorância: tem mt curso no Brasil onde isso se aplicaria? Também acho que melhor fazer distinção entre pergunta tipo trabalho de casa (que não vai ajudar a ninguém além desse trabalho) e perguntas semelhantes que solvem um problema verdadeiro, de qual não tem informações na net (ao menos em Português). Desse último tipo acho que ao menos dar uma resposta mínima, mostrando o caminho, será bom dar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu particularmente ignoro completamente se há prova de esforço ou não. Acho totalmente irrelevante.

Se a pergunta é boa, não há motivo para não responde-la. Imagine que alguém criou uma pergunta muito boa, mas não demonstrou esforço para solucionar, você vai fechar a pergunta? E os milhares de usuários que vem do Google procurando a mesma coisa, se deparam com uma questão fechada sem respostas, será que estes iriam ter coragem para perguntar novamente? Sendo que já teve uma questão fechada?

**Nós não respondemos apenas para quem perguntou, isso aqui não é um chat privado**, nossas **respostas são publicas** e de beneficio para qualquer um que tenha o mesmo problema.

Comment: Pergunta capciosa: e o que define uma pergunta "boa"?

Comment: @bfavaretto muitas coisas. Um código que não funciona e _wrong assumptions_ só são realmente uteis quando a pergunta é mais especifica e é preciso de contexto para identificar o erro. Muitas perguntas genéricas são muito melhores sem um monte de _lixo_ confundindo a questão.

Comment: Nesse ponto concordo com você. O que precisamos achar aqui é uma definição de boa pergunta, e do que vamos aceitar ou não. Só o tempo dirá :)

Comment: `"Se deparam com uma questão fechada e sem resposta"`, e com uma explicação muito clara do *porquê* do fechamento e *do quê* deve ser feito pra fazer uma pergunta *on-topic*. Isso não acontece "do nada" nem é irreversível.