# O que fazer com perguntas que podem ter múltiplas respostas?

Tags: debate, perguntas

A pergunta [Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/793/diferenca-na-utilizacao-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint) foi a motivação dessa discussão.

Precisamos definir como tratar esse tipo de pergunta. Até podemos, por coincidência, seguir o que outros sites já fazem, mas não precisamos nos preocupar com isso. Ou podemos criar nossa própria regra, que atenda nossos interesses.

Ela deixa ampla para responder sobre múltiplas tecnologias. Claro que poderá haver respostas que atendam todas as tecnologias especificadas, mas pode ser que gere respostas diferentes para cada tecnologia. Nesse caso, não há uma resposta certa, mas várias.

O que fazer nesse caso?

- Não permitir que ela exista? Talvez sugerindo que ela seja feita para cada tecnologia separada.
- Permitir desde que seja wiki. Exigir ou sugerir?
- Permitir de qualquer forma porque o importante é que gerará conteúdo útil para o autor e outros leitores
- Outra solução

Comment: Como eles agem com esse tipo de questão no SO?

Comment: @Zignd Deliberadamente eu não coloquei porque somos uma nova comunidade que pode agir sem muita preocupação com o que os outros fazem. Vou editar para reforçar isso. Só quis deixar claro que não precisamos seguir o que outros fazem.

Comment: @Zignd No SO fechamos a mesma por "muito vaga", que é basicamente dizer que tem que ser limitada a uma linguagem em particular.

Comment: Lendo a atualizacao da resposta do @mgibsonbr e pensando um pouco aqui, se eu for desmembrar a minha pergunta, sera no minimo 3 perguntas especificas, oracle, mysql e sql server (nao sei se repetiria a pergunta sobre oracle, porque a que ja existe nao questiona ou aborta varios outros itens citados na minha pergunta). Para mim, isso nao seria mal, o google poderia indexar e eu ate ganharia mais pontos (se eu quiser olhar por esse lado), porem para quem esta pesquisando pelo mesmo ponto de vista que estou questionando fica muito mais dificil conseguir uma resposta objetiva e rapida.

Comment: Pessoal, acho esta discussão válida e necessária, mas me senti totalmente injustiçado com a tal da "duplicidade" da questão. Então para que não fechem, editei e deixei especifico para MySQL, abri outras questões para SqlServer e Informix, mas na de Oracle, não abri outra pq sei que vocês vão fechar ela então na questão original adicionei um comentário solicitando para detalhar a minha duvida. Porém não tenho fé de que vou conseguir uma resposta, pois como a resposta está aceita, diminui em muito a chance de outros lerem minha duvida e complementar a resposta. E ai, como consigo minha resposta?

Comment: @ceinmart Eu ainda não sei o que fazer com sua pergunta. Sei que ela não é duplicada e outra não será também. Se você conseguir fazer a pergunta deixando claro as diferenças para a outra, você vai ganhar apoio. *Para todos*: tentar convencer outras pessoas é um exercício fabuloso e ajuda no crescimento profissional e até pessoal de qualquer um. Haverá casos que gerará frustração mas podemos tomar isso como incentivo para melhorar a capacidade de persuasão, mesmo que seja apenas escrevendo um texto de uma forma melhor para sutilmente convencer todos que você está no caminho certo.

Comment: @bigown, Gostaria de ter alterado minha questão para community wiki, mas não tenho acessos para isso. Então fiz as alterações que muitos estão solicitando (ainda assim marcaram a outra questão como duplicada! vai entender), mas vejo uma inflexibilidade aqui que considero degenerativa para o SOpt, pois se for para ficar limitando outras informações técnicas só porque uma questão é parecida (não igual), vai ficar muito pobre este SO de informações. Já que pessoas não vão conseguir pedir detalhes diferente sobre a mesma situação, mesmo que para tecnologias diferente.

Comment: @ceinmart O começo pode trazer algumas dificuldades, mas a experiência mostra que a comunidade (membros ativos e moderadores) acerta em quase 100% das vezes. Existem mecanismos para evitar quase todos erros. Claro que muitas vezes a pessoa que não conseguiu o que queria vai sempre achar que a comunidade está errada. Ás vezes é preciso um pouco mais de esforço para conseguir o que quer. Não estou falando que não é o seu caso, falo genericamente para que essa informação sirva para todos. Eu sempre estou atendo para ver se algo está indo mal e tentar ajudar dentro do que eu posso.

Answer (score 7):

Sei que já deixei algures um comentário ou resposta sobre este mesmo assunto, mas a minha opinião é:

**Uma pergunta para não ser fechada tem que ter uma resposta que a comunidade aceite como "a correta", e que em termos práticos pode ser testada ou implementada para se comprovar.**

Para que tal aconteça, todo e qualquer cenário que leve a "múltiplas respostas corretas" não vai beneficiar ninguém, vai gerar discussão e duvidas <sup>*(ver exceções mais a baixo)*</sup>.

## Penso que:

A pergunta pode ser respondida corretamente múltiplas vezes devido ao fator linguagem? Ok, vamos dizer ao OP para colocar a mesma pergunta para cada uma das linguagens à qual o mesmo pretende obter uma resposta, e limitar a actual a uma só linguagem através da inclusão da respetiva tag.

---

## Exceções

Existem claro cenários onde várias respostas estão válidas, como é o exemplo de uma pergunta sobre "Como deslocar o elemento X para a esquerda?" onde vão surgir vários excertos de código diferentes, todos a chegar ao mesmo resultado final, mas mesmo aqui o OP consegue escolher o que mais se adequa ao seu caso em particular e marcar essa resposta como correta, ao que as outras respostas vão ser votadas pela comunidade e receber também a sua reputação.

---

<sup>**Notas:**

Este tópico é de certa forma extenso e permite uma discussão longa, pelo que, para já limitei a minha resposta ao problema da pergunta em questão...</sup>

Comment: Na segunda frase, em negrito, creio que você quis dizer "para *não* ser fechada", não?

Comment: @bfavaretto certo! :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Um formato que eu me lembro de já ter visto (depois procuro as fontes) é:

- Permitir que cada um adicione uma resposta envolvendo uma tecnologia específica;
- Criar uma resposta do tipo *community wiki* contendo a melhor "resposta geral" (i.e. independente de tecnologia) e **links para cada resposta individual** - servindo como um índice para a forma de se aplicar aquela técnica à sua tecnologia de escolha.
- Aceitar essa resposta, de modo que ele fique no topo.

O único viés que eu vejo é que provavelmente terá muita resposta duplicada, e não tem muito o que fazer com elas (exceto votar nas melhores para que subam, e só incluir estas no índice). Creio que num primeiro momento poderíamos permitir sim esse tipo de pergunta na comunidade. Se surgirem problemas inesperados, a gente reavalia.

### Utilidade

Algúem poderia se perguntar: "qual a utilidade de uma pergunta que não está direcionada para um caso específico?". Embora reconheça que isso é mais uma exceção do que uma regra, existem casos em que uma **solução conceitual** é conhecida, mas **aplicá-la** a um caso particular não é muito claro.

Fiz uma pergunta desse tipo uma vez no SO em inglês (["Clearing memory in different languges for security"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10166986/520779)) motivado pelo fato de que conhecia uma recomendação de segurança a partir da documentação do Java, mas sempre que precisava fazer algo numa plataforma diferente tinha dificuldade de encontrar a informação necessária. Da mesma forma, a pergunta ["Como prevenir ataques do tipo SQL Injection"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312) poderia (se estivesse formulada de uma maneira menos ampla) se beneficiar desse formato (a intenção original do autor era que cada resposta envolvesse uma tecnologia específica).

Em ambos os casos, trata-se de um interesse coletivo (aumentar a segurança), muito semelhante às perguntas de ["como fazer X?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/105). Na minha opinião (outros podem discordar) é mais interessante formular as perguntas nesse formato do que ter várias parecidas onde só muda a tecnologia:

- [Como faço para remover acentos em uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-faco-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string) (C#.NET)
- [Remover acentos de uma String em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/remover-acentos-de-uma-string-em-java)
- (logo vão surgir perguntas semelhantess pra PHP, Python, Ruby...)
- [Capitalizando nomes em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247/capitalizando-nomes-em-c)
- ...

Eventualmente (se for uma necessidade comum) seria útil coletar essas perguntas num "índice", com links para cada pergunta individual. Se a pergunta já foi feita com a intenção de criar um índice, não vejo muita diferença...

**Contra-argumento:** "é besteira se criar um índice manual, deixa o Google fazer isso por você"

Eu até concordo, o problema é que às vezes fica difícil se diferenciar entre a ausência de soluções para determinada tecnologia e a ausência de perguntas sobre ela. Existe uma maneira segura de se limpar a memória em JavaScript? Eu não encontrei, será que devo perguntar? Mas se está lá o índice, e não tem entradas pra JavaScript - ou a melhor resposta diz que não é possível - então eu saberei que tenho que pesquisar por conta própria, uma solução de conhecimento comum não existe.

### Conclusão

Na minha opinião, se o autor da pergunta decidiu fazer um esforço ativo pra construir um índice, e alguém (ou ele próprio) decidiu fornecer respostas, então não há motivo para bloqueá-lo. Desde, é claro, que isso seja feito de forma organizada e padronizada. Peço que avaliem o formato sugerido acima, talvez com a restrição adicional de que a pergunta também tem que ser *community wiki* (de modo que quem responder, será exclusivamente para contribuir com conhecimento, sem abrir a possibilidade de abuso do sistema de pontuação).

Comment: Não vejo problema especificamente na duplicidade de respostas, já que isso ocorre mesmo quando a pergunta é mais restrita. Não é o ideal, mas não é um problema adicional. O SO original deixou muita coisa para decidir depois e hoje não consegue mais resolver certos problemas. Fica difícil instruir novos usuários fazerem o certo quando tem postagens ruins antigas quando era permitido. Aí ou você não conserta ou elimina conteúdo relevante porque ele não mais está em acordo com as novas regras.

Comment: @bigown Falo porque o problema se potencializa quando tem muitas tecnologias envolvidas (ex.: 3 pessoas respondendo pra Java, 4 pra C#, 2 pra Python, 5 pra PHP... tudo numa mesma pergunta). Numa pergunta "normal" a duplicidade não é um problema, é até uma coisa esperada (na Area 51 diz-se que "2.5 respostas por pergunta é um beta saudável, 1 só precisa ser mais trabalhado"). E concordo com você que temos que estabelecer *guidelines* agora, sim! Tanto que sugeri um formato, para entrar na discussão.

Comment: P.S. disse que ia procurar fontes, mas até agora infelizmente não estou encontrando... Costumava ter algumas perguntas desse tipo nos FAQs antigos, mas depois da reformulação da Ajuda já não consigo achar algumas coisas de que me lembrava

Comment: Claro, entendi isso.

Comment: Ola a todos, sou o autor da pergunta discutida e concordo com o mgibsondbr. Entendo que a pergunta nao vai resolver um problema especifico, mas esse tambem nao foge da parte tecnica util aos desenvolvedores e dbas. Perguntas separadas nao vao responder objetivamente. Concordo que se houver multiplas respostas a questao deve ser convertida em community wiki e entao linkado as respostas mais validas.

Comment: Ainda deliberadamente evitando me posicionar nesse momento, achei bom mostrar que apesar da postura do SO original ser de não permitir esse tipo de pergunta, elas existem aos montes organizando as respostas em índices. Por isso achei por bem discutir isso. O SO tem muitas regras que na prática não são seguidas. Vamos tentar evitar isso definindo uma regra clara, benéfica e que os membros concordem. Eu sei que o tamanho do site dificulta ter uma postura linear, mas também tem o problema das regras mudarem muito no meio do caminho.

Comment: Só uma ideia, que na verdade teria que ser dita para a equipe do SO. Na wikipedia quando você está vendo uma página em inglês tem um menu a esquerda com links para o mesmo artigo em outro idioma. Talvez algo assim pudesse ser implementado, mas ao invés de idioma seria linguagem de programação/tecnologia...

Comment: Seria tipo aquele campo ao lado de toda pergunta escrito vinculado, onde fica as perguntas da qual a atual é duplicada, basta o sistema do Stack Exchange nos dar permissão para modificar aquilo. Acho que se num feedback você explicasse como isso poderia melhor o site, talvez eles aceitariam.

Comment: @Zignd basta ter um link na pergunta e/ou em alguma das respostas para uma outra pergunta no mesmo site, que elas aparecem na lista de perguntas relacionadas [se é que é disso mesmo que você está falando]. Por isso creio que uma resposta-índice teria o mesmo efeito (seja ela uma resposta destacada - no início - ou não).

Comment: Embora minha ideia pareça legal, eu não acho que eles iriam nem se quer considerar e a questão teria uns -20 votos. Mas se alguém quiser tentar sugerir me passa o link que eu apoio.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que as perguntas devem ser específicas sobre uma determinada tecnologia e não exigir uma resposta que englobe varias outras tecnologias (como por exemplo: "Como faço X no SGBD I, J e K?").

Desse modo:

- ficará mais fácil apontar qual a possível duplicata de uma pergunta;
- teremos perguntas e respostas menores, por tanto você consegue o encontrar o que procura com mais rapidez;
- a manutenção é mais fácil, pois suponha que eu conheço muito bem uma determinada tecnologia, mas nem tanto uma outra que está na mesma pergunta ou resposta, ficaria mais fácil para mim aplicar uma modificação pois teria certeza que ela se encaixaria nesse contexto.
- para o OP ficaria muito mais fácil identificar qual é a resposta correta, pois suponha que o usuário A respondeu a pergunta ("Como faço X no SGBD I, J e K?") englobando todas as tecnologias, mas deu maior enfase e melhores explicações na tecnologia I, já o usuário B fez o mesmo, mas deu maior enfase e melhores explicações na tecnologia J. Provavelmente o OP ficaria confuso já que só pode escolher uma questão como correta.

Sendo assim concordo com o primeiro tópico que diz que esse **não podemos permitir esse tipo de pergunta**.

Comment: Embora eu concorde com muitos dos seus argumentos, creio que a decisão que precisamos tomar não é estabelecer "qual o formato ideal de pergunta", mas sim "se a pergunta está no formato X, ela deve ser permitida ou não?".

Answer (score 1):

#### Em termos gerais

Perguntas com mais de uma resposta têm o seu lugar. Às vezes existem várias maneiras de se fazer a mesma coisa, como menciona o Zuul. Isso eu aceito totalmente - até porque não é raro alguém postar uma resposta super completa que englobe múltiplas soluções.

Já casos que requeiram um índice, como os citados pelo mgibsonbr, tenho mais dificuldade em aceitar. Não é o formato ideal para o engine do site, então parece gambiarra. Para que eu deixe de votar para fechar (ou até vote para reabrir), o autor terá de me convencer da utilidade da pergunta e das respostas que ela possa gerar. Essas perguntas, no SO, hoje só sobrevivem após diversos fechamentos e reaberturas, e discussões no meta e por chat.

Portanto, "perguntas com mais de uma resposta" não é uma categoria boa para o julgamento das perguntas, pelo menos não por si só. Algumas são completamente válidas, outras são totalmente inválidas; e sempre há uma grande zona nebulosa entre esses dois grupos.

#### Sobre a pergunta que gerou esta discussão

Eu me pergunto se a [versão original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/793/1) é mesmo uma pergunta sobre várias linguagens. Qual seria a utilidade prática de se perguntar isso? Talvez o desenvolvimento de uma camada de abstração que converse com todos aqueles SGBDs, mas nesse caso o autor deveria deixar isso bem claro.

Me parece mais uma pergunta teórica do tipo "Conheço bem a ferramenta tal e sei que ela se comporta assim. Isso é um standard desse tipo de ferramenta? Outras similares se comportam igual?" Isso pode ser uma boa pergunta. Acho que o erro do autor foi listar e usar como tags os outros SGBDs.

A "mitose" da pergunta em várias não me pareceu uma boa solução. Não resolve o problema do autor, que queria uma comparação de várias coisas, e o grupo de perguntas parece ter brotado artificialmente no site, considerando que ele é hoje bastante pequeno.

Answer (score -1):

Deve ser retirada.

É uma pergunta que por si só mostra que o locutor quer discutir o assunto. Pela sua experiência ele poderia ter acesso a documentação livros, tech specs, irc, fontes específicas etc.

Devemos seguir o que vem funcionando no stackoverflow em inglês. Perguntas amplas, não construtivas ou objetivas devem ser sinalizadas.

Comment: Discutir? não mesmo! Não pedi opiniões, pedi como funciona. Simples e direto. Entendo que a realmente pode gerar múltiplas respostas como o @bigown citou, mas é a natureza da situação (programar para sistemas multi-BD). Em questão de ter acesso a documentação livros e etc, todos nós temos e todos nós podemos pesquisar e testar.Mas se for assim , pra que existe o SO? Entendo que ele existe justamente para encurtar este caminho e dar respostas objetivas. Seja unificando o conhecimento (respostas community wiki) ou deixando ele espalhado em pequenas migalhas (perguntas individuais).

Comment: PEnso não ter me expressado bem: Seria melhor dizer que quem pergunta quer ouvir outros pontos de vista.