# Quando se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título?

Tags: suporte, faq, perguntas, título

Vejo que muitas vezes é redundante colocar o nome da linguagem/tecnologia no título - uma vez que já existem as tags - e ele acaba sendo posteriormente removido por um editor. Entretanto, em alguns formatos de pergunta (por exemplo o ["como fazer X"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/sobre-esforco-em-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x)) **não colocar** acaba tornando ela meio vaga:

- [Como faço para arredondar números para o inteiro mais próximo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/815/como-faco-para-arredondar-numeros-para-o-inteiro-mais-proximo)
- [Como faço para remover acentos em uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-faco-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string)

Essas são perguntas que, muito provavelmente, serão feitas para múltiplas linguagens, isto é, a menos que a comunidade aceite [perguntas que formam listas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-com-podem-ter-multiplas-respostas). Compare as perguntas do mesmo tipo, mas que incluem a linguagem no título:

- [Capitalizando nomes em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247/capitalizando-nomes-em-c)
- [Remover acentos de uma String em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/remover-acentos-de-uma-string-em-java)

Se formos mesmo repetir essas perguntas múltiplas vezes - uma para cada linguagem - como fica a situação do título? O que consideram mais apropriado?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Eu particularmente quando faço uma pergunta muito específica antes, além da tag também menciono a linguagem de alguma forma no título. Não sei se o Google indexa o conteúdo levando e consideração nossas tags. E quase sempre que faço uma pesquisa com nome da linguagem aparece um resultado do SOEN.

Comment: Eu acho interessante colocar a linguagem na pergunta, apesar de já ter acostumado olhar as TAGs se a intenção é trazer mais pessoas para o SOpt quanto mais detalhado mais fácil para o visitante que não conhece ainda a ferramenta.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

É comum ver perguntas com títulos to tipo:

- *[PHP] Como fazer tal coisa?*
- *Erro #0000 ao compilar biblioteca tal - Android, Windows, Java, MVC*

Essa é uma convenção das listas de correio eletrônico e dos antigos fóruns na web.  Serve para saber qual o assunto daquela *thread*. A rede Stack Exchange usa um [sistema de classificação através de Tags](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) e não tem *threads*, que é o que também se refere o Tour do site com o ["*Não tem bla bla bla*"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

É muito fácil buscar e listar perguntas com as tags, e a maioria dos usuários que respondem seguem as do seu interesse e podem ignoram outras:

<kbd>[image: assinatura de tags na página principal]</kbd>

Para buscar por um assunto específico, use `[nome-da-tag] assunto da pesquisa` no box de busca.

Além disso, o meta elemento `<title>` no HTML é criado com a tag de mais peso na pergunta:

<kbd>[image: título na tab do browser]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: título na página do sopt]</kbd>

**Não use tags no título**, é redundante.

**Quando for necessário usá-las**, deve ser em estilo conversacional e orgânico, como no caso de:

> Posso usar jQuery para fazer tal coisa, ou tem que ser JavaScript puro?

Comment: Deu vontade de ir totalmente contra nosso [guia de estilo e formatação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/74) para destacar a frase **Não use tags no título, é redundante.** :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, ali no GEF não se fala da formatação dos títulos, deveriamos? . . . Aliás, a única referência é a resposta do Matheus, que revela exatamente de onde vem essa convenção ultrapassada: `Eu uso fóruns há anos na internet e sou a favor de títulos esclarecedores`

Comment: Mas... não tem como formatar os títulos (das perguntas, se é disso que você está falando). Não sei se essa parte das tags se encaixa lá. Acho que estava na versão original do bigown, e eu removi para focar em formatação. Se bem que em "estilo" poderia entrar mesmo.

Comment: É, removi mesmo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/1297/revisions (ver rev. 10)

Answer (score 11):

Não acho que fique meio vaga, para isto servem as tags...

Se procurar no google [esta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102806/340760) com a tag e sem o nome no titulo ([busca no google](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=How%20should%20I%20concatenate%20strings?&btnG=Search&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=#hl=en&q=How%20should%20I%20concatenate%20strings?%20site:stackoverflow.com&safe=off)) o resultado é

> c# - How should I concatenate strings? - Stack Overflow

Caso a tag seja incluída no titulo o sistema automaticamente insere a segunda tag mais popular no titulo. O resultado, neste caso, seria:

> .net - How should I concatenate strings in C#? - Stack Overflow

E para uso interno fica pelas tags. É possível adicionar tags favoritas mostrando o que é mais relevante para você.

Comment: Interessante, não tinha reparado nessa funcionalidade! Ou seja, na sua opinião não é problema existirem N perguntas com o título igual, somente com as tags diferentes, é isso? E quanto às perguntas que **já** têm a linguagem, deixamos como está ou sugerimos uma edição para removê-las?

Comment: Me sinto indiferente quanto a isso, não acho que isso tenha sido um problema no Stack Overflow e talvez não seja um problema aqui. Pode ser que tenha casos que uma tag no titulo o deixe mais legível, então não acho necessário remover, só caso esteja muito redundante...

Comment: Também não vejo necessidade de se criar um padrão, seja de incluir a linguagem no título ou não. Não vejo vantagens em se adotar um dos dois, e ambos tem a desvantagem de criar um fardo pra quem pergunta.

Answer (score -3):

Não tem porquê reinventar regras e discussões que já foram discutidas e fazem parte do StackExchange.

Como podemos ver, essa discussão já foi levantada e inclusive já está no [FAQ do MetaStack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

A resposta para a [pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) foi que nós não devemos colocar a linguagem no título visto que as tags funcionam muito bem. Porém não é proibido coloca-la, segue exemplos reais:

Não deve ser feito:

```
OCI-22053: erro de overflow - C#
```

Pode ser feito:

```
Como importar arquivo MDB ler e gravar no SQL
```

Novamente, acho que devemos olhar pelo menos o [FAQ existente em inglês](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) para não perguntarmos algo já respondido.

Comment: Não há pre-requisito de compreensão de inglês, ou de familiaridade com o Stack Exchange pra fazer parte do SOPT. Além disso, nós temos total liberdade para criarmos nossas próprias regras.