# Como lidar com edições em postagens?

Tags: debate, formatação, postagem

Em [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/qual-seria-o-uso-adequado-de-formatacao-em-perguntas-e-respostas) já foi tratado do uso adequado do *markdown*. Algumas respostas forma interessantes mas ficou uma dúvida?

Um *guideline* foi estabelecido?

O que fazer com quem não segue o *guideline*?

Eu já vi o próprio Gabe, entre outros, revertendo (automática ou manualmente) edições que não seguem alguns padrões de fato que o site segue. Devemos fazer o mesmo? (eu tenho feito)

O que fazer quando um usuário insiste em fazer edições que serão revertidas por outro logo em seguida?

E pior ainda. Quando ele insiste na edição dele que está fora dos padrões do site, caracterizando um *edit-war*, o que fazer?

Parece existir outros abusos de edição de código, potencialmente descaracterizando sua intenção original. Ok, eu sei que o ideal é reverter, mas tem alguns usuários que insistem.

Uma coisa é ficar editando para melhorar o que alguns usuários, especialmente novatos, não postaram bem. Outra é ficar arrumando o que alguns usuários insistem em estragar os *posts*.

Detalhe importante: **esperei o problema acontecer**. São edições que estão gerando mais trabalho do que solucionando qualquer coisa. Na minha opinião, é melhor ficar totalmente sem essas edições, mesmo perdendo também uma ou outra boa que as pessoas que estão abusando fazem.

Comment: Acho bom padronizar, pois vejo um abuso do sistema de edições inconsistentes e/ou desnecessárias: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/14553/revisions . Isso acontece costumeiramente, e são sempre os mesmos 2 ou 3 users que enfiam chuva de tags no post, e/ou misturam o sentido de cada um. Além disso, tem a questão dos edit wars, mas foge dessa pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco Essa edição é um caso típico, e cada mudança que ele fez, ele formatou de forma diferente, ou seja, nem ele sabe como formatar. Várias vezes ele já ficou editando de novo p/ ficar c/ a última edição e que fique do jeito que ele goste, independente do padrão adotado no site.

Comment: Mas esse user faz isso costumeiramente. Já vi mais de uma vez arrumarem bagunça dele e ele volta e mexe, não sei direito qual é o objetivo verdadeiro. Se fosse só deixar o post em ordem, não teria essa obsessão por ser o último a mexer sempre. Num caso normal eu deixaria uma mensagem tentando orientar, mas no caso em pauta vira sempre bate-boca.

Comment: Ele tem uma pauta toda própria do que deve editar. E pior que não é o único que faz edições que não ajudam nada e fogem do padrão. Alguns casos são mais bem intencionados que outros. Mas só boa intenção não ajuda o site.

Comment: @bfavaretto Se achar que é duplicata, pode fechar. Talvez eu possa mudar alguma coisa porque no fundo minha preocupação é o abuso.

Comment: @bfavaretto editei para evitar a duplicidade. Aceito sugestões.

Comment: Certo, você focou na questão do abuso, que é mesmo outro problema. A minha pergunta foca em guidelines de formatação, e mesmo não tendo consolidado nenhuma, seria o lugar para consolidá-las. O problema do abuso e principalmente edit wars precisa ser tratado por moderadores, então não podemos fazer muito além de sinalizar e debater opiniões aqui. Seria legal ter uma resposta do Gabe à sua pergunta. Já o caso dos votos pra fechar "em rebanho" e badge hunters me parecem diferentes, que mereciam uma pergunta separada.

Comment: Pedi explicitamente ao FCCDias para participar aqui; se não houver diálogo, acho que uma puxada de orelha por parte do moderador é fundamental.

Comment: @brasofilo legal! Ele não é o único, tem vários casos de edições em que a pessoa só edita para deixar do jeito que ele gosta sem melhorar a qualidade do post em nada e ir em direção contrária ao padrão que o site tem adotado.

Comment: É, eu já vi alguns casos, mas nunca disse nada aos editores... Mas acho que tendo um post canônico aqui no Meta e dando um toque deve ser suficiente na maioria das vezes. Mas, neste caso, a *Edit war* já indica um temperamento "teimoso" ;)

Comment: Tem teimosia mesmo. E não parece tanto porque já houve bate-boca com algumas pessoas que tentaram ajudá-lo a entender o que estava fazendo. Mas esses comentários me geral são apagados para não poluir a pergunta. Então como não existem moderadores que ficam vigiando o site o tempo todo, o problema não fica aparente. Mas ele sempre se acha certo e todos os outros estão errados. Veja só http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14553/copiar-html-e-alterar-ng-model#comment25786_14553

Comment: Ah! Que pena, ele apagou. Na essência ele disse que todos nós é que devemos mudar.

Comment: Parece que ele não sabe que moderadores podem ver os comentários deletados.

Comment: para deixar claro é que esse não foi a primeira vez que ele entrou em edit-war e que ficou reclamando que os outros estão errados. E ele é o caso mais aparente e mais grave mas tem outras pessoas fazendo edits indesejáveis, mas essas outras **parecem** ser um pouco melhor intencionadas. Resolvi levantar a questão porque o problema é recorrente.

Comment: Para entender um pouco mais no que ele está interessado e o quanto ele tem interesse em fazer parte de um comunidade: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14292/discussion-between-fccdias-and-brasofilo

Comment: Eu por acaso estava acostumado no SOEN a colocar a sigla `HTML` como código, mas acho muito mau gosto editarem só por isso. Como código ou sem ser código o que interessa é que esteja legível e percetível. Acho que também estão a embirrar com ele.
Eu por exemplo gosto de por estrangeirismos em itálico. São gostos, mas desde que esteja percetível acho que não deveriam mexer.

Comment: Pelo o que eu vi no histórico, o FCCDias quis manter a todo custo sua edição, começando a sabotar as edições posteriores a dele. Outro detalhe foi em relação ao título, mudou de 'alterar' para 'manter', depois reverteram, e ele não mudou novamente. Acho que ele deveria vir aqui e explicar o que aconteceu, talvez o que motivou ele a fazer isso tenha uma explicação razoável.

Comment: @PauloMaciel é mais ou menos isso. Na verdade se observar bem ele nem manteve um padrão de edição, cada vez mudou a mesma coisa de um jeito diferente que a anterior que ele mesmo tinha feito. A preocupação não era um formato específico e sim que a dele prevalecesse.

Comment: @bigown Já fiz algumas perguntas no SOEN e nunca foram editas, mesmo com saudações, mesmo com algumas siglas erradas. Acho que o povo anda demasiado preocupado com edições. Se o texto está limpo, para que andar a editar? A meu ver era deixar pelo menos uns minutos para que o próprio autor pudesse editar.

Comment: Estamos a começar e toda a gente quer mostrar serviço, mas tenham calma, relaxem e deixem o povo editar as suas próprias perguntas

Comment: Já teve pergunta sua editada no SO e em geral as perguntas são bem escritas. Se elas fossem mal escritas elas teriam sido editadas como acontece com a maioria dos posts ruins. Experimenta escrever de qualquer jeito lá e veja o que acontece. Eu defendo que edições mínimas que vai ajustar só um detalhe sem muita importância devem ser evitadas, assim como acontece no SO. Aqui como lá a edição deve ter relevância, deve ajudar a pergunta ser mais legível. Sempre me posicionei contra a edição irrelevante. Se eu não deixasse passar nada não teria nenhum post nem minimamente ruim no site.

Comment: @bigown Acho que por exemplo [estas edições](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/7702/revisions) são um abuso, alteração completa da questão, modificação de tags, etc. Ou estarei errado? Ah concordo só com a primeira edição do bfavaretto.

Comment: @bigown não percebia a tua resposta

Comment: @JorgeB. De uma maneira geral foram abusivas mesmo.

Comment: Outro exemplo de edição que não acrescenta nada. Fico pensando se uma pessoa que insiste em fazer edições assim que só acrescentam **ruído**, deveria continuar com privilégio de edição. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/15110/revisions

Comment: Eu discordo um pouco do consenso a respeito de edições mínimas. Acho que usuários que já possuem o privilégio de editar diretamente, sem passar por análise, podem sim corrigir problemas mínimos (fique claro, corrigir problemas, não alterar o post como bem entender). As edições sugeridas devem sim ser o mais completas possível, pois sem essa exigência seria muito fácil manipular o sistema para ganhar pontos.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu também não ligo para edições mínimas que não sejam para obter reputação ou ganhar medalha. Eu evito fazer qualquer edição mas não me importo quando vejo uma boa edição mínima. Só para deixar claro, você está falando em geral ou da edição que postei logo acima? Acha que essa edição acrescentou ou algo útil ou só ruído?

Comment: Eu estava falando em geral. A edição que você citou acima não acrescenta nada de útil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu sou contra a criação de um conjunto de **regras** sobre formatação. Acho que criaria um ambiente autoritário e inóspito, além de fomentar ainda mais guerras de edição, já que agora existe um jeito "certo" de formatar. Aposto o que quiserem que ia ter gente passando o dia todo acertando cada `inline` no site.

Em resumo, acho que faz mais mal do que bem.

Dito isso, esse não é o primeiro caso de desentendimento sobre regras de edição (e nem a primeira vez que vem parar no Meta) e ter uma referência para respaldar seus atos sempre é bom.

Então eu proponho a criação de um *Guia de Estilo*.

### Dá no mesmo, não?

Não na minha cabeça. O Guia de Estilo serve como referência para quem está aprendendo ou como base para resolver discussões, mas não torna todos os posts que não seguem ele **errados**. É um guia.

Os termos dele podem ser abertos à votação pelo Meta e, como de praxe, não há necessidade de seguir o padrão do SO. Não há resposta errada. O argumento para cada uma das regas ([tag-links](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-links), `inline`, etc) pode ser apresentado e a comunidade vota no que achar melhor.

### E as guerras?

Eu honestamente entendo o @FCCDias, vendo seus edits sendo constantemente revertidos sem um motivo "concreto". Mas a forma de tratar algo que você discorda não é revertendo seguidas vezes. O Meta existe para isso. Se você acredita que fizeram algo de forma indevida, discuta aqui.

A comunidade toda pode opinar sobre qualquer assunto aqui, e é a melhor maneira de fazer suas posições serem ouvidas por todos.

Comment: Concordo plenamente.

Comment: Concordo sobre a necessidade de um guia. Em relação ao usuário que você citou, você está falando especificamente da guerra que ocorreu na pergunta linkada acima nos comentários? Porque tem outros casos. Eu já tentei debater com esse usuário, e ele não pareceu muito disposto. Nesse caso, discutir no meta não adianta muito, já que a outra parte não parece interessada.

Comment: Concordo com tudo desde que fique estabelecido que um usuário também querer impor as suas vontades (declarado publicamente que é isso que ele quer) não seja considerado o certo. O que eu fiz foi trazer para o meta assim que vi que as edições não seriam produtivas. Não sei o quanto dá para perceber todos os os problemas que ele se envolveu, o quanto as pessoas tentaram fazer ele repensar a atitude e foram mal tratados.

Comment: O caso do **usuário** vai ser tratado privadamente, como de praxe. Minha resposta foi no sentido do que pode ser feito para evitar novas edit wars (sobre markdown) no futuro. Não há forma de prevenir guerras de edição, e nada que possa ser feito de forma genérica sobre elas.

Comment: Caro @Gabe, gostaria de dizer que em nenhum momento o motivo principal foi guerra, mas, aqui tem um pessoal que fica editando nossos post por nada. Tem pessoas que entram só para ficar editando desconsiderando que os outros não possam fazer ou aprender, o último war que me envolvi foi motivado a isso, a edições que muitas vezes não tem cabimento, e o fiz por vontade próprio, não sou nenhum idiota ou moleque, mas, eu mandei pelo site antes disso uma reclamação do mesmo e não obtive resposta. Relato: um dia alterei um post estava no padrão, limpo, e por causa de uma virgula outro usuário editou

Comment: @Gabe é um dos melhores que já participei, mas, aqui existem problemas como em qualquer lugar, DownVoto, por exemplo, é a coisa pior, e tem pergunta no Meta sobre isso mas, nada fica resolvido... 

Peço desculpa a comunidade, que fique claro a `comunidade` que é muito boa mesmo! 

Obrigado! sem mais!

Comment: @FCCDias Tenho certeza de que você não tem nenhuma má intenção em relação ao site. Seus posts e sua participação são muito bem vindos, tanto no site quanto no Meta. Com base nos seus comentários, está difícil entender exatamente quais os problemas que você está enxergando e é para isso que existe o Meta. Eu **realmente** gostaria de ver um post seu sobre o que você não concorda, o que acha que poderia melhorar.

Comment: @FCCDias A questão das edições é uma que poderia ter sido mais bem resolvido há algum tempo, aqui no Meta. Eu vejo que houve uma adoção "implícita" de um padrão de formatação e que pode, tranquilamente, ser visto como uma panelinha. O padrão do SO certamente não é obrigatório aqui, e pode haver mais gente como você, que gostaria de ver um outro padrão. Trazer a discussão ao Meta é a forma dar uma chance a mais pessoas participarem, que discordem de você ou que concordem, e que não teriam como opinar de outra forma.

Comment: @FCCDias Bom saber que você está disposto a discutir. Se quiser, estou no chat, pode me chamar lá.