# Quais são todos os magic links que possuímos?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, magic-links

Magic Link é um recurso muito útil que tem como principal função evitar a fadiga dos utilizadores do site.

Eles só funcionam em comentários, da seguinte forma:

1 - Você digita um atalho, ao invés de um texto imenso.
2 - Na hora que você envia o comentário esse atalho é convertido em um texto maior e já vem com um link para o assunto em questão.

Gostaria de reunir todos esses Magic Links em um só lugar para sempre que precisarmos acharmos com facilidade, pois se for difícil achá-los eles perdem o propósito de existir, correto?

Vamos colocar tudo em um único post CW, pode ser? Vou colocar todos que eu consegui coletar e quem souber de mais favor incorporar na resposta.

Comment: Acho que tínhamos um magic link para o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, mas não consegui encontrar. Alguém sabe?

Comment: Achei algo interessante: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/229289 mas no momento não posso transcrevê-los para cá

Comment: @bfavaretto, tem como personalizar a tradução dos `[help/SEÇÃO]`? Que apareçam todos como `central de ajuda` não tem nada a ver... Tem uma feature-request pra isso no Metão, mas como a gente tem localização pode ser que seja fácil do nosso lado, é?

Comment: Não sei, o Gabe ficou de levar o assunto dos magic links pra reunião com os desenvolvedores no final da semana que vem. @brasofilo

Comment: Deveria ter um para o help do markdown, que é um dos mais subutilizados do SOpt no meu ver.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Segue abaixo uma lista com todos os Magic Links que possuímos disponíveis hoje.

## Perguntas e respostas

---

Como aparece o texto: **Como perguntar**

Magic Link: `[ask]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

---

Como aparece o texto: **Como responder**

Magic Link: `[answer]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

---

Como aparece o texto: **editar**

Magic Link: `[edit]`

Para onde ele linka: para a página de edição da publicação em que está o comentário.

## Tags

---

Como aparece o texto: [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)

Magic Link: `[tag:jquery]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery

---

Como aparece o texto: [debate](/questions/tagged/debate)

Magic Link: `[meta-tag:debate]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debate

## Central de ajuda

---

Como aparece o texto: **exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**

Magic Link: `[mcve]`

Para onde ele link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

---

Como aparece o texto: **central de ajuda**

Magic Link: `[help]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

---

Como aparece o texto: **central de ajuda**

Magic Link: `[help/on-topic]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

---

Como aparece o texto: **central de ajuda**

Magic Link: `[help/dont-ask]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

---

Como aparece o texto: **central de ajuda**

Magic Link: `[help/behavior]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

---

Como aparece o texto: **central de ajuda**

Magic Link: `[meta-help]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

## Tour do site / FAQ

---

Como aparece o texto: **tour** ou **Tour**

Magic Link: `[tour]` ou `[Tour]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

---

Como aparece o texto: **FAQ**

Magic Link: `[FAQ]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

---

Como aparece o texto: **perguntas frequentes**

Magic Link: `[faq]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

## Sites

---

Como aparece o texto: **Stack Overflow em Português**

Magic Link: `[pt.so]`

Para onde ele linka: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: **Stack Overflow em Português Meta**

Magic Link: `[meta]`

Para onde ele linka (a partir do site principal): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: **Stack Overflow em Português**

Magic Link: `[main]`

Para onde ele linka (a partir do meta): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: **Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português**

Magic Link: `[chat]`

Para onde ele linka: http://chat.stackexchange.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: **Stack Exchange**

Magic Link: `[se]`

Para onde ele linka: http://stackexchange.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: **Stack Overflow**

Magic Link: `[so]`

Para onde ele linka: https://stackoverflow.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: **Super User**

Magic Link: `[su]`

Para onde ele linka: https://superuser.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: **Server Fault**

Magic Link: `[sf]`

Para onde ele linka: https://serverfault.com/

---

Como aparece o texto: ***Nome do site***

Magic Link: `[prefixo.se]`

Para onde ele linka: `http://prefixo.stackexchange.com/`

Exemplos: `[apple.se]`, `[android.se]`, `[wordpress.se]`

Comment: Não seria melhor termos esses *magic links* traduzidos para o português? Algo como `[como-perguntar]`, `[como-responder]`, `[ajuda]`, etc (talvez mantendo em inglês só casos como `[chat]`)

Comment: @LuizVieira eu acho que seria excelente, mas acho que seria o casa de abrir um novo tópico com a tag novo-recurso, se fizer ja tem meu voto. A proposito, isso tb resolveria o problema do ML edit, que o texto aparece como "edit" e não como "editar"

Comment: Feito: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/magic-links-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: `[ask], [answer], [edit], [tag:jquery], [meta-tag:discussao], [help], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior], [meta-help], [tour], [FAQ], [pt.so], [meta], [main], [chat], [se], [so], [su], [so], [sf], [apple.se], [android.se], [wordpress.se]` => [ask], [answer], [edit], [tag:jquery], [meta-tag:discussao], [help], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior], [meta-help], [tour], [FAQ], [pt.so], [meta], [main], [chat], [se], [so], [su], [so], [sf], [apple.se], [android.se], [wordpress.se]

Comment: não seria interessante ter um *magic link* de [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), assim como temos do [ask]?

Comment: criei uma nova pergunta para a questão do comentário anterior http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2357

Comment: `[portuguese.se]` [portuguese.se]