# Magic links em Português

Tags: novo-recurso, magic-links

Seria interessante termos os *[magic links](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1616/quais-s%C3%A3o-todos-os-magic-links-que-possu%C3%ADmos)* traduzidos para o Português?

Por exemplo, `[como-perguntar]` ao invés de `[ask]`, `[como-responder]` ao invés de `[answer]` e `[editar]` ao invés de `[edit]` (talvez apenas mantendo opções como `[chat]`).

Pode ser um preciosismo, ou talvez sejam mais fáceis de memorizar por quem não tem facilidade com o Inglês.

O que vocês acham? Seria possível termos uma alteração como essa por aqui no SOPT?

Comment: O Gabe ficou de discutir esse assunto na próxima reunião que tiver com os desenvolvedores, no final da semana.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322/traduzir-texto-do-magic-link-edit

Comment: Eu prefiro versões mais curtas: [perguntar] e [responder]. A confirmar: acho que os ML são implementados globalmente na rede...

Comment: @brasofilo mas nada impede que possamos pedir esse novo recurso, ate mesmo pq talvez seja hora de mudar algumas coisas na implementação do SE, já percebeu que toda modificação feita no conteúdo original afeta aqui e alguém tem que vir e arrumar na mão? A exemplo do novo boletim da comunidade, que toda hora volta para "Hot Meta Posts", imagina quando tiver SOTR, SORU, SOFR, SOGE, SOES...

Comment: @bfavaretto ficou em águas de bacalhau.