# Comportamento frente a críticas, sugestões e edições

Tags: debate, comportamento, pergunta-específica

Hoje houve uma discussão sobre o conteúdo de uma resposta [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30772/uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-grande-ou-muitas-pequenas/30780)

O autor da reposta não concordou com as críticas à resposta e contra argumentou o que gerou mais argumentações até chegar ao ponto de precisar de intervenção (muito bem vinda) do moderador para acalmar os ânimos.

Após isso o autor editou a resposta aceitando as críticas (até recebeu Upvotes), mas a discussão foi desgastante

A pergunta em si já era um pouco discutível e o autor não aceitou as remarcações de tags ou até mesmo a edição para reabertura pois a pergunta pode ter ótimas respostas.

Frente a isso a ao antigo post do @Gabe ([Estado da Pilha #1: Carinho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho)) fiquei me perguntando:

Será que o comportamento foi o correto em relação à critica da resposta? E em relação a edição para melhoria da pergunta? Ou sobre o ajuste das tags?

Será que a comunidade está indo pelo caminho correto com postagens fora do padrão ou com necessidade de melhoria?

Será que não seria melhor simplesmente sinalizar a resposta como "ruim devido ao tamanho ou conteúdo" e a pergunta como foi feito e deixar o AP sem obter o melhor da pergunta que ele fez com alguns ajustes?

Será que oferecer sugestões ou críticas é uma coisa tão ruim assim? Ou não saber ouvir ou aceitar que é?

Será que o tour não deveria ser obrigatório antes da primeira pergunta ou resposta?

Comment: Na minha opinião era fechar, negativar e está feito. Ela seria apagada como tantas outras. Ninguém é obrigado a alterar nada e ninguém é obrigado a tentar por a pergunta uma boa pergunta. Cada um sabe de si, não vale a pena entrar em discussões. Damos a opinião ao AP e ele que decida o que fazer. Se não fizer nada fecha-se (se for o caso disso) e está a andar.

Comment: Você chamou a atenção pra esta discussão nos comentários da Pergunta (problemática, mas resolvido com ajuda de veteranos) mas está falando de uma Resposta... *it does not compute*...

Comment: @brasofilo é que foi o mesmo problema, tanto na resposta quanto na pergunta. Houve esse acaloramento e discussões sobre o que foi postado tentando melhorá-lo. E em ambos os casos acho que cabe o mesmo comportamento além do que na pergunta se tem mais visibilidade para o debate

Comment: Outro esclarecimento: que eu saiba OP se refere à [pessoa que iniciou a publicação](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean), ou seja, o AP (autor da pergunta).

Comment: Acho q confundi esse conceito. Já vou corrigir. Obrigado @brasofilo

Comment: Eu dei uma resposta na questão citada, e recomendei a edição para não ser fechada por parecer uma pergunta baseada em opinião apenas. O autor achou que estava certo e deu no que deu. Tem gente que compreende e aceita dicas, tem gente que não. Não há o que fazer para mudar quem não tem vontade de coadunar com o bem de uma comunidade, a não ser clicar em (-) e esperar o trancamento.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, se você acha que a pergunta merece ser fechada, não responda, além de votar negativamente e pra fechar, peça esclarecimentos e/ou explique o que está errado. Se a pergunta pode ser salva através de uma edição que não modifique o sentido original, *just do it*.

Comment: @brasofilo, foi o que fiz, recomendei uma edição, mas abri mão de votar para que ficasse claro que eram opiniões além da minha. Fiz questão de comentar que a questão tinha potencial para boas respostas. Vai entender... Oo

Comment: Vixe, o cidadão lá se ofendeu pra valer... Tomou a [help] ao pé da letra: *`Se não se sente confortável com a ideia de que suas contribuições sejam editadas de modo colaborativo por outros usuários confiáveis, este site não é para você.`*

Answer (score 10):

> Será que o comportamento foi o correto em relação à critica da resposta?

Se alguém tem alguma reserva quanto a qualidade técnica de uma resposta, o normal é dar um voto negativo e explicar o motivo. O problema é que a reação mais comum é tomar o voto negativo como um ataque pessoal, e isso pode degenerar numa guerra verbal. Nesse caso, é melhor não alimentar o conflito e sinalizar para que um moderador intervenha.

> E em relação a edição para melhoria da pergunta? Ou sobre o ajuste das tags?

A pergunta original tinha potencial para se tornar uma excelente pergunta, mas estava mal formulada e mal tageada. As edições dos usuários veteranos simplesmente salvaram a pergunta.  O autor da pergunta só precisa conferir as seções *Perguntado* e *Nosso Modelo* da **Central de Ajuda** para entender que não houve censura ou ataque pessoal nessas edições.

> Será que a comunidade está indo pelo caminho correto com postagens fora do padrão ou com necessidade de melhoria?

O modelo wiki do Stack Exchange é o caminho correto.

> Será que não seria melhor simplesmente sinalizar a resposta como "ruim devido ao tamanho ou conteúdo"

Não, respostas erradas ou pobres não devem ser sinalizadas. Vote negativamente e/ou faça um comentário do porquê.
Em relação à pergunta, acredito que as providências corretas foram tomadas e agora o AP vai receber todos os benefícios de uma boa pergunta: votos positivos e respostas esclarecedoras.

> Será que oferecer sugestões ou críticas é uma coisa tão ruim assim? Ou não saber ouvir ou aceitar que é?

É comum confundir críticas ao contéudo com críticas à pessoa. Se a pessoa confunde isso, o problema é dela, não há muito que se possa fazer. Deixe pra lá e procure outra pergunta interessante.

> Será que o tour não deveria ser obrigatório antes da primeira pergunta ou resposta?

Isso só é um problema no Stack Overflow em inglês onde o volume de publicações é gigantesco. Aqui dá para gerenciar facilmente, é só fazer comentários explicando qual o problema com a postagem e como resolver: [[ask], [answer], [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1616/quais-s%C3%A3o-todos-os-magic-links-que-possu%C3%ADmos?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Acho que não é uma boa pergunta, principalmente quanto à formatação e clareza.
Ainda assim acredito que as edições foram precipitadas e sem conteúdo.

Olhando o histórico de atividades da questão isso fica bem claro. De antemão é feito um aviso sobre como a qualidade da pergunta influencia a possibilidade de se obter boas respostas, o que é *verdade*, mas não é a *regra absoluta*. A melhor resposta, por exemplo, ocorreu antes mesmo de qualquer edição ser feita à pergunta. É uma ótima resposta, e foi feita em cima do que, aparentemente, era uma pergunta "ruim".

Ao meu ver os votos para fechamento da pergunta foram críticos demais, basicamente por conta da presença da palavra "melhor". O texto original é perfeitamente respondível sem que se torne uma guerra de opiniões, considerando que estabelecia parâmetros objetivos para o julgamento das opções, mas, como ela abre a *possibilidade* de que uma ocorra, a comunidade decide punir a pergunta preventivamente. Não acho que isso seja o correto.

A ótima resposta que a pergunta obteve é a primeira prova de que a pergunta não era inerentemente ruim só por conter a palavra "melhor". A segunda é que o texto final, pós edições, nada mais é do que uma re-escrita que ao invés de dizer:

> Qual o melhor entre A e B?

Diz apenas:

> Por que B é ruim e A é bom?

Há uma inferência de que métodos grandes são ruins que não faz parte da pergunta original e o autor tem razão em reclamar disso. O zelo é tanto que, em prol de uma suposta melhoria no que não precisava ser melhorado, correu-se o risco de invalidar o bom conteúdo das respostas.

Em resumo, acho que houve excesso de precauções, excesso de zelo e uma aversão automática à uma pergunta que, apesar de não ser perfeita, era demonstradamente cabível no site.

Comment: Você tem razão quando diz que as edições não acrescentaram muito. Mesmo a inferência que foi acrescentada não é tão importante. O erro maior, de quem editou e de quem respondeu, foi não ter entendido que o foco da pergunta era no consumo de memória, e não no comprimento dos métodos. Mas a partir do momento em que havia 3 respostas com o foco errado, o conjunto pergunta + respostas ficou estranho.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo. Mas aí entra na parte da clareza da pergunta que ninguém se interessou, ou se dispôs, a resolver. Foram todos em cima da "principalmente baseada em opiniões" e daí pra frente desvirtuaram ainda mais a pergunta, em relação ao que o autor queria

Answer (score 1):

Só coloco esta resposta, porque a discussão deste tema começou numa pergunta que eu fiz, e que a meu pedido, foi retirado o meu nome nessa pergunta. Posto isto, e porque já passou tempo suficiente para não ser mais uma acha para a fogueira, gostaria de dizer o seguinte:

1) A um grande poder corresponde uma grande responsabilidade.

2) Se este é um espaço aberto a discussão onde todos podem responder e perguntar, eu nunca pensei usar o poder de edição a não ser para corrigir algum erro de sintaxe em código. Para o restante tenho um espaço para resposta ou comentário. É assim que eu entendo este site.

3) A falta de clareza das perguntas normalmente, são castigadas de 2 formas: ou não tem resposta ou as respostas não vão de encontro daquilo que quem pergunta quer saber.

4) Se não entender a pergunta ou não sei a resposta não respondo, mas não tiro a oportunidade de quem entendeu ou sabe a resposta de responder. Só avalio negativamente uma pergunta quando tenho a certeza absoluta que a pergunta é mesmo sem sentido. (Apesar de ver muitas perguntas que se o autor fizesse a mesma pergunta no Google ou lesse a documentação teria a resposta imediata.)

Especificamente, em relação à pergunta que coloquei:

1) A pergunta que coloquei começava assim [*"Em termos de uso de recursos e boas práticas de programação o que é melhor..."*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30772/1). Alguém logo respondeu com a sua opinião pessoal, sobre o que ele acha que devia ser. Tudo bem. Esperava algo um pouco mais objetivo. Não era o que eu estava á espera, mas como estava dentro das boas praticas, deixei. Pode ser que alguém responda com base no recursos.

2) Logo depois alguém mudou o tópico. Estranhei, a minha vontade era "ouvir" pessoas que trabalham bastante com PHP. Podia ser uma pergunta comum a muitas linguagens, mas a mim interessava-me a especificidade do PHP. **Principalmente no uso dos recursos**.

3) Para meu espanto, em vez de ter mais respostas, começaram a aparecer comentários na primeira resposta e o autor a responder em vez de usar o seu poder de edição da sua resposta de forma incluir a sugestões que aceitou.

4) Nunca pensei ter respostas baseadas na "fé" de cada um, mas em dados objetivos.

Quero deixar bem claro, que respeito a forma como cada um usa os poderes que este site dá, como espero que entendam que as minhas palavras não são uma critica pejorativa ao site. Apenas eu não me sinto confortável e não quero que um dia apareça o meu nome em algo que não subscrevo, como era o caso da pergunta depois de editada.

Quanto a sugestões e criticas feitas, ainda e sempre reservo o direito de as aceitar e seguir.

Comment: Duas meta discussões de como lidar com perguntas ["Subjetivas"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) e ["Principalmente baseadas em opinião"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-pergunta-baseada-em-opini%C3%B5es). Normalmente, o que editores mais experientes são encorajados a fazer com perguntas que estão a caminho de serem fechadas é re-escrever o texto para remover o caráter "subjetivo/opinativo" e tentar focar em parâmetros objetivos. {...}

Comment: {...} Eu realmente não vejo que a idéia original do seu post tenha sido alterada radicalmente da versão [\[1 de 6\]](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30772/1) pra versão [\[6 de 6\]](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30772/6). . . . A mudança de PHP pra *Language Agnostic* pode ser considerada sim uma alteração radical do sentido da sua pergunta mas, aqui é pura opinião, acho que as respostas agnósticas são bastante úteis a quem programa em PHP. . . . Queria saber o que vc acha da qualidade das respostas que foram dadas até agora, acha que explicam sua dúvida original?

Comment: @brasofilo, não me leve a mal nem pense que sou arrogante, mas apenas para começar a utilizar os mesmos termos, por favor pode dizer-me o que entende por "recursos"?

Comment: Acabo de ver que essa é a peça chave que provocou seu justo enfado. Tinha lido esta resposta sem atentar para isso. . . Bom, chegaste a conferir as meta discussões que linkei? Acredito que, sabendo as diretrizes para uma "boa pergunta subjetiva", e tendo em conta as respostas oferecidas lá na original, se vc tiver interesse pode abrir uma nova pergunta orientada a PHP e uso de recursos.

Comment: Parece ser que o "problema" é que era uma pergunta tão interessante que todos ficaram aflitos em editá-la para *on-topic* e que pudesse receber respostas, atropelando assim seu interesse nos recursos. . . . Anyway, agradei muito de ler a visão de cada um dos que respondeu :)

Comment: Acho que os usuários mais antigos, os que frequentam o site diariamente e os que ajudam nas tarefas de manutenção, podem ter sim tendencia a formar "turminha", mas ao mesmo tempo são os mais abertos ao debate civilizado e à procura de soluções. Ao primeiro sinal de problemas/conflitos/opiniões-contrárias no site principal, o recomendado é abrir uma Meta pergunta e solicitar [meta-tag:debate] ou [meta-tag:suporte]. Como disse, nada impede vc abrir uma nova pergunta orientada à sua dúvida sobre PHP/Recursos. Saludos!

Comment: Normalmente, quando a pergunta é perfeitamente on-topic, ninguém mexe e, se mexer alterando o sentido, o autor tem todo direito de reverter a edição. Enfim, tamos aí. Abraço!

Comment: Fiz uma ligeira edição na sua resposta com base nos nossos comentários. Fique à vontade para re-editar se achar que as ênfases não são adequadas.

Comment: Oi Manuel. Fico contente que você tenha aparecido aqui na discussão. Eu não concordo com tudo o que você disse, mas admito que a comunidade foi um pouco afobada com a sua pergunta. É uma mania que nós, que vivemos de olho no site, temos, queremos resolver todos os problemas rapidamente. A minha edição (após o fechamento), e acredito que as seguintes também, tinham o objetivo de reabrir a pergunta. Não tinha nada de vaidade no meio, isso é uma interpretação sua. Porém a pergunta passou a impressão errada para muita gente [... continua ...]

Comment: [cont.] Quase ninguém enxergou que o foco era no consumo de recursos, nem no PHP, que estava discretamente citado numa tag apenas. Veja que o próprio @brasofilo, que deve ter acompanhado a confusão toda, não percebeu esse foco nos recursos até poucas horas atrás. Eu sei que isso estava escrito lá, mas por algum motivo (retórico?), pareceu menos importante aos olhos de muita gente. Bom, não sei se você viu, mas o bigown acabou postando uma pergunta separada para atender à sua dúvida (e ele mesmo respondeu): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31485/.

Comment: Desculpe me estender tanto nos comentários. Em relação a edição de conteúdo alheio, vale a pena ler [este artigo da central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Esse tipo de edição faz parte da proposta do site. Infelizmente às vezes há equívocos. E se o equívoco vem acompanhado de uma reação mais inflamada do autor, as coisas às vezes saem do controle. Foi o que houve na sua pergunta, creio. Enfim, peço que tente não olhar o que ocorreu como um desrespeito a você, pois não foi o caso. As intenções de todos eram as melhores. Espero que você siga contribuindo com o site. Abraço!

Comment: Manuel, acompanhei de longe essa discussão. Primeiro, sugiro não usar o termo perjorativo "turminha". Sim, alguns usuários tem a visão mais ou menos alinhada por conviverem online e é mais fácil entender alguém que você já conhece do que um estranho, não é? Acontece que o site tem + de 10 mil usuários cadastrados (fora os visitantes) e apenas alguns poucos fizeram comentários, ainda tentando ajudar. Estou aqui no SOpt desde o primeiro dia e, mesmo como um dos usuários mais antigos e ativos, ainda levo "paulada" se escrever besteira.

Comment: E sobre vaidades, sim, há isso em todo lugar. Porém, isso também vale para quem escreve. Uma boa parte das pessoas que desistem do site o fazem porque tentam fazer os outros se adequarem a elas e não o contrário, isto é, adequar-se ao modo como o site funciona. Isso também não significa que o SOpt é rígido em seu modo de ser, mas que a forma de mudar é primeiro aprender como as coisas são para depois propor mudanças.

Comment: Quanto ao seu item 2, entendo que isso possa assustar, mas também me intriga. Você nunca fez um trabalho em equipe ou programação em par e assinou seu nome com parte do conteúdo feito por outra pessoa? Além disso, você é notificado da edição, pode facilmente reverter, corrigir algo que não concorde ou mesmo remover a questão.

Comment: Quanto ao item 3, embora seja de muito boa intenção sua atitude, isso permitiria respostas de baixíssima qualidade qualidade no site. Fechar perguntas *off-topic* por um processo democrático é um recurso importantíssimo do SO. Isso ajuda a manter a qualidade, mas infelizmente pode levar a excessos. E, finalmente, quanto ao item 4, creio que você está absolutamente, 100% correto. Já tivemos várias discussões aqui no meta sobre isso e minha intenção é fazer justiça a essas "perguntas boas, mas de difícil interpretação".

Comment: Concordo com muita coisa que o Manuel escreveu e acho que houve um afoitamento na análise da pergunta. Como o @brasofilo disse, lidaram como se deve lidar com perguntas subjetivas. Mas não vejo a pergunta inicial como *subjetiva*, nem *baseada em opiniões*... Ela pode realmente ter defeitos de não ser muito clara, mas não é subjetiva. O Manuel explicou isso muito bem aqui no Meta. Assim, as edições realmente deturparam o sentido inicial, buscando um adequamento desnecessário ao site.