# "magic strings" é possível?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Eu vi este link [Quais são todos os magic links que possuímos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1616/3635) então procurei (talvez eu não saiba o melhor termo pra pesquisar no meta.SE) mas não encontrei, seriam *magic strings* (não sei se este termo está correto), seria variáveis dentro dos comentários e postagens pra facilitar, por exemplo, eu quero criar alguns comentários comuns pra enviar a outros usuários como por exemplo eu digitaria isto:

- > Boa noite %ap%, está bem difícil deduzir o que pode ser, é *altamente* recomendável que leia os seguintes links para que você não venha a ter dificuldades em transmitir problemas futuros para novas perguntas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

E ele retornaria algo como:

- > Boa noite João, está bem difícil deduzir o que pode ser, é *altamente* recomendável que leia os seguintes links para que você não venha a ter dificuldades em transmitir problemas futuros para novas perguntas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Isto é possível ou já foi proposto? Isto é apenas um exemplo, poderiam ser outras "variáveis", só que no momento eu vi esta necessidade de usar o nome de quem postou, pra fazer comentários rápidos e ao mesmo tempo *parecer* mais atencioso com o autor, pra que ele crie talvez algum interesse em ler os links ou outras coisas (acho que chamar a pessoa pelo Nome, apelido, nickname, ajuda a comunicação).

Comment: +1 E acho que também seria legal se desse pra incluir o comentário enlatado inteiro. Tipo: `Boa noite %ap%, %ce1%`, onde 1 seria o número do comentário enlatado...

Comment: Ah, agora que vi o link, não sabia que já tinha alguns, muito legal!

Answer (score 10):

Não lembro de [ter visto isso no Metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new/magic-links?show=all&sort=newest&pageSize=50)... Sei que tem super-moderadores monitorando nosso Meta, mas acho que uma *feature-request* desse tipo mereceria ser feita lá em inglês para alcançar mais olhos interessados. E se quiser seguir esse caminho, sugiro estudar como foi o pedido/implementação dos *magic links* e mostrar mais exemplos do formato que propõe e porquê isso vai beneficiar a rede.

Para o que menciona, eu uso um Userscript para resolver o nome do usuário e uma Extensão do Chrome para meus próprios *magic links*. Para este último, esta outra extensão também é bastante usada: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/10590).

### [Reply link in Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments)

<sup>(minha resposta lá tem o código revisado)</sup>
[image: reply links on comments]

### [WPA-shortcodes](https://github.com/brasofilo/WPA-shortcodes)

<sup>[Escrito](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/magic-links-specific-for-wordpress-answers/) por um dos moderadores do WordPress Developers. O link acima é para um fork que fiz com código revisado e adaptado.</sup>

Magic link personalizado


<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Magic link renderizado


<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Você usa esse AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE.? Eu uso ele mas eu não consigo sincronizá-lo com aquele `remote`. Eu até cheguei a criar um repo no github com comentários enlatados pra poder sugerir ao povo de manter um repozão lá com todos, mas como não funcionou não levei para a frente. Já esse Reply link in Comments eu não conhecia mas é bem legal.

Comment: Depois dá uma olhada na minha resposta pls. Eu não entendo muito bem o funcionamento do Stack Apps.

Comment: @Math: pois é, o Reply Link facilita, uso bastante. Cheguei a experimentar o AutoReview mas achei mais simples a extensão WPA

Comment: @Math Chegou a ver o repo do script que eu criei pra popular o AutoReviewComments? Tem o link aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/707 (no fim da pergunta)

Comment: @bfavaretto pq tem que criar um servidor local?

Comment: Porque o AutoReviewComments só aceita uma URL como origem dos dados. Pode ser um serviço rodando por aí também, se alguém quiser hospedar. @Math

Answer (score 7):

Como o Brasofilo já bem respondeu, os script do [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) podem resolver o seu problema. Eu uso o [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/29568) e gosto muito. Nele você pode criar comentários enlatados personalizados e pode ou não adicionar uma mensagem de boas-vindas antes, do tipo:

> Olá [username], bem vindo ao [pt.so].

O `[username]` é trocado automaticamente pelo script do Stack App que adiciona o nome do usuário autor da publicação que você está comentando, já o `[pt.so]` nada mais é do que um magic link. Já essa mensagem de boas vindas fica desvinculada do texto, o que eu acho bem prático para poder atualizá-lo ou removê-lo da sua mensagem.

Eu cheguei a criar um [repositório no GitHUB](https://github.com/matheuscs/comentarios-semi-enlatados) para compartilharmos uns com os outros os nossos comentários enlatados, mas por algum motivo a parte do script de sincronização com um arquivo remoto não está funcionando (ou eu que não estou sabendo usar).

Além disso tem um pequeno bug com o encode dos caracteres que se o nome do usuário por exemplor for `André`, o `[username]` será substituído por `Andr&#233;`, acredito que isso pode ser corrigido e submetido na própria página do Script Apps como resposta, e você ganha reputação por isso. Essa parte o brasofilo já pode nos explicar melhor como que funciona :)

Comment: Ali no Stack Apps depende de como o AP publicou o código, se é só no Apps, então publicar uma resposta com suas melhorias é o caminho adequado. Se por acaso tem um repo no Github, é melhor ir lá para fazer feature-requests ou submeter patches. O autor do AutoReviewComments pede especificamente para usar o Github: http://stackapps.com/a/4564

Comment: O legal desses scripts/extensões é que dentro dos nossos templates podemos usar magic links, p.ex., `[perguntar]` pode renderizar como `Por favor, leia o guia [ask]` e ao adicionar o comentário o sistema faz o parse do `[ask]` oficial

Comment: Boa extensão, mas não seria melhor se fosse nativo?

Comment: @Patrick com ctz, tudo que é nativo é melhor, mas a exigência de variedade de funcionalidade dos usuários é infinita, por esse motivo que existe uma comunidade para troca de experiência e código entre os membros da comunidade. E dessa forma a gente vai se virando. Acredito que uma coisa ou outra acaba se provando essencial e a empresa resolve implementar de forma nativa, mas isso pode não ter se mostrado essencial ou viável, e está assim até hoje.