# Podemos usar a Citação <blockquote> para destacar texto?

Tags: debate, formatação

Quero confirmar a sugestão para uso do `<blockquote>` como **destaque visual** que consta no nosso [guia de formatação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas/1297#1297):

> ### Citações
>
> - A marcação de *quote* (citação) ">" deve ser usado obviamente para citações de terceiros. Saídas de programas, mensagens de erro e textos que não são códigos podem ser considerados citações de terceiros. Evite o uso de formatação de código para o que não é código.
> - A mesma marca é comumente usada para avisos e outros blocos de texto que mereçam algum destaque visual. <sub><sup>`<------ isto`</sup></sub>

No Metão e no Meta.SO <sup>[*citation needed]*</sup>, a orientação é pra só usar isso quando fazemos citações de textos alheios. Inclusive [a definição do elemento HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) é essa mesma, ênfase em *["extended quotation"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Aquotation):*

> The **HTML `<blockquote>` Element** (or *HTML Block Quotation Element*) indicates that the enclosed text is an extended quotation.

Me chamou a atenção no site principal o uso para fazer destaque visual e me pareceu errado, só depois vi que nosso guia permite isso.
Minha questão é: devemos usar somente **negrito** e/ou *itálico* para dar esse destaque, ou deixamos pra lá e não fazemos nada pois essa subversão é um recurso útil?

Comment: Podia ter um fixo no link 'ajuda' do comentário e/ou na '?' da resposta. Só há referência de como usar a formatação mas não quando... To lendo o link. TKS

Comment: Quando uso `<code>` o enter só funciona para 1 espaço e as vezes o texto abaixo do código é outra explicação, então eu dou `<br>` para separar como parágrafo.

Comment: Entrei la, mas depois eu apareço com mais calma. Nem sei usar direito, só entrei para dar suporte em questões.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Em geral no markdown dois enters abrem um novo parágrafo, enquanto um enter sozinho funciona como uma quebra de linha normal no html - que como observado, vira um espaço simples. Não há necessidade de inserir `<br>`s manualmente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este uso que você cita normalmente é algum aviso, provavelmente temporário. É um alerta para algo muito importante para dar entendimento melhor à pergunta ou resposta. Em geral não faz parte do conteúdo natural da postagem.

Portanto podemos interpretar este como um **alerta** a contrário do negrito que é uma ênfase importante no texto que está sendo escrito, seja para reforçar a importância daquele trecho, seja para **destacar** como a parte mais relevante da leitura.

De uma certa forma é um abuso da citação, porém ele é útil em alguns casos. Note que no texto não há a recomendação de seu uso e sim que ele pode ser usado.

Se você acha que ele está sendo usado de forma mais abusiva, seria interessante apresentar exemplos. Este é o tipo de situação que o caso específico pode ajudar entender o problema.

Nunca é demais reforçar que o guia de formatação é um trabalho colaborativo para criar, no máximo, uma **recomendação**. Não é uma obrigação. Quem segue ele certamente não está fazendo nada errado, seja na postagem original, seja na edição de conteúdo. Quem não segue originalmente não está fazendo nada errado também. O guia serve mais para evitar edições de conteúdo de terceiros ao bel prazer de cada um. Se você vai editar algo que não é seu, que seja para padronizar o que a comunidade acha interessante, para deixar com uma cara comum e não para deixar do jeito que o editor acha bom.

Comment: Na verdade, os exemplos que tenho não constituem nenhum abuso e acho que estou interpretando muito estritamente a "normativa". O que vi são destaques (usados só **uma** vez, e não várias) para, exatamente, alertar de alguma coisa que o autor(a) acha importante ressaltar. **++** no parágrafo final para "recomendação", "bel prazer" e o "jeito que o editor acha bom".