# Como destacar imagens que tem um fundo branco?

Tags: suporte, formatação

Quando uma imagem tem o fundo e as margens brancas pode ficar um pouco confuso dentro de uma pergunta ou resposta, especialmente quando é uma captura de tela aqui do próprio site. Por exemplo:

[image]

Como podemos fazer para destacar a imagem do fundo?

<sub>Inspirado por [*How to make images stand out when posting images with whitespace?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270147/1287812)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Com `<blockquote>`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270148/1287812)

<sup>**Não funciona no site mobile.**</sup>

```
>![descrição da imagem][1]
```

> [image]

---

## [Com `<kbd>`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/1287812)

<sup>**Funciona no site mobile.**</sup>

```
<kbd>  
![descrição da imagem][1]</kbd>
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<sup>A quebra de linha (com dois espaços em branco) é pra fazer um "`padding-top`".</sup>