# Liberar permissões para modificar 1 letra

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado, edição

Gostaria de pedir se é possível liberar, aos editores, permissão para editar textos nos quais tenham poucos erros. Veja um exemplo comum na imagem em anexo.
Gostaria de corrigir a letra "C" por "S" na palavra "comente".

Todo o restante do texto está perfeito, sem erro algum, porém, ao tentar editar essa única letra, é negado a edição pois é exigido que tenha mais alterações "relevantes".

Pode parecer algo bobo sem sentido pois quem sabe português consegue interpretar.

Mas olhando por outro ângulo, se o leitor não entende português e tenta traduzir o texto num tradutor ou mesmo olhando em dicionário, fica bem confuso e até impossível de conseguir traduzir ou interpretar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link original do screenshot: [Enviar objeto via POST entre Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67979/enviar-objeto-via-post-entre-javascript)

Answer (score 16):

O nome disso é [TOC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transtorno_obsessivo-compulsivo) e eu sei bem como você se sente :)

Brincadeiras a parte, é fato que em alguns casos um caractere pode realmente fazer a diferença. O seu exemplo talvez não seja um dos mais gritantes, pois a publicação ainda pode ser entendida em seu contexto por inteiro e não é uma única palavra que tornou a resposta inválida, em alguns casos, principalmente em códigos, um caractere pode transformar uma resposta errada em uma resposta certa.

Entretanto, essa solicitação já foi feita diversas vezes no Meta Stack Exchange e foi sempre declinada, como podemos ver aqui: [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76891/229289) e na lista de duplicadas que se encontra ao lado direto dela.

Permitir que a solicitação em questão seja aceita pode implicar em abusos de usuários atrás de reputação fácil, e como não temos mais o motivo de rejeição de sugestão por "Too Minor" (não lembro bem como era em português, acho que era Edição Insuficiente, ou algo do tipo), ficaria mais difícil para os revisores impedirem esses abusos.

Por ora, o único jeito de vencer essa restrição é atingindo os 2.000 pontos de reputação e adquirindo o privilégio de editar publicações sem precisar passar pela fila de análise. Enquanto não se tem esse privilégio, para casos mais graves, é totalmente aceitável deixar um comentário abaixo da publicação para que alguém que o possua fazer as edições necessárias.

E apesar de você afirmar que o restante do texto está perfeito eu posso constatar que meu nível de TOC é mais grave ainda que o seu, pois no caso em específico eu faria as seguintes alterações para vencer a imposição do sistema  de restringir a edição de um caractere (e da minha obsessão):

> Javascript -> JavaScript (2x)
>   Ajax -> AJAX
>   Http -> HTTP
>   inicio -> início

E assim essa publicação pode facilmente ser corrigida por qualquer usuário ;-)

Comment: nível máximo de TOC ✓

Comment: TOC, TOC. Who's there?

Comment: @JorgeB. No comentário que você postou acima, você se esqueceu que toda frase deve começar com letra maísucula. Desculpe por te avisar, mas é que tenho TOC referente a isso.

Answer (score 8):

Quando não tem [privilégio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) para aplicar a edição imediatamente (+ de 2 mil pontos), a edição vai para análise e precisa de dois votos para ser [aprovada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

A justificativa por tras do limite dos 6 caracteres é que corrigir uma simples falha ortográfica é desperdiçar o tempo da fila de análise, e quem está aprendendo a editar (dentro do modelo Stack Exchange) precisa tentar corrigir o máximo possível, não o mínimo.

Quando é um erro tipográfico no código **de uma resposta**<sup>`*`</sup>, as opções são:

- deixar uma mensagem no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) avisando, é quase certo que algum usuário com privilégio de edição vai fazer a correção;
- deixar um comentário embaixo da resposta, assim o autor ou um editor podem corrigir; mesmo que não seja corrigido, pelo menos fica ali o aviso aos visitantes.

Não use o alerta aos moderadores para pedir que corrijam, não é o trabalho deles.

<sup>**`*`** Ver seção sobre código em [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201)</sup>