# Pequenas correções devem ser ignoradas?

Tags: debate, suporte, edição

Quando você vai fazer uma pequena correção, no caso com menos de 6 caracteres aparece o seguinte aviso:

> As edições devem ter no mínimo 6 caracteres. Há mais alguma coisa para melhorar esta publicação?

Como deve-se proceder? Ignorar estes erros, uma vez que não existe um botão Não? Utilizar uma sinalização?

Eis [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43757/quando-usar-setters-e-getters/43762) uma pergunta que achei:

```
function setValor($valor){
    $this-valor = $valor;
}
```

Sendo que faltou um '>' após o `$this`

```
$this->valor = $valor;
```

Comment: Sinalização não! só em em casos muito extremos. Precisa tomar cuidado  e ter certeza ao editar código fonte de uma postagem o ideal é deixar um comentário para o autor notificando do erro/correção. Tem várias perguntas onde o problema é um erro de sintaxe, se ele for corrigido a pergunta perde o sentido

Comment: *o ideal é deixar um comentário* <- alertando o autor e outros que podem usar o código.

Comment: É que de vez em quando eu fico lendo posts atento "demais" e quase sempre vejo um pequeno erro, mas não mudo por causa desse aviso, então resolvi perguntar @rray

Comment: Relacionada e provável duplicata: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3876/4793

Comment: Ia postar uma resposta aqui, mas é quase exatamente o mesmo que responderia na outra. Postei lá e voto para fechar como duplicata.