# URLs do meta so-pt estão com subdomínio invertido nos sites de busca (google), causando aviso ssl

Tags: suporte

Agora há pouco pesquisei um assunto no google e encontrei um link que precisava. Quando acessei, o chrome (android) acusou que o ssl possui erro no common_name do certificado.

O link indexado no google (muitos links), estão assim:

```
https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3876/4793
```

Acesse usando o chrome num Android. O browser interrompe a navegação com aviso de site inseguro bla bla bla.

Deveriam ser assim, o "pt" antes do "meta"

```
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3876/4793
```

Screenshot do que mostra o chrome:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ter uma noção, digite algo assim no google

```
stackoverflow meta pt palavra_chave
```

exemplo

```
stackoverflow meta pt duplicada
```

Um screenshot do resultado no google

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare nos links, muitos deles estão indexados como **meta.pt** e outros como **pt.meta**.

Poderia eliminar o problema adicionando o nome "meta.pt..." no SAN (Subject Alternative Name).
O Google e outros mecanismos de busca vão eliminando com o tempo conforme reindexam as páginas mas isso leva tempo. Além do mais ainda pode existir links antigos em sites diversos por aí (facebook, blogs, etc) e muitos deles não vão atualizar pois são sites comuns e não indexadores de URLs.

O certificado do SO é do Digicert: https://www.digicert.com/multi-domain-add-subject-alternative-names.htm

```
Common name: *.stackexchange.com
SANs: *.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackauth.com, sstatic.net, *.sstatic.net, serverfault.com, *.serverfault.com, superuser.com, *.superuser.com, stackapps.com, openid.stackauth.com, stackexchange.com, *.meta.stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com, mathoverflow.net, *.mathoverflow.net, askubuntu.com, *.askubuntu.com, stacksnippets.net, *.blogoverflow.com, blogoverflow.com, *.meta.stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.email, stackoverflow.email, stackoverflow.blog
Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Location: New York, NY, US
Valid from May 20, 2016 to August 14, 2019
Serial Number: 06680cd5078ecc39ccf42df79fd3eb7d
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
```

Comment: O site já esta com redirecionamento permanente (`301`), é provavel que em algumas semanas/meses todos links no google sejam apontados corretamente, o dominimo mudou de meta.pt. para pt.meta. justamente devido aos certificados, isto foi a pouco tempo, então ainda pode levar mais algumas semanas como citei, é algo que depende do Google reindexar e são muitas páginas.