# Por que não permitir edições com menos de 6 caracteres?

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso, edição

Ontem me deparei com uma resposta com vários votos e aceita ([A linguagem C# é recomendada para ser distribuída online com banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111070/a-linguagem-c-%c3%a9-recomendada-para-ser-distribu%c3%adda-online-com-banco-de-dados/111119#111119)) com um pequeno erro de ortografia. Estava escrito *códio* ao invés de *código*.

Uma questão tão visitada com um erro bobo desses me incomodou, então fui editar, mas precisava alterar ao menos 6 caracteres, então tive que inventar alguma alteração para ir junto.

O ponto é: **Por que não podemos sugerir edições com qualquer quantidade de caracteres?** Se o problema é a recompensa, que a edição que altere só numero X de caracteres não ofereça recompensas, mas por que proibir???

Comment: Aparentemente esse limite vale somente para usuários com reputação menor que 2000. A partir desse patamar, você ganha o privilégio de [editar perguntas sem precisar passar por revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Parece-me que esse limite também deixa de valer a partir dos 2000. O motivo certo para o limite eu não sei, mas penso que seja evitar edições desnecessárias, já que o fato de (antes dos 2000) ganhar 2 de reputação para cada edição aprovada pode favorecer esse edição desnecessária.

Comment: Entendo não sabia que tinha relação com reputação. Como disse, por mim eu nem ganharia reputação pela edição, mas queria contribuir corrigindo o erro gramatical. O problema é só eu não ser permitido fazer isso. Como a edição tem que ser aprovada de qualquer maneira quando não se tem a reputação necessária, não faz sentido proibir

Comment: Eu concordo que os critérios poderiam ser revistos, muitas vezes é necessário e importante mudar um único caractere. Mas enfim, a [resposta de um dos fundadores do site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/401803) deixa bem claro a visão que eles tinham (e que pelo jeito não mudou até hoje): se vc tem menos de 2000 pontos, suas edições tem que ser aprovadas por 2 pessoas, então seria "trabalho demais para uma mudança muito pequena" ou algo assim. Por fim, ele termina com "*This will not be changing. If you want to make single-character trivial edits, earn 2k rep.*"

Comment: Relacionado (e talvez duplicada?): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3876/112052

Comment: O português por si só é uma linguagem bastante complexa, nesse sentido, existem diversas maneiras de passar por esse critério sem se tornar uma forma abusiva. Por exemplo: aproveitar para verificar vírgulas de forma incorreta (separando sujeito e predicado, verbo e complementos), adicionar _itálico_ a palavras estrangeiras, adicionar marcação de `código` em trechos de código. E em casos em que um único caracter pode trocar o total sentido da frase, Exemplo era para ser `Somente`, mas está `Comente`, troque por um sinônimo `Apenas`.

Comment: @VitorSubhi eu entendo e concordo, mas você não vê que no último exemplo você só faz essa alteração pra contornar o sistema?
O ponto é que esse limite de 6 caracteres não funciona para limitar alterações, só nos obriga a fazer malabarismo

Comment: @VitorCeolin Sem dúvidas, nesse mesmo exemplo talvez o esforço para analisar se a alteração da palavra `apenas` se encaixa corretamente no texto, seja ainda maior do que simplesmente a troca do único caracter que está de fato necessitando de alteração.

Answer (score 5):

Eu entendo que o motivo é para evitar abusos de edição ou para não fazer edições que não são tão necessárias. E essa poderia ser classificada assim. Mas ela também não deixa de ter utilidade.

Eu sou a favor de rever os critérios, acho que o sistema pode ser um pouco mais inteligente, não só nisso, e permitir com alguma forma de restrição (exigir mais autorização), porque há benefício em editar um caractere. E sua sugestão é só um exemplo que poderiam pensar em formas de permitir o que é útil sem incentivar o abuso.

Ao mesmo tempo é permitido fazer **inúmeras** edições de vários caracteres que nada acrescentam e não muda o destino da postagem.

Obrigado pela edição. Fez o que tinha que fazer, contornar a bobagem do sistema.

Comment: Já deixei de editar publicações por não saber se uma simples correção gramatical seria bem vinda, mas agora sei que o é. Concordo plenamente com essa *revisão dos critérios*, pois a fila de edição do SOpt é bem tranquila e creio que "liberar" isso nessa comunidade não traria problemas de abuso :). Alguns critérios podem fazer sentido no SOen e aqui serem "absurdos", como já vi alguns comentários sobre medalhas "quase impossíveis".