# Qual o correto procedimento a ser adotado para corrigir erros de ortografia (graves ou não) em perguntas, a fim de orientar o usuário?

Tags: debate

Gostaria de saber qual o correto procedimento seguido pelos administradores do Stack Overflow, que podemos adotar para corrigir perguntas que tem erros, graves ou não, de ortografia, de sintaxe e de interpretação?

**Exemplo:**

Eu nao consigo usar o java poque esse erro esta ocorrendo comigo?

**Correto:**

Eu não consigo executar um código em `Java` corretamente, porque esse erro está ocorrendo (...) no código abaixo: (...)

Comment: Eu não acho que Java precise ser `monoespaçado`...

Comment: Na verdade, se for ao "pé da letra" Java poderia ser apenas em *itálico*, por se tratar de uma palavra de língua estrangeira, no caso da linguagem de programação, (normas da ABNT vide: http://www.profeliana.com.br/noticia/137), embora não exista um consenso, mas, como ela é utilizada com frequência na nossa língua, não vejo mal algum em "monoespaça-la" para efeito de destaque.

Comment: @MaiconHeverton Não há necessidade de se seguir normas técnicas de escrita no site, nem de se ater exclusivamente à lingua portuguesa. O único objetivo é que os posts sejam claros.

Comment: @MaiconHerverton Relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101

Comment: No que se refere a SOpt, este Meta site *é mais importante* que a ABNT ;) Os editores frequentes nos damos o trabalho de discutir quais seriam as melhores pautas e recomendações, como outros sites lidam com problemas comuns, e compilá-las em pares de P&R (Q&A) para referência futura. Você tem liberdade total para dar pitaco, editar o que achar conveniente (ou sugerir  edição até alcançar o privilégio de edição livre), abrir novas discussões. Igual que no site principal contamos que fez sua pesquisa prévia para abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Re: ABNT, o uso de monospace para nome de linguagens ou como "destaque" já foi discutido aqui neste meta e no Meta SO (novo e antigo), consenso até agora: não é pra isso, é só para código e elementos do sistema (file names). Só não editei isso da sua pergunta por que é importante para a essencia da mesma e para uma resposta adequada.

Comment: *Java*, ou qualquer nome de linguagem ou tecnologia não precisa ser escrito com qualquer diferenciação simplesmente porque é um nome. Caso contrário teríamos que escrever Obama como `Obama` ou *Obama* e isso não faz sentido. Não é a mesma coisa para termos, por exemplo, Padrões Web ou *Web Standards*. Note que esses termos geralmente possuem uma tradução, mesmo que não comumente usada.

Comment: No exemplo citado, não há problema com interpretação pois é "entendível". Acho que nesses casos, uma edição é desnecessária. A única coisa que eu faria é remover o ponto de interrogação pois é uma afirmação e não uma pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O procedimento correto é editar a pergunta/resposta. Temos aqui no Meta uma compilação do que se considera as melhores práticas na rede Stack Exchange:
[**Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201)

É uma compilação do que já se aprendeu em outros sites da rede e das nossas próprias experiências e decisões aqui dentro do Stack Overflow em Português.

[Como bem diz o Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4340/qual-o-correto-procedimento-a-ser-adotado-para-corrigir-erros-de-ortografia-gra#comment13446_4340), o principal é que os posts sejam claros. Não há nada escrito em pedra e não tem ninguém que fica fiscalizando tudo o que acontece, temos liberdade de agir conforme nosso bom-senso e experiência (no site e fora dele).

Ao editar, é recomendado colocar um resumo de edição descritivo. Essencial enquanto não tem 2k e de bom tom em qualquer caso. Pode ser que o AP (autor do post) não confira isso, mas é um registro permanente que explica sua edição e útil para que outros editores/moderadores entendam o processo sem precisar revisar toda a edição.
Ao editar o post de um usuário novo, dependendo do nível da edição, é um gesto gentil informá-lo através de um comentário dos motivos da edição.

Sempre que tiver uma sugestão ou nova idéia, é só abrir um novo meta-tópico e uma vez resolvido, incorporar a decisão no [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

---

Re: "administradores do Stack Overflow"
Entendo que existem 4 níveis de usuários:

- os empregados da Stack Exchange (community managers, programadores e [semi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)-[deuses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded)), administradores em sentido estrito;
- os moderadores eleitos pela comunidade (ou apontados enquanto o site não ganhou autonomia), são voluntários e não recebem salário, sua principal função é resolver os problemas que os usuários experientes não podem;
- os usuários experientes com privilégios diversos (2k+, 3k+, 10k+, 20k+), que em teoria conhecem bem o funcionamento do site e atuam com poderes de moderação e administração;
- os usuários iniciantes, de 1 a 1999 pontos, que em teoria estão aprendendo o funcionamento do site.