# Como formatar uma citação bibliográfica utilizando o padrão ABNT em uma resposta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, respostas, formatação, licença

Esta pergunta se refere à seguinte resposta:

[Ordenação com heapsort](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110152/ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-heapsort/110836#110836)

O padrão *ABNT* define normas técnica para citações e referências bibliográficas.

Link para o padrão:  [Normas da ABNT - Citações e Referências Bibliográficas](http://www.leffa.pro.br/textos/abnt.htm)

Na resposta em questão, utilizei os padrões "Livros no todo" e "Mais de três autores", porém, achei que o formato não ficou adequado (ou, melhor dizendo, ficou "feio").

Consultei:

- a busca do Meta por "bibliografia", "referências", "citações"
- a página de [Ajuda do markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
- o FAQ da Comunidade [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas)
- fiz uma busca no Google por *"stackoverflow answer formatting bibliography"*

Mas não encontrei nenhuma regra de formatação a respeito de citações de livros, teses, monografias, e nem comandos que permitissem uma formatação mais clara para o leitor.

Minha pergunta é: qual a formatação correta (comandos markdown) a ser utilizada para citações no formato ABNT, em respostas onde as referências devem (ou podem) seguir este padrão?

Comment: Veja se a resposta desta [pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4777/27190) ajuda você.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Olá! Eu achei várias dicas deste tipo. Inclusive, no SO em inglês, já tem um "botão" que gera automaticamente essa referência no formato correto para o usuário colocar no trabalho. A minha pergunta é o "contrário" dessa situação. Exemplo: Eu consulto um livro para responder, e quero colocá-lo como referência no texto resposta. Acho interessante utilizar uma norma técnica (comum no meio acadêmico), por ser "padrão" e por facilitar para o usuário, caso ele precise ou queira consultar a fonte. Como não encontrei nada sobre o assunto, achei interessante fazer a pergunta aqui! :-)

Comment: Acho que a as normas da ABNT não são obrigatórias aqui, já que o SOpt  e usado por usuários de diversos países, porem me fica a duvida se deve seguir este modelo brasileiro aqui. De uma olhada nesta [pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4685/27190) do Gabe que explica um pouco sobre a Licença do site, se não me engano tem um modelo que deve seguir lá, porem sem muitas exigências.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho: Eu li esse post ontem e, inclusive dei +1 na pergunta e na resposta..rsrs. Entendo que não é obrigatório, mas parece um assunto interessante e, como eu sou novo aqui, seria legal ouvir as sugestões do pessoal (por isso a tag `debate` e não `suporte`). Em tempo: pelo tipo (da pergunta que eu mencionei acima), o AP deve estar acima do nível de graduação, por isso, fiz questão de seguir a norma na resposta. Acredito, também, que outras pessoas poderão ter essa dúvida no futuro e se alguém procurar em alguma ferramenta de busca, poderá encontrar facilmente o(s) resultado(s) aqui!

Comment: É um assunto que deve ser levado em consideração +1 (normas de citações, referencias e formatações), tanto para o conteúdo do SOpt e dos sites da rede Stack Exchange e para o conteúdo que vem de fora da Stack Exchange, não só no meio acadêmico que tem ser praticado. Entretanto, muitos aqui não são do meio acadêmico e desconhece muitas dessas regras de formatação e citação, porem eu acho relevante sua questão, eu mesmo tenho duvidas de como citar fontes, ou se poderia criar uma ferramenta para ajudar nas citações.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho: Acabei de achar um modelo que parece bom no [Math Overflow](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1631/formatting-a-citation-to-a-mathoverflow-answer). Não tenho certeza, mas parece que, dentro da tag `code`, tem *itálico* e **negrito**, uma linha de destaque à esquerda e as letras não ficam tão grandes. Mas, pelo que entendi, o MO tem mais recursos de formatação disponíveis que aqui no SOpt, inclusive para fórmulas matemáticas. Você sabe, por favor, se é possível formatar assim aqui?

Comment: Você pode testar o que quiser da formatação no chiqueirinho: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/sandbox-ou-chiqueirinho-de-formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o?s=1%7C0.6189

Comment: Tem até uma tag exclusiva la **citations** :). Eu não conheço uma forma de formatar, acho que algum usuário aqui deva saber, vamos ver o que a comunidade sabe sobre isso.

Comment: Não é exatamente o que pergunta, mas os pdf's linkados nesta resposta podem ser úteis como referência: [Eu posso utilizar o conteúdo das perguntas e respostas do SOpt para fazer trabalhos de faculdade?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4815/201)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O bloco de citação que você usou (`>` em markdown) costuma ser utilizado para o próprio conteúdo citado, e não para a referência dele. Mas eu não entendi muito bem quais são os recursos de formatação de que você sente falta. O Markdown tem negrito e itálico, suficientes para atender às normas da ABNT (entre outras). O que você queria era algo mais estruturado, como um BibTeX, que você pudesse exportar de algum lugar e usar no site? Se for isso, não tem mesmo, e [parece que nem vai ter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260365).

Se quiser apenas "embelezar" a sua lista de referências, você pode começar criando um cabeçalho MD do nível adequado (com `#`, `##` etc.), e, se quiser, reduzir a fonte das referências utilizando `<sup>` ou `<sub>`. Eu não usaria `marcação de código` para isso, afinal não é código.

Por fim, sobre citar posts do site, o recurso do Math Overflow que você citou está disponível em toda a rede Stack Exchange. Basta construir uma URL neste formato:

```
http://{site}.com/posts/{id_do_post}/citation
```

Comment: A tag `sub` resolveu o problema!! Era a fonte que estava muito grande perto do texto. Após a edição, parece que ficou muito bom! Obrigado :-)

Comment: Ficou bom mesmo :)