# Como é feita a edição de textos das perguntas

Tags: debate, perguntas, edição, formatação, edições-sugeridas

Hoje editei uma pergunta e logo em seguida outro usuário fez a validação e editou em cima do que eu tinha feito não alterado praticamente nada do que já tinha feito.

Isso é correto? não existe nem um critério para verificação de quem editar depois?

[Minha edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/60501)

[Edição do outro usuário.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/120347/revisions)

Comment: A sua edição não era ruim, era fraca, mas não ruim, no entanto a edição do Diego estava bem mais completa e com melhor formatação removendo inclusive textos desnecessários, não quer dizer que você vai ser prejudicado, ou que alguém discorda de você, o Diego só viu a oportunidade de organizar melhor, o Diego tem acesso a uma coisa chamada fila de analise e qualquer edição que precisa de aprovação chega pra ele, se ele aprovasse a sua ainda teria que esperar mais 2 votos pra aprovar por completo pra ele poder editar depois, no caso cancelar e editar ocorre na hora e assim ele pode melhorar.

Comment: Existe um critério sim, e eu segui o descrito na central de ajuda, como pode ser visto neste [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Acredito que edições devam tornar o conteúdo mais fácil de ser lido e entendido, procurando deixar o foco no problema apresentado. Sua edição não era ruim, mas rejeitei mais pelo histórico, não leve a mal mas ja vi muitas edições suas como esta, inclusive algumas até alterado o sentido original.

Comment: Não leve isso como uma crítica, mas o intuito de quem avalia as filas é filtrar, o que eu fiz neste caso foi filtrar uma edição que poderia ter sido melhorada. Para fazer uma boa edição, lembre sempre do descrito neste link, com o tempo, você vai pegando o jeito, já tive edições rejeitadas também e ainda estou aprendendo com os veteranos sobre edições e demais conteudos do site. Qualquer duvida em alguma outra edição que você discordar, você pode me "pingar" no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) ou me marcar na pergunta. :)

Comment: Você efetuou mais duas edições bastante superficiais, e ambas eu rejeitei também. Lembre-se disso: *"Tente tornar a publicação significativamente melhor ao editá-la, e não apenas alterar uma única letra. Não estimulamos as edições mínimas e triviais."*

Comment: Cara, mais uma que não vejo diferença nenhuma. [daqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/120366/revisions) Pra [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/60525)

Comment: Veja que salientei com code apenas algumas palavras-chave, removi tags invalidas e adicionei outras relevantes e deixei a dúvida mais direta. Você adicionou vários itálicos apenas, isso não melhora a leitura, as edições devem tornar o conteúdo mais fácil de ser lido, adicionar coisas relevantes e remover conteúdo irrelevante.

Comment: Veja essa edicao http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/120376/revisions, parece uma mudança boba né? Mas olha como melhorou o título com a redução? Veja essa aqui? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/120347/revisions Mais drástica, mas tornou o conteúdo mais fácil de ser entendido. Nem sempre é necessário aplicar formatação no texto, apenas torná-lo objetivo já é o suficiente.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Talvez eu até tivesse escolhido "editar e melhorar" em vez de "editar e rejeitar", mas concordo com o @Diego pois foi um bom "puxão de orelha" que inclusive te trouxe aqui para pedir esclarecimentos.

Assim que chegar aos 2 mil pontos poderá editar no site sem supervisão de ninguém e sem límite de caracteres. Enquanto não chega lá, a intenção é que faça a melhor edição possível para não desperdiçar o tempo dos revisores.

Acho que o melhor conselho que posso dar é: ***edite sem medo***. Troque aquele título que não diz nada por algo que o Google vai achar bom e que o próximo novato vai ter mais chances de encontrar.
Este título é simplesmente horroroso: "Aplicação JAVA - Netbeans".

Agradecimentos, saudações, pedidos de "luz", *"sou um pobre novato aprendendo programação"*, isso tudo é bobagem, ruído que não acrescenta em nada. Remova sem perdão. Tem algum comentário do AP que pode incorporar na pergunta? Pode fazer e sinalizar o comentário como "obsoleto".

Já viu alguém implorando ajuda ou contando seus problemas pessoais na Wikipedia? Pois então, aqui é a mesma coisa, isso não interessa. Quem responde quer saber seu problema exato e oferecer uma resposta totalmente técnica. Lá no Chat ou nos comentários trocamos *smilies*.

Fazer um resumo de edição explicativo é importante se quiser sua edição aprovada sem problemas. Eu acho importante de maneira geral, mas depois dos 2k fica à seu critério.

*<sub>**Referência para ficar craque em formatação:**</sub>*

### [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201)

Comment: Ok. Só achei um pouco sem esclarecimento  algumas alterações que foi feita em cima do que ja tinha feito deu a impressão que a segunda edição era algo mais para ganha ponto e não para demonstra o que realmente deveria ter sido corrigido antes.

Comment: Apesar de quem alcançar 2k não ter que ter as edições aprovadas,  ainda sim deve-se tomar cuidado com o que se modifica na pergunta. Acredito que o objetivo das aprovações de 500 até 2000 é fazer com que o usuário vá aprendendo como deve editar o conteúdo do site, tornar objetiva e direta as perguntas, mas sem alterar a intenção do autor, ou acrescentar coisas que podem atrapalhar a leitura. Assim quando alcançar a rep, ele terá aprendido o bastante e será independente de revisões.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza não se ganha ponto por edição após os 2k e nem por aprovação, a intenção era como o brasofilo disse, "puxão de orelha". Como já disse nos comentários, alguma edições suas estavam supérfluas demais, tanto que as últimas 2 suas que vi na fila estavam bem melhores e significativas e foram aprovadas, o objetivo era justamente esse.