# Vamos dar um chacoalhão nas tags?

Tags: debate, tags

A edição do conteúdo é um dos pontos mais fortes do SOpt e toda rede Stack Exchange. Podemos melhorar o conteúdo na sua formatação, ortografia, gramática, estilo, melhorar o texto no geral com informação mais compreensível, tirar informações supérfluas tais como saudação e agradecimento, *tags* no título, enfim, dá para melhorar muita coisa, tem até um [guia que dá algumas dicas de como editar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101).

Uma das edições mais importantes, simples demais de fazer (pode dar reputação fácil se fizer com consciência, medalha também) que se bem pensada pode ter um efeito enorme, é das *tags*. **Classificar as perguntas é fundamental** para dar um melhor entendimento ao conteúdo e depois ser mais fácil localizar o conteúdo ajudando buscas manuais e indexação por buscadores.

## Esforço concentrado

Então proponho um esforço concentrado pra gente dar uma arrumada nas *tags*. Todos que tenham um mínimo de domínio e afinidade de alguns assuntos, tenha tempo e disposição pode ajudar melhorar a classificação podem começar fazer sua parte.

Claro que depois é bom mantermos o esforço de manter tudo em ordem. Depois de arrumar o que está ruim agora ficará mais fácil. Teremos mais experiência e é só arrumar o que surgindo todo dia pra não deixar bagunçar.

Então proponho duas grandes frentes:

1. Vamos **discutir *tags* específicas** para ver o que pode ser criado sinônimo, mesclar, separar as ambíguas, "bloquear" o uso, melhorar a definição e recomendação de uso na descrição da sua Wiki. Boa parte do que for definido poderá ser feito por um moderador, mas precisa da participação de todos que entendem de cada assunto;

   Então conclamo a todos começarem postar debates aqui no meta sobre as *tags* de uso mais problemático (não precisa ter pressa, mas não vamos "enrolar"). Eu tenho uma boa lista pronta para postar. Farei aos poucos as que vocês não postarem. Em alguns casos farei em grupo porque estão relacionadas.

   Note que a intenção não é sair matando *tags*. Raramente isso é necessário, especialmente nas que são muitos usadas. Se elas existem em montes de perguntas é porque deve ter demanda. Podemos debater todos. Só prefiro dar prioridade nas que precisam de uma organização urgente. Eu já matei algumas que não faziam sentido.
2. Vamos **analisar as perguntas das *tags* mais problemáticas** e editar tirando, trocando ou colocando *tags* para organizar.

   Se você domina um assunto e tem certeza que uma pergunta está com *tag* errada já pode ir editando também. Mas acho que o ideal seria fazer isso de forma mais forte depois de um debate e de uma melhor descrição de uso na *tag* específica.

   Se tiver dúvidas do que fazer, poste um debate, pergunte no chat. Se está na dúvida então significa que não deve mexer no que pode piorar. Mas não quer dizer que não deva tentar fazer alguma coisa com auxílio de outras pessoas. Chamar atenção já é uma ajuda.

## Exemplos do que podemos fazer

Tirar o que não é relevante que foi colocado porque a pessoa quis atrair atenção, porque o assunto está na moda, porque o autor não entende o problema que tem em mãos ou não entende porque usar a *tag*, além de confundir o uso ou até digitar errado, só para citar alguns exemplos. Tá cheio de caso de perguntas com *tags* que nada tem a ver com o conteúdo.

Um caso que precisa de muita melhora é onde a *tag* é ambígua e acaba sendo usada para motivos bem diferentes. Não pode, isso precisa de solução.

Colocar *tags* que dão melhor semântica é outra coisa bem útil. Há casos óbvios que faltam *tags* triviais, como a linguagem usada. Mas há casos que precisam de *tags* mais específicas para mostrar do que se trata. Nem sempre é fácil fazer essa classificação, mas ela é importante. Tem muita pergunta com menos *tags* do que deveria. Não são só as *tags* de tecnologia que vão definir o conteúdo. Precisamos dar mais opções de filtro para quem buscar para estreitar os resultados. A pergunta está pedindo para falar do que ali, além da tecnologia usada?

Mais exemplos: onde devemos tirar [orientação-a-objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos) que as pessoas colocam sem nada ter a ver com isso.

O que fazer com [tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela) e [table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) que são usadas para as mesmas coisas, e essas coisas são mais do que dois assuntos completamente diferentes.

[app](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app) tem utilidade para algo pontual? Ou é só ruído? Se tiver utilidade, vale manter e ter que ficar lidando com o uso errado o tempo todo?

É óbvio que a pessoa usa [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) e [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) quando na verdade queria usar [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), certo? [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) está sendo usada certo com outras tecnologias?

Tem vários casos assim, [framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework) é um exemplo do que é usado solto equivocadamente. [sql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) e [server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) é outro exemplo.

Tem coisa que é sinônimo de outra coisa, mas nem todas perguntas na *tag* é o sinônimo. Tem que arrumar as perguntas antes de matar ou mesclar a *tag*. A principal tarefa é reclassificar as as perguntas, separar o que é ambíguo, durante esse processo identificaremos onde a *tag* não cabe.

Se for sair editando evite editar muitas perguntas juntas para não "poluir" a página principal. De madrugada e final de semana já dá para abusar um pouco mais.

## Mãos à obra

O que acham? Que sugestões podem dar para facilitar o processo? Vamos começar?

Comment: Um dos principais problemas que eu vejo é alguém que está desenvolvendo um sistema com Laravel. Daí quando dá um erro de jQuery, ele adiciona as tags `Laravel`, `Javascript` e `jQuery`, quando na verdade, ele só precisa consertar o código no `JS`. Nesses casos, eu removeria a tag Laravel, na edição

Comment: @WallaceMaxters exatamente disso que estou falando, precisamos dar uma limpa nisso e mostrar para todos que já deve editar logo tão logo esteja claro que a pergunta é sobre um assunto e o outro é apenas incidental (ele está usando aquilo, mas o problema não é ali). Tem caso que ter JS e jQuery pode ser ruim tb. Mas não em todos. Pode ser que a intenção dele é ter solução nas duas formas. Mas há casos que colocou as duas sem saber porque.

Comment: @bigown talvez também o site deva deixar claro que as tags são para definir o que está relacionado com a pergunta, e não aquilo que ele está usando no projeto. Se eu tenho um problema de jQuery e estou usando o Django, uma coisa não tem  nada a ver com a outra, mas o usuário novato pode pensar que ele precisa adicionar as tags para especificar o que ele usa, e não o que tem a ver com a pergunta.

Comment: Pode contar comigo para essas edições, ótima iniciativa

Comment: @bigown depois q eu chegar da faculdade vou listar algumas tags numa resposta minha, ai podemos ir melhorando.

Comment: São tags que são muito usadas mas ñ tem descrição do que elas são.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho o que você acha que dá para ir arrumando, pode fazer, o que acha que precisa de debate, vê se deve abrir separado ou junto. Quando se faz uma lista de coisas não relacionadas acaba não sendo muito produtivo. O que falta descrição é mais para por mesmo, nem precisa discutir. A não ser que tenha acontecido algum problema (alguém reprovou uma boa descrição).

Comment: Há muito que penso que algo deveria ser feito em relação às tags. Quando vi o empenho que tem posto no assunto achei que era altura de eu passar do "algo deveria ser feito" para o  "fazer algo". Nos últimos dias tenho arrumado e editado algumas wiki das tags referentes ao Android. Sei que o mais importante na tag é definir a sua aplicabilidade, mas essa tem sido a minha principal dificuldade. Tem alguma dica/sugestão ou critica(não se acanhe) em relação ao que tenho feito?

Comment: @ramaral preciso pensar em dicas :) Crítica não tenho nenhuma. Talavez precisar ver algum padrão que ajude nos casos de uma *tag* ser muito mal usada. Não sei se ajuda muita coisa. O que eu percebo é que se a pessoa não quer organizar, ela nem vá ler a descrição que quase sempre deve conter onde usar ou não usar. Principalmente o não uso deve ser destaco. tenho colocado antes de tudo e com um "NÃO USE" para cer se chama atenção. Pelo menos serve para quem quer organizar ter uma parâmetro melhor de como usar a *tag*. Tem *tags* que é difícil usar errado, a não ser quando se é um *train wreck*.

Comment: Sim, ver as perguntas que tem a tag é uma boa forma de identificar maus usos. Tenho é de conseguir sintetizar isso numa ou duas frases. Escrever "use só se a pergunta for sobre [tag] e não porque utiliza [tag]" nem sempre me parece adequado ou suficiente.

Comment: @ramaral Escrever dessa forma cai em referência circular :D Mas você entendeu o problema...

Comment: @bigown a tag [webview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/webview/info) na hora de atribuir uma descrição fiquei um pouco confuso, porque existe a classe `WebView` do Android e também o WebView que é um componente do Android que permite que apps Android exiba conteúdo web. Deve considerar como classe mesmo?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho não sei, certamente tem quem saiba mais que eu, por isso é preciso abrir debate sobre ela. Talvez seja caso pra mesclar. Mas antes precisa ver se precisa fazer uma reclassificação em algumas delas. Precisa ter certeza que não existe outros usos para a *tag*, etc.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho É a mesma coisa, a classe [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) é a implementação do componente.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho tenha em atenção que ela não é exclusiva do Android existe também para desenvolvimento de aplicações [Win8+ e UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx)

Comment: @ramaral o ideal seria um debate em local específico, mas percebo que precisa desambiguá-la e talve não deixar usar essa *tag* que é ambígua. Também pode fazer uma delas ser sinônimo de outra, mas pode gerar confusão.

Comment: @ramaral acho que aquele caso da tag Android era bem puxado para aqui!

Comment: Podes juntar a tag [tag:android-studio] que é **quase sempre** usada quando alguém pergunta sobre android e usa o studio como IDE.

Comment: @JorgeB. conseguis-te acompanhar os comentários lá?

Comment: @JorgeB. +1 . Acho difícil alguém que entende de Android Studio não entender de Android, então não acho que não ter a tag android-studio vai fazer a pergunta alcançar menos gente.

Comment: Novamente vou dizer que debater *tags* específicas fica melhor em um pergunta específica. EU tenho quase certeza que a *tag* [tag:android-studio] é extremamente mal usada porque a pessoa não sabe a diferença entre a linguagem, o sistema operacional, o IDE e outras coisas. É uma tragédia. Mas nos poucos (talvez nem tão poucos assim) casos que o problema for com o Android Studio, ele não poderá usar a *tag* correta?

Comment: Eu queria ter algo assim: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137706/140010. Isto também: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags

Comment: @bigown Você pode me dizer se fiz algo de errado aqui? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283917/176034 - Se possível até postar alguma resposta.

Comment: Não tem porque eu dar uma resposta lá. Acho que isso foi discutido antes lá. Talvez não com exatamente a mesma proposta apresentada ou pelo menos nada tão detalhado, agora, mas parece que foi recusado. O *post* é muito bom, acho que os negativos foram contra a proposta.nem preciso explicar pra você como é processo, não tem muito o que fazer, a não ser sentar e chorar, a não ser que apareça um CM lá e diga: era exatamente isso que estávamos procurando e vamos fazer. Pelo menos vimos um bom exemplo de como as coisas podem ser conduzidas: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/221800

Comment: E fica a dica de como as coisas são feitas em outros sites da rede: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/221800

Comment: [tag:asp.net-mvc] é uma tag que frequento diariamente. Posso frequentar também a [tag:mvc] e editar os posts de lá com uma frequência maior.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez seria ótimo, especial mudar quando é usam [tag:asp.net] e [tag:mvc]. Acho que ttem uma ou duas perguntas que cabem elas separadas.

Comment: Minha opinião: tirar as tags com versões: 
**EXEMPLO**: `postgres` `postgres 9.5`