# Vamos limpar as tags?

Tags: debate, tags, comunidade

Estou propondo algo que tenho até medo. Porque sei que algumas pessoas querem bem poucas *tags*, mas o SO não foi concebido para isso.

Não sei se as pessoas vão querer participar como precisa. Provavelmente este será meu último esforço maior no site.

Não estou falando de matar qualquer coisa. Seriam as que realmente estão poluindo e tem uma boa solução. Estou falando sempre de mesclar e criar sinônimo, nunca de só matar a *tag*. A não que encontre algum caso grave que já deveria ter sido resolvido antes.

No SOpt temos pouco mais de 2800 *tags* (fora as com zero perguntas atreladas que á sinônimos - com um, logo ela será apagada pelo sistema). No SOen são mais de 65 mil. Não estamos mal.

Tem alguns critérios que eu gostaria de estabelecer, mas isso deve ser discutido.

Começa fazer com as *tags* com 2 perguntas associadas. Depois vai pegando as que tem um pouco mais em cada passo, adotando critérios mais rígidos em cada salto.

Só mescla o que realmente é interessante estar junto com outras perguntas em *tag* mais importante e só se a mais importante já não estiver saturada. Tem que ficar mais fácil achar o conteúdo e não mais difícil de estar em um bolo enorme que só parece com aquele assunto.

Também não ó caso de ter que arrumar o que tem em *tags*, é diferente [dessa proposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5283/101).

Não se deve mesclar muitas. Deve manter as que são relevantes. Por exemplo [vlang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlang) foi usada uma vez (será apagada pelo sistema porque ficou um tempo sem uma segunda pergunta), mas seria uma que sobreviveria com 2 apenas. Ela é muito relevante e não pode ser confundida com outras. Assim como [hash](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hash) e [hashcode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashcode) **talvez** devessem ser uma só. Mas não as outras que estão relacionadas como o tema *hash*.

Lembre-se, as *tags* devem ajudar as perguntas serem encontradas.

Deem suas opiniões e digam se vão participar. Vamos ver como organizar melhor isso para não ficar cada um fazendo de um jeito. Não pode sair fazendo sem haver concordância da "comunidade".

Comment: Quero participar da iniciativa. Na verdade, minha opinião é até impopular, que boas perguntas não tem mais que 2 tags. Claro que não é uma regra, mas podemos agrupar muita coisa...

Comment: Não é isso. Sobre2, é tags que tem perguntas, não perguntas que tem 2 tags. Perguntas boas tem quantas tags forem necessárias. Em alguns raros casos até deveria ter mais que 5.

Comment: Organizar as tags não é uma solução permanente, precisa de manutenção constante, novas perguntas são feitas, novas tags serão criadas e a bagunça volta. Há algum objetivo com isso? Por exemplo, melhorar a busca e evitar duplicatas. Haverá bastante trabalho e não vejo nenhum grande benefício, mas não tenho tanta experiência na comunidade e, já a alguns anos, não sou mais muito ativo

Comment: @Costamilam por isso não sabe que praticamente se encerrou as atividades aqui.

Comment: A maioria das tags que tem menos de 5 perguntas são tags inválidas ou mal-definidas. E pelo menos umas 90% das tags são assim.

Comment: @Maniero podia remover a tag "destaque" então, já que o debate já acabou e a proposta foi "recusada"