# Existe alguma formalização das formatações de pergunta e respostas?

Tags: debate

Onde posso encontrar orientações para a formatação de pergunta e respostas no SO?

Sabemos que as perguntas devem ser o mais impessoal possível mas e quanto a utilizar siglas, se devem ser maiúsculo ou minúsculo ou código deve ser identado com 4 ou 2 espaços e por aí vai. Temos um documento ou um local onde pode haver estas orientações ou não queremos ser tão formais a este ponto?

Comment: [Sim, existe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas)