# Vale a pena buscar e corrigir erros ortográficos em perguntas e respostas?

Tags: debate, qualidade

Às vezes pesquiso na busca do site por erros ortográficos no tocante a termos importantes, tipo:

- *javacript*, em vez de *java**s**cript*
- *identação*, em vez de *i**n**dentação*

Claro se eu for procurar erros ortográficos em todo tipo de palavra irei passar a vida toda corrigindo. Mas eu foco em termos importantes, que podem influenciar numa busca.

E encontro algumas (às vezes várias) perguntas e respostas com tais erros. Como em alguns casos o resultado da busca é elevado, consegui corrigir alguns. Vez em quando, no tempo livre, faço isso pensando estar ajudando a melhorar a qualidade do site, um trabalho de formiguinha mesmo, porque às vezes são muitos posts.

Porém me surgiu uma dúvida:

Esse trabalho é relevante mesmo, a nível de busca interna do site? Acredito que pro Google não seja tão importante porque penso que o algorítimo de busca do Google encontra palavras mesmo com erros ortográficos, ou estou errado? É válido de qualquer forma corrigir esses erros ou deixa como está?

Comment: Creio que valha a pena, visto que as vezes você procura uma dúvida sobre banco de dados, mas a resposta/pergunta anterior está descrita com o bando de dados (imagine os dados com chifres em um pasto infindável no Mato Grosso...)

Comment: ahaha... boa....

Comment: Vale ressaltar que fazer essa limpeza pode ocasionar um _flood_ de perguntas antigas no feed, e de modo geral isso não é lá a melhor coisa do mundo. Novidades devem ser a preferência do feed... Se você encontrar pontualmente/ocasionalmente e corrigir na hora, não há "poluição" do feed com "velharias"; um movimento para fazer uma grande mudança geral normalmente é melhor quando conduzido em um período de baixa atividade no site, como agora (tarde da madrugada no Brasil e em Portugal).

Comment: Concordo com o @JeffersonQuesado, é necessário, mas para os casos novos e pontuais.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Deve estar a falar das minhas respostas de certeza, eu fiz esse erro e nem corrigi xD. É claro nao foi propositado, apenas sou demasiado preguicoso.

Comment: Triste mesmo é vc corrigir "pequenos erros ortográficos", formatar e talz para, no final, alguém não aprovar a edição dizendo que "não altera em nada"...

Comment: @LipESprY pequenas correções geralmente não são aprovadas porque não influenciam no entendimento. Quando vc tiver uma certa reputação, vc poderá fazer qualquer edição sem que seja preciso aprovação.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É bem válido. Idealmente não mude só esse erro achado, revise toda postagem.

É difícil dizer o quanto ajuda e quanto prejudica, afinal se as pessoas procurarem pela forma errada não vão achar, mas acho que esta não é uma boa justificativa para não mudar.

O Google pode até achar, mas não dá peso igual.

Mas tenha certeza que está corrigindo certo e não introduzindo erros. O correto é indentação. O que é possível até colocar em itálico por ser um neologismo. Veja [resposta no Portuguese Language.SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/identar-indentar-ou-endentar) e temos a *tag* escrita [indentação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indenta%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Também:

- https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/identacao-ou-indentacao/
- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Só para deixar claro, use JavaScript e não javascript. Conforme o [guia de estilos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101).

E observe os comentários ditos acima. Faça bem devagar ou de madrugada.

Conforme comentário abaixo, trazer códigos que estão apenas em sites externos para dentro do SOpt é mais importante ainda, um podia pode ser que o site externo não esteja mais disponível, pode dar algum problema, pode ser difícil de acessar, pode exigir algo que há bloqueio, enfim, o conteúdo externo é auxiliar e o conteúdo precisa estar aqui para a publicação estar conforme.

Comment: Sim, JavaScript. Coloquei tudo em minúsculo só como exemplo para mostrar a falta da letra "s". :D

Comment: Aproveitando a pergunta do Sam, e para não abrir outra pergunta sobre o assunto de Edição, vou levantar outro ponto. Notei que temos várias perguntas antigas onde as pessoas colocaram o código em um link externo, por exemplo no http://jsfiddle.net ou similar. Esse tipo de conteúdo também deve ser editados para ter o código do link externo incluído diretamente no Snippet do StackOverflow?

Comment: @hugocsl ia dar um trabalho enorme fazer isso porque muitos códigos no JSFiddle utilizam bibliotecas externas, e passar isso pro snippet do site seria, ao meu ver, muito trabalhoso. Eu penso que (posso estar enganado) não há mt problema em deixar os códigos no JSFiddle (claro, o ideal seria no snippet) porque eles não são apagados, logo não há mt aquele perigo de link inexistente prejudicando um post. Pelo menos é essa impressão que eu tenho. :D

Comment: Um exemplo de site que saiu fora do ar é o [CPearson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367342/7690982), infelizmente este faleceu e o site saiu do ar. Os esforços de alguns membros do Mr Excel reviveram o site, um dos melhores para Excel VBA. Uma alternativa para contornar um problema desses foi redirecionar os links para o [https://web.archive.org/](https://web.archive.org/).