# Como sobrepor uma tag?

Tags: suporte, tags

Considere [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38812/). Estava a observar que no título e nas tags, a tag "*java ee*" aparece em destaque e em primeiro lugar, respectivamente.

Existe alguma maneira de alterar essa "dominância" de uma tag sobre as outras? Na pergunta do exemplo o assunto é relacionado ao *java ee*, mas de longe a tag "*tomcat*" se encaixaria melhor.

Answer (score 7):

As tags abaixo da pergunta parecem ser organizadas pelo número de perguntas de cada tag e acho que não tem nada que possamos fazer para alterar isso:

> [image: java-ee : 82 perguntas]
>
> [image: tomcat : 34 perguntas]
>
> [image: netbeans : 24 perguntas]

Analisando outras perguntas, vi que se o número de perguntas é igual aparece primeiro a que tem mais seguidores.

Já no `<title>` do browser, acho que a prioridade é a mesma, mas se o título da pergunta contivesse "java-ee", então a tag que apareceria no *title* seria "tomcat":

[image: browser title]

Ressaltando que é importante usar tags no título de maneira orgânica: [Quando se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1911/201).

<sup>Referência: [Set the actual priority tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114626/185667)</sup>