# "[Resolvido]" em título de pergunta não fica parecendo coisa de fórum?

Tags: debate

Tinha uma pergunta aqui no site que estava com o seguinte título:

[*Integrando HTML + Node.js com Angular.js em "Real Time" [RESOLVIDO]*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156427/integrando-html-node-js-com-angular-js-em-real-time)

Provavelmente isso foi uma edição do AP, que colocou esse "[RESOLVIDO]" no final.

Depois de uma [leve pesquisada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=resolvido) no site, vi que várias perguntas têm esse "resolvido" no título, de várias formas diferentes.

Um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por um momento em pensei duas coisas:

- *Mas o site já não tem a opção de "marcar como útil"? Por que o AP fez isso?*
- *Isso está parecendo coisa de fórum*

Como proceder em tais casos? Devemos editar todos os títulos que têm isso?

Particularmente, eu penso que fazer isso no título deixa a formatação feia.

<sub>No caso da pergunta acima, retiraram  "[Resolvido]" no título, mas deixei a pergunta aqui para saber qual procedimento tomar em futuros casos semelhantes.</sub>

Comment: Resolvido com resposta eu tiro o resolvido, resolvido sem resposta com resposta nos comments: eu peço pro OP postar, ou se for velha, reposto como Wiki da Comunidade. Resolvida abandondada: fechar. Em todos os casos, edição no título

Comment: @Bacco foi o que fiz aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154333/101 Tinha resposta em comentário. apaguei tudo e postei CW.

Comment: Eu estava retirando o "Resolvido" desta pergunta, mas o diegofm foi mais rápido kkk

Comment: Ainda estava sobrando um "[Resolvido]" no título [e eu já retirei também](/posts/5389/revisions). Nem precisa agradecer :)

Comment: @bigown esse título tá estranho agora...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mas não para tirar isso? :)

Comment: Vamos ter que editar a resposta do victor?

Comment: A situação aqui pode ser descrita como `huehuehue br`

Comment: Pelo que entendi é só no título, não é?

Comment: *Sua zueira foi revertida com sucesso! Deseja continuar?*

Comment: Ou será que tem que ver o contexto antes de editar alguma coisa? Tem gente que faz roboticamente. Afinal se fosse só tirar a palavra o sistema já fazia. QUem não entendeu nada da zueira: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5389/6

Comment: @bigown tenho a impressão que esse contexto não se aplicaria ao site.A não ser que o usuário pergunte: "Como posso adicionar a string "[Resolvido]" no texto em PHP?"

Comment: Contexto em JS: `const RESOLVIDO = 0; var lista = [RESOLVIDO]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tem que remover.

É o mesmo problema disso: [Quando se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297/101).

Vou mais longe. Tem muito título que parece fórum. Entre eles:

- [Dúvida] Porque está dando erro

  tem dois problemas aí
- Dúvida sobre PDO

  tem dois problemas aí e mais um se eu for fazer *bullying* com tecnologia :P
- Ajuda com Visual Studio

E assim vai.

O mesmo vale para o corpo das perguntas. tem muita redundância que eu tiro sempre. Exemplo:

- Gostaria de saber o que é...
- Alguém pode me ajudar?
- Agradeço quem souber!
- É o seguinte, estou confuso com um problema aqui.

Tira todas essas coisas. Não ajuda nada.

Comment: Obrigado, você acabou abrangendo mais coisas que precisam ser "polidas". +1

Comment: A intenção foi essa, já que haviam respostas diretas.

Comment: As outras não estão melhores para a pergunta direta?

Comment: Todas as respostas estão boas, se tivesse como, rolava até recompensa :p

Answer (score 19):

### [RESOLVIDO]

É só editar o título da pergunta.

Comment: Oh, my troll xD

Answer (score 16):

Proponho **remoção** da pseudo-tag em título. A pergunta pode possuir uma resposta aceita ou não - isso já é, por si só, uma indicação de solução.

Comment: "Tag" no título foi ótima. Tentaram fazer um mecanismo manual dentro do site (Ô loco!). Acho desnecessário também...

Comment: Além disso pode orientar o OP a não colocar o [RESOLVIDO] mais e sugerir a leitura de: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91).

Comment: @rray já fiz a pergunta no meta para eu poder linkar ela sempre que precisar, entende?