# Como lidar com perguntas com certo grau de subjetividade?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, perguntas, pergunta-subjetiva

A pergunta [Devo adotar o padrão de nomenclatura do meu framework ou legado da equipe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2030/boas-praticas-para-nomear-tabelas-e-colunas) recebeu um voto de fechamento, o que gerou uma pequena discussão nos comentários.

Acho importante debatermos essa questão aqui. O sistema oferece um motivo para fechamento chamado de *principalmente baseado em opiniões*, e faz isso porque, na experiência da Stack Exchange, perguntas que pedem opiniões acabam gerando uma lista de respostas imensa, muitas vezes paginada, e nenhuma delas pode ser considerada "correta" ou "conclusiva". Disso eles concluíram que o *engine* do site não é adequado a esse tipo de pergunta.

Aqui no SOpt temos uma certa liberdade para decidir o que vale e o que não vale. Então proponho os seguintes pontos para discussão:

- **Qual grau de subjetividade vamos aceitar nas perguntas?**
- **Como determinar isso?**

Para tocarmos esta discussão, sugiro a leitura de [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), do Robert Cartaino ([tradução do bigown para o português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)). Num contexto um pouco mais amplo, vale ler também [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/), do Jeff Atwood.

Comment: Um dos problemas desse tipo de pergunta é que pega moda: http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2040/como-utilizar-classes-proprias-corretamente-no-laravel

Comment: Putz, essa daí é bem vaga...

Comment: Essa se não for editada, tem que fechar.

Comment: Vaga? É simples e objetiva. Tenho uma classe qualquer e preciso utilizar dentro do laravel. Não sei o que poderia ser mais objetiva.

Comment: @ElizandroPacheco Imagino que os demais comentários que fizeram na sua pergunta te mostrem por que achei vaga.

Answer (score 6):

Uma dificuldade que vejo, seja qual for a postura adotada, é aplicá-la com imparcialidade. Essa pergunta, por exemplo, votei pra fechar, mas outras (como a ["Onde devo colocar um código JavaScript em um documento HTML?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-codigo-javascript-em-um-documento-html/1112#1112)) eu optei por deixar aberta - ainda que outros usuários tenham votado pra fechar na época.

Por que? Simplemente porque eu tinha **conhecimento** de critérios objetivos para responder a segunda pergunta, porém estou **ignorante** de critérios semelhantes para a primeira. Em outras palavras, o meu *background* pessoal me faz julgar algumas perguntas como subjetivas e outras não, mas outros com mais/menos conhecimento que eu poderiam julgar diferente.

A solução, na minha opinião, seria esperar um pouco mais antes de votar pra fechar. Observar as respostas dos outros. Se ficar confirmado que tudo não passa de "achismo", ou se a pergunta ficar sem resposta nenhuma (i.e. todo mundo se abster de responder, por não ter nada de objetivo pra dizer) então levar adiante o voto pra fechar.

Dar oportunidade aos outros de responder - mesmo uma pergunta *off-topic* - permite que o autor se beneficie (ou ao menos tenha contato com opiniões diferentes), e a longo prazo não "polui" o site (pois fechar cedo ou fechar tarde não faz diferença pro SEO, certo?). Essa é minha opinião pessoal, estou aberto a contra-arguentações.

Comment: Concordo, pelo menos neste momento em que os critérios ainda não estão claros, é melhor segurar um pouco os votos de fechamento.

Comment: Isso vai acontecer mesmo. É bom ficarmos alerta para não cometermos injustiça fechando ou deixando aberta. Claro que nunca seremos perfeitos. No momento atual eu acho que a espera é produtiva. No futuro teremos que reavaliar isso. A minha experiência é que esse tipo de pergunta nunca fica sem resposta, o problema é justamente o oposto. Se ficar sem resposta, provavelmente ninguém entendeu. Um dos problemas dessas perguntas é que elas são simples demais, aí todo mundo quer pular no barco. Nada contra perguntas simples, mas sim esse tipo de simplicidade. Off-topic já debatido, fecho na hora.

Comment: Fechar depois não causa grande problema, mas com o tempo teremos que fechar o mais rápido possível quando ficar caracterizado que a pergunta não é adequada para o site. Deixar aberta também abre a porta para debates intermináveis e na prática sempre deixar aberta por um tempo e quase o mesmo que não fechar, todo mundo vai se aproveitar dessa brecha. Tem que passar a mensagem certa. Agora estamos aprendendo como agir, então deve haver uma certa condescendência.

Comment: Falando especificamente de perguntas sobre "boas práticas", esse é um caso em que os iniciantes tornam as coisas mais difíceis. Já pensei em votar contra **respostas** subjetivas, mas acaba sendo uma gota no balde: um monte de gente vota positivo pra expressar opinião. Talvez fechar logo não seja ruim, se alguém de fato tem uma resposta boa pra dar e quiser ter o esforço para tal, pode apresentar a questão no meta e votar para reabrir (justificando por que a questão parece subjetiva mas não é). Basta 4 concordarem para a pergunta ganhar "outra chance"...

Answer (score 6):

Eu uso sempre os critérios do http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ para **ajudar** decidir se deve fechar ou não. Algumas ainda ficam difíceis definir. Algumas passam na maioria dos itens mas sempre quase na dúvida. Outras passam bem na maioria mas reprovam em uma ou duas de forma tão flagrante, que é melhor fechar.

Basicamente precisamos seguir o que a rede definiu, **não podemos adotar os critérios que bem entendemos**. A forma de aplicar **pode variar um pouco**.

Não tenho problemas com perguntas subjetivas, que tragam várias respostas. **Se fosse tão ruim ter várias respostas, haveria um limite para elas**. Foi deixado em aberto intencionamente porque pode haver situações que várias respostas são boas. Ver também [O que fazer com perguntas que podem ter múltiplas respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-podem-ter-multiplas-respostas)

Mas perguntas subjetivas ruins não podem ser permitidas. Em geral elas não ficam bem na mão de novatos (não que isso seja critério para definir qualquer coisa, o novato pode muito bem fazer uma pergunta subjetiva boa se fizer o dever de casa, mas quase nunca fazem, é normal que isso aconteça).

Tem que tomar vários cuidados para fazer uma pergunta que não traga opiniões e respostas desnecessárias, para não dizer inúteis. Tem que praticamente ameaçar de processo judicial quem vai responder sem atender os requisitos estritos :)

O que precisamos é afinar o critério, IMHO, as perguntas subjetivas são bem-vindas mas elas devem ser boas, permitir que o site siga sua filosofia principal onde pelo menos tenta-se uma objetividade parcial. Quem pergunta deve se esforçar para exigir isso dos autores de resposta. E quem não responde dentro dos critérios, que escapa para a opinião, está dando uma resposta errada para a pergunta bem feita, como ocorrer em qualquer outra pergunta objetiva.

Comment: Só que a pergunta que postei como mote aqui não é um caso óbvio de pergunta ruim. O que me faz pensar até que ponto precisamos seguir as regras da SE. Meu objetivo é ter conteúdo de qualidade, não quero ver gente votando para fechar só porque `/boas práticas/.test(pergunta) === true/`. Em muitos casos, uma edição resolve. A justificativa da SE de que perguntas subjetivas geram áreas "sujas" do site com conteúdo inútil vem da experiência deles com o SO. Eu me questiono se devemos tomar isso como verdade universal, ou deixar rolar para ver o que vai acontecer AQUI.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu acho que essas regras são imutáveis. No Programmers se tentou mudar e não foi aceito. O que pode é afinar o critério, conforme eu falei. já deixei claro que sou favorável a subjetivas boas. Qual a razão para ter qualquer coisa abaixo disso? Tem como pedir boas práticas decentemente e produzir respostas boas.

Comment: Não sei qual é o limite entre afinar e mudar as regras. O Gabe tem dado a entender que aqui há bastante margem para se agir diferente. E sobre a pergunta específica, o que você acha? Para mim, ela é como "uso o padrão X mas preciso usar também um framework onde o padrão é Y; e agora?". Vale?

Comment: @bfavaretto 60% boa :) Vamos aguardar. Quero deixar claro que sou "inclusionista" e não "deletionista". Mas tudo tem limite. Regra é regra, critério pode ser coloca um pouco mais para um lado ou para outro, critério é ajuste fino, você está falando da mesma coisa mas o tom muda. Se falar de outra coisa, mudou a regra.

Answer (score 3):

Eu não criei design patterns, mas algum autor criou. Podem ser "considerados boas práticas". São referências de literatura, com estudos de caso, reconhecimento internacional, etc., a exemplo dos padrões de projeto GRASP ou GoF.  São modelos que quando implementados, podem ser seguidos para se obter maior consistência nos projetos, facilitando manutenção, entendimento, etc.

Quando eu fiz a pergunta, tive uma dúvida real sobre uma inconsistência na equipe, onde cada um trazia suas opiniões pessoais para modelar o banco. Fiz a pergunta para ter uma referência, para esclarecer aos colegas de equipe através exemplos de literatura, o que se teria de mais moderno e prático na área. Queria um Flyweight, um Singleton, um Observer dos bancos de dados, um pattern.

Fiz uma pergunta neste beta com uma dúvida real, construtiva, que poderia orientar parte dos usuários com os mesmos problemas em sua equipe de trabalho, mas estão decidindo por fechar.

Comment: Se a pergunta for fechada, eu voto para reabrir. E tenho certeza que há outros usuários que também vão votar igual.

Comment: Olha só, já tem 4 votos para reabrir. Você poderia ainda editar o último parágrafo (a pergunta), incluindo mais detalhes sobre o tipo de resposta que você espera. Seria legal também incluir na descrição um pouco mais sobre o contexto; uma coisa que falta é entendermos se você vai reusar um bd pré-existente, que precisa ser compatível com outros sistemas, ou se está criando um sistema do zero.

Comment: @bfavaretto, já fiz algumas alterações na pergunta.

Comment: Eu vi, melhorou :)