# Good Subjective, Bad Subjective

Tags: debate, perguntas

## TL; DR do TL; DR

Pergunte algo que dê para **aprender**, não para fazer pontos, ser popular ou incentivar a participação vazia.

## TL; DR

- Grandes questões subjetivas inspiram respostas que explicam o "porquê" e o "como" - peça explicação
- Grandes questões subjetivas tendem a ter respostas longas e não curtas - não peça para listar coisas
- Grandes questões subjetivas têm um tom construtivo, justo e imparcial - seja e incentive a imparcialidade, cabeça aberta
- Grandes questões subjetivas convidam a partilha de experiências e não de opiniões - peça para a pessoa contar como ela resolve aquilo
- Grandes questões subjetivas insistem que opiniões devem ser apoiadas por fatos e referências. Opinião não é de todo ruim - diga não ao *fake news*, peça *fact checking*
- Grandes questões subjetivas são mais do que diversão social boba - aqui não é o Facebook, Yahoo Respostas ou Youtube

Não dê espaço para a pessoa responder algo que ela não sabe e não pode justificar consistentemente.

Boas respostas cabe discordância, más respostas sequer podemos discordar de tão vazias que elas são.

Perguntas objetivas não estão sujeitas a esta análise.

## Subjetivo Bom, Subjetivo Ruim

O Stack Exchange funciona com base em perguntas com respostas factuais objetivas. Nós fomos absolutamente claros sobre isso por tanto tempo quanto me lembro, até mesmo
nos primeiros dias, pré-beta do Stack Overflow. Está ali na FAQ padrão do Stack Exchange:

> **Que tipo de perguntas eu não deveria perguntar aqui?**
>
> Evite fazer perguntas que são subjetivas, argumentativas, ou que requerem uma discussão ampla. Este não é um fórum de discussão, este é um lugar para questões que podem ser respondidas!

Assim, as **questões que não são respondíveis - discussões, debates, opiniões - devem ser fechadas como subjetivas** (hoje mais claramente é usado o motivo "Principalmente baseado em Opiniões). Parece bastante simples: fato bom; opinião e discussão ruim. Mas por quê?

A maioria dos fóruns e salas de bate-papo tem um problema de escala. Quanto mais pessoas se juntam à discussão, mais ruído cada uma dessas conexões pode trazer. Assim, os fóruns ficam progressivamente mais barulhentos e mais ruidosos, e de repente um dia... [você para de aprender](http://scobleizer.com/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/)<sup>(en)</sup>.

> ... uma hora os especialistas (ou seja, pessoas que estão te ensinando coisas) se cansam e você é deixado com uma experiência que se parece mais com a banca de jornal do supermercado do que com uma estante de livros em Harvard. - Robert Scoble

Porque acreditamos profundamente na aprendizagem, estamos dispostos a fazer grandes esforços para suprimir as discussões, debates e opiniões que - embora muito divertidos - causam a inevitável ruptura da maioria dos fóruns.

Insisto que a **objetividade é boa para computação e matemática**. Mas você pode passar das ciências exatas para as ciências sociais. Há especialistas nestas áreas, mas elas são, por definição, não exatas. Na verdade, a maioria das áreas acadêmicas não têm respostas objetivas. Temas como economia, engenharia, artes, literatura e ciências sociais não têm exatamente respostas corretas e incorretas. Há uma lista de propostas no [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) sobre temas cada vez mais subjetivos, e acreditamos que muitos deles vão se tornar grandes sites no Stack Exchange!

[image: XKCD]

É aí que começa o problema.

**Nós nunca afirmamos que questões subjetivas sejam abominações horríveis que nunca devam ser feitas**. Nós simplesmente optamos por renunciar a essas discussões subjetivas, como já havia dezenas e dezenas de fóruns que já atendiam a elas.

Mas desenvolvimento de software nem sempre é uma ciência exata. Indo além das perguntas "*este código compila ou não*", você está lidando com questões de **boas práticas**, experiências e comportamentos. Talvez porque as nossas comunidades se tornaram tão acostumadas a receber respostas rápidas, precisas e oportunas, seus membros sentem que mesmo um **Stack Overflow subjetivo seria melhor do que as alternativas**. Tanto assim, que os nossos colegas programadores criaram um site irmão especificamente para suas questões subjetivas reprimidas no site original. Pegue um monte de questões subjetivas, represe-as por dois anos ou mais, e... cabum!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O site [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) explodiu da noite para o dia, hospedando algumas dos melhores (e piores) perguntas contidas na rede Stack Exchange.

Agora vire a página.

[Moms4mom](http://moms4mom.com/) era um estudo de caso sobre sites subjetivos do Stack Exchange 1.0 (grupos alugavam a plataforma do SE para fazer o site que bem entendessem). Os proprietários sabiam desde o início que o tema da paternidade era inerente e profundamente subjetivo, e fundamentalmente inadequado para nossa plataforma. Paternidade/Maternidade é um dos temas mais subjetivos que eu posso imaginar; cada criança é diferente, cada pai é diferente, e culturas inteiras são totalmente diferentes na forma como eles abordam educação infantil. Afinal, quem pode dizer com certeza [em que ordem deve-se assistir à saga Star Wars com seus filhos pela primeira vez](http://moms4mom.com/questions/161/what-order-should-i-watch-the-star-wars-saga-with-my-children-for-the-first-tim)?

O pessoal do Moms4mom encarou a questão da subjetividade e trouxe um conjunto de princípios para criar discussões subjetivas úteis sobre "parenting": o chamado [**Back It Up! Principle**](http://web.archive.org/web/20100610191403/http://moms4mom.com/back-it-up), que significa que suas respostas devem ser postadas com base em:

- Algo que aconteceu com você **pessoalmente**
- Algo que você pode **confirmar** com uma referência

Eles falavam que "opinião, por si só, é apenas ruído". Não estavam dizendo que as opiniões subjetivas devem ser evitadas, já que tentavam moldar o seu site Q&A inerentemente subjetivo como algo construtivo, informativo e útil. Como se vê, há todo um campo de "expertise" subjetivo que tem as características para criar grandes sites de Q&A:

[image: Objetivo/Subjetivo]

Se pudermos evitar conversas que são - e esta é a parte realmente complicada - muito subjetivas, podemos manter os ideais de um grande site Q&A em face de temas completamente subjetivos. Nós podemos evitar cair nos padrões destrutivos previsíveis de discussão aleatória, debate e opinião que transformam um site de uma experiência de aprendizagem em uma revista de fofocas barata.

Eu posso, na maioria das vezes, dizer quando uma questão é excessivamente subjetiva. Nem sempre posso descrevê-la, mas [eu sei quando vejo uma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it). Infelizmente, isso não é bom o suficiente para basear uma política.

> Não vou tentar hoje ainda, definir [pornografia hard- core], e talvez eu nunca poderia ter sucesso em fazê-lo de forma inteligível. Mas eu reconheço uma quando eu vejo... - Potter Stewart, da Corte Suprema dos Estados Unidos

Mesmo a definição do que é muito subjetivo no Stack Exchange é um pouco... *subjetivo*. Mas nós **podemos fornecer um conjunto de diretrizes que ajudam a determinar o que é uma boa pergunta subjetiva**. É semelhante a determinar o que é o "uso justo", e o que não é - um teste multifatorado em que você tenta ajustar algumas diretrizes para as especificidades de sua situação.

## Diretrizes para Grandes questões subjetivas

1. **Grandes questões subjetivas inspiram respostas que explicam o "porquê" e o "como"**. As melhores perguntas subjetivas convidam a explicação. Se você está pedindo uma recomendação do produto de algum tipo, você quer respostas que contenham informações detalhadas sobre os recursos e como eles podem ser usados, e por que você pode querer escolher um em vez do outro. "*Como?*" e "*Por quê?*" tem valor mais duradouro do que um monte de características de um produto em uma lista gigante, não importa o quão completa. Em contraste, as questões subjetivas ruins deixam os autores das respostas lançarem respostas atropeladas (sem compromisso com o resultado) que talvez forneçam um nome e um link - mas não fornecem qualquer tipo de explicação adequada, contexto ou comprovação.
2. **Grandes questões subjetivas tendem a ter respostas longas e não curtas**. As melhores perguntas subjetivas inspiram seus colegas a *partilhar as suas experiências reais*, e não apenas deixam uma "tirinha de jornal" boba ou uma linha com uma meia frase, na esperança de ser recompensado com *upvotes* por ser meramente o primeiro a postar o que qualquer um poderia fazer. Compartilhando uma experiência leva pelo menos um parágrafo, idealmente vários parágrafos. Se eu estou perguntando sobre como fazer biscoitos, não me dê uma lista de compras de supermercado: leite, manteiga, baunilha, ovos. Não há praticamente nada que eu possa aprender a partir de uma lista curta, estática de itens de supermercado que compõem uma receita. Em vez disso, diga-me o que aconteceu da última vez que você fez os biscoitos usando a receita! Compartilhe suas experiências detalhadas, para que todos possamos aprender com elas.
3. **Grandes questões subjetivas têm um tom construtivo, justo e imparcial**. As melhores perguntas subjetivas evitam a rota muito sedutora do discurso vazio e inflamado (*ranting*) e a busca pelo debate acalorado (*flamebait*). Elas dão o tom certo de aprendizagem construtiva e de colaboração, desde o início, ao enfatizar que estamos todos aqui para aprender uns com os outros, mesmo se temos diferentes pontos de vista ou crenças sobre a maneira correta de lidar com decisões o que são inerentemente subjetivas. Não estamos aqui para lutar uns com os outros, o que seria um enorme desperdício de tempo. *Há sempre mais de um caminho correto*.
4. **Grandes questões subjetivas convidam a partilha de experiências e não de opiniões**.  Certamente experiências alimentam opiniões, mas as melhores perguntas subjetivas descaradamente e sem vergonha alguma priorizam a partilha de experiências reais e são contra opiniões aleatórias. É mais útil para compartilhar conosco *o que você fez do que o que você pensa*. Todo mundo tem uma opinião. É preciso zero esforço ou imaginação para ter uma opinião sobre tudo e qualquer coisa. Mas as pessoas que **fizeram** coisas, coisas do mundo real, e têm as marcas e cicatrizes em suas costas para mostrar - estas têm algo que compensa compartilhar. Você deve ser unicamente qualificado para ter a sua opinião com base nas experiências específicas que teve. E você deve compartilhar com a gente essas experiências, e mais especificamente o que você *aprendeu* com suas experiências!
5. **Grandes questões subjetivas insistem que opiniões devem ser apoiadas por fatos e referências**. **Opinião não é *de todo* ruim**, desde que ela seja apoiada por outra coisa que não "*porque eu sou um especialista*", ou "*porque eu disse isso*", ou "*porque sim*". Use suas experiências específicas para confirmar suas opiniões, ou aponte para algumas pesquisas que você fez na web ou em outro lugar que forneça evidências para apoiar suas alegações. Nós gostamos de você. Queremos acreditar em você. Mas até a própria Wikipedia {{carece de fontes}}. E boas perguntas subjetivas deixam isso claro desde o início: *comprove*!
6. **Grandes questões subjetivas são mais do que diversão social boba**. As melhores perguntas subjetivas evitam as armadilhas sociais do tipo "Getting To Know You" (GTKY,  ou "Legal saber do que você gosta") e entretenimento banal. Às vezes as pessoas só querem buscar uma **lista de ideias que podem ajudar a resolver um problema real (melhor livro, melhor abordagem)**. Estas perguntas podem ser **boas quando há conhecimento real** na lista de respostas. O que *não é* bom são as questões sociais de conexão pessoal, que são criadas apenas para impressionar os outros, tais como "Qual é a coisa mais legal/engraçada/idiota/estranha que você viu/fez/experimentou hoje?", Ou questões em que o tópico real do site é usado apenas como ligação espúria, como "comida favorita para programadores". Se você remover a parte "para os programadores" desta questão, ela é realmente única para a nossa profissão? Poderia um membro comum da nossa comunidade razoavelmente esperar *aprender algo que o torne melhor em seu trabalho* a partir desta pergunta? Se não, então é uma questão subjetiva ruim.

Então, está aí: a diferença entre uma boa pergunta subjetiva e uma má pergunta subjetiva - expressa como seis diretrizes básicas. Se você está se perguntando se uma questão subjetiva particular é digna, não se preocupe mais. **Aplique as seis diretrizes de perguntas subjetivas e veja como ela pontua**. Se a pontuação é baixa, feche-a. Se a pontuação é alta, vote para destacá-la. Essa política é **compulsória em toda a rede** onde a subjetividade é parte do próprio tópico do local.

Se você acha que tudo isso é muito complicado, bem, eu acho que é *subjetivo*. Mas, como Robert Scoble apontou corretamente, este é o preço de permitir alguma subjetividade sem deixá-lo minar e destruir o aspecto de aprendizado das nossas comunidades, que acreditamos que as torna valiosas em primeiro lugar.

Quanto a mim, eu digo que **questões subjetivas estão mortas. Vida longa às questões subjetivas**!

---

Tradução livre e adaptada de [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) que é texto base que ajuda decidir quando um conteúdo é adequado aos sites de **toda rede** quando ele é subjetivo, escrito pelo [Robert Cartaino](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/author/rcartaino/) (Gerente de Comunidades). Algumas ênfases são minhas.

É responsabilidade do autor da pergunta exigir que esses itens sejam seguidos. Se o autor fez tudo certo e alguém não seguiu os requisitos colocados, aí a resposta está errada naquela pergunta e todos estão livres para fazer o que for necessário para deixar isso claro. Mais prontamente votando contra a resposta, já que ela não responde o que foi perguntado.

Se não ficou claro, isto **não está sendo postado para limitar o uso de perguntas subjetivas e sim para mostrar quais são aceitáveis e muitas são**.

Um ponto importante não tratado no texto é que a aceitação de uma resposta não significa que ela é a única resposta correta. A aceitação indica qual é a melhor resposta para o autor que é a única pessoa que pode aceitar uma resposta na pergunta dele. Pode-se inclusive aceitar a própria resposta *desde que ela seja a melhor*.

<sub>Preferi manter o título original que tem mais charme.</sub>

Comment: Postem o link deste texto nas perguntas sempre que for pertinente. Precisamos educar os membros que não entendem totalmente o SO. Os novatos e principalmente os **veteranos**!

Comment: Aproveito para criticar um procedimento horrível enraizado: agrupar diversas respostas dos participantes na pergunta. Isso tem vários problemas que não vou listar aqui. Se deve ter uma lista única do que os autores estão postando, então deve ser uma **resposta** do tipo *community wiki*.

Comment: Fiz uma tradução da tirinha do XKCD, veja o que acha :)

Comment: @Bacco Muito legal a tradução. Todos ajudando, podemos fazer algo melhor. Nem peguntei se podia usar, mas acho que está implícito. Já ficou claro para todos mas o crédito é todo do Bacco. Achei que ia ser (e acho que deve ter sido) muito difícil conseguir fazer isso.

Comment: Ah sim, era pra usar mesmo. O que dá um pouquinho de trabalho é manter a tipologia no estilo da original, mas vale como terapia ;) . O importante é mantermos a filosofia do site em pt!

Comment: @Bacco ficou muito bom! Como você fez para manter a tipologia? :)

Comment: @VictorHugo Um pouco de copy & paste, um bocado de Clone Stamp do Photoshop, retoques em pixels individuais com Pencil (e um pouquinho de rabisco à mão pras letras faltantes).

Comment: Muito bom tópico, não tinha visto ainda!

Comment: Wayback Machine arquivo de [Moms4mom "Back It Up!" princípio](http://web.archive.org/web/20100610191403/http://moms4mom.com/back-it-up).

Comment: Muito bom o texto mesmo, parabéns, mas me diga o que levaria eles a lerem, se mesmo sugerindo uma leitura ao "como criar um exemplo mínimo" (que é um teco fácil) eles costumam ignorar, de que maneira devemos incentivar a leitura?

Comment: "Pergunte algo que dê para aprender, não para fazer pontos, ser popular ou incentivar a participação vazia." A ironia é palpável! Não tem quase nada para se aprender no post, exceto uns bons links.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento depois de ler certos comentários aqui mesmo, realmente eu vejo que texto grande é ignorado (exceto por uns bons links).