# Posso traduzir e re-postar aqui as perguntas sobre livros (mas com algumas edições)?

Tags: debate

Bom, no SO em inglês tem várias perguntas históricas, das quais eu acho as mais importantes as listas de livros de várias linguagens, que agora são inválidas lá.

Acontece que apesar de serem inválidas lá, já foram válidas, e foram, e ainda são, muito úteis a comunidade.

Então eu gostaria de saber, se agora nos estágios iniciais do nosso SO em português se posso colocar esse tipo de pergunta aqui (e quem sabe alguns outros tipos).

Eu adoraria listas de livros por exemplo, não só com os livros em inglês no SO em inglês, mas também edições em português, locais de onde encontrar tais livros, livros escritos direto em português, etc...

Answer (score 7):

De uma maneira geral, não. Nós temos mais perguntas *on-topic* aqui, mas a qualidade das perguntas e respostas não muda tanto. Somos um site de desenvolvimento de software e não apenas programação.

Perguntas que geram lista de itens continuam indesejáveis aqui. Se essas informações são tão importantes, elas devem ser colocadas na wiki da tag apropriada.

Claro que o que estou dizendo pode mudar se for desejo da maioria dos usuários. Há algumas pessoas que pensam que nesse ponto, não há porque mudar a regra já bem estabelecida por toda rede SE.

Outras perguntas objetivas são muito bem-vindas como a que você já [postou sobre C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2717/porque-na-linguagem-c-array6-e-igual-6array).

[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)