# A pergunta sobre herança versus composição deve ser fechada como subjetiva?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, pergunta-subjetiva

A pergunta [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/e-errado-usar-heranca-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns) já foi fechada como subjetiva, reaberta e estava prestes a ser fechada novamente, até que coloquei uma recompensa nela.

Sim, ela tem aspectos subjetivos (o próprio título já fala em "errado"), mas é bem fundamentada, útil e, da maneira como foi formulada, tende a gerar respostas no estilo ["subjetivo bom"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective), aquele que embasa e justifica as opiniões em detalhes.

Nessa pergunta específica, não temos até agora nenhuma resposta de poucas linhas dizendo "eu acho que sim/não", que é justamente o motivo da existência da regra contra perguntas subjetivas.

Por isso minha posição é: prefira a qualidade do conteúdo à pureza das regras do site, que não devem ser seguidas cegamente.

Comment: Acredito que a pergunta original devia figurar no meta, como bem dito neste comentário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/e-errado-usar-heranca-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns#comment19988_11594

Comment: Mas @Filipe.Fonseca, o Meta é um lugar para se discutir **o site**, não técnicas e conceitos de programação.

Comment: Se não aqui no meta, talvez no chat, porém realmente não vejo o formato do site compatível com este tipo de pergunta.

Comment: Bom, no chat sem dúvida é válido. Você leu *[Good subjective, bad subjective](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)*, @Filipe.Fonseca?

Comment: Lí sim, inclusive estava terminando de ler quando você me enviou o primeiro comentário. O problema das "boas perguntas subjetivas" é que mesmo e talvez principalmente nos textos longos de resposta, acabamos por ter uma feira das vaidades nas respostas.

Comment: Não sou **totalmente** contra perguntas subjetivas, mas 'é certo', 'é errado', 'qual a melhor forma' e 'qual é a linguagem/software indicado' realmente, mais uma vez **ao meu ver**, cabem muito bem no chat. Já no site, nem tanto.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Verdade, mas ainda acho melhor que uma lista de ruídos. Não é o caso até agora nesta pergunta, certo? As 3 respostas são ok (algumas sejam melhores que outras). O que eu acho que é precisamos arranjar um jeito de permitir conteúdos bons assim, e eliminar as porcarias. Tem muita pergunta aberta que é ruim, e com respostas ruins. Prefiro aquelas fechadas do que uma boa aberta, mesmo que desviando um pouco das regras (e digo um pouco, pois considero mesmo esse caso como "bom subjetivo").

Comment: Repare que o título fala em errado, mas o corpo da pergunta define esse conceito no contexto dela. Não é uma pergunta leviana (tipo "o que é melhor, C# ou Java?")

Comment: De forma alguma considerei a pergunta leviana, ela foi extremamente bem formulada, as respostas estão bem completas, embora não sejam totalmente imparciais(premissa do "bom subjetivo"), mas acho que essa pergunta é a porteira que se abre pra uma boiada que realmente tem o potencial de poluir bem a comunidade. O precedente para (outros) concursos de popularidade (bem) menos sofisticados e que adicionam (muito) menos à comunidade.

Comment: Comentário a parte, @Filipe.Fonseca, acho que cai na tentação da feira das vaidades ao mencionar minha trajetória na resposta. Meu ponto não foi pavonear e sim deixar claro a evolução de opiniões de acordo com meu contexto de vida e experiência. Se vocês acharem que eu devo reescrever / reajustar essa parte (ou outras partes) por favor me falem que eu edito.

Comment: De forma alguma @AnthonyAccioly . Como dito anteriormente, esta pergunta em particular não é o problema, mas sim a porteira por onde passa uma boiada de concursos de popularidade.

Answer (score 7):

## O que está errado com a pergunta

Minha primeira reação em relação à essa pergunta foi "devemos fechá-la". Por dois motivos principais (além do fato de chamar uma discussão subjetiva):

- Ela tenta confrontar decisões práticas com teoria, isso é feito a partir de entendimento simplificado e razoavelmente subjetivo do [Princípio de Liskov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (no caso, interpretação de "perfeitamente substituível").
- Ela soa muito com algumas perguntas em fóruns e listas de e-mail de Haskell e Scala. O que percebi ao longo do tempo é que esse tipo de pergunta gera acaloradas e intermináveis discussões pseudo-acadêmicas.

No fundo o que estamos discutindo é rigorosidade vs flexibilidade, bem como aplicabilidade de um princípio para além do seu contexto (pense em extrapolações da mecânica quântica utilizadas para justificar "A lei da atração").

## O que está certo com a pergunta

Dito isso não consegui ignorar a pergunta do utluiz. Fiquei com "coceira" para responder por n motivos:

- A dúvida é natural, "elegante" e interessante
- O autor da pergunta é uma pessoa que passei a admirar e que sei que seria o último a desejar um debate improdutivo (mesmo sabendo que ele sabiamente testa os limites do que cabe no Stack Overflow de vez em quando :D)
- Essa é uma pergunta que pode ser respondida (se o autor da resposta estiver disposto a dar a cara para bater).

Mas principalmente o que me fez responder a pergunta é que ela cria uma referência útil para outros programadores (o meu principal, quando não único, crivo).

Mesmo os temas opinativos como "Devemos deixar de usar exemplos clássicos de herança?" e ainda a questão "implícita" sobre tomar um princípio a risca vs saber quando "roubar" também podem ser respondidos (com muita, muita cautela e deixando claro que essa é uma opinião e não uma "verdade").

## Conclusão

Eu certamente fecharia essa questão no SOE. Já no SOPT realmente penso que esse tipo de questão está em uma área "cinza". Por um lado a pergunta do utluiz foi um sucesso, levantou respostas excelentes e todos os envolvidos souberam como se comportar (um verdadeiro [Clube de cavalheiros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentlemen%27s_club), repleto de intelectuais discutindo causas nobres). Por outro lado a fase de "Maçonaria" em que podemos agir como uma sociedade discreta bem intencionada está com os dias contados. Perguntas como essa vão atrair polêmica, bem como respostas - corretas e erradas - que podem confundir ainda mais quem está buscando por referências.

Logo, meu voto é um tanto quanto inconsistente. Eu acho que devemos manter essa pergunta aberta (até para fins de teste), mas em geral penso que devemos fechar perguntas dessa espécie, principalmente se o OP, diferente do @utluiz, não demonstrar intenção de refrasear a pergunta.

Comment: " Por outro lado a fase de "Maçonaria" em que podemos agir como uma sociedade discreta bem intencionada está com os dias contados.". **Bingo!**

Comment: Não tenham tanta certeza, no SO tem várias "sociedades secretas" (ou nem tanto) agindo nos subterrâneos (ou até na superfície) :)

Comment: Verdade, @bfavaretto . Vide nosso amigo _pombo_ que acusou a comunidade de teoria da conspiração no esquema de aumento de reputação fraudulento e acabou banido...

Comment: É, @Filipe.Fonseca. Felizmente existem também os secretos "do bem".

Comment: Estou ciente das sociedades discretas @bfavaretto, porém já vi "brincadeiras entre colegas" (figuras icônicas no SOE) sendo invadidas e tumultuadas. Eu não estou de nenhuma maneira querendo excluir usuários ou soar elitistas, pelo contrário, estou apenas dizendo que democracia atrai debate. Infelizmente os portões para o  "bom debate" são facilmente escancarados... Não sei se quero "combater" tudo o entra junto sem uma regra clara sobre o assunto.

Comment: Eu entendo seu ponto, e até tenho me queixado em vários lugares pelo fato de nossas regras ainda não serem claras o suficiente. Mas mesmo sendo, ainda há espaço para um pouco de subjetividade, de um certo tipo, como descrito no artigo a que me referi na pergunta. Isso gera um pouco de confusão, pois  julgar o que é "um bom subjetivo" também envolve subjetividade – e aqui talvez a minha interpretação divirja um pouco da sua e da do @Filipe.

Comment: concordemos em discordar, @bfavaretto. Afinal, em discussões por via de regra não existem verdades absolutas.

Answer (score 7):

Talvez algo me esteja escapando, mas eu não enxergo essa pergunta como subjetiva em absoluto. Inicialmente, eu a classificaria como ampla demais e não é claro o que está perguntando, mas após as edições - em resposta ao feedback da comunidade - ela se tornou na minha opinião uma pergunta "conceitual objetiva". E pessoalmente, ficaria muito triste se o SOpt fechasse as portas para perguntas conceituais.

### "Ser polêmica" é uma razão válida para fechamento?

Suponhamos que eu perguntasse "quais as vantagens dos tipos dinâmicos sobre os tipos estáticos?", essa pergunta seria fechada? Muito provavelmente. Mas ela **merece** ser fechada? Se não fosse o problema [em potencial] do monte de resposta opinativa que iria surgir, eu considero perfeitamente possível enumerar os prós e contras de uma ou outra abordagem, e as situações em que cada uma delas se sai melhor. E garanto que muita gente tem essa dúvida, mas nem arrisca perguntar porque sabe que isso vai degenerar em um "debate religioso"...

A pergunta em análise é bem menos polêmica que a exemplificada acima, especialmente após as últimas revisões. Embora não exista consenso sobre a melhor forma de se usar as ferramentas que os computadores nos oferecem - indo desde o "deve haver uma e apenas uma maneira de se fazer algo" (ex.: filosofia do Python) até o "há vários caminhos até o objetivo, escolha o seu" (ex.: Perl) - e cada uso trará seus prós e contras, não é isso que está sendo debatido na pergunta. Ela deixa claro que o escopo está reduzido a alguns objetivos específicos, e que as respostas devem ajudá-lo a atingir esses objetivos... e não debater **se são ou não bons objetivos**.

Eu poderia apresentar [argumentos](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Soft_Coding.aspx) **a favor** de uma cadeia longa de `if`s em detrimento do polimorfismo. Eu poderia apresentar argumentos contrários à necessidade de segurança de tipos (e aos princípios SOLID em geral). Etc. **Mas nada disso responde à pergunta**. Respostas desse tipo devem simplesmente ser sinalizadas como tal.

Devemos evitar fazer uma pergunta simplesmente porque ela atrai respostas mal direcionadas?

### Isso abre as portas para perguntas similares de má qualidade/respostas opinativas?

Talvez, mas essa não é a pergunta correta. Diversas decisões foram tomadas que têm potencial disruptivo (ex.: permitir que usuários anônimos perguntem/respondam), mas se concluiu que os benefícios superam os custos (ex.: limpar as perguntas/respostas ruins), e foram adotadas. E nesse caso, o benefício supera o custo?

Talvez eu esteja usando óculos cor-de-rosa, mas me parece um pessimismo exagerado achar que qualquer abertura que for dada nas regras automaticamente um monte de trolls vai se agarrar a ela e usá-la pra justificar com sucesso qualquer vandalismo, e seremos incapazes de contê-los por "detalhes técnicos".

Devemos assumir que somos incapazes de lidar com os eventuais problemas? Antes mesmo deles se manifestarem?

### O StackOverflow é para quem?

Definitivamente não somos uma comunidade elitista - pois não só estamos abertos a perguntas de nível introdutório como não há sequer [muita] discordância em relação a isso. Mas temos de tomar cuidado para não acabarmos vítimas de uma ["Revolução Cultural"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Cultural_Chinesa), e banirmos do site qualquer pergunta mais "intelectual".

Quem está aqui há mais tempo costuma fazer perguntas de maior qualidade, não porque somos "melhores" de alguma forma que quem chegou depois, mas sim porque - no papel de *early adopters* - participamos ativamente da construção do site e suas regras. E como co-responsáveis pela moderação do site, sentimos que temos de dar um bom exemplo, sendo particularmente cuidadosos com a forma que perguntamos/respondemos. Usuários mais novos, ainda que sejam tão ou mais capazes do que nós, dificilmente terão o mesmo nível de **envolvimento** (já que as regras estabelecidas no beta privado possuem uma "inércia" difícil de ser quebrada, passando a impressão que quem chegou depois tem que se adaptar a elas e pronto).

Mas isso não significa - espero - que o tempo em que perguntas mais sofisticadas podiam ser feitas esteja com os dias contados. Eu parei de participar do SOen meses antes do SOpt abrir, justamente por estar cansado daquele turbilhão de perguntas que se resumem a "estou fazendo X e deu o erro Y, como resolver?" (nada contra essas perguntas, inclusive elas vivem salvando minha pele quando estou codificando de fato). Meu "altruísmo" tem limites, se não estou aprendendo nada nem me entretendo (ou ganhando algo com isso, nem que seja mais *page views* no meu perfil, ainda que no momento eu não tenha muito uso pra eles), eventualmente acabo desanimando de continuar no site.

Estou divagando, mas isso não é pra ser sobre mim: é uma característica da nossa sociedade que eu chamaria de "de terceiro mundo" (sinto muito se a expressão é ofensiva pra alguém). Trata-se da ideia de que toda a ciência e tecnologia é desenvolvida **lá fora**, e que nós somos apenas **consumidores** dessa tecnologia. Reparem [nesse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9026/como-e-feita-a-randomizacao-pelo-computador#comment18814_9026) criticando uma pergunta (ênfase minha):

> Essa pergunta não faz sentido, Em que ela agrega um programador? Bom em nada já que **ele não tem a intenção de criar um código Random**, ...

Essa concepção - que não é exclusiva desse usuário em particular, eu garanto - de que a função de se criar linguagens, bibliotecas, etc é de **outras pessoas**, e que a nossa é somente **utilizar** essas ferramentas pra resolver problemas do dia-a-dia, é algo que eu tento sempre combater - só não sei como...

Numa outra linha (mas ainda dentro do tema "O StackOverflow é para quem?"), há a oposição a perguntas/respostas com maior nível de aprofundamento. Veja por exemplo [essa conversa no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14662130#14662130) (Disclaimer: trata-se de uma crítica a uma resposta minha, e que por sinal estava errada mesmo - mas não pelos motivos citados):

> (...) Dei uma resposta de seis linhas, eu acho.
>
> A outra resposta (que prefiro não falar de quem foi) foi hiper prolixa, passou por filosofia, etimologia, mais um monte de coisas, e não respondeu porcaria nenhuma.
>
> (...)
>
> Eu apenas acho que é muito preciosismo. "Ah, a resposta tem que ser hiper completa". Às vezes o que o cara quer tá em 2 linhas.

Eu já fui aluno, e posso dizer que entendo bem o sentimento: de fato, às vezes o que a gente quer é só o mínimo necessário "pra passar na prova", e é um saco quando a pessoa que está nos ajudando fica cheia de discurso. Mas, *no meio escrito*, isso é relevante? Acho que cabe um pouco de bom senso (um "TL;DR" se sua resposta for demasiadamente longa), mas no final das contas mais informação é melhor que menos - quem quiser se aprofundar lê a resposta completa, quem não quiser pára de ler mais cedo...

Tudo isso que estou dizendo (que é mais uma resposta **aos comentários** na pergunta e demais respostas, do que à pergunta em si) é para deixar claro que - na minha opinião - esse tipo de pergunta deveria sim continuar sendo aceita, até mesmo estimulada. Há espaço na comunidade para ambos os públicos (iniciante e avançado), não devíamos reduzir ao "menor denominador comum". Não sei que tipos de problemas isso poderá causar no futuro (ainda não participava do SO na época em que foi criado o Programmers, mas li que este se iniciou com uma proposta bastante diferente da que tem hoje - evidência que o motivo não foi "perguntas conceituais serem problem no SO"). Mas estou disposto a "pagar pra ver"...

### Conclusão

Eu apóio o sentimento de "prefira a qualidade do conteúdo à pureza das regras do site, que não devem ser seguidas cegamente" ... exceto que nesse caso não é necessário sequer violar qualquer regra. Perguntas conceituais estão no foco do site, a pergunta em questão é sim objetiva, e o fato de que perguntas desse tipo *podem* atrair conteúdo indesejável não é motivo para restringi-las sem maiores evidências de que isso está acontecendo de fato.

Comment: Pô, resposta hiper prolixa.

Comment: @bfavaretto TL;DR: Dxá 'berta

Comment: Olá mgibsonbr, só para criar polêmica (evil :D), eu não penso que o que está sendo discutido aqui é o fim das perguntas conceituais e ou sofisticadas. Você respondeu uma pergunta conceitual de forma muito boa que deu origem à pergunta do utluiz. O SOE tem alguns exemplos muitos bons de perguntas amplas com respostas (muito) sofisticadas - [como essa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming). A questão aqui é não abrir portas para perguntas do tipo "confronto dos mundos".

Comment: Perguntas como tipagem estática vs tipagem dinâmica atrairão polêmica sim, com certeza várias (ou todas) as resposta terão um bias conforme a cultura do cara, não há resposta certa dentro de um contexto mais fechado. Não acho que somos inferiores a comunidade global de nenhuma forma, só penso que devemos tomar alguns cuidados para não repetir alguns erros dela. A polêmica dessa questão não vem da sua sofisticação, e sim da interpretação de "perfeitamente substituível" (empregado na sua resposta anterior) bem como do confronto entre material didático e prática.

Comment: Pesquisa é feita aqui no Brasil, coisas revolucionárias são descobertas e desenvolvidas aqui no Brasil. Não acredito que sejamos meros consumidores de informação; dito isso fóruns técnicos e no formato de Q&A sofrem sim de pseudo-academicismo crônico. Não é todo dia que um Conal Elliott responde sua pergunta (nem aqui nem no SOE)... Como alguém que também zela pelo site, eu só peço para tomarmos cuidado para, com boa intenção, não criarmos um problema.

Comment: BTW, como outro velho de guerra do SOE acredito que sua natureza atual mais "fisiológica" é uma contrarreação (admito, exagerada) da comunidade à atenção massiva que perguntas "polêmicas" ou "engraçadas" recebiam; principalmente quando a desinformação é bem aceita. Comentários em respostas "erradas" com 300 upvotes dificilmente impedem que informação "errada" se alastre.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Concordo que é difícil mesmo promover informações corretas quando a comunidade não é criteriosa ao avaliar a qualidade das respostas. Restringir o tipo de pergunta aceita àquelas em que não há dúvida sobre o que é correto ou não de fato é uma solução. Mas será a melhor solução? Isso eu não sei dizer... P.S. sobre a questão da ciência, não quis dizer que não há inovação aqui, simplesmente que não temos a **cultura** da inovação. Falta coordenação, falta valorização, falta incentivo, mas mesmo assim ela acontece. Mas na nossa área pelo menos, me parece a exceção e não a regra.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Quanto ao "fim das perguntas conceituais e sofisticadas", agora que caiu a ficha: de fato, estive argumentando com um "espantalho" (*straw man*) esse tempo todo... Comecei a resposta tentando argumentar por que não acho que a pergunta em questão é subjetiva, mas acabei tentando defender ardorosamente as perguntas conceituais, ainda que não tivesse ninguém "atacando" elas...

Comment: Ri muito com o TL;DR

Answer (score 5):

O que posso dizer em defesa da pergunta é que, apesar do título dela ser subjetivo, seu conteúdo certamente tem algum teor acadêmico e pede uma reflexão baseada em conceitos já estabelecidos.

Além disso, ela já foi bastante melhorada (graças aos muitos comentários) no sentido de cercar as possibilidades de opiniões espúrias. O conceito de "errado" foi mais bem definido em uma atualização recente. Daria para melhorar muito mais, construir praticamente uma hipótese de uma dissertação, mas minha limitação de tempo e conhecimento acabou a deixando-a no estado em que se encontra.

Eu sei que muito da subjetividade foi minha falta de capacidade em explicar claramente o problema e as suas consequências, mas creio que a maioria conseguiu compreender o suficiente.

Sugiro àqueles que ainda a considerem subjetiva demais para o site que, levando em conta todo o conteúdo e não apenas o título, destaquem quais pontos estão dúbios, precisam de melhorias ou são opinativos. Fiquem à vontade para editar a questão, explicitadas as razões para tal.

---

A questão toda surgiu porque eu mesmo tenho dificuldades às vezes para ilustrar conceitos de OO e acabo utilizando analogias ruins. Então, quando a outra questão (que deu origem a esta) foi direcionada no sentido de usar herança apenas em casos específicos, isso me pareceu entrar em choque com a forma que temos ensinado e aprendido na teoria.

O ponto inicial era: ao usar OO na prática temos que rever e reaprender o que aprendemos na teoria? Porque me parece a coisa mais comum termos que desmistificar o uso de OO que parece bonito em teoria, mas não funciona na prática.

Comment: Só espero não ter complicado ainda mais.