# Devemos usar o sistema de gratificação para impedir o fechamento de perguntas?

Tags: debate, comportamento, fechamento, recompensa

## Contexto

Na pergunta "[É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/e-errado-usar-heranca-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns/11713#11713)" ocorreu algo inusitado. Apesar da qualidade da pergunta ser indisputável, a comunidade ficou dividida sobre a pertinência dela no Stack Overflow.

Em determinado momento haviam 4 votos para que a questão fosse fechada. Para impedir o fechamento precipitado da questão um usuário voluntariamente deixou um pequena gratificação em aberto na questão, o que impede seu fechamento.

Como essa questão [já esta sendo discutida no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174/a-pergunta-sobre-heranca-versus-composicao-deve-ser-fechada-como-subjetiva), e como eu fui o usuário que postou a primeira resposta para a questão, não quis abrir mais um tópico no meta mencionando o ocorrido e tumultuar ainda mais o processo de votação. Agora que a recompensa já foi atribuída e a pergunta perdeu um pouco a visibilidade acho interessante abrir esse debate.

**Disclaimer**: Eu fui contemplado com a gratificação; caso a comunidade julgue o mecanismo improcedente serei o maior "prejudicado". Deixo claro que concordo com o que foi feito nesse caso específico, porém não ficarei chateado se os pontos em questão forem considerados improcedentes e tiverem que ser revertidos.

## Minha opinião

Tivemos um caso justificável para o uso de recompensas para impedir o fechamento de uma questão. É uma questão muito boa, elaborada por um usuário experiente, disposto a editá-la / aperfeiçoá-la, além de estar discutindo um assunto que muitas pessoas da comunidade estão dispostas a abraçar.

## O problema

Dito isso, o uso do artifício disparou meu *spider-sense*. Em especial, independentemente dos méritos dessa questão em específico, me preocupou o fato dos 4 votos para fechá-la terem ["decaído"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12176/stop-the-decay-of-closing-votes-when-a-bounty-is-set) automaticamente durante os dias em que a questão estava em destaque. Agora que a pergunta tem vários votos positivos, respostas bem elaboradas e uma recompensa atribuída, ela dificilmente receberá 5 votos e será fechada. De certa forma a recompensa não apenas atrasou a decisão de fechar a pergunta, o artifício influenciou a decisão.

## Referências

Esse problema foi discutido exaustivamente no [Meta do SOE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140206/how-to-prevent-your-question-being-closed-just-post-a-bounty-on-it). Seguem os principais pontos:

- É um acontecimento raro uma vez que questões fora de contexto dificilmente sobrevivem tempo suficiente (dois dias) para que uma gratificação seja aberta.
- A gratificação é um contrato com o usuário que a ofereceu. O fechamento de uma questão com recompensa gera um problema (ou o usuário que ofereceu a recompensa perderia os pontos ou um moderador teria que intervir).
- As questões ainda estão sujeitas à votos negativos e sinalizações para o moderador.

## O que está sendo discutido

Não estou discutindo os méritos desse caso em específico, nem sugerindo que a Stack Exchange mude o mecanismo ([já existem propostas para isso no Metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions)). Também não estou apontando dedos uma vez que concordo com a postura do usuário que atribuiu a recompensa nesse caso em específico.

Dito isso, não acho que votos negativos sejam o mecanismo correto para substituir votos para fechar a questão (uma pergunta descontextualizada não necessariamente é ruim; em outros sites da rede esse poderia ser, por exemplo, o caso de uma migração), e certamente não acho que *flags* para moderação sejam o mecanismo correto para lidar com esse tipo de situação salvo casos extremos.

Então a minha pergunta é: Devemos abraçar o uso de recompensas para impedir o fechamento de questões em território "cinza"? (A grande vantagem aqui é impedir o fechamento precoce de boas questões). Ou devemos fazer um acordo de cavalheiros e não recorrer à essa prática? (E com isso evitar influenciar decisões).

Comment: Mais um caso: [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9044/4186) precisou ser reaberta,  e só com a gratificação começou a ganhar respostas... Pessoalmente acho que casos como esse (bem resolvidos) ajudam a expandir as fronteiras do "off-topic".

Answer (score 12):

Bom você ter levantado esse assunto. Caso alguém não tenha se dado conta, fui eu quem colocou a recompensa na pergunta em questão, e fui eu quem abriu a [discussão sobre ela no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174/a-pergunta-sobre-heranca-versus-composicao-deve-ser-fechada-como-subjetiva). Optei por não tratar disso ali pois achei que iria desviar o foco da discussão.

### Por que coloquei a recompensa

Admito que minha estratégia tem um quê de *trapaça*, já que foi uma atitude unilateral ante a um fenômeno de grupo (os quatro votos para fechar). Ponderei antes de tomar essa atitude, e quero deixar claros os motivos que me levaram a ela:

- Claramente não se tratava de uma pergunta desleixada; naquele momento, o autor já havia feito duas edições em resposta aos comentários que criticavam a pergunta, e seguia buscando *feedback* da comunidade para modificá-la ainda mais se necessário.
- A única resposta existente até então era muito boa. Para além das opiniões pessoais do autor, a resposta discute fatos e oferece subsídios para que seus leitores tomem sozinhos a decisão.
- As opiniões em torno da pergunta estavam divididas. Ela já havia sido fechada e reaberta uma vez, e os comentários já eram mais de vinte. A pergunta *exigia* discussão no lugar apropriado (aqui no meta), e a recompensa serviria também para atrair mais gente para cá.
- O *segundo* fechamento da pergunta era iminente (já havia 4 votos), e se ela fosse fechada não poderia receber novas respostas. Me pareceu um triste destino para uma pergunta com potencial para gerar excelentes respostas.
- A recompensa, acompanhada da discussão no meta, seria uma maneira de maximizar a visibilidade da pergunta, enquanto o fechamento tenderia a reduzi-la. Mais visibilidade aumentaria as chances de surgirem outras boas respostas.
- Uma alternativa possível (além de não fazer nada) era sinalizar a pergunta esperando que o Gabe a [bloqueasse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) com um aviso de disputa de conteúdo. Não me pareceu uma boa ideia dado meu objetivo de tentar agregar mais bons conteúdos, já que perguntas bloqueadas não podem receber respostas, nem votos, nem ser editadas.

Alguns dos motivos acima certamente envolvem fatores subjetivos. Sim, parte da minha motivação foi instintiva e não racional. Eu queria proteger o que considero benéfico para o site.

### Como lidar com situações parecidas

Apesar de ter usado desse artifício, não acho que isso deva ser banalizado. Em quase 3 anos de participação nos sites da Stack Exchange, foi a primeira vez que fiz isso, pois considerei a situação excepcional.

Por outro lado, é complicado controlar isso. Quem possui reputação suficiente para colocar recompensa em uma pergunta tem o direito de fazê-lo, é assim que o sistema funciona. Às vezes, ocorrem abusos. Já vi péssimas perguntas, indefensáveis, que deveriam estar fechadas, mas acabaram perdurando abertas (pelo menos por mais uma semana) devido a uma recompensa. Nesses casos, o que faço é sinalizar a pergunta e delegar a decisão para um moderador, que pode optar por remover a recompensa se assim julgar necessário.

Não acho que um acordo de cavalheiros seja uma solução muito eficiente. Por mais que haja cavalheiros (e damas) dispostos a acatar esse acordo, sempre haverá quem não concorde. Considerando que este foi o primeiro caso do tipo no nosso site, sugiro deixar as coisas como estão, sempre mantendo atenção na lista de perguntas com recompensa. Quem vir um abuso, sinalize para que um moderador avalie e reverta a situação se necessário. Se houver abusos frequentes (e reconheço que o que fiz pode ser considerado um abuso), retomamos a discussão. Se acharmos que precisamos de alteração no sistema, tratamos do assunto no metão.

Comment: Não abordei isso na minha resposta pra não desviar demais do foco, mas não considero "uma atitude unilateral ante a um fenômeno de grupo" algo ruim em si: quando alguém acessa a fila de análise e vê uma pergunta nomeada para fechamento, só isso já **predispõe** a pessoa a enxergar problema naquela pergunta (da mesma forma que votos negativos fariam; ou o contrário, votos positivos e/ou gratificação predispondo a mantê-la aberta, como apontado pelo OP). Um "pé no freio" bem colocado pode ser bom para conter isso - desde é claro que feito de boa fé, como acredito ter sido o caso em questão.

Comment: bfavaretto, obrigado por "dar a cara para bater" aqui junto comigo. Obrigado a você também mgibsonbr. No geral fico dividido sobre o assunto. Por um lado não considero o que foi feito uma "trapaça"; também não tenho muito medo que "a moda pegue" pois o artifício requer bastante conhecimento sobre o funcionamento do site (eu nunca tinha reparado que era possível fazer isso). Por outro lado concordo contigo que esse foi um remédio "tarja preta", possui efeitos colaterais e deve ser administrado com cautela.

Comment: Em especial, após ler a questão [Até que ponto a reputação contribui para a comunidade além dos privilégios?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200) fiquei com isso na cabeça. Precisamos moderar, precisamos liderar por exemplo, mas devemos tomar muito cuidado para não "forçar a mão"; em especial devemos ficar atentos sobre como os novos usuários percebem nossa atuação no site. Existe uma linha sútil aqui. Algumas ações nos fazem ser percebidos como influenciadores para o bem, outas como o "STF do SOpt". É importante deixar claro que nenhuma decisão veio "de cima", e sim de iguais.

Comment: Deus me livre me compararem ao Joaquim Barbosa! @AnthonyAccioly

Answer (score 10):

Uma das razões da existência do mecanismo de gratificações é chamar a atenção da comunidade para uma pergunta específica. Há até uma opção explícita "essa pergunta não recebeu atenção suficiente". Na maioria dos casos o que fica implícito é "a falta de atenção à pergunta fez com que ela não tivesse boas respostas", mas essa não é a única interpretação.

Se uma pergunta está "na fronteira" do foco da comunidade (i.e. não é claramente *on topic* nem *off topic*), então seu tratamento acabará por depender de **quem** deu atenção à pergunta: se os poucos usuários que a viram julgaram ser *on topic*, não votarão pra fechar e ela permanecerá aberta. Se eles julgarem ser *off topic*, votarão para fechar. Seja num caso, seja no outro, a decisão desses usuários pode não ser **representativa** do que pensa a comunidade como um todo.

Nesses casos, o melhor curso de ação na minha opinião é tentar atrair o máximo de olhares possíveis para a pergunta, de modo que todos possam colocar seu ponto de vista ou - se a comunidade estiver dividida - que pelo menos a votação seja mais expressiva (i.e. o que a maioria dos avaliadores dedicir corresponda ao que a maioria da comunidade pensa). Se a pergunta "sobreviveu" aos dois dias necessários até a recompensa ser possível (seja permanecendo aberta, seja sendo fechada e reaberta uma ou mais vezes), "congelá-la" num estado aberto ajuda inclusive a evitar decisões precipitadas.

Quanto aos votos para fechar terem "decaído", não enxergo isso como um problema, muito pelo contrário: se a diferença entre uma pergunta ficar fechada ou aberta for apenas 4 votos, então ela ainda está na borda do *on topic*/*off topic*, e na dúvida é melhor que  fique aberta ("melhor uma pergunta ruim aberta que uma boa fechada"). Aí volta a questão da representatividade: aqueles 4 usuários em particular não poderão votar novamente para fechar, mas se seu voto corresponde ao desejo da comunidade então haverá outros para fechá-la em seu lugar.

- Em tempo: o requisito de 5 votos para fechar não é na minha opinião o ideal: num universo de 7000+ usuários (109 com privilégio de votar para fechar), *apenas* 5 votos decidir o destino de uma pergunta é muito pouco! Isso só funciona na prática porque a grande maioria das perguntas é fácil de ser avaliada - e aquilo que os 5 votaram provavelmente será o mesmo que os outros todos votariam (de modo que não faz sentido elevar demais o requisito pra fechar). Justamente por essa razão que não considero 4 votos "perdidos" numa pergunta controversa algo significativo, a ponto de demandar alguma ação corretiva.

Dito isso, já vi muita pergunta ruim no SOen que recebeu um *bounty* por falta de atenção (i.e. ninguém votou pra fechar, ninguém respondeu, aí o próprio usuário colocou a recompensa impedindo ela de ser fechada), e algum mecanismo para permitir que a mesma fosse fechada (imediatamente ou ao final do *bounty*) seria sim desejável. Se algo assim for implementado, poderia a princípio ser usado em perguntas desse tipo também (área cinza). Inclusive esse seria um bom cenário para - aproveitando-se da visibilidade aumentada que a recompensa proporcionou - utilizar um sistema de votação menos enviesado, por exemplo em que um voto para manter aberto anulasse um para fechar, e a decisão final só fosse tomada caso o peso de um lado fosse significativamente maior que o outro.

Comment: Concordo em termos, acredito que isso só deva ser utilizado em casos excepcionais. Meu medo de defender isso com unhas e dentes é que o tiro saia pela culatra, e aumente o número de perguntas *ruins* que usem o sistema de recompensas para permanecerem abertas. Ainda bem que quase niguém lê o meta, hehe!

Comment: Eu ainda ontem pus uma pergunta com gratificação que já tinha um voto negativo e poucas visualizações, entretanto melhorei consideravelmente a pergunta e coloquei gratificação. Hoje já tenho uma resposta muito bem dada e pode ser que ainda venham mais. Acho muito bem que se possa fazer isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Verdade, mas o que está sendo discutido aqui por definição só se aplica a casos excepcionais. As perguntas ruins de verdade serão fechadas logo (antes dos dois dias) e dificilmente serão reabertas. E as perguntas *tumbleweed* só serão notadas depois que a recompensa já estiver lançada - aí já é tarde demais para se fazer algo, só resta aguardar que ela termine...

Comment: Aguardar ou sinalizar. Eu concordo com você que estamos falando de casos excepcionais; me preocupo com quem lê as coisas pela metade e fora do contexto, com quem vai ler só o título da pergunta do Accioly e o seu "Sim" em negrito. O problema é mais com o tipo de ênfase do que com as suas ideias.

Comment: @bfavaretto Bem observado! "Sim" e "Não" em negrito funcionam bem para *poll questions*, mas nesse caso concordo que é prejudicial. Vou alterar isso.