# Oferecer gratificação para evitar que a pergunta seja fechada. Pode isso Arnaldo?

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas, gratificação

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54539/cep-da-minha-cidade-onde-posso-encontrar-fonte-aberta-atualizada-e-confi%C3%A1vel), me parece que foi adicionado gratificação, principalmente, para evitar fechamento como duplicada [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400/como-buscar-um-endere%C3%A7o-por-cep-nos-correios).

Pode isso **Arnaldo**?

Isso é permitido, no escopo do site?

**Minha opinião sobre a pergunta:**

Em meu entendimento sobre a pergunta em especifico, acredito que ela seja realmente duplicada [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400/como-buscar-um-endere%C3%A7o-por-cep-nos-correios), já que apesar do autor tentar edita-la e argumentar que se trata de outra diferente, não vejo respostas consideravelmente diferentes das já existentes a possível duplicada.

O que pode ser feito, para que isso não se torne uma pratica constante, para evitar o fechamento de perguntas e tentativa de "ganhar tempo"?

> Há [essa questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1204/devemos-usar-o-sistema-de-gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-impedir-o-fechamento-de-perguntas) tratando, mas no caso é uma pergunta que está sendo fechada por outros motivos e não por duplicata, e lá ela já tem uma boa resposta. E já fiz o que entendi que deveria ser feito, sinalizei a pergunta aos moderadores.

Comment: P/ os tugas: http://uolesportevetv.blogosfera.uol.com.br/2011/10/10/galvao-bueno-descobre-o-bordao-pode-arnaldo/

Comment: Eu acho que o grande diferencial da pergunta é que esta pede uma fonte aberta, enquanto a outra é específica sobre os Correios (a empresa, cuja base é fechada, e vendida como serviço).

Comment: @bfavaretto, sim, mas a outra já tem varias respostas apontando para opções de fonte aberta, como por exemplo: [esta](https://github.com/PostmonAPI/postmon) e [esta](http://viacep.com.br/). Mas como citou utluiz, nos comentários a resposta dele: "duplicata é questionável", o que eu olho principalmente é se as resposta da possível duplicata respondem completamente a pergunta, mas isso é interpretativo.

Comment: Na época daquela pergunta, não havia outra onde as resposta se encaixassem melhor, né? Agora tem. Concordo que a situação não é clara. Por outro lado, não acho que a recompensa aqui tenha sido um artifício para evitar fechamento (como eu fiz naquele outro caso que você citou). Tem comentários na pergunta debatendo o fechamento, mas ela não tem nenhum voto para fechar (nem mesmo votos expirados).

Comment: @bfavaretto, não entendi: "Na época daquela pergunta, não havia outra onde as resposta se encaixassem melhor, né? Agora tem.", que época, que pergunta? Também não sei se isso aconteceu aqui, até por que depois de postar aqui percebi nas datas dos acontecimentos lá, não levam a crer que a recompensa foi para evitar um fechamento. E sim para tentar dar destaque a questão.

Answer (score 7):

Na minha opinião, se o usuário está realmente disposto a, literalmente, *colocar sua reputação em jogo* para salvar a pergunta e tentar obter uma resposta melhor, acho que esta é uma estratégia válida.

Ninguém vai se ferir por deixar uma pergunta aberta por uma semana. E se após o período da recompensa ele não obter um resultado satisfatório ou provar que a pergunta é válida, então esta acabará sendo fechada.

Comment: Entendi, então o negocio é tipo, não concordo! Então adiciono na agenda(para daqui a 7 dias), votar para fechar como pergunta duplicata de tal? Obs: Só vejo um problema, pessoas que não percebam a possível duplicata e respondam a pergunta, de forma duplicada também. (Ai vira uma m.... hehe)

Comment: @Fernando Não acho certo fechar a pergunta por um possível problema que nem ocorreu ainda. Eu recomendo que evitemos fechar perguntas se o único motivo for "medo" do que pode acontecer. Para perguntas e respostas com problemas, existe a opção de editar, votar contra, etc. Se aparecer uma resposta ruim ou duplicada, dá para votar para remoção ou sinalizar, por exemplo. Além do mais, a questão da pergunta ser duplicata é questionável. Eu não creio que vai aparecer uma resposta duplicada, justamente pelo motivo indicado no comentário do bfavaretto à esta pergunta.

Comment: Surgiu uma resposta repetida já lá: [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56601/2998), e na pergunta possivelmente duplicata já tem essa resposta varias vezes: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/414/2998), [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412/2998), [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/520/2998), [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/448/2998), deve-se fazer algo? Sinalizar? Eu não vejo muito o que fazer agora além de deixar assim?

Comment: @Fernando O Peter Kraus já deixou um comentário lá. É o primeiro passo. Eu negativei a resposta porque ela não atende aos critérios de ser confiável e atualizada. Não tinha visto que a resposta já estava quadruplicada. Certamente é porque o usuário é novo no site. O que é estranho é que a resposta  deve ter passado pela fila de análise, portanto foi aprovada por mais mais de um usuário.

Answer (score 3):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>*Aos portugueses: este aí é o [Arnaldo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnaldo_Cezar_Coelho)* ⇧</sup>

Sem tratar do caso específico, colocar recompensa para evitar fechamento [é questionável e só deve ser tentado em casos extremos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1204/devemos-usar-o-sistema-de-gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-impedir-o-fechamento-de-perguntas) – e, mesmo assim, o ato pode acabar desfeito por um moderador. Quando eu fiz o mesmo em outra pergunta, por exemplo, eu ainda não era moderador do site, e fiz sabendo que o Gabe poderia remover a recompensa a qualquer momento.

## Sobre o caso específico

Não me parece que o objetivo tenha sido evitar o fechamento, já que há pergunta estava parada há dias, e sem nenhum voto para fechar. Acho que foi para chamar mais atenção para o assunto e conseguir boas respostas.

Sendo assim, não vejo motivo para invalidar a gratificação. Isso não quer dizer que a pergunta nunca será fechada. Após o fim da gratificação ela pode receber votos de fechamento normalmente. Pretendo também rever as duas perguntas, e avaliar se seria o caso de mesclá-las (o que junta todas as respostas em apenas uma delas, mantendo a outra fechada). Neste momento não digo nem que sim, nem que não, pois não tive tempo de avaliar em detalhes todas as respostas.

Comment: É depois eu avaliei melhor as datas, percebi que para esse caso especifico, não parece que a gratificação foi para evitar um fechamento, pois já estava aberta a vários dias, eu que não tinha a visto antes. Mas atualmente eu não fecharia mais a questão, após ver algumas resposta, e uma possível iniciativa bem interessante (não sei se para comunidade, mas para mim sim), de buscar uma solução viável e legalmente correta, não sei vai dar certo, mas é bem legal. A respeito de mesclar, não sei se seria possível.