# "Esta pergunta oferece recompensa e não pode ser fechada"?

Tags: debate, fechamento, recompensa

Identifiquei uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237780/64969) que achei não muito clara. O autor da pergunta já havia posto uma recompensa para ela. Quando eu tento votar pelo fechamento, sou surpreendido com a seguinte mensagem:

[image: não posso fechar por ter recompensa]

Então, fico com os seguintes questionamentos:

- esse realmente é o comportamento ideal para o site, não fechar perguntas com recompensas?
- esse recurso não pode ser abusado pelo autor?
  Por exemplo, para perguntas claramente fecháveis, caso o AP perceba um movimento na direção de fechar a pergunta, mas que esse movimento não conseguiu juntar os 5 votos a tempo, ele poderia por a recompensa e forçar um maior tempo com a pergunta no ar

Comment: Já passei por isso e o que conclui que realmente não há motivos para mudar: a recompensa só pode ser oferecida 2 dias após aberta a pergunta, então se continuar aberta até lá é porque provavelmente deve se manter aberta (exceções ocorrem esporadicamente de forma a não comprometer a comunidade). O mesmo quanto ao abuso, eu particularmente nunca vi isso acontecer e não acho que comprometa de alguma forma o site.

Comment: Se houver algo de muito errado com a pergunta, você pode sinalizar e nós moderadores iremos avaliar. Podemos retirar a recompensa se considerarmos que está havendo abuso do sistema, mas já aviso que isso é bem raro. Isso dito, [eu mesmo já abusei desse recurso do sistema](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1206) – porém antes de ser moderador, e com a melhor das intenções.

Comment: Sobre a pergunta em si, olhei por alto agora e parece razoável. O que não estiver claro pode ser discutido nos comentários. Então não é o caso de remover a recompensa.

Comment: @bfavaretto um dos pontos que me preocupou nela foi [esse comentário do autor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237780/ao-adicionar-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-sistema-n%c3%a3o-compila/239048#comment489601_239048) em sua resposta, feita minutos após a recompensa ter sido aberta. Entendi como um "ah, obrigado pela ajuda mas deixa quieto, não preciso mais". Também senti falta de contexto para ver onde estaria quebrando.

Comment: Enfim, meu foco neste questionamento aqui no meta era preocupação com a possibilidade de abusar da recompensa, o que já foi devidamente respondido =D

Comment: Vou marcar como duplicata da que eu linkei, o debate é o mesmo (apesar de as perguntas partirem de casos bem diferentes)