# A pergunta não é baseada em opiniões mas as respostas sim, porque ser fechada?

Tags: debate

Fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15292/base-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-nodejs/15435?noredirect=1#15435) no SO. Até o momento existem 3 votos para fechar por ser baseada em opiniões.

A pergunta em si não é baseada em opiniões mas sim as respostas que estão a surgir.

Limitei o contexto da dúvida e listei as perguntas, porém o que eu reparei é que as respostas foram dadas por pessoas que estão a começar no SO e que provavelmente não conhecem bem as regras ainda.

Por mais que seja boa a intenção de quem respondeu, só vai fazer com que a pergunta seja fechada e com isso pergunto, **não seria correcto eliminar a reposta no lugar da questão**?

**Antes que editem a pergunta, escrevo em pt Portugal. XD

Comment: Entendes que nenhuma das repostas lá colocadas até o momento são soluções reais para teu problema?

Comment: @Renan eu não discordo de você, inclusive reconheci o problema e votei para fecha-la. A questão que te trouxe aqui "Se não posso pedir opinião, não posso utilizar o SO" surgiu não pelas minhas perguntas fechadas, mas pelas perguntas que podem ter uma resposta técnica e são levadas para o lado pessoal e acabam por ser fechadas (não é o caso das minhas questões, que foram fechadas e eu não discordo).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem perguntas que são difíceis de ser feitas. Elas ficam em uma linha tênue se deve ser fechada ou não.

Essas perguntas exigem um esforço maior de quem está perguntando. Tem que direcionar as respostas. Tem que mostrar que tipo de resposta não é aceitável, ou pelo menos deixar claro como deve ser a resposta.

A avaliação para fechar deve ser feita primariamente pela pergunta. Mas muitas vezes deixamos abertas perguntas que acabaram recebendo boas respostas. Não é de se admirar que as pessoas também acabem usando as respostas como argumento para decidir sobre a pergunta.

A responsabilidade pelas respostas é da pergunta, quer queira, quer não. Eu mesmo já fiz algumas perguntas difíceis quando estava em beta privado para testar o comportamento. Mas todas as vezes que poderia atrair opiniões, eu deixei claro o que o eu queria. Não impediu algumas opiniões, mas o cuidado extra no texto ajudou.

O que posso adiantar é que uma resposta ruim, mas que ainda é uma resposta, pode no máximo receber votos negativos. **Uma resposta só deve ser removida quando ela sequer é uma resposta**. A qualidade da resposta é avaliada pelos votos.

Perguntas tem a mesma avaliação e também podem ser fechadas. Não é uma punição, é apenas um indicador que a pergunta não atende certos critérios. Inclusive o fechamento pode ser revertido se acontecer algo (normalmente uma edição) que faça a pergunta ser considerada boa. Fechar uma pergunta não é o mesmo que eliminá-la. Ela apenas fica em estado limitada esperando que alguém a melhore. E quase sempre será o autor que fará isso.

No limite costumo deixar a pergunta aberta. Mas no limite em um assunto que não entendo ou não me interesso também não vou poder ajudar a não ser dar dicas genéricas de como salvá-la.

Não posso ajudar muito além de dizer para tentar melhorar. Se a pergunta realmente é importante para você, não é só uma curiosidade, vale o esforço em repensar ela de outras formas que atraia respostas melhores. Eu já gastei horas em uma **pergunta** que fiz.

A primeira pergunta é altamente opinativa. Performance é muito genérico, existe várias formas de medir isso. E a única forma de dar uma resposta apenas **razoavelmente** próxima é colocar todos esses dados para funcionar e testar. É mais fácil você fazer que pedir para pessoas aleatórias na internet. Sem testar, qualquer resposta é baseada em opinião. E mesmo testando, ainda tem grandes margens para erro sem ter critérios bem definidos do que é performance para este caso.

A segunda, pode até ter uma resposta objetiva, mas em geral quem é fã vai dizer que sim sem critério algum.

A terceira e quarta cai no mesmo problema da primeira. A terceira piora os parâmetros apresentados antes que eram mais específicos. A quarta nem faz muito sentido.

Interessante, fazendo a análise aqui, agora, eu passei achar que não está tão no limite assim, me parece que não há como dar uma resposta que não seja opinião.

Não é fácil fornecer um fato técnico sobre estabilidade de biblioteca. Não é impossível, mas a prática mostra que não costuma ser possível.

A única forma que vejo para dar fatos concretos sobre o desempenho é criar o teste que você deveria fazer. E ainda a pessoa teria que criar cenários possível do que seja o conceito de performance para o caso.

E vamos dizer que tenha alguma resposta que indique o que você quer. Você implementa tudo errado e não atinge o objetivo que queria. A resposta não serviu para nada.

Você está dando premissas abstratas e querendo fatos concretos. É complicado.

Os 3 bancos que você escolheu são difíceis de comparar, eles costumam atender necessidades tão distintas que você eliminaria dois deles antes de pensar na performance. E mesmo que tente comparar, depende muito da aplicação (concreta, não uma suposição genérica) e a forma de implementar ela. Ninguém tem o mínimo de informação sobre a aplicação. E mesmo que tenha bem mais não quer dizer que resolve o problema.

Você quer saber como fica o desempenho? O Cassandra é usado pelo Facebook. O MySQL é usado pela Wikipedia. Já é um parâmetro que tem bom desempenho. É uma forma de olhar para performance. Eu já sei que essas duas soluções aguentam bem mais que 50GB e 100mil views diários. No [site do SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) tem informações que ele aguenta esse volume, e é uma avaliação conservadora, minha opinião é que ele consegue fácil 10 vezes mais que eles acham. Eu consigo fazer uma aplicação que aguenta 100 ou 1000 vezes mais.

Mas como a aplicação é desenvolvida chega nesses volumes é outra estória. Faça do jeito errado e você pode ter 1 bilionésimo ou menos do desempenho que outras pessoas conseguiram.

Ainda fica a minha dica mas no momento que estou escrevendo este texto a sua pergunta só pode ser respondida com opiniões.

Comment: Resolvi votar para fechar e assim acabar com a pergunta, apesar da intenção ser sobre o desempenho da BD citas com NodeJS, que não é uma linguagem amadurecida como o PHP, por exemplo. O que eu queria era fatos técnicos, por exemplo, MongoDB é ótimo para se utilizar com NodeJS mas existem diversas limitações. A pergunta era sobre qual base de dados mais estável para se trabalhar no contexto que citei, a reposta poderia até ser qualquer uma das 3.

Comment: Eu entendi o seu ponto de vista, e desde já foi uma ótima análise, mas como você disse, depende muito de como eu construí a aplicação, mas posso construir a melhor aplicação do mundo mas se a BD não trabalha bem no contexto que citei, todo trabalho será em vão. No fim da sua análise, respondeu que o facebook trabalha com Cassandra, é um ótimo parâmetro, mas no meu caso tem um NodeJS no meio.

Answer (score 2):

Comentei lá na pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A orientação para não postar coisas que são exclusivamente de opinião **é para quem pergunta**. Se tem dois usuários (recém chegados) **respondendo** com coisas puramente de opinião, isso não é um problema *per se*.
Já vão duas respostas dessas... a pergunta foi fechada por conta disso...
*você tem certeza à respeito da pergunta?*

Confira o artigo [Subjetivo bom, subjetivo ruim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective).

Comment: Nem precisa saber inglês: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective

Comment: após a análise do @bigown resolvi votar para fechar, entendi o ponto de vista e o erro estava mesmo na pergunta, apesar de limitar o contexto e as perguntas, não deixava de ser uma pergunta baseada em opiniões, o que não percebi quando criei a pergunta.