# Se não posso pedir opinião, não posso utilizar o SO

Tags: debate

Estou insistindo um pouco neste assunto de "perguntas baseadas em opiniões" não para tentar mudar algo no SO mas sim para ter uma melhor participação e acredito que com essa questão posso ajudar alguém no futuro.

Após ter algumas questões fechadas (e após a vossa análise, percebi o porque) por ser baseada em opiniões, cheguei a conclusão que não posso utilizar o SO para pedir orientações a cerca de um assunto qualquer relacionado a programação, porque não vejo maneira de ser orientado sem suscitar opiniões.

Por exemplo, o utilizador quer criar um chat como o facebook mas não sabe qual linguagem utilizar e gostaria de ter uma orientação de quem já fez algo, saber sobre dificuldades e limitações, algo que ajude a decidir qual caminho percorrer.

A pergunta com certeza teria muitas respostas baseadas em opiniões, mas há termos técnicos que podem justificar uma escolha, como por exemplo, uma linguagem mais adequada para real-time. **Neste caso seria uma partilha de experiência e não de opinião.**

Eu entendo que esse tipo de questões será respondida a medida que vou experimentando, mas posso evitar erros, como por exemplo, escolher PHP no lugar de NodeJS para construir o chat.

O que eu entendo é, não posso utilizar o SO para uma pergunta com o contexto acima, para isso teria que utilizar um fórum com o sistema convencional.
A pergunta poderia até ter uma resposta técnica bem formulada e não seria fechada, mas sempre irá correr o risco.

Comment: Pelo que está definido no escopo do SOPT, é mesmo assim que funciona. A linha entre o que é opinião e o que não é, é muito ténue, como já alguém tinha dito aqui. Eu quando é assim prefiro ir procurar no google, em inglês porque esse tipo de informação em português não existe praticamente. Seria uma ideia para outro site do SE em PT, tipo http://pt.programmers.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Não quero ser chato, mas.. sobre essa sua pergunta aqui, o que exatamente você pretende atingir com ela? Você quer uma opinião, um conselho, uma diretriz, ou só quer desabafar mesmo? Digo isso pq a principio eu li seu titulo achando que você tinha esquecido do `?`, mas pelo jeito não. Apesar de aqui no meta não ser proibido criar uma pergunta que não é uma pergunta não entendi o que você espera com essa publicação e como espera que os usuários da comunidade contribuam com ela.

Comment: @JorgeB. Aqui somos até mais adeptos de opiniões que o Programmers (não muito claro). Já fui moderador lá e o que é aceito aqui seria fechado lá. Vou até testar uma coisa no meta que vi no Programmers. Filipe: Por toda descrição que você fez, parece opinião mesmo. Cada um vai dizer o que gosta mais de usar (dá para fazer chat em qq linguagem) e não dar informações realmente relevantes. Você está querendo que pessoas decidam por você. Talvez você ache que é fácil alguém dizer o que vai ser bom para você e que dê para confiar nisso, mas isso não é real. Tem maneiras e maneiras de pedir ajuda.

Comment: Isso não é uma pergunta, mas sim um desabafo. Local para desabafo são fóruns, ou um blog pessoal.

Comment: @Renan Eu li o post "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective" e foi com base nele que criei esta pergunta, porque no exemplo que sugeri, a 2 tipos de resposta possível: opinião pessoal ou troca de experiência com fundamentos técnicos. Se o pessoal começa a responder o que acha, a pergunta é fechada mas se alguém construir uma resposta com fundamentos técnicos, com certeza é uma troca de experiência e não será fechada.

Comment: @bigown a questão não é um desabafo e sim uma afirmação que descreve a realidade do SO actualmente. No exemplo que sugeri, a 2 tipos de resposta possível: opinião pessoal ou troca de experiência com fundamentos técnicos. Se o pessoal começa a responder o que acha, a pergunta é fechada mas se alguém construir uma resposta com fundamentos técnicos, com certeza é uma troca de experiência e não será fechada. Na minha ideia, a pergunta pode ser fechada por causa das respostas e não pela pergunta.

Comment: @Filipe eu não falei em desabafo. E não disse que fecharia uma pergunta hipotética, até porque não posso tomar uma ação concreta baseado em hipótese. Eu não saio fechando tudo o que vejo pela frente. Eu tento analisar o mérito, a possibilidade de surgir algo bom dali. O problema é que quem quer fazer este tipo de pergunta não está querendo ou não sabe como fazer a pergunta render de verdade. Deixa margem para a opinião ao invés de centrar no que importa, no que resolve um problema real.

Comment: @bigown pois não disse, na sequência de comentários me enganei no utilizador, era o Renan. Mas veja, se o utilizador quer uma orientação, ele não tem algo em concreto, apenas um problema (criar um chat como o facebook) e dizer que PHP não é linguagem adequada e sim, por exemplo, NodeJS que é voltada para aplicações real-time, não é uma opinião, é um fato. Ao responder isso estou a ajudar o utilizador a tomar uma decisão correta, de utilizar a linguagem correta sem levar para o lado pessoal.

Comment: @Filipe Ele não tem um problema, ele tem algo que ele quer fazer e não sabe por onde começar. Realmente o SO não é bom para isso. Você está partindo de premissas que não existem. Você está querendo que opiniões virem fatos. E esse é o motivo para opiniões não serem aceitas. Porque as pessoas se agarram a suas opiniões, acham que são fatos e isso não ajuda ninguém. Só existe um fato em tudo isso. Não existe linguagem correta a não ser que você queira, por exemplo, usar PHP em uma página no browser, aí não dá. O resto é opinião. Sua afirmação confirma que esta não é uma pergunta boa.

Comment: @bigown penso que aqui está a divergência, eu acredito na orientação técnica sem levar para o lado da opinião, mas o problema é que pode existir mais de uma resposta válida e então a afirmação de que o SO não é adequado para tal pergunta está correta. O chat por exemplo, é fato PHP não ser adequado,  porém existem várias linguagens adquedas e responder NodeJS é uma opinião, estou certo?

Comment: Diversas pessoas discordam de você. As pessoas que já fizeram chat em PHP sem problemas sabem que não é verdade. Tudo o que você está escrevendo mostra que você quer que sua opinião seja verdade. Só isso. Talvez a pergunta deva deixar claro "analisei a tecnologia Y e a tecnologia X, aparentemente esta tem vantagem A B C, e desvantagem D E F, a outra tem as vantagens 7 8 9, etc, ou mesmo "no que diz respeito a Y, as duas linguagens se comportam da mesma forma?" etc, restringindo ao que você quer saber de fato. Senão, é realmente um caso de opinião e não de experiência no tópico específico.

Comment: @bigown o fato de fazer um chat em PHP com sucesso não quer dizer que seja adequado e isso pode ser provado tecnicamente sem levar para o lado da opinião, agora dizer que NodeJS é melhor eu concordo com você, é querer que a opinião seja um fato que não é, é apenas uma opinião e não se encaixa no SO.

Comment: "fazer um chat em PHP com sucesso não quer dizer que seja adequado e isso pode ser provado tecnicamente sem levar para o lado da opinião". Eu fiz um recentemente, pois um dos requisitos era funcionar mesmo com JS desabilitado. (no caso, o auto-refresh era fallback, e o update "normal" um ajax, mas como mero upgrade) De qualquer forma, vou tentar pensar numa prova técnica pro PHP estar errado.

Comment: @Bacco não é questão de ser errado, é possível fazer com o PHP utilizando o long polling, mas veja uma análise completa aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10496/analise-sobre-codigo-ajax/10515#10507 inclusive foi uma resposta que comecei com "não recomendo..." e logo em seguida dei fatos técnicos que suportam a minha opinião. Veja, dei uma opinião mas não fiquei por ai, a justificação está dentro do aceitável pelo SO, porém a pergunta está sujeita a opiniões e antes de la chegar, alguém poderia dar apenas uma opinião e a pergunta ser fechada.

Answer (score 8):

### 1. Se não posso pedir opinião, não posso utilizar o SO

R: Em princípio, seria isso mesmo. Mas não precisa desanimar por isso, pois com uma certa flexibilidade, dentro do limite razoavel, dá pra salvar muitas questões com cara de opinião. Para isso, veja o ítem 2 que você mencionou, que é uma forma intermediária que poderia atender sua necessidade:

### 2. Neste caso seria uma partilha de experiência e não de opinião.

R: Respostas baseadas em experiência são diferentes de opiniões, este assunto está coberto nesta questão. Como as duas coisas se confundem, e a experiência por si só pode ser insuficiente para uma resposta, recomendo a leitura com atenção da questão abaixo, para analisar cada caso em concreto:

[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)

> Lembrando que o SOpt está sendo moldado ainda, então o Meta está sempre aberto para discussões concretas.

Comment: Mas é muito fácil confundir experiência com opinião :) O fato de você dar nome de experiência, não significa que ela não seja apenas uma opinião. Tem que haver sustentação. Por exemplo: "Eu fiz um chat em PHP e ficou bom" ou "**Eu** tive muitos problemas fazendo um chat em NodeJS" são experiências. E daí? Ajudam alguém? A experiência tem que ser qualificada. Mas eu entendi o que o Bacco quis dizer.

Comment: @bigown talvez tenha faltado eu mencionar mais explicitamente "leia a questão abaixo para você saber quais experiências são válidas, e se a experiência pretendida se aplica ao que é permitido no SOpt". Talvez num futuro edit ;)

Comment: Eu entendi, só quis reforçar isso.

Comment: @bigown achei válido seu comentário. Editei a questão pra dar uma reforçada na necessidade de leitura do link.

Comment: @bigown Eu li o post "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective" e foi com base nele que criei esta pergunta, porque no exemplo que sugeri, a 2 tipos de resposta possível: opinião pessoal ou troca de experiência com fundamentos técnicos. Se o pessoal começa a responder o que acha, a pergunta é fechada mas se alguém construir uma resposta com fundamentos técnicos, com certeza é uma troca de experiência e não será fechada.

Comment: @Filipe nisso eu concordo, o problema é que a pergunta tem que ajudar a resposta ser bem direcionada. Perguntas que beiram a opinião precisa ser **muito** bem feitas. As que são pura opinião nem devem ser feitas. Note que todos estão enxergando opinião no que você quer com uma pergunta dessas. A resposta do Renan mostra isso com detalhes. As frases que usei acima são experiências mas não fornecem fatos. Ou você quer que a pessoa conte todos os detalhes que aconteceu com o projeto? Aí fica muito amplo. Você tem que ter uma dúvida concreta. Não pode ser algo flutuando sobre o assunto.

Comment: @bigown o que eu queria dizer é que há perguntas que estão no limite que podem ter repostas técnicas como podem ter opiniões e cabe a quem responder não levar para o lado pessoal, o exemplo que citei, do chat, não preciso contar a experiência, basta explicar porque o PHP não é adequado para real-time e o NodeJS sim, bastava só uma explicação técnica.

Comment: Pergunta boa e respostas ruins => negative as respostas; pergunta boa e respostas boas => está tudo ótimo; pergunta ruim e respostas boas => vamos **tentar** passar pelo bom efeito colateral causado; pergunta ruim e respostas ruins => feche logo. Isso é o que deve ser feito. A pergunta tem que ter seu próprio mérito, a única exceção que dá para fazer e se por acaso ela acabe trazendo alguém que consiga dar uma resposta salvadora. O problema é que você acha que uma pergunta ruim é boa.

Answer (score 5):

Existe um problema de alinhamento claro entre o que você se propõe a discutir e o que faz parte do escopo do SO. Sugiro uma lida na central de ajuda. Cito um trecho de [uma seção relevante:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

> **Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?**
>
> Para evitar que sua pergunta seja sinalizada e possivelmente removida, evite fazer perguntas subjetivas onde…
>
> - toda resposta seja igualmente válida: “Qual é seu _ favorito?”
>
> (...)
>
> - não haja um problema real para resolver: “Tenho curiosidade de saber se outras pessoas se sentem como eu.”
> - você faça uma pergunta hipotética e aberta: “E se acontecer _?”
>
> (...)

Você mesmo concorda que coisas como ***"escolher PHP no lugar de NodeJS para construir o chat"*** são puramente questão de opinião. Nesse caso, não existe resposta correta. Na verdade, trata-se de uma comparação entre maçãs e laranjas - portanto qualquer resposta que favoreça uma ou outra tecnologia é errada por princípio.

Esse tipo de pergunta não é útil para ninguém. Nem para você, que vai deixar um completo estranho tomar decisões técnicas no seu lugar (o caminho para um arrependimento futuro bem amargo), nem para os demais membros do SO, já que isso não ajuda ninguém a resolver problema algum.

> Neste caso seria uma partilha de experiência e não de opinião.

Discordo. Discorrer que tecnologia A é melhor do que B em termos gerais, sem um problema muito objetivo e reproduzível a ser resolvido, ainda é questão de opinião. Isso dá margem a aberrações do tipo "linguagem foo é melhor do que linguagem bar porque a IDE tem um botãozinho que automatiza essa ou aquela tarefa...".

Isso não quer dizer que os problemas que você tem não possam nem mereçam ser discutidos; Apenas ocorre que o SO tem um objetivo a cumprir, que é ser uma central de referência para soluções de problemas reais relacionados a programação. Existem outros espaços na Internet onde você pode discutir experiências pessoais, ou qual tecnologia/linguagem é melhor, e suas perguntas e tópicos serão todos aceitos sem fechamento. Fica aqui uma sugestão de um site mais adequado: http://br.answers.yahoo.com/‎

P.S.: escolher PHP no lugar de NodeJS não é um erro. Isso é opinião, não fato.

Comment: Como eu respondi acima, penso que aqui está a divergência, eu acredito na orientação técnica sem levar para o lado da opinião, mas o problema é que pode existir mais de uma resposta válida e então a afirmação de que o SO não é adequado para tal pergunta está correta. O chat por exemplo, é fato PHP não ser adequado, porém existem várias linguagens adquedas e responder NodeJS é uma opinião. Como disseram no inicio que era um desabafo, acredito não ser, este tópico pode ajudar alguém no futuro com a mesma dúvida. Fiquei bem esclarecido com a vossa ajuda.