# Resposta grandes, para perguntas pequenas, sem fundamento?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Ultimamente no SOPt, estou vendo respostas grandes para perguntas sem contextualização, que é muitas vezes não traz uma resposta genérica, mas, sim um resposta especifica apenas a 1 usuário. Ora, é dito aqui que as respostas devem servir para vários usuários, ai eu pergunto:

1) Até que ponto é benéfico a quantidade excessiva (muitas vezes) de explicação em uma resposta (questão)?

2) Seria uma forma de impor que a sua resposta é teoricamente melhor do que a do outro usuário?

3) Sair do contexto da pergunta é bom até que ponto, porque, muitas vezes a pergunta não é clara e as respostas são "imaginativas", ou seja, ahhhhhhhhh eu sei o que ele ta querendo saber, não seria melhor adicionar comentários antes de responder finalmente?

4) Ando vendo muitas respostas aqui com simplesmente experiências (assunto batido, mas, não resolvido) e uma chuva de Votos nessas respostas. Qual o sentido verdadeiro disso, ajudar ou simplesmente promover?

Por favor, se puderem e quiserem respondam, os comentários abaixo da pergunta não ajudam muito em questões aonde podemos melhorar o SOPt.

Comment: Normalmente as respostas mais longas costumam ser as mais genéricas e as que mais ajudam diversos usuários. O que não pode é deixar de responder a pergunta e **principalmente** responder algo errado. Os votos representam um pouco o que a comunidade acha da resposta. E a comunidade erra também. Tem várias respostas erradas com algumas imprecisões sendo votadas positivamente e elogiadas por membros da comunidade.

Comment: Chuva de votos em posts pobres é... bah. Resposta grande/detalhada pra pergunta simples fica ao gosto de quem escreve, faz porque quer, sorte de quem recebe, e mais uma excelente resposta pros arquivos do site; acho que é *win-win*.

Comment: Quando a pergunta dá margem para muitas interpretações eu sempre tento chegar a uma conclusão perguntando nos comentários. Como em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17022/dentro-de-um-if-a-ordem-dos-termos-altera-o-resultado. A pergunta é ruim e todas respostas postadas são e só poderão ser especulação. Em geral, quem é experiente não responde algo tão vago. Espero que ela possa ser melhorada e apropriadamente respondida.

Comment: Não entendi o ponto 1. Você está falando de perguntas com muita explicação do problema, ou de respostas com muita explicação sobre a causa?

Comment: E você poderia dar exemplos de perguntas e respostas que tenham os problemas que você cita? Eu não estou entendendo bem aonde você quer chegar. O comprimento da resposta não diz nada sobre a qualidade dela.

Comment: @bfavaretto foi editada o ponto 1. Sobre seu outro questionamento, você poderia dar seu testemunho como resposta igual o nosso amigo `mgibsonbr`, claro se puder, Obrigado.

Comment: @brasofilo peço que dê o sua resposta como o nosso amigo `mgibsonbr`, você me disse que sabe bem como funciona o SO a muito tempo, gostaria de ver sua expressão numa resposta, acredito ser de grande valia pra comunidade, claro se puder e quiser !!! obrigado!

Comment: @bigown, gostei da sua clareza do seu comentário, mas, se puder realizar um reposta com tudo isso que você citou seria de grande valia a todos nós, claro se puder, obrigado !!!

Comment: Desculpe, @bfavaretto, não vou apontar dedos! nem apontar quais questões ou perguntas, isso seria leviano e poderia só causar desentendimentos. Mas, mesmo assim muito obrigado!

Comment: @HarryPotter é um direito seu, mas ajudaria o debate ficar mais focado. Ajudaria a gente entender com exemplos do que você está falando evitando dar margem à especulação (cada um deve estar fazendo o sua). Se a comunidade está errando precisamos saber onde é o erro. Não é questão de individualizar, mas entender o erro melhor. Faça o que achar melhor.

Comment: @bigown, não tem individualização, não acho nada melhor, é um pergunta com carácter verdadeiro do que acontece aqui ultimamente com algumas respostas de modo geral, eu to vendo muito texto e pouco conteúdo. Só ratificando não vou apontar dedos, é só você olhar como estão algumas respostas. E avalei se achar que para você é válido se não for eu respeito a sua opinião!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>*"... estou vendo respostas grandes para perguntas sem contextualização, que é muitas vezes não traz uma resposta genérica, mas, sim um resposta especifica apenas a 1 usuário..."*</sub>

Ai temos 2 questões: A resposta realmente responde o que foi perguntado? Se sim, o problema está na elaboração da pergunta provavelmente. Se não responde, a comunidade vai refletir isso nos votos. O ideal nesse caso, como um todo, é que as pessoas parem de votar (tanto up como down) em assuntos que não entendem, assim os votos refletirão a verdadeira qualidade da pergunta.

<sub>1) Até que ponto é benéfico a quantidade excessiva (muitas vezes) de explicação em uma resposta (questão)?</sub>

Desde que acrescente detalhes que façam alguma diferença no entendimento do assunto, melhor. Por outro lado, volta e meia também vejo muitos casos de parágrafos inteiros (e até printscreens em excesso), que só acrescentam tamanho na resposta, e poderiam ser ditos em 2 linhas de texto, mais objetivamente, ou explicações de assuntos bem diferentes do que foi perguntado (parecendo que a pessoa pesquisou correndo e adaptou sem entender do assunto). Neste caso, percebi que a comunidade tem votado de acordo, e o tamanho da resposta por si só não é suficiente para garantir bons votos.

Obs: no SOpt especificamente, nem sempre vota de acordo - tem alguns casos em que a pessoa não quer aprender, então ela vota no código pronto, e não em boas explicações. Infelizmente, pois isso desvaloriza um pouco a comunidade.

<sub>2) Seria uma forma de impor que a sua resposta é teoricamente melhor do que a do outro usuário?</sub>

Provavelmente, se a pessoa "encheu linguiça", deve ser uma tentativa disso. Mas as regras da Stack Exchange foram feitas de uma maneira que, apesar de não serem perfeitas, acabam não dando muito "lucro" pra falta de conteúdo.

Aqui no SOpt ainda não está tão bom, pois muita gente vota por aparência ainda, mas é só questão de maturidade da comunidade. Aí temos que ensinar a votar, em vez de questionar a liberdade de quem responde.

<sub>3) Sair do contexto da pergunta é bom até que ponto, porque, muitas vezes a pergunta não é clara e as respostas são "imaginativas", ou seja, ahhhhhhhhh eu sei o que ele ta querendo saber, não seria melhor adicionar comentários antes de responder finalmente?</sub>

Se sair do assunto, realmente não é bom. Mas nesses casos, há grande chance de outro responder objetivamente, e a pessoa que fez a resposta "enrolada" acabar ficando pra trás tanto nos votos quanto em accept (seja a resposta longa ou curta). Realmente, nada a fazer, senão educar a comunidade a votar com qualidade.

<sub>4) Ando vendo muitas respostas aqui com simplesmente experiências (assunto batido, mas, não resolvido) e uma chuva de Votos nessas respostas. Qual o sentido verdadeiro disso, ajudar ou simplesmente promover?</sub>

Creio que está bem explicado aqui: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/)

**Em resumo:**

No meu ver, a questão levantada não é algo que realmente necessite de nenhuma providência específica, e realmente o sistema de votação e auto-moderação da comunidade teoricamente ajustará essas coisas com o tempo. Só está sendo um processo lento, pelo fato de aqui a comunidade estar sendo muito tolerante com abusos, o que me parece uma situação proposital da Stack Exchange para uma "nova experiência" com a nossa comunidade.

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco, pela sua resposta!

Answer (score 10):

Recentemente fui o autor de uma dessas respostas. Meu raciocínio foi o seguinte:

1. Usuário pergunta ["Como substituir uma determinada posição de uma string em Javascript?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16963/215)
2. Eu procuro uma pergunta semelhante para fechar como duplicata.
3. Não encontro. Penso: "WTF?! Não temos uma pergunta canônica para uma coisa tão trivial?"
4. Percebo que é muito provável que **esta** pergunta se torne canônica (principalmente pelo título). Isso significa que:

   1. Uma resposta bastante completa pra mesma vai beneficiar muita gente;
   2. Ela vai atrair muitos upvotes.

Eu já havia comentado pedindo mais detalhes do autor, mas quando a ficha caiu quanto ao exposto acima, achei melhor dar uma resposta bem detalhada cobrindo todos os casos. Mesmo que o próprio OP só estivesse interessado em um caso particular, ou até mesmo que - na remota chance de ser um caso do Problema XY (como bem abordado na [resposta do bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16964/215)) - não fosse essa a melhor resposta *do ponto de vista do OP*.

(Não quis cometer o erro [dessa pergunta sobre regex no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9655164/520779) - onde dei uma resposta sem muito esforço achando que a pergunta ia logo ser fechada, tomei vários downvotes, editei pra ficar melhor, e hoje é minha resposta melhor votada - pena que está como *community wiki*...)

Com base nisso, respondo às suas perguntas:

1. É preciso diferenciar entre o cerne da pergunta (i.e. aquilo que está sendo perguntado de fato) e o **contexto** da mesma (i.e. qual situação particular do OP o motivou a fazer a pergunta). Nem toda pergunta é simples e direta como essa mencionada, a maioria é difícil de responder fora de um contexto maior. Por isso, o máximo de informação **relevante** que o OP puder dar, melhor, ainda que o núcleo da pergunta seja simples e conciso.

   Pois no final, quando o problema específico do OP estiver resolvido, as pergunta/respostas ainda estarão ali, para beneficiar futuros usuários com o mesmo problema. Esses usuários provavelmente não se interessam em nada pelo contexto do OP (pois eles têm seu próprio contexto), mas podem identificar rápido se aquilo que é perguntado corresponde ou não ao seu problema individual - e se vale a pena ou não ler as respostas ou buscar por outras postagens.
2. Talvez, mas isso é bom ou ruim? É bom lembrar que o SO não é um "jogo" pra ver quem ganha mais pontos, e sim um recurso para ajudar a nós desenvolvedores no nosso trabalho. A gamificação é apenas um **incentivo** extra para atingir tal objetivo (pois traz reconhecimento a quem contribui). Dessa forma, se um usuário estiver disposto a dar uma resposta mais completa a uma pergunta, isso deve ser encorajado - pois é material de referência útil para quem chegar a essa pergunta por outros meios, e não necessariamente tiver um problema *idêntico* ao do OP (apenas parecido).
3. Não sei te responder qual é a medida certa. Responder logo em vez de comentar faz sentido "estrategicamente", pois permite que você tenha a primeira resposta. Mas também é um "risco", pois se o contexto for diferente do que você imaginou, sua resposta estará errada e você terá que gastar mais do seu tempo e dedicação para corrigi-la (ou, no mínimo, excluir a resposta errada, e ficar sem "recompensa" pelo seu esforço na primeira resposta).

   Esse fenômeno (apelidado no SOen de [*"fastest gun in the west"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/177950) - "o gatilho mais rápido do oeste") é endêmico na StackExchange, e não parece haver solução fácil. Se ele causa detrimento à comunidade ou não, é discutível, pois há valor em se obter respostas rápidas ainda que de início imprecisas. E funcionando como um wiki, é sempre possível melhorar perguntas e respostas incrementalmente, não é estritamente necessário que saia perfeito logo de primeira.
4. Na minha opinião, troca de experiências é algo muito valioso. Tem coisas que você pode debater teoricamente à exaustão, mas só fazendo na prática é que você aprende de fato. Mas quanto mais contato você tem com pessoas que já passaram por problemas semelhantes - e a possibilidade de ouvir o seu relato - maior a chance de que você não repita os erros que elas cometeram e/ou tome ações preventivas contra problemas que você não imaginava que ia ter. (É isso que me motiva a fazer perguntas [desse tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15534/215), por exemplo, pois sei que terei que investir um tempo e esforço significativo ao empregar isso em meus projetos, e um esforço pró-ativo agora vai me poupar muita dor de cabeça depois)

   E mesmo se uma pergunta não pede explicitamente por experiências, votos positivos numa resposta com esse conteúdo são sinal de que as pessoas acharam ele útil. E pessoalmente, eu concordo: ter a pergunta respondida é bom, mas aprender também é bom. Desde que não fuja demais do tópico em questão, é claro...

Comment: (off-topic: faz uma custom flag e pede pra [removerem o CW](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9655164/520779))

Comment: Faço minhas as suas palavras. Eu evito (mas não fujo) das perguntas que ajudam só uma pessoa. E todas as vezes que posso responder, procuro atender o interesse de outras pessoas que estão lendo. Não consigo ver como respostas longas podem ir contra a filosofia do site se elas respondem o que foi perguntado. Eu costumo responder sobre X, tentando contextualizar para Y. Atende ao maior número de pessoas.

Comment: @brasofilo Hehe mas fui eu mesmo que coloquei ela como CW. Achava que era uma pergunta sem importância, e não queria gastar mais tempo com ela. Mas o OP marcou minha resposta como aceita, aí eu não pude excluir, então marquei como se dissesse: "essa pergunta agora pertence à comunidade, quem quiser mexer nela fique à vontade". Mas ninguém mexeu, e eu fui ficando cansado de ver votos contrários na minha timeline, acabei indo lá e consertando. Mas os pontos são o de menos, só mencionei ela porque foi outro exemplo de pergunta simples, sem contexto, mas que acabou ficando popular (50 mil views).

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr, pelo sua resposta!