# Perguntas simples == resposta simples?

Tags: debate, respostas

**Não acredito ser uma duplicata de:**  [Resposta grandes, para perguntas pequenas, sem fundamento?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1399/resposta-grandes-para-perguntas-pequenas-sem-fundamento)

Me considero intermediário em Python, mas a vontade de responder a perguntas é maior. Tenho até experiência com [Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) e [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/), mas é raro aparecer perguntas do tipo. Então por esse motivo, é mais comum (se não unicamente) eu responder perguntas simples ou de Python puro do que de algum módulo específico que apareça.

Acontece que devido à esse meu "problema" acabo, às vezes, respondendo perguntas cujo erros são extremamente simples (um erro de digitação ou lógica básica) com respostas muito grandes onde tento abarcar tudo o redor da questão.

Uns bons exemplos seriam [essa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/381432/39577) ou [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380530/39577), onde eu expus algo simples com uma resposta longa.

**Existe algum mal em responder perguntas do tipo com respostas "longas" ou é melhor responder com algo mais direto?**

É que sempre fico meio sem jeito, por que sinto que estou respondendo aquilo "pra dizer que eu respondi".

Comment: Por estarem bem avaliadas acho que é um bom sinal que não há problemas nisso :D

Comment: Pessoalmente não considero esses dois exemplos de respostas como longos. E acho sempre melhor explicar detalhado o problema e solução do que dar uma resposta meio simples e vaga

Comment: Passando o olho, suas respostas parecem boas. Não vejo problemas em responder assim, muito pelo contrário. Às vezes o erro da pergunta é simples, mas a causa mais profunda do erro pode ser falta de compreensão de um ou mais conceitos. Suas respostas parecem partir desse princípio, e acho isso muito positivo! Eu mesmo costumo responder assim. Então, repetindo, suas respostas são boas, mesmo que as perguntas tenham sido fechadas.

Comment: Existem escritores e escritores, leitores e leitores. Inclusive, uma mesma pessoa pode funcionar como um tipo de leitor (aquele que quer entender a fundo o problema) ou como outro tipo (precisa se livrar de uma pedra no sapato, sem se incomodar no momento com o porquê). Eu mesmo fiz ambos os papéis mês passado aqui no SOpt. Então, essa relação de implicação "pergunta simples <==> resposta simples" não é relevante. Há nichos para ambos estilos de resposta.

Comment: Por sinal, é difícil você ter uma apresentação/estilística plena que atenda a ambos os casos, então o estilo de escrita pode justificar a existência de outra resposta. Tentei fazer [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/377527/64969) algo que atenda a esses 2 públicos de leitores, mas não necessariamente consegui atender.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho interessante que você explicou o processo e apresentou exemplos e ficou uma resposta leve e bonita de se ler. E... realmente, às vezes respondemos extensamente e o autor da pergunta apenas deu um Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V, testou e se esqueceu da resposta. No seu caso, você apresentou para os dois casos. Me parece uma boa abordagem.

Comment: Como respondeu o @bruno101, muitas vezes a pergunta vai além da dúvida simples do autor, e uma resposta alongada abordando com mais profundidade o tema serve de referência para o futuro, além de ensinar mais sobre o assunto. Sem falar que o autor da resposta demonstra real interesse em contribuir para a comunidade, pois dedicou tempo, conhecimento e pesquisa de forma filantrópica.

Answer (score 15):

Respostas longas, que exploram o problema e suas possíveis soluções são as respostas que eu mais gosto. Acho muito bacana quando uma simples dúvida gera uma aula sobre o tema. Aliás, respostas longas tendem a ser mais úteis para os demais membros da comunidade, pois costumam sanar dúvidas periféricas além da dúvida principal levantada pelo OP.

Comment: Acho que cabe um adendo aqui: uma resposta longa não de enchimento de linguiça, mas de conteúdo útil extenso.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, com certeza, Não pode dar uma de [gerador de lero lero](http://www.cafw.ufsm.br/~bruno/disciplinas/desenvolvimento_web/material/lerolero.html). hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Muitas vezes quem pergunta não tem a real noção da profundidade do assunto, lembrando também que um dos objetivos do SOpt é a perpetuidade das respostas, ou seja, ao responder uma pergunta, esta se falando **diretamente** com o perguntador e **indiretamente** com alguém no futuro, portanto respostas longas completas e com conteúdo, ao meu ver, são extremamente bem-vindas, por diversas vezes me peguei "passeando" entre perguntas e respostas pelo simples interesse em saber mais sobre determinado assunto.

Comment: Achei bem legal a sua visão pensando em buscas futuras para as questões. Realmente, quando uma pergunta simples é respondida com algo mais completo, para uma futura consulta aumenta muito as possibilidades de exploração do assunto. Também acho legal quando é possível dar mais de uma resposta (na mesma resposta) à pergunta, assim como existem os comentários na página oficial do php.net onde as pessoas colocam formas diferentes de usar os comandos ali explicados e de dar atenção a mais detalhes além do que a página aborda.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin, verdade, muitas vezes a resposta "A" é a mais indicada que a "B" para solucionar o problema, porém não sendo a unica forma, existem perguntas com N respostas que agregam muito valor não somente a pergunta mas também ao entendimento geral, porém não recebem o voto de avaliação por não solucionar diretamente ou em alguns casos por não ter sido dada em um tempo menor. Por isso considero que todas as respostas (bem feitas), mesmo as que não são selecionadas, tem seu grau de importância.

Comment: Sim, e quando encontro respostas abrangentes, mesmo que não tenham sido escolhidas por quem fez a pergunta, considero dar um "up vote" pelo esforço que a pessoa teve ao expandir a resposta para mais além da resolução do problema. Acho isso muito válido para que, quem expandiu a resposta, perceba que seu esforço não foi em vão.

Answer (score 2):

*Perguntas simples == resposta simples?*

Não necessariamente

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383093), aparentemente é simples, mas minha resposta é um tanto longa. Pelo meu entendimento, o autor não sabia muito bem o que é o HTTP, logo, não adianta eu explicar pra que server o *status code* sem antes explicar como o protocolo funciona, o que são as requisições e respostas, etc. Então resumi tudo isso para, depois, explicar pra que serve o código, as divisões (*ranges*) e dei alguns exemplos

Basicamente, algumas perguntas são simples porém precisam de um entendimento previo de alguma outra coisa, ou seja, não adianta responder que maça é uma fruta se a pessoa não sabe o que é uma fruta

Há também casos em que a pergunta é sobre A e alguém pode responder sobre B e C também por ser muito relacionados, como [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501), onde é perguntado sobre API, biblioteca e framework e uma das respostas também contempla toolkits e SDKs

Outros exemplos:

- [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402)
- [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441)
- [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322)

Comment: Eu tinha até já visto e já tinha deixado o +1. Achei excelente que você trouxe antes os "pré-requisitos". É muito bom para pessoas que querem sair pulando passos, daí elas percebem que realmente deviam ter estudado *x* antes de *y*. Ensina também a pescar. Tem muito usuário que a gente percebe que anda pulando etapas.

Comment: Valeu, tem um bucado desses tipos de pergunta, as vezes o cara nem se liga. "Ensina também a pescar", acho que o corretor trocou "pensar" por "pescar", ou então me explica ai como pescar com HTTP, só mandar um GET para `http://mar.com/peixe`?

Comment: Desculpa, era uma referência [a um famoso ditado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1968/ensinar-a-pescar-ou-dar-o-peixe). Realmente me expressei mal.

Comment: Não se expresso mal não, eu que não conhecia, esse é novo pra mim, talvez podia ter deixado o link (pra ter certeza que, se a pessoa não conhece, vai entender)