# Devemos aceitar pedidos de melhoramento de código?

Tags: debate

A respeito desta pergunta aqui: [A classe Model padrão MVC no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20734/a-classe-model-padr%C3%A3o-mvc-no-php)

O perguntador apenas jogou o código e pediu dicas de como melhorá-lo, sem dar mais informações.

Devemos aceitar esse tipo de pergunta?

Comment: Sei que a pergunta pareceu um pouco (bastante) vaga, mas como sou novato nessas questões, não soube me expressar da melhor forma, podemos dizer que foi proposital para que os mais experientes dessem sugestões mais avançadas para me forçar à estudar.

Comment: Nesse caso especifico, acho que uma pergunta como essa poderia ser sinalizada como "principalmente baseada em opiniões" uma vez que cada programador tem suas preferencias e seu modo preferido de fazer as coisas, usamos padrões para facilitar o entendimento dos códigos mas mesmo assim vemos diferenças claras entre códigos de programadores diferentes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perguntas desse tipo podem ser muito boas e produtivas porque envolvem conceitos importantes sobre desenvolvimento de software, orientação a objetos e programação em geral.

Se bem feitas, elas caem na categoria *[Good Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)*, pois atraem respostas longas e com qualidade o bastante para acrescentar algo.

Além disso, os usuários votaram a favor de Code Review em "[Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)".

---

No entanto, falando especificamente sobre a [questão citada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20734/a-classe-model-padr%C3%A3o-mvc-no-php), ela não me parece muito bem trabalhada. O usuário criou uma grande limitação nas respostas ao pedir simplesmente uma avaliação do código dele, mas ao mesmo deixou o escopo muito amplo ao não contextualizar nada sobre o sistema onde o código será aplicado. Por isso creio que a pergunta não atraiu muita atenção.

Essa questão poderia (em minha opinião) ser melhorada se perguntasse sobre as melhores abordagens para se fazer uma classe base, afinal creio que (como eu) muitos desenvolvedores já gastaram bastante fosfato com isso.

Não vou fechar a questão porque não a considero fora de escopo nem com baixa qualidade, mas sugiro que se houver usuários que pensam diferente votem para fechá-la e dêem um feedback para o OP sobre o motivo pelo qual fizeram isso.