# Respostas de opinião

Tags: debate

no passado respondi uma pergunta no pt sobre organização de arquivos num projeto.

Como sabemos existem diversos padrões por aí e que devemos escolher bem quando formos utilizá-los, com base na nossa necessidade.

Na minha resposta, informei que com base na minha experiência, recomendava determinado padrão para determinado problema, ou seja em minha opinião. Que inclusive foi aceita. Mas mesmo assim, minha resposta foi editada, para que não parecesse mais uma opinião baseada em minha experiência.

Eu acho isso um perigo pois muitos, principalmente iniciantes, vêem respostas assim como "bala de prata" o que não é. Por isso acho interessante nestes casos, deixar explícito que é sim uma opinião e que pode ser discutido.

Enfim, o que acham a respeito?

Agradeço de antemão o tempo que dedicaram a discutir esse assunto que muito me interessa.

Comment: Tem uma forma de fechamento que serve justamente para estes casos. O certo é o fecharmos perguntas onde as respostas serão principalmente baseadas em opiniões.

Comment: Aproveitando, extremamente relacionada: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/64969; o foco é em pergunta, principalmente que "_Opinião não é de todo ruim [...] Use suas experiências específicas para confirmar suas opiniões_". Então creio que seria sim, muito importante, ressaltar que a resposta é baseada na sua experiência e seria interessante falar experiências negativas com outras alternativas

Comment: Achei aqui o evento que motivou sua postagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/157309. Eu discordo da edição que foi feita. Se desejar, podemos desfazer. Ou então reincluir as partes que explicam da experiência em projetos anteriores

Comment: Podemos votar. Eu acho interessante justificar, como foi dito, os motivos pelos quais disse tudo aquilo. Se acham que é para o bem voltar, eu concordo.

Comment: Não acho interessante votar, acho que tem que analisar caso a caso, não é sempre que opinião vai ser ruim e vice-versa. Votar não vai colocar um parâmetro para coisas que podem ser muito variantes, não tem solução "global". O melhor é você postar a resposta e os detalhes antes da edição para analisarmos o caso especifico.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado de fato, desde o começo do site, em cada época surge uma meia duzia que sai aprovando sem muita análise, esse é um dos males da gamificação. No caso específico que você mencionou, não foi um edit, foi uma descaracterização. Fica a sugestão para o Diego de [reverter o edit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/283236/revisions) caso este não represente sua intenção plenamente. Quem tiver algo a acrescentar, pode usar o espaço de respostas para um post próprio.

Comment: Agradeço imensamente os comentários. Reverti a edição, como sugerido. Comecei há pouco a usar a plataforma com frequência e fico feliz em participar da comunidade e destes debates que nos fazem crescer e muito!

Comment: Peço perdão por não ter colocado a pergunta em questão neste questionamento. Este é a minha primeira pergunta aqui no Meta, e já percebi que as pessoas aqui estejam mais interessadas, e que talvez sejam mais experientes. Agradeço mais uma vezx

Answer (score 3):

Eu acredito que a edição em questão é essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/283236/revisions

A pergunta está no limiar entre ser baseada em opiniões, ou não. Entendo que você vê sua resposta como opinião também, porém você fez bem em listar as características de cada forma de organização presente no contexto. Isso ajuda outras pessoas a tomarem decisões baseadas em suas próprias necessidades.

A proposta do Stack Overflow é ser o repositório de conhecimento que primeiro vem à cabeça quando se tem um problema para se resolver, por isso opiniões costumam não ser bem vindas. Nós em geral evitamos discussões do tipo:

> **Pergunta:** um framework [expletivo] e o jQuery, os dois na mão de um estagiário, tu acha que o cara vai produzir igual com os dois?
>
> **Resposta:** claro que sim, [PHB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss). Estagiário é estagiário.
>
> **Comentário na resposta:** creio que não.

Mas nós valorizamos discussões assim:

> **Pergunta:** existe **vantagem técnica** em se utilizar o padrão A ao invés do padrão B **nesta situação**?
>
> **Resposta:** usar o padrão A vai te trazer esses benefícios e estas desvantagens, enquanto com o padrão B você tem isso e aquilo. Vai depender do seu contexto, que ainda pode ser influenciado por estes outros fatores: ...

Existem outros posts que abordam o mesmo tema, então podem ser relevantes para a discussão deste:

[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/1658)

[Como lidar com perguntas com certo grau de subjetividade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/482/1658)

Comment: De fato @Renan. Sempre que entramos em assuntos assim, é bom deixarmos claro o motivo TÉCNICO pelo qual nossa resposta foi construída. Obrigado pela sua resposta.