# O que fazer com respostas que são boas mas não respondem o que foi perguntado?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, perguntas

Em [Quais as principais vantagens e desvantagens de se usar um parser LL ou um LR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2044/quais-as-principais-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-se-usar-um-parser-ll-ou-um-lr) ocorreu esse problema.

Nenhuma crítica aos autores das respostas. Lembro sempre que estamos todos aprendendo. E temos vícios antigos também.

O Victor deu uma resposta muito interessante, correta, e útil para quem está procurando informações sobre *parsing*. Depois o mgibsonbr também deu uma resposta que foi muito útil para mim e será para outros, mas não foi no ponto principal da pergunta ou mal se aproximou dos demais. Um pouco culpa minha que fiz edições tentando melhorar e ver como uma pergunta difícil deve ser tratada (o SO prefere fechar logo perguntas que precisam ser trabalhadas para ficar boa) e foi piorando. Mas ainda assim, a pergunta principal (no título e no primeiro item listado [nessa edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2044/4)) deixava claro que era uma comparação entre esses dois algoritmos especificamente.

Eu perguntei sobre [Mike Tyson](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Tyson) Vs [Evander Hollyfield](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evander_Holyfield) e foi respondido em uma resposta sobre as vantagens de ter um [Maguila](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maguila) na luta, e na outra, (a grosso modo) como a luta deve ocorrer (a resposta pode ser bem útil para outra pergunta que resolvi trazer que pode apresentar outros problemas :) ).

O normal é negativar e avisar o autor da resposta. Mas a resposta foi útil, especialmente [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2044/quais-as-principais-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-se-usar-um-parser-ll-ou-um-lr/2106#2106). A outra é útil mas fala de outra coisa e **pode** até parecer que o autor está se fazendo propaganda do seu algoritmo preferido. Esse é um caso que o autor provavelmente poderia ter perguntado em comentário se poderia incluir um novo algoritmo na contenda.

Particularmente, quando a pessoa não quer introduzir controvérsia na resposta, há boa intenção, eu apenas ignoro a resposta ou no máximo deixo um comentário para fazer a pessoa entender que ela não respondeu a pergunta. Dá até dó se a pessoa remover a resposta, o que ela provavelmente vai querer, se tiver votos negativos.

Qual procedimento que devemos adotar como padrão? Isso servirá para orientar a comunidade e principalmente os moderadores.

---

A resposta do mgibsonbr suscitou uma outra questão que já foi parcialmente tratada em [O que fazer com perguntas no estilo "Como fazer X?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/sobre-esforco-em-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x). O que fazer com perguntas conceituais que não sabem bem onde quer chegar?

Isso é importante porque em alguns casos a resposta "inadequada" foi postada porque a pergunta não é clara. Se for um caso bem objetivo, que envolve um problema no código, é mais fácil ver que a resposta que não responde a pergunta. Em uma pergunta conceitual, envolve tanta coisa no conceito, e se a pergunta está sendo feita, é porque o autor não o entende bem. Devemos então ser mais condescendentes com respostas a conceitos que parecem evasivas mas que podem ajudar entender o problema todo?

Ou o problema está nas perguntas conceituais? Minha percepção que perguntas conceituais são mais abertas mesmo, está correta? E isso significa que devemos rever se [aceitamos perguntas conceituais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Primeira pergunta: a pergunta está "certa"?

Em geral, quando não há malícia envolvida, o objetivo da resposta é ajudar o autor. Se o autor da resposta acreditou que responder algo diferente do que foi perguntado é o que seria mais útil, então claramente há um problema na pergunta. Divido isso em 2 casos:

1. A pergunta sofre de fato do ["problema XY"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/como-lidar-com-o-problema-xy), e deveria ser editada para expor **o problema real** - o que o autor está tentando fazer e enfrenta dificuldades - e não qual foi sua tentativa de solução e que **também** está trazendo dificuldades (principalmente por **não ser a solução ideal** para o problema original).
2. A pergunta está correta, o **contexto** do autor exige que se busque uma solução para exatamente aquilo que foi perguntado, ainda que **em outras circustâncias** uma abordagem diferente seria melhor (ex.: o chefe exige que a tecnologia A seja usada, ainda que B seria a escolha ideal).

Em ambos os casos, creio que a ação correta a se tomar é **editar a pergunta** para que fique bem claro o que está sendo perguntado (i.e. levar o problema pra `X`, se for o caso 1, colocar mais contexto, se for o caso 2). Isso pode levar algumas respostas a ficarem descontextualizadas, mas creio que uma simples nota na resposta - explicando que ela se refere a uma revisão anterior da pergunta - seria o suficiente.

### Segunda pergunta: a resposta é útil?

Eu sei que, só porque alguém escreveu **algo** útil não significa que o melhor lugar para esse conteúdo é aqui [na rede StackExchange]. Mas lembro de ter lido, [repetidas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/) [vezes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51097/177950), que **não é bom apagar boas respostas**:

> if there’s anything of worth in the answers, the question should be merged with another question rather than being deleted!

A citação acima vem de uma discussão sobre perguntas duplicadas, mas creio que também se aplica aqui. Embora nesse caso, como a resposta se refere a algo diferente do que foi perguntado, fica a dúvida: "onde colocar essa resposta?"

Na minha opinião, se a resposta se encaixa bem em **pelo menos uma revisão** da pergunta sendo feita, então não há necessidade de movê-la. Um comentário ou nota no topo esclarecendo o fato pode ajudar a evitar que ela seja votada contrário/sinalizada como "não é uma resposta", e se a comunidade achar que a resposta tem valor (votando a favor, fazendo com que ela "suba" na ordem) então futuros visitantes ainda poderão se beneficiar dela.

### Terceira pergunta: o problema está nas questões conceituais?

Na minha opinião, **não**, o problema está na **falta de contexto**. Tomando a pergunta que iniciou essa discussão como exemplo, se fosse colocado que, no processo de análise de ferramentas e técnicas para se implementar um compilador, resolveu-se focar [por ora] nos métodos LL e LR, e precisa-se de ajuda para compreender as características X, Y e Z dos mesmos - então ela seria uma pergunta conceitual, focada e objetiva.

Eu reconheço que questões abertas demais são problemáticas, e deveriam ser evitadas. Ainda que uma pergunta do tipo "quero projetar um compilador, por onde começar?" seja um conhecimento "de nicho", e possa se beneficiar da experiência de outros que já passaram pelo mesmo problema, ela **não é uma boa pergunta para esse site**.

### Conclusão

Creio que não devemos tratar respostas que não respondem diretamente à pergunta "a ferro e fogo". Devemos antes nos perguntar se ela busca dar a malhor orientação possível ao autor, **dentro do contexto do que foi perguntado**. Se ela parecer aceitável, sugiro que deixemos ela no site, ou a submetamos ao "voto popular" (i.e. se for bem votada e não tiver reclamação, deixa, se for mal votada e sinalizada por muitos, apaga).

Comment: Ironicamente você não respondeu a pergunta :D Tudo bem, aqui é diferente e eu não quis perder a piada :) Vamos ver o que outros dizem. Mas concordo com tudo o que disse. E vou editar a pergunta de novo, tentando não deixar inválida pelo menos a pergunta que bateu quase no centro do alvo.

Comment: @bigown haha, boa! Mas pode deixar que eu vou elaborar mais na minha opinião, o ponto chave aqui é "eu sempre busco dar a melhor orientação possível pro autor". Se o autor de fato fez a pergunta errada, a ação correta seria editar a pergunta para que o problema **real** fosse colocado. Se a pergunta estava certa, então a ação correta seria **editar a pergunta** para colocar o **contexto** que ficou faltando para se determinar que - de fato - a pergunta estava certa... (agora, se a pergunta estava mesmo certa e não precisa de edição: flag como "não é uma resposta"...)

Comment: Estava procurando um texto que diz algo como "ninguém pode vencer um debate quando os debatedores usam perfeitamente as técnicas de debate". O texto é muito melhor que esse resumo e diz que você pode ganhar a percepção da maioria. Sempre existem argumentos que invalidam argumentos colocados. Então a conclusão que chego é que o SO fez certo e não permitir perguntas que geram dúvidas ou que envolvam questões conceituais. Mas aqui não é o SO. Se vamos aceitar perguntas conceituais, provavelmente teremos que aceitar perguntas um pouco mais abertas e respostas que não vão tão ao centro da pergunta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para englobar o problema apresentado. Sempre vai haver alguém que vai achar um problema em um pegunta que é inerentemente mais aberta. Me parece que cada edição que fizer vai agradar um lado ou ou outro, mas nunca ficará bom.

Comment: @bigown Editei a reposta para que ela de fato seja uma resposta... :P

Comment: Estou escrevendo uma resposta que está ficando bem parecida com a sua edição, rs! Porém, mais curta.

Comment: Excelente edição. Servirá de referência para ações que tomarmos na comunidade. Não discuto que se a resposta for bem aceita, ela deve ficar intocada. E mesmo que não seja, só por não estar tão adequada (sem outros problemas maiores) ela não deveria ser excluída, que a única ação a fazer além de votar e comentar nela. Quando você fala em "quero projetar um compilador, por onde começar?", ela é ruim por ser ampla e pedir primariam,ente por recursos externos?

Comment: @bigown "Quando você fala em 'quero projetar um compilador, por onde começar?', ela é ruim por ser ampla e pedir primariamente por recursos externos?" – sim, e também é pouco clara. Uma pergunta assim não nos dá subsídios para saber que tipo de resposta o usuário precisa (e uma resposta completa, que atenda a qualquer um, seria gigantesca e claramente fora do formato do site).

Comment: Agora que a resposta tem duas partes, e se você postar separadamente, como pergunta + resposta, o caso do XY, e linkar daqui pra lá?

Comment: @bigown Quando dei o exemplo do "quero projetar um compilador, por onde começar?" estava apenas **reafirmando** a regra que as perguntas não devem ter escopo amplo demais. Expressando concordância. Ou seja, sou a favor de perguntas conceituais **desde que** com escopo "tratável". (P.S. uma pergunta desse tipo não precisa necessariamente se tratar de "pedir recursos externos"; uma troca de experiências já poderia ser bem útil. Só não me parece adequada pra engine do SE - e portanto para esse site)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Entendi. Coloquei outra para dar mais "pano para a manga" :) Fui por outro caminho para ver se é uma abordagem melhor, apesar de parecer pior.

Comment: @bfavaretto Feito! Deixei a resposta aqui (pois ela se encaixa bem no que está discutido) e movi o caso do XY para outra pergunta - linkando de volta pra cá e salientando que parte da questão (o que fazer com as respostas) já foi bem debatida.

Answer (score 10):

É difícil ter uma regra objetiva como "sempre vote contra" ou "sempre vote para excluir", embora em muitas respostas essas sejam as atitudes corretas (talvez na maioria, como é o caso no SO).

Nesses casos eu costumo me perguntar o seguinte:

1. **A resposta é boa? É útil para alguém que esteja lendo a pergunta?**
   Se não for, é bem provável que eu vote contra, e/ou para excluir a resposta.
2. **A pergunta sofre do [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/como-lidar-com-o-problema-xy), e a resposta responde X?**
   Nesse caso a resposta fica, e muitas vezes vou votar a favor, se for muito boa. Posso ainda tentar editar a pergunta para explicitar X melhor – tomando cuidado para não destruir o contexto das demais respostas.
3. **A pergunta permite mais de uma resposta?**
   Aí minha atuação provavelmente será na pergunta, e não na resposta, mas depende do que vamos decidir fazer com o tipo de pergunta em questão (existe [mais de](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/482/como-lidar-com-perguntas-com-certo-grau-de-subjetividade) [um](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-podem-ter-multiplas-respostas)). Posso votar para fechar a pergunta, vou deixar a resposta em paz (ou votar a favor, dependendo da qualidade). Posso ainda editar a pergunta para deixá-la mais específica, tomando o mesmo cuidado que apontei no item 2.

#### Sobre [Quais as principais vantagens e desvantagens de se usar um parser LL ou um LR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2044/quais-as-principais-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-se-usar-um-parser-ll-ou-um-lr)

Apesar dos problemas da pergunta (principalmente em sua primeira revisão), eu não acho que ela deva ser fechada, nem que as duas respostas que não foram direto ao alvo mereçam qualquer tipo de represália. Discutir isto aqui estaria fora do que foi perguntado, mas eu acho que precisamos encontrar maneiras de manter no site conteúdos que sejam de qualidade, mas que às vezes fogem às regras estabelecidas.

#### Um exemplo mais simples

**[Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518/como-obter-o-multiplo-de-algum-valor-em-php/2104#2104) a [Como obter o múltiplo de algum valor em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518)**

Tem 3 votos contra, mas seria a (ou uma?) resposta correta a uma pergunta claramente XY. O problema é que a resposta não dá nenhuma explicação, apenas dá a solução em código.

Vou procurar localizar outros exemplos, já vi vários mas não estou achando agora.

Comment: Concordo 100%. Mas você acha que o último exemplo é XY? Não votei down lá, só costumo fazer quando vejo má intenção ou completamente fora das regras. Mas achei completamente fora do que foi perguntado. Minha posição pessoal, que quero oficializar, é de deixar pra lá, "não fede, nem cheira", então não faço algo positivo ou negativo.

Comment: Acho que é XY porque a pergunta começa com "preciso fazer uma busca no bd"; é bem simples já trazer via sql os resultados classificados como ele quer, mas ele pede em php sem explicar motivos para isso (uma possibilidade seria performance).

Comment: A do multiplo do PHP só é correta se você tomar o exemplo como problema (são coisas diferentes). Eu por exemplo votei contra por não ser uma solução verdadeira (vide meu comentário na própria resposta), e ser colocada como tal.

Comment: Seu comentário lá foi ótimo. E é verdade, `CASE WHEN...` não é uma boa solução, mas a conta pode ser feita em SQL. Escolhi um exemplo ruim. @Bacco