# O que é o "problema XY"?

Tags: debate, perguntas, proposta-para-faq

O que é o problema XY?

Quando eu fizer uma pergunta, como posso reconhecer que estou cometendo esse problema? Como evitá-lo?

Comment: Good discussion to raise here, but you might wish to pick an example that's less problematic in other respects.

Comment: @Shog9 I may do. I'm a bit tired now, this discussion has been going since yesterday... But as soon as I spot a better example (little hard to find by now, the site's still young - this was the first of this kind that I saw) I'll replace this. Otherwise, I'll make one up, or copy and translate the original on MSO.

Comment: @Shog9 jumping in the hell :) Welcome!

Comment: Why is everyone speaking in English? o.O

Answer (score 85):

Vou contar uma historinha que demonstra o que é o problema XY:

> Alonso é uma pessoa que gosta muito de água de coco. Ele estava triste, pois embora ele tivesse muitos cocos a sua disposição, ele tinha dificuldade para encontrar água de coco por não conseguir abrir os cocos.
>
> Em um belo dia, Alonso estava vendo um filme de ação na TV com muitas explosões e também jogando bastante Angry Birds e então teve uma ideia **brilhante**, **fantástica** e **sensacional**, algo verdadeiramente **genial**: Se ele usasse um tanque de guerra para explodir os cocos, poderia quebrá-los e então obter a água de dentro deles!
>
> Alonso, muito criativo que é, imediatamente começou a bolar uma máquina para extrair água do coco. Fez vários experimentos e testes e no final montou um dispositivo que consistia de uma mesa feita de uma liga de aço super-resistente de titânio e tungstênio com um buraco no meio e um buraco no chão abaixo. Esse buraco na mesa era coberto por uma peneira. Há alguns metros de lá, havia um tanque de guerra posicionado que atirava o projétil precisamente em cima do coco. Tudo isso era realizado dentro de uma sala fechada (e com as paredes pretas recobertas de fuligem) para que o vento e a chuva não desviassem o projétil de sua trajetória.
>
> Quando o tanque disparava, o coco era então explodido em milhões de pedacinhos que voavam para todos os lados. A maior parte da água de coco era vaporizada na explosão, mas uma pequena parte dela acabava passando pela peneira e caia no buraco no chão (Alonso havia tentado com um balde antes, mas a explosão sempre destruía o balde). Pedaços de pó carbonizado e de fuligem do coco, da peneira e do projétil também caiam dentro do buraco no chão, mas ele já havia aceitado a ideia de se habituar a beber água de coco com essas impurezas.
>
> Alonso estava ficando satisfeito com a sua máquina, mas ela ainda tinha um problema: A peneira era destruída a cada disparo realizado. Substituir a peneira manualmente era algo muito trabalhoso, pois eram precisos centenas de disparos para se conseguir um litro de água de coco (a maior parte dela vaporizava nas explosões) e para cada um deles, ele tinha que substituir a peneira manualmente, o que demandava muito tempo. Colocar o coco em cima da peneira, um por um, também demandava tempo.
>
> Alonso já havia conseguido automatizar o tanque de guerra para realizar um disparo a cada 30 segundos, só faltava o problema de posicionar o coco e a peneira automaticamente após cada disparo. Um conjunto de esteiras deveria dar conta, mas ele não sabia como projetar isso. Dessa forma, ele decidiu elaborar a seguinte pergunta para pedir ajuda:
>
> > **Como posso fazer um conjunto de esteiras com blindagem anti-tanque, capazes de transportar automaticamente peneiras e cocos até um buraco em cima de uma mesa?**
>
> Essa é uma pergunta realmente singular, mas provavelmente Alonso receberia respostas bem diferentes se fizesse essa outra pergunta:
>
> > **Tenho alguns cocos, mas não consigo tirar a água que está dentro deles. Como faço para abri-los e então coletar a água de coco?**

Comment: Usaram criatividade nessa. +1

Comment: Depois dessa resposta, eu acho que nunca mais mencionei ao AP outra coisa a não ser "abrir/quebrar cocos com tanque/canhão"

Comment: hahahahaha adorei a metáfora, vou usar sempre agora, obrigado Victor! rs

Comment: O abridor de cocos dessa história foi patenteado pela Companhia ACME.

Comment: O único porém é que quando alguém pergunta "Tenho alguns cocos, mas não consigo tirar a água que está dentro deles. Como faço para abri-los e então coletar a água de coco?" geralmente a pergunta é fechada por ser muito ampla e/ou baseada em opiniões.

Comment: @KaduAmaral acho que tem razão. Seria fechada em minutos. Muito ampla a questão: devia perguntar por um único coco. E faltam detalhes: seria um coco verde ou daqueles marrons com a casca mais dura? E foram comprados com nota fiscal ou encontrados no chão na praia?  Qual a origiem precisa do material?

Answer (score 50):

O **problema XY**, [tal como definido no MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), é o seguinte:

> O problema XY consiste em perguntar sobre sua tentativa de solução em vez do seu problema real.
>
> Ou seja, você está tentando resolver o problema `X`, e você acredita que a solução `Y` vai funcionar, mas em vez de perguntar sobre `X` quando você encontra dificuldades, você pergunta sobre `Y`.

## Um exemplo

Suponha a seguinte conversa num chat:

> <Q> Existe uma função para retornar uma string entre dois delimitadores?
>
> <B> não entendi o que você quis dizer, mas duvido que exista uma função assim
>
> <C> split e slice
>
> <D> partition também
>
> <Q> Ja tentei partition
>
> <Q> Estava tentando pegar o número no meio de uma string como essa: "atributo1: 50.223, atributo2: 442.1"
>
> <D> por que não escrever um método de parse no formato da string?
>
> <Q> eu imaginei que devia existir algo pronto pra isso
>
> <D> pares = [x.strip() for x in s.split(",")]; atribs = {k: v for x in pares for k, v in x.split(": ")}
>
> <D> existem algumas bibliotecas, mas formatos simples são fáceis de fazer à mão -- se você não liga pra tratamento de erros
>
> <D> mudar o programa para usar um formato mais conhecido, como json ou yaml, é preferível quando possível
>
> <Q> Esse código na verdade vem do HTML
>
> <Q> mas eu não sei como interpretar Javascript com um HTMLParser ou seja lá como se chame
>
> <D> ele está só embutido no html, ou em uma versão avacalhada do html?
>
> <Q> Está embutido no HTML
>
> <D> se isso é javascript (e é, exceto pela falta das chaves), json provavelmente pode interpretar
>
> <Q> valeu
>
> <D> Só deixando claro: json só interpreta estruturas de dados, não código js
>
> <Q> Tudo o que eu preciso interpretar é uma estrutura de dados

O problema é na verdade sobre como interpretar estruturas de dados em JavaScript, não encontrar "uma string entre dois delimitadores", mas mesmo assim leva um bocado de tempo e esforço pra chegar no problema real.

Isso é mais fácil de resolver em um chat totalmente interativo (independentemente do tipo), mas em um site da SE, onde você detalha uma postagem um pouco, publica ela, e depois tem que esperar 5-30 minutos ou mais antes de conseguir *feedback*, realmente ajuda já começar na direção certa.

## Por que isso é um problema

Essa situação pode levar à frustração de quem está tentando te ajudar, porque na hora que você pergunta a solução que você **precisa** pode não ter nenhuma conexão óbvia com o problema que você **está tentando resolver**.

## Como evitar

Aos perguntadores, para evitar cair nessa armadilha sempre inclua informação sobre o contexto mais amplo além de qualquer tentativa de solução. Se alguém pedir por mais informações, em especial uma pergunta mais específica, dê os detalhes relevantes. Se existem soluções que você acredita que serão sugeridas mas que você já descartou, não evite falar nelas - em vez disso explique por que você acha que elas não se aplicam a seu caso, uma vez que isso dá mais informação sobre seus requisitos e ajuda os demais a fornecerem melhores respostas.

Answer (score 32):

Tradução da [resposta original em inglês](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/176034), que considero mais simples e mais fácil de entender que a outra resposta que já temos e que é mais votada do MSO:

> O problema X-Y, como ele é chamado às vezes, é um bloqueio mental que causa uma enorme quantidade de desperdício de tempo e energia, tanto da parte da pessoa que está procurando ajuda quanto da parte das pessoas que estão tentando ajudar. Isso frequentemente ocorre da seguinte forma:
>
> - O usuário quer fazer X.
> - O usuário não sabe como fazer X, mas acha que pode dar um jeito de resolver o problema se ele conseguir fazer Y.
> - O usuário também não sabe como fazer Y.
> - O usuário pede ajuda sobre Y.
> - Outros usuários tentam ajudar acerca de Y, mas ficam confusos porque Y parece ser um problema estranho para se querer resolver.
>   Depois de muita interação e tempo perdido, finalmente fica claro que o usuário realmente quer ajuda com X, e que Y nem mesmo serveria como uma possível solução para X.
>
> O problema acontece quando pessoas têm as suas linhas de pensamento presas em uma determinada abordagem e não pensam em dar algum passo para trás nela. Ficando abertos para dar mais uma olhada no contexto geral, estas pessoas poderiam retornar ao problema X e continuar a busca por soluções alternativas.

Comment: Minha resposta também é uma tradução de uma do MSE, mas parece que a original foi bem aprimorada desde então - tornando ela melhor do que a tradução que temos aqui (mas não necessariamente melhor do que a que você traduziu). Desmarquei a minha como aceita, vamos deixar o pessoal votar.

Comment: Eu gostei como complemento, mas não "aceitaria" pq essa resposta não indica como resolver o problema. Acho que ambas podem sofrer um "upgrade", visto que é um assunto extremamente importante.