# "votar contra" e "votar negativamente"

Tags: debate, perguntas, voto-contra, votos

Gostaria de dar uma opinião sobre a questão de **"votar contra"** ou **"votar negativamente"**. É uma questão bem pessoal, sei que cada um vai pensar de sua maneira mas:

> **O que significa votar contra?**
>   Votar contra, também chamado de "votar negativamente", é como a comunidade indica quais perguntas e respostas são as menos úteis.

O problema é que pessoas acham que a pergunta e menos útil, só por causa que já sabem ou não tem interesse na pergunta.

Acho que não poderia existir isso de votar contra não, principalmente para as pessoas que são novas na comunidade StackOverflow.

Muitas vezes, a gente faz uma pergunta que pode parecer simples demais para alguns, principalmente os veteranos e alguns dos mais experientes votam contra a pergunta da pessoa muitas as vezes por que já sabem do assunto e por achar a pergunta simples demais para eles.

Comment: Pra mim não é nem questão de "simplicidade" da dúvida, e sim, o quanto de esforço o autor teve, desde a elaborar a questão até a pesquisar razoavelmente sobre a dúvida. Não estou dizendo que a pessoa deveria ir procurar no google e não aqui, mas tem muitas duvidas que já tem até respostas no site. A questão do esforço em elaborar a questão pesa principalmente no autor ter ao menos procurado elaborar um texto entendível dentro do idioma do site, porque além de ter que entender o problema, ter que interpretar um texto mal redigido ninguem merece.

Comment: e verdade , mais acredito que se a pessoa ver uma pergunta que já tenha resporta no site, acho que não custa nada  a pessoa postar o link da pergunta

Comment: Sim, não é para todos os casos, foi um exemplo superficial, mas pense nas perguntas onde pedem código pronto, por exemplo, estas você não acha que merecem ser avaliadas negativamente?

Comment: @Articuno talvez ! mais acho que deveriam  ter mais consciência .
já que já existe a avaliação positiva acredito que não seria necessário votar negativamente não!

Comment: Bom, respeito sua opinião, mas continuo no pensamento que o recurso existe para ser usado. O que deve ser mediado é como cada um usa, mas isso também vai de opinião.

Comment: e lamentavel isso. muitas as vezes as pessoas entende ate a  pergunta que foi feita . e ainda vota contra só por causa de um simples texto digitado errado

Comment: Não distorça o que eu disse. em momento algum do meu comentário eu disse que voto negativo deve ser usado para erro de digitação, por favor, releia meus comentários e tente interpretar melhor o que eu disse a respeito.

Comment: O mais interessante é ver a maturidade de alguns usuários deste site. A gente tenta expressar nossa opinião numa discussão sadia numa questão como essa com o autor mas tem gente que age como criança birrenta e sai procurando postagem antiga da gente e negativa, vocês tão de parabéns pelo alto nivel de maturidade.

Comment: nao sei  do que voçe ta falando ! mais obrigado pela opinião valew mesmo

Comment: Danilo, foi um desabafo, não foi direcionado a você, tanto que abri debate contigo sobre o tema. Mas infelizmente o site tem usuários que não sabem participar, e agem exatamente como você falou e eu até discordei.

Comment: @Articuno  ta certo ! eu gostei das  suas opinião  e gostei da sua participação  aqui

Comment: Olá, Danilo. Sinto muito que sua experiência no Stack Overflow em português não tenha sido positiva. Você pode abrir uma reclamação para que o SO lhe devolva o valor da sua assinatura.

Comment: Quanto a esse ponto específico: `Acho que não poderia existir isso de votar contra não, principalmente para as pessoas que são novas na comunidade stackoverflow.` - acho que no Quora não existem votos negativos. De qualquer forma, fica aqui uma oportunidade de negócio: você pode criar o seu próprio site de perguntas e respostas sobre programação, com pontuação semelhante ao Facebook - ou seja, sem a possibilidade de votos negativos. Talvez você faça sucesso com isso ;)

Comment: @Danilorodrigues sendo rude assim você cria todo um contexto de inimizade ao seu redor. Seja respeitoso

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ta ! desculpa ai  a todos .e por que eu percebi que tem gente que não quer ajudar e so quer criticar . em vez de ajudar ou tentar ajudar  fica falando coisas inúteis e ate mesmo votando negativamente sem motivo nenhum

Comment: @Danilorodrigues no caso do Renan, como eu tenho experiência com ele (ele é um dos que eu acho mais experientes no site), tenho certeza que o tom jocoso dele não foi uma crítica barata sem maiores intenções. Um dos principais valores do site é **presuma boa intenção**. A crítica que ele fez foi para que você pudesse perceber que o seu comportamento precisa ser revisto. Releia o texto dele outra hora, sem emoção, e perceba o quão genial ele foi. Nem uma vírgula do que ele pôs foi à toa, foi tudo direcionado a explicar qual a expectativa da comunidade e contrapor à sua.

Comment: Obrigado @JeffersonQuesado. É isso mesmo. Depois de refletir um pouco vi que existem já outras perguntas questionando o uso de votos negativos. Acho que o conteúdo já existente é mais direto do que eu consigo ser nos comentários.

Comment: A propósito, o Renan não precisa que ninguém o defenda. Minha intenção não foi defender ele. Foi apenas mostrar o que era o texto, quais as intenções e tentar guiar a interpretação para o que se propõe.

Comment: @Renan concordo com a pergunta candidata à duplicata. Acho que não a conhecia, por via das dúvidas vou imergir nela. Muito obrigado pela dica \o/

Comment: Tente reler a sua [pergunta que teve -4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282899/qual-o-link-devo-usar-no-meu-artigo-da-pagina-de-eventos-para-ela-abrir-e-carre) no seu estado inicial (antes das edições). Repare como ela é muito vaga e impossível de responder sem o html e css. Isso fará com que possíveis usuários rapidamente negativem pois não está clara. Eu diria que mesmo no seu estado final não está clara. O texto está confuso e não tem o CSS que controla o posicionamento dos elementos. Não leve esta analise da forma errada, estou a tentar ser o mais imparcial possível.

Comment: @Isac coçe esta falando de qual pergunta ?

Comment: O meu comentário acima tem um link para a pergunta a que me estava a referir

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essa é uma daquelas perguntas que podem gerar polêmica por isso tentarei ser o mais objetivo possível em minha resposta.

Primeiro eu gostaria de dizer que a frase abaixo não é uma verdade absoluta:

> Muitas vezes agente faz uma pergunta que pode parecer simples demais
>   para alguns, principalmente os veteranos e alguns dos mais experientes
>   votam contra a pergunta da pessoa muitas as vezes por que já sabem do
>   assunto e por achar a pergunta simples demais para eles.

Claro que é possível que ocorram votos insensatos mas garanto que não é a maioria, até dúvido que alguém tenha esse comportamento, ao menos não foi isso que aprendi fazendo parte desta comunidade:

> [Quando devo votar contra?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
>
> Use os votos contra quando encontrar uma publicação destacadamente
>   negligente e malfeita ou uma resposta que esteja claramente, e talvez
>   perigosamente, incorreta.

Eu sou membro do *SO-PT* a mais ou menos 7 meses e falo por mim no começo fiz umas perguntas e respostas bem ruins <s>até hoje faço rsrs</s>.

Os usuários novos principamente tem que ter em mente que ao entrar em uma comunidade é preciso entender como ela funciona. Saber como elaborar as perguntas, saber lidar com opiniões adversas e **críticas construtivas** faz parte de aprender. Tudo bem se a pergunta ou resposta não for muito boa, contando que o autor busque entender o porque e melhorar os **down votes** passaram despercebidos e poderão até virar **up votes**.

Muitas vezes ocorrem perguntas **sem vergonha** como, por exemplo, lições de casa que o autor nem tentou resolver. Precisamos entender que aqui é compartilhado um **conhecimento rico** em que muitos penaram para adquirir.

**Conclusão:**

O **down vote** é uma ferramenta importante que ajuda a limpar a comunidade e manter um conteúdo de qualidade.

Comment: legal ! mais acho que tem perguntas bem votadas ai que nem tem esses conteúdos de qualidade todo!

Comment: tem gente que ate entende certas perguntas,  e votam contra por  um simples erro de português,uma simples coisa que a pessoa pode fazer uma edição e resolver

Comment: Também não sei se isso é verdade pois muita gente tira conclusões precipitadas sobre o porque tomou um downvote, diria até que alguns tem dificuldade em aceitar. Mas por favor se você ver um caso onde onde o downvote foi usado de forma abusiva compartilhe com a comunidade, nós temos moderadores que reprovam fortemente esse tipo de comportamento.

Answer (score 14):

Uma coisa é voto contra em pergunta e outra é voto contra em resposta.

Tão logo você atinja a quantidade de pontos de reputação necessários para votar, você é praticamente livre para votar contra ou a favor daquilo que quiser como bem entender. Entretanto, há de se fazer duas ressalvas:

1. Tentativas de manipulação de votos ou votações em série são observadas e monitoradas pelo sistema e pelos moderadores. Não tente fazer isso.
2. Espera-se que você vote de forma justa. Não dê voto a favor de porcaria. Não dê voto contra perguntas e respostas de boa qualidade. O não-voto também é uma opção válida.

Como os usuários podem votar contra ou a favor anonimamente de acordo com os critérios que melhor lhe convierem, isso significa que nem sempre votarão de forma justa e pouco pode ser feito para combater votos dados de forma injusta além de conscientização.

Entendo que receber voto negativo em perguntas é frustrante. Eu pessoalmente dou votos negativos apenas em casos muito graves, que felizmente são poucos, mas muitos usuários por aqui clicam no negativo com mais facilidade.

Não vou entrar muito nos motivos mais comuns para receber votos negativos em perguntas, pois já criei [uma pergunta aqui no meta dedicada exclusivamente a isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132). Há outras coisas que poderiam ser acrescentadas lá, mas pelo menos uns 90% dos casos são os que lá estão.

Digo que algo entre um terço a dois terços das perguntas postadas aqui têm problemas sérios que as tornam difíceis de serem respondidas adequadamente e qualquer tentativa de resposta é vã. Eu não costumo votar negativo nelas se não houver algo muito forte para tal, mas costumo dar votos de fechamento. Entretanto muitos outros usuários pensam diferente de mim e dão bastante votos negativos.

A maior parte dessas perguntas com problemas acaba sendo deletada cedo ou tarde, o que é bom porque na maioria das vezes, elas nada mais são que lixo poluindo a comunidade. Entretanto, existe um lado negativo nisso:

- Afasta, magoa e traumatiza diversos usuários novos.
- Cria uma ilusão que essa comunidade tem muito menos problemas do que de fato tem ou já teve.
- Faz com que esses usuários (talvez seja o seu caso) que tem suas perguntas votadas negativamente e fechadas se sintam perseguidos pois veem isso acontecendo com poucos dos demais usuários.

O que ocorre é que o voto negativo serve para sinalizar perguntas e respostas com problemas. Quem vota negativamente (seja em pergunta ou resposta) é incentivado e convidado a deixar algum comentário explicando o que há de errado e justificando o voto, mas nem todos os usuários o fazem por diversos motivos:

- Não têm ânimo/vontade/tempo/estômago suficiente para argumentar.
- Acha que argumentar seria uma perda de tempo.
- Acha que argumentar pode ser desnecessário pois outros já fizeram ou farão isso.

Não sei qual é o seu caso específico, mas já vi por aqui inúmeros casos onde tentar argumentar e explicar com o autor da pergunta era algo em vão. Infelizmente, isso acaba deixando muitos usuários experientes menos propensos a explicar os seus votos negativos.

É verdade que existe sim gente que vota injustamente, tanto positivo quanto negativo. Entretanto, na maioria dos casos os votos são justos. E mesmo quando as pessoas votam de forma que acreditam sinceramente que são justas, ainda assim existem distorções no sistema:

- O problema do bicicletário e da usina nuclear, onde perguntas sobre temas mais simples que quase todos entendem (o bicicletário) atraem mais atenção e mais votos do que aqueles sobre temas complexos que poucos entendem (a usina nuclear).
- O problema da resposta mais rápida do oeste, onde a primeira resposta postada não apenas tende a atrair mais atenção e mais votos que as demais, mas também tende a retirar atenção e votos das respostas subsequentes.

Para você que é um usuário novo por aqui e pelo visto já apanhou um pouco, deixo algumas recomendações:

- Você não é o primeiro e nem será o último, isso acontece por aqui todo dia.
- Mesmo ótimos usuários que temos hoje já passaram por esse problema.
- Leia as demais perguntas e respostas do site para ter uma ideia de como você deveria ou não postar perguntas e respostas.
- Tente responder perguntas também. Ao tentar fazer isso, você esbarrará em certas dificuldades oriundas de problemas nas perguntas que você não percebia antes. Com isso, aprenderá a evitar esses problemas em suas perguntas também.
- Lembre-se que isso daqui não é um fórum como os demais na internet. Nos fóruns, a maioria dos tópicos acaba assumindo o formato de uma conversação entre múltiplos participantes com postagens ordenadas cronologicamente. Nos tópicos dos fóruns, algumas postagens tem o propósito de responder ao que foi perguntado, mas outras buscam debater, questionar ou esclarecer pontos de outras postagens e por vezes há conversas paralelas. **O formato do StackOverflow é diferente.** O nosso formato é pergunta e resposta, sendo as respostas independentes umas das outras e ordenadas por votos ao invés de cronologicamente. Respostas que não tentem responder à pergunta são rapidamente apagadas. Esclarecimentos, debates e críticas ficam apenas em comentários nas perguntas e respostas.
- Leia [tudo que está aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132) e também [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). Há diversos outros materiais no meta com boas orientações de como esse site funciona.
- Quando for postar uma pergunta, pense como um advogado: "*Que tipo de coisas um suposto adversário poderia querer atacar na pergunta para que ela não fosse respondida?*" Pense também como alguém que fosse responder e que não conhece o seu sistema: "*Que informações importantes deveriam estar por lá para servir de embasamento para quem se dispor a responder?*" Edite e reelabore a pergunta quantas vezes forem necessárias antes de postar até chegar no ponto onde você não veja nada nela que possa razoavelmente ser questionado.