# Usuários novatos e votos negativos: o que fazer?

Tags: debate, voto-contra, novos-usuários

Olá, sou novo no SOpt e estou me adaptando ao funcionamento aos poucos, espero que essa pergunta seja de alguma forma construtiva.

Perguntas de usuários novatos no SOpt são constantes, e infelizmente a maioria vem sem nenhuma pesquisa, ou leitura dos artigos de ajuda e afins, o que acaba resultando em uma pergunta mal-formatada, mal-escrita (ortografia, gramática...) tornando praticamente inviável ajudar.

O que acaba resultando em uma grande quantidade de *downvotes*, o que muitas vezes acaba de certa forma afastando esses usuários (alguns é justificável, pois querem apenas um *helpdesk*, mas outros realmente poderiam vir a ser uma boa contribuição).

Meu questionamento é: Como agir nesse tipo de situação? Sempre tento ajudar a melhorar a formatação, pergunto mais detalhes, e tento tornar a questão mais clara para que outros possam ajudar (até porque posso ajudar apenas em assuntos que possuo um pouco de conhecimento).

Na posição de usuários mais experientes, quando a pergunta ainda é recuperável ou o usuário apenas "jogou" a questão e foi embora? E última pergunta, em que casos realmente existe a necessidade do *downvote* para uma pergunta de um novato?

*obs: Li as perguntas similares, mas não encontrei uma com exatamente esses questionamentos.*

Comment: Pessoalmente sou contra downvotes, dificilmente alguma pergunta realmente é uma inutilidade total que ninguém nunca vai buscar, além do fato de utilidade ser bastante opinativa, o que é útil pra um não necessariamente é útil para outro, fora isso o jeito é tentar melhorar no que dá e tentar explicar um pouco o funcionamento do site

Comment: Como já comentei em várias outras situações: uma melhoria que eu faria pra novatos é dizer "Não se assuste, voto negativo é parte do site" e em seguida apontaria para uma leitura de como evitar, e toda a infinidade de documentos explicando como usar melhor o site. (da mesma forma nos fechamentos etc). Se mesmo assim o cara se ofende, eu até acho vantagem que ele não participe mais enquanto não estiver preparado pra assumir os problemas do próprio post (afinal, isso não impede o usuário de continuar consultando o site, aposto que a maioria que "diz que não volta mais" continua fazendo).

Comment: Caro @GuilhermeCostamilam discordo com todo respeito, quem já tem tempo no site sabe que muitas coisas na teoria são otimas, mas na pratica são desastrosas, imagine para cada 100 usuários novos por dia vc ter que explicar coisas óbvias que estão no tour e no help, quer assumir a responsabilidade, otimo, é uma escolha sua, mas garanto que isso não trará beneficio algum, claro que temos que ser receptivos, mas downvote não é um "caia fora", é uma maneira de apontar "sua postagem tem problemas", isso você pode explicar, como o Bacco disse, se a pessoa se acostumar desde cedo melhor e ...

Comment: ...pessoalmente acredito que você talvez tenha tido uma experiencia ruim com isso e por isso tenha a impressão totalmente errada, acredito com o tempo você vai entender e notar que nem tudo que parece bonito "no papel" vai ser funcional na pratica, ainda mais quando uma coisa se repete inumeras vezes, acho que o correto é as pessoas chegarem aqui e aprenderem a receber criticas construtivas e se esforçarem para serem ajudadas, assim como outros se esforçam para ajudar, ambos lados tem que colaborar, e ser contra o downvote é promover uma ideia errada da ferramenta...

Comment: ... Se fosse do mal mesmo nem existiria tal funcionalidade, espero que não leve nada a mal e assim construiremos uma comunidade saudável.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não estou dizendo que deveria ser retirado a parte de downvote e fechamentos, mas penso em algumas outras possibilidades (apenas imagino, nem cheguei a analisar muito), ao meu ver fechamentos como duplicata entre alguns outros deveriam causar perda de reputação e alguns tipos de perguntas deveriam ser fechadas, perder reputação e ser escondidas (assim como o robo faz) imediatamente quando algum membro de reputação alta ver (tipo perguntas pedindo pra responder pesquisa, essas que são muito fora do escopo), como disse apenas alguns momentos de imaginação sem muitas analises

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam as perguntas tem que se "mover" independente de quem atua e do score que a pessoa tem, inclusive tem alguns de score alto na comunidade que são usuários que realmente nem chegam aos pés de alguns com score bem mais baixo.  Fora que entendo suas sugestões, mas reforço dizendo, tem que ter mais experiencia para entender que a coisa é mais embaixo e dificilmente possiveis "soluções" assim resolveriam de verdade o problema. Com o tempo de atuação no site você vai começar a sentir melhor o porque e como ocorrem certas situações comuns ;)

Comment: Uma coisa que tenho notado muito em usuários novatos (impressão minha, posso estar errado em alguns casos, ou na maioria, e diria até nem tanto novatos) é a tal da preguiça. Me parece que o usuário tem preguiça de formular uma pergunta boa, selecionar o código relevante e colocar na pergunta, digitar um texto explicativo, apontar os locais no código etc. Eles simplesmente criam um título genérico, um texto curto e difícil de entender (não que textos longos signifiquem alguma coisa) e postam uma infinidade de código onde quem se interessar em analisar terá que decifrar. Isso que acho ruim tb.

Comment: Enfim, montar uma boa pergunta. Parece que o "montar" é que faz o usuário ter preguiça. É muito mais fácil usar CTRL+C e CTRL+V de qualquer jeito, colocar um textinho mais ou menos e pronto, e aguardar a resposta. Eu sou do tipo que seguro o dedo pra dar downvote, mas quando me deparo com algo assim o downvote é inevitável, mesmo o cara sendo novato.

Comment: Isso já foi comentado em outra pergunta, no SO ao fazer uma pergunta, tem agora um formata passo-a-passo que ajuda a identificar se a pergunta pertence ao site e coisas básicas. Acredito que algo assim por aqui, com umas perguntas do tipo "já pesquisou no site e no google?", "já leu o tour?", se detectar falta de código na pergunta "não tem um código para compartilhar?", coisas simples que minimizariam isso, e só desapareceria depois do usuário te uma certa reputação, um número de perguntas, etc

Comment: Por incrível que pareça tem FanBoy até de linguagem de programação, é lamentável!

Answer (score 16):

Parte do que você fala, eu abordo [nesta outra minha resposta de uns meses atrás](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6889/132). Não vou repetir tudo o que está lá aqui porque não é necessário e basta seguir o link. Assim sendo, vou focar na parte da sua pergunta que essa minha outra resposta não responde:

> Meu questionamento é: como agir nesse tipo de situação? Sempre tento ajudar a melhorar a formatação, pergunto mais detalhes, e tento tornar a questão mais clara para que outros possam ajudar (até porque posso ajudar apenas em assuntos que possuo um pouco de conhecimento).
>
> Na posição de usuários mais experientes, quando a pergunta ainda é recuperável ou o usuário apenas "jogou" a questão e foi embora?

Primeiro, que corrigir erros de formatação, ortografia, acentuação é ótimo. Isso é muito bom. Tanto que se você fizer isso, em pouco tempo vai ganhar a medalha [image: Strunk & White], das 80 edições. O nome dessa medalha é horroroso, mas quem consegue tê-la provavelmente é um bom usuário na comunidade. Se for bastante dedicado, consegue a [image: Copidesque], de 500 edições (e que também tem um nome horrível).

Se você não apenas corrigir as perguntas por edição, mas também respondê-la e a sua resposta tiver pelo menos uma pontuação de +1 (afinal, responder porcaria não vale) e no máximo 12 horas entre as duas ações (serve para evitar alguns abusos), então você vai ganhar a medalha [image: Intérprete]. Se você gostar de fazer isso e continuar fazendo, depois de 50 vezes, você vai conseguir a medalha [image: Aprimorador], e quem detém essa medalha decerto faz boas contribuições ao site, pois além de responder as perguntas com boas respostas, ele também conserta essas perguntas. Se você ficar viciado em fazer isso por alguns anos, depois de repetir esse processo 500 vezes, vai ser recompensado com a raríssima medalha [image: Luminar], que só dois usuários do site conseguiram até agora: o Maniero foi o primeiro e eu sou o segundo. Gostaria que mais pessoas tivessem essa medalha.

As medalhas [image: Copidesque] e [image: Luminar] não são fáceis de se conseguir e existem por um motivo: para estimular os usuários a fazer mais edições.

No entanto, as edições não devem ser abusadas. Editar perguntas e respostas que claramente não têm salvação, não só não ajuda como também atrapalha. Perguntas fechadas que são editadas entram na fila de reabertura e se a pergunta não for salvável, isso só irá tumultuar a fila de análise. Se a pergunta era salvável mas a edição era ruim, quando uma boa edição for feita, ela não vai entrar de novo na fila de análise.

Quanto a edição de respostas ruins, se a resposta estiver na fila de análise de "não é uma resposta" ou de "qualidade muito baixa" e for editada por meio da fila de análise, ela é retirada da fila. Se a resposta for salvável e útil, é ótimo que ela saia dessa fila. Mas se a resposta era lixo, retirá-la da fila de análise é algo nocivo.

Edições também devem ser úteis. Tem gente que edita qualquer coisa desnecessária só querendo ganhar os 2 pontos sem se preocupar com a qualidade do que está editando. Tem gente que desvirtua totalmente a pergunta/resposta. Esse tipo de coisa é prejudicial.

Assim sendo, a dica é: Edite bastante, mas só tome cuidado de fazer edições boas e em perguntas/respostas que as mereçam.

Segue um exemplo de uma edição totalmente desnecessária em uma pergunta com poucas chances de salvação, tumultuando a fila de reabertura:

<kbd>[image: edição]</kbd>

E um exemplo de uma edição de uma resposta totalmente irrelevante também:

<kbd>[image: edição]</kbd>

Comment: Admiro sua paciência de recortar cada tag perfeitamente e hospedar cada uma individualmente.

Comment: 1- essa postagem sobre as medalhas ficou tão detalhada que daria um artigo de FAQ xD. 2- Entendo a preocupação com as edições, não tinha me atentado com a questão da qualidade da pergunta que estava editando, faz todo o sentido o que disse.

Comment: @CypherPotato Editei para coloquei o link paras as medalhas também. :)

Comment: +1 pela ótima explicação sobre as medalhas, e claro pelo incentivo a contribuir com o site

Answer (score 8):

Votos devem ser dados ao conteúdo e não à pessoa. Isto significa que novatos não devem ter tratamento especial. Conteúdo bom positivo, mais ou menos deixa como tá, e ruim negative.

Ajudar sempre é bom, ainda mais para novatos, especialmente os que estão apenas perdidos mas estão com vontade de acertar. Ajudar e votar não são excludentes.

Não querer negativar uma pergunta ruim porque é um novato não é de todo ruim, mas positivar algo ruim porque a pessoa é novata ou porque tem foto de mulher, ou por qualquer outro motivo é bem ruim, tanto quanto negativar porque não vai com a cara da pessoa ou tem qualquer *bias* em relação aquela pessoa.

Votos são para classificar o conteúdo nada mais que isso. Até queria que o site deixasse isso mais claro, e talvez até que escondesse por um tempo quando a pessoa é novata. Talvez para todos para evitar o voto "maria vai com as outras", embora seja bem complicado fazer isso dar certo.

O negativo foi instituído para isso mesmo, tem que votar, tem muita coisa bem ruim. Ultimamente me parece que mais que o normal, embora eu acho que a maioria que eu vejo de problema é caso para fechamento e não negativo. Alguns casos são para ambos, mas poucos. Eu até acho que poderiam abolir o negativo ou limitar a ficar em -1 (embora acho que qualquer negativo deveria mesmo é ser removido), mas precisaria sofisticar melhor os fechamentos, remoções ou pelo menos poder colocar alertas em conteúdo ruins. Como não tem, é o negativo mesmo que funciona.

Os meus negativos geralmente vão para postagens sem cuidado algum, para casos onde a pessoa não tem a menor preocupação com o que está fazendo. Pequenos problemas, falhas pontuais que qualquer um poderia cometer, coisas que dependem de certo conhecimento que nem todos tem obrigação de saber, essas eu não negativo. Mas o critério exato é de cada um, desde que não seja descaradamente pra prejudicar alguém (também gostaria que algo fosse feito nos casos que a pessoa prejudica outras disfarçadamente).

Eu parto do princípio da universalidade. Sem preconceito ou privilégio, mas admito que eu tento dar um desconto quando a pessoa é novata, se estiver meio empatado eu acabo não negativando quando é novato, mas quase sempre eu sei bem se merece ou não.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o ponto onde eu queria chegar _"embora eu acho que a maioria que eu vejo de problema é caso para fechamento e não negativo. Alguns casos são para ambos, mas poucos."_

Answer (score 4):

A maior causa de fechamentos de perguntas é porque elas já existem e já foram respondidas. Dificilmente uma pergunta feita no site fica sem resposta porque, mesmo se uma pergunta já foi respondida em algum lugar, é notificado e vinculado o link para aquela resposta na pergunta.

Sobre o **downvote**, é uma liberdade de demonstrar de forma anônima que a pergunta não faz sentido, é ruim ou que não há fundamento. Não vejo porquê dar downvote se a pergunta for pendente, mas isso não deixa de ser uma opinião pessoal.

Como o @bacco disse, **downvote** não é ofensa, nem humilhação, é apenas uma maneira de demonstrar que sua pergunta há problemas **objetivas**, e **não gramaticais.** Erros gramaticais podem ser resolvidos **por edição**.

É sempre bom editar a pergunta para que seja fácil compreender o que a pessoa está tentando resolver **sem mudar o seu objetivo**, muito menos **abreviar** o que ela quer, mas quando é impossível entender o que a pessoa quer, simplesmente sinalize a pergunta como **baixa qualidade**, e então será enviada para análise.

Perguntas e respostas de novatos são analisadas diretamente na Fila de Análise, passando por edições, sinalizações e fechamentos sempre quando necessários.

Leve em consideração esses termos que eu sempre considero antes de tocar numa pergunta:

- Há problemas ortográficos? Edite a pergunta e corrija-os.
- A pergunta já foi respondida? Sinalize e vincule o link para a pergunta que já tem a resposta.
- Não tem objetivo ou finalidade a pergunta? Pergunte nos comentários o que a pessoa quer fazer.
- É um debate/discussão de opinião? Sinalize. **Perguntas não devem ser baseada em opiniões e debates.** ([Relacionado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum))
- Pergunta ruim? Downvote.
- Pergunta boa? Upvote?
- Não se surpreendeu? Nem vote.

Por suma, acredito que não devemos deixar de comentar o objetivo da pergunta se não for explícito, pedir edições do autor sempre quando necessário, não deixar de sinalizar se tiver algum problema que está com problema, e não deixar de votar na pergunta para mostrar ao autor que há algo errado na pergunta, e no final, **após pesquisar se não há o mesmo problema já respondido**, é conveniente responder a pergunta.

Comment: Vou usar como um guia esses questionamentos que sugeriu.

Comment: Só discordo da primeira frase da sua resposta. Na minha opinião a maior causa de fechamento são as coisas que estão [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132). Tirando isso, concordo plenamente.

Answer (score 2):

Eu também sou novato aqui no site e tomei downvote uma vez. Sabia que tinha a chance de tomar downvote devido que o código que postei era só uma parte, mas era a parte que estava dando erro, mas eu consertei e consegui resolver minha questão.

Sempre que peço ajuda em algum lugar eu sempre tento antes, pesquiso sobre uma possível solução e quando não consigo nada pergunto. O problema de ser novato ou novo em um assunto novo (pelo menos para mim) e querer participar de uma comunidade para si ajudar/ajudar os outros é que devido a sua falta de conhecimento não dá pra ajudar todo mundo ou se envolver em assuntos mais avançados. O que faz sempre minha vontade de ser mais ativo nesses lugares diminuir bastante.