# E quando o problema é parte de um problema maior?

Tags: debate

Eu gostaria de evitar o "[problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/112052)", mas muitas vezes o problema do sistema é muito mais complexo do que caberia em uma página, e o StackOverflow é limitado quando se trata de um código muito extenso, daí muitas vezes cabem o uso de jsfiddle.net por exemplo.

Além disso, muitas vezes o problema, é colocado sob uma outra perspectiva, que nem sempre é o caso real, mas uma simulação prática de como deveria funcionar.

Por se tratar de uma parte do problema de uma solução maior, que muitas vezes, seria necessário desmembrar toda a arquitetura do sistema. Então, inevitavelmente, procuramos exemplificar com uma pequena alternativa para que as pessoas possam se orientar pelo que esperamos como solução ou resposta.

Um pensamento que falta aos analistas do StackOveflow neste quesito, é pensar que: "se algumas pessoas estão perguntando é porque justamente elas se limitaram a ver uma única resposta para o problema, e que as vezes não é a saída correta, mas sim o caminho que eles só conseguem enxergar para o problema da questão". Mas, não a maioria, uma boa parte, prefere empurrar o problema e jogar a pessoa na questão da tal "pergunta XY"...

Ninguém espera encontrar respostas pelos próprios caminhos, sendo assim não estariam com dúvidas. Mas esperam que se assemelhem ao resultado esperado.

Evidente que há casos que realmente é um problema XY, mas também há situações que só simulando o resultado para que alguém entenda o problema.

Já tive que colar muito código para entender que meu problema era bem menor, e depois refatorar o código e a questão. Serve como exemplo de que muitas das respostas que nem sempre chegam a solucionar o problema, acabam servindo como solução para melhorar uma pergunta, e de certa forma estar mais próximo de uma solução, ao menos para ajudar a entender o real problema.

Quando se trata de publicarem os caminhos que foram percorridos durante o processo de desenvolvimento do código, nem sempre é uma questão XY.

Comment: Não sei se entendi a questão e acho que tem algumas premissas falsas nela, mas pode ser só porque não as entendi. Nem entendi qual é a real questão, porque só tem uma no título, mas ele não quer dizer muita coisa. Normalmente em um debate se propõe algo, mesmo que em aberto e não como uma opção para as pessoas escolherem sim ou não. Em algum ponto parece só uma afirmação, quase um *rant* (quem nem sempre é ruim), não fica claro onde se quer chegar.

Comment: No meu ver, é simples assim: *Se a dúvida não se encaixa no modelo do site, não poste no site*. Pronto. (a pessoa pode procurar um fórum, contratar um analista, conversar no chat sobre o assunto, qualquer coisa que não envolva postar no SOpt - o modelo é claro e documentado, e apesar das novas tendências da rede, coisas elementares para o site ter virado referencia foram seletividade e objetividade). Agora, se tem alguma pergunta que acha que foi indevidamente classificada como XY, só trazendo o link específico para avaliação (note que Problema XY por si só não significa fechamento).

Comment: Um pensamento que falta a muitos que perguntam é "*as pessoas não conhecem meu sistema e toda informação que elas terão é o que eu colocar na pergunta, não tem como alguém adivinhar o contexto geral se eu não disser*". E se a pessoa pergunta uma coisa X mas depois começa a falar de outra coisa Y, daí vem a percepção de problema XY. O grande erro de muita gente é esse: culpar quem está tentando ajudar e não reconhecer que o problema pode ser a forma como a pergunta foi feita. Aliás, não sei se era isso que vc queria discutir, mas não vou afirmar (ainda) que é um problema XY :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo dá a impressão dessa pergunta ser XY :) Eu acho que grande parte dos problemas XY é que a pessoa quer uma solução específica, e errada, para o problema. Em geral ela posta a consequência, mas só resolve pela causa. E obviamente fruto do que eu vivo falando e as pessoas não se importam, elas não querem aprender a programar, só querem ver o problema resolvido., e aí não tem solução que dê jeito. Por isso odeio quando respondem coisas só para fazer funcionar. Em geral o AP aceitará aquela resposta, pessoas positivarão porque funciona e ensina errado a todos que não são questionadores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu gostaria de fazer um comentário, mas acabou que a lista de coisas que eu ia acabar falando iria ser muito maior do que seria adequado colocar como uma sequência de comentários. Então, vamos lá.

> Eu gostaria de evitar o "problema XY", mas muitas vezes o problema do sistema é muito mais complexo do que caberia em uma página

Ótimo por reconhecer que se deve evitar o problema XY. Mas, sinceramente, o sistema é composto por vários pequenos trechos de código que executam cada um sua parte. O sistema ser complexo demais significa que ele tem vários "módulos" (num sentido bem frouxo do que seja um módulo) e se comunica com vários deles. Sendo que a própria comunicação inter-módulos também é um módulo em questão.

Quando o problema no sistema é tão grande que se precisa colocar o sistema inteiro na pergunta para entender o que está acontecendo, isso é um sinal de que há um vazamento de abstração entre os módulos. Se você tivesse interfaces muito bem definidas (sim, eu sei, mundo ideal, condição irreal), não precisaria se preocupar com esteiras blindadas anti-tanque. [Apenas com cocos e coleta de sua água](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6585/112052).

Também tem o ponto de que aqui não somos analistas (mais sobre isso depois), e não estamos recebendo para resolver problemas pontuais. Estamos aqui para compartilhar conhecimento sobre programação e assim elevar o nível lusófono de conhecimento na área.

Para você citar essa frase desse jeito específico, é de se esperar que esteja em problema com o módulo de comunicação ou com outro módulo que é invocado por este módulo de comunicação. Isolar o problema real faz com que haja a correção real do problema.

Por exemplo, recentemente, tive [problemas com um detalhe](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/-/merge_requests/28) que me passou despercebido: a implementação de `Map.merge` é *estável*, e eu estava tendo problemas pois o jeito que meu programa estava construído exigia essa estabilidade.

O problema se deu nos testes automatizados, em que a faixa de preço do produto (que fica mais barato em saltos discretos ao atingir determinado patamar de quantidade) resgatada não era a condizente à quantidade inserida na venda. Em algum momento do código eu substitui internamente o código do coletor `groupingBy` para usar `Map.merge`. E só foi detectado o problema nessa questão da faixa de preço. Eu poderia ter resolvido isso de diversas maneiras, mas meu problema real foi só a questão de que o `merge` não estava estável. Se eu resolvesse o problema no caso individual, talvez outros pontos com problemas possíveis poderiam passar despercebidos e gerar grande encrenca no código.

Agora, como foi detectado isso? Nos testes automatizados do "módulo" de item. Esse, por sua vez, chamava o "módulo" de produto que chamava o módulo de obter a faixa adequada de uma lista ordenada (estritamente crescente) pela quantidade. Só que a lista estava ordenada de modo inverso. Logo, o erro se deu em outro ponto.

Então, na montagem do produto, eu vejo que a ordenação da lista era feito através de uma consulta no banco. A partir daí, não seria necessário nunca mais verificar a ordenação. Porém, na transformação da consulta do banco em objetos, foi necessário usar o `Collectors.groupingBy` (módulo de implementação de novidades do Java 8 no TotalCross). E a saída disso estava com erros. Viu como o problema foi possível ser detectado no "módulo" de criação do produto? Dentro desse módulo, era devido a um problema em outro módulo, que por sua vez delegava ao módulo `Map.merge`. E a solução foi simplesmente [garantir a estabilidade](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/-/merge_requests/28/diffs#68567efed6d56a6bf8054f3adbc70d1fc7f1854e_101_100).

> muitas vezes o problema, é colocado sob uma outra perspectiva, que nem sempre é o caso real, mas uma simulação prática de como deveria funcionar.

Sim, essa primeira parte se chama "abstração" (sob perspectiva que não é o caso real). A segunda é MVCE. Isso se faz para que você consiga entender a raiz do seu problema. E montar a partir daí a solução adequada com as poucas modificações necessárias, e se for necessário vazar alguma abstração o fazer também.

> Por se tratar de uma parte do problema de uma solução maior, que muitas vezes, seria necessário desmembrar toda a arquitetura do sistema.

De volta a questão aqui da componentização/modularização. Quando você está escrevendo o algoritmo, imagine que cada módulo está falando um com o outro:

[image: elementos da comunicação]

> Extraído de https://escrevendoofuturo.blogspot.com/2015/03/teoria-da-comunicacao.html

O problema pode estar no emissor, no receptor, na própria mensagem, ou o "código" sob o qual se espera que a mensagem seja interpretada. Por exemplo, no caso que eu descrevi acima, o problema estava na mensagem que não estava obedecendo aos critérios do "código" da comunicação: lista ordenada estritamente crescente.

> procuramos exemplificar com uma pequena alternativa para que as pessoas possam se orientar pelo que esperamos como solução ou resposta.

Aqui entra a questão de separar os módulos e o poder de abstração.

> Um pensamento que falta aos analistas do StackOveflow neste quesito

Prometi que voltaria a este ponto, não foi? Vamos lá, pegar como o SOpt [se auto define](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas

Tá vendo alguma menção a analista aí? Bem, não diretamente, mas há a menção a "programadores profissionais". Agora, quem é um programador profissional? A definição que eu consigo ver "troco código por dinheiro".

[image: will code for food]

Acontece que alguns analistas também são programadores, mas o inverso não é necessariamente verdade.

> pensar que: "se algumas pessoas estão perguntando é porque justamente elas se limitaram a ver uma única resposta para o problema, e que as vezes não é a saída correta, mas sim o caminho que eles só conseguem enxergar para o problema da questão"

Aqui temos uma adaga: se a pessoa não demonstrou esforço no entendimento do problema nem parece que está motivada para aprender o que fez ou deixou de fazer, provavelmente ela está aqui só pelo *helpdesk*. E não somos um *helpdesk*. Aqui respondemos coisas que serão úteis para o mundo, então definir um escopo do problema, o "módulo" onde ele se encontra, torna isso mais apreciável. Ainda mais consideração poder de abstração.

> Mas, não a maioria, uma boa parte, prefere empurrar o problema e jogar a pessoa na questão da tal "pergunta XY"...

Isso daqui é uma (outra) adaga de argumentação usada: se você está perguntando sobre algo que não é o seu problema real, falar sobre esse problema que você mesmo criou e como resolvê-lo sem realmente atacar o problema real será mais danoso do que incitar a levantar o problema real.

Eu mesmo já fiz uma pergunta sobre o [ponto Y](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408497/64969), mas deixei claro qual era o meu problema X. Tentei deixar o mais claro possível os limites e escopo do problema Y. Resultados? [Resposta para Y](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408514/64969) e [resposta para X](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408525/64969).

> Ninguém espera encontrar respostas pelos próprios caminhos, sendo assim não estariam com dúvidas

Devo discordar totalmente desse trecho. Dúvidas surgem quando as pessoas estão tentando resolver problemas, e isso é natural. Por exemplo, vendo uma regex Perl que reconhece números primos, [fiquei curioso em saber se é uma linguagem regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/436448/64969), já que os constructos usados por essa regex não são próprios de gramáticas regulares.

Perguntei isso porque me veio a dúvida durante os meus estudos. Algum tempo depois, [achei a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437316/64969) (Por sinal, estava de madrugada curtindo um hotel durante o carnaval quando me veio essa resposta, com esposa e filho dormindo). Notou como eu encontrei a resposta pelo meus próprios meios?

Isso é sempre o correto, a pessoa sempre deve achar todas as respostas para suas próprias dúvidas. Na verdade, não. Derivado dessa minha resposta, tive outra dúvida pertinente, [saber se números compostos são linguagem livre de contexto](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3567812/506414). Eu demoraria bastante para ter o [*insight* que responde o problema](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3568435/506414), talvez até maior do que eu tenho disponível nesta vida, mas para isso que existe o compartilhamento de conhecimento.

> Evidente que há casos que realmente é um problema XY, mas também há situações que só simulando o resultado para que alguém entenda o problema.

Faltou-lhe aqui novamente a questão da abstração e da comunicação com os módulos. Precisa analisar a mensagem, o "código" em que está essa mensagem, o emissor e o receptor. Tem também o ponto de coisa extremamente específica só vai servir para quem abriu a pergunta, sem serventia para difundir conhecimento.

> Já tive que colar muito código para entender que meu problema era bem menor, e depois refatorar o código e a questão

Isso significa que você não entendia realmente seu problema original. E, sim, isso é bom. Agora, necessitar colar código para perceber isso é algo que não é bom. Chega a ser ruim.

De modo geral, através da explicação do código (que é mais importante que o código em si), se deveria perceber ou ter uma noção muito bem encaminhada para saber se aquilo é o que se deseja ou não. Precisar colar o código de uma resposta como atividade rotineira significa que as respostas estão enroladas (explicação de difícil compreensão), sem explicação (as vezes o código é auto-explicativo/se torna auto-explicativo quando se tem um determinado conhecimento) ou você não está sendo crítico.

> Serve como exemplo de que muitas das respostas que nem sempre chegam a solucionar o problema, acabam servindo como solução para melhorar uma pergunta, e de certa forma estar mais próximo de uma solução, ao menos para ajudar a entender o real problema.

> Quando se trata de publicarem os caminhos que foram percorridos durante o processo de desenvolvimento do código, nem sempre é uma questão XY.

Isso é plenamente verdade. Já pensou em melhorar sua esteira?

Comment: Cara, vc expandiu minha mente agora, obrigado!