# É errado postar um código no SO que estávamos falando no Telegram?

Tags: suporte

Um colega de um grupo de Telegram que participo, postou nesse grupo um código obfuscado que continha algum problema. Ele recebeu esse código como um desafio para descobrir onde estava o problema e estava pedindo auxílio.
Achei interessante o código e resolvi analisá-lo.
No final achei que ficou bastante interessante e achei que talvez fosse útil para mais alguém e resolvi pedir a ele pra postar aqui no SO.

Mas ele está recebendo vários votos negativos sem qq explicação. Alguém pode dizer se isso fere de alguma forma alguma regra do SO em português ou qual é o problema ?
Até onde eu sei o SO (ao menos o em inglês que eu participo mais) encoraja os usuários a responderem suas próprias perguntas como forma de documentação de soluções.
Peço que se eu estiver enganado me corrijam.

A pergunta é essa aqui:

[Problema com o código em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459905/problema-com-o-c%c3%b3digo-em-javascript)

Grato

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara, por isso os negativos e o fechamento

Comment: Tem um código, uma quase explicação, só diz o contexto de onde surgiu o código e um pedido de ajuda, mas não explica com o que deveríamos ajudar

Comment: Vi que tem uma resposta sua, pelo o que pude ver, somente você poderia responder a pergunta (detalhe é que não tem nada perguntado no corpo da pergunta)

Comment: O meu teve explicação (note que tem varios posts seus que eu positivei, e nenhum me pediram explicação do porque), mas fez bem em trazer pro meta. Sobre perguntar e responder a própria pergunta, é incentivado inclusive. Só que tem os pilares básicos pra isso acontecer. Eu sinceramente acho que uma boa lida no Guia passado ajudaria a "otimizar" essa conversa toda, assim como esse outro post aqui: [Aqui não é o StackOverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/70)

Answer (score 9):

De forma geral não é um problema desde que seja pontual.

A pergunta não está feita de forma muito boa, ela está jogada e é quase um enunciado, falta informações, e provavelmente só quem teve uma conversa em outro lugar consegue responder, então não é que algo começado no Telegram seja o problema, é que para responder adequadamente precisa ir nesse grupo e ver o que rolou lá. Inclusive para para analisar, votar tem que fazer isso, esse é o problema.

Eu não negativei a pergunta, até porque tem limite de votos por dia e gasto todos eles quase todos os dias e tenho que escolher o que negativar, mas acho que esses problemas podem ser motivos para os negativos.

Me deu mais vontade de negativar, mas também não o fiz, porque o código é terrível, uma complicação quase inexplicável e que provavelmente não precisa daquilo tudo. É um dos códigos mais escabrosos que vi na vida, e já vi muitos. Parece código para fazer graça, mas indica que nem é. Esse pode ser outro motivo.

E aí a resposta acaba ficando complicada porque perpetua a ideia de que aquilo seria um bom código, ainda que pelo menos esteja mais legível. Eu também não negativei porque sem entender a pergunta seria difícil entender a resposta e nem quis analisar, e sem analisar eu não quis votar. A resposta não parece boa (não estou dizendo que ela está errada).

Tem potencial para esse conjunto ser mais danoso para outras pessoas do que algo bom. Até poderia ter o mesmo conteúdo básico, com muitas ressalvas, com alternativas, com a indicação que talvez seja um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/101), aí quem sabe, se a pergunta fosse melhor formulada, desse uma resposta boa ou até excelente, mas faltou pra chegar nisso.