# O que vamos fazer com as perguntas de suporte técnico?

Tags: debate, perguntas

O Stack Overflow em Português é um acervo de conhecimento voltado a programação. Nós colaboramos com o conteúdo que se aplica ao dia-a-dia e possa ser reproduzido em uma simples situação. Algumas situações são pouco abrangentes mas mesmo assim acarretam informação quando o conteúdo é de qualidade e didático.

O problema é quando nosso conteúdo passa a ser específico para situações específicas em códigos específicos. Não é esse o objetivo do site. Não prestamos suporte técnico.

## O problema disso

Ocorre que essas perguntas ainda são aceitas e estão no site. Muitas geram o [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy/5210#5210) porque na real é tão mal detalhada a pergunta que no final acaba sendo algo de ambiente, ou por trás dos panos está tudo bagunçado e não dá para responder em só uma resposta. Precisaria de um suporte de longo prazo para resolver aquilo.

**Não estamos aqui para resolver seu problema de graça.** Muitas perguntas são apenas de erros básicos que se resolveriam ao perguntar para outro programador, mas isso não está contribuindo em **nada** para a comunidade. Não é algo didático ou algo que vai acarretar algum conhecimento em quem ler aquilo.

Alguns exemplos de perguntas de "tech support" são:

- [obter dados de mysql usando javascript e ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177474/obter-dados-de-mysql-usando-javascript-e-ajax)
- [Erro ao rodar programa Kivy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540588/erro-ao-rodar-programa-kivy)
- [Erro ao rodar o comando "npm run prod" no Git Bash para dar Build em um projeto Ionic 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248019/erro-ao-rodar-o-comando-npm-run-prod-no-git-bash-para-dar-build-em-um-projeto)
- [Media de dias de compra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540580/media-de-dias-de-compra)
- [Método retornando undefined JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540538/m%c3%a9todo-retornando-undefined-javascript)

Algumas foram fechadas e outras requerem que escrevemos um código inteiro para o OP. Sequer escreveu uma linha ou sequer tem ideia de como começar.

Nós devemos continuar aceitando esse tipo de conteúdo no site?

Comment: *Nós devemos continuar aceitando esse tipo de conteúdo no site?* Se não, a comunidade tem fôlego para fechar o volume dessas perguntas que aparece todo dia?

Comment: Além do fato de nos preocupar com as perguntas, também temos que nos preocupar com com as respostas e temos que nos preocupar com o temperamento dos novos usuários. A comunidade está com poucos usuários dispostos a curar o conteúdo do site e menos ainda dispostos a orientar o uso do site. Por exemplo, acabei de ser insultado por quase uma hora de todas as formas por um usuário que não aceitava o fato da resposta estar equivocada e não produzir o resultado pedido pelo AP, numa pergunta ao estilo suporte técnico. Pelo menos ao final editou e corrigiu a solução.

Comment: O que deveríamos fazer é fechar tais perguntas. Mas como já dito, são poucos os que ainda se preocupam com a qualidade do site e que ainda votam para fechar. A maioria não se importa com o que o site é (ou pelo menos deveria ser), são raros os que lêem as regras. Dos que lêem, uma minoria entende e consegue se adequar. Talvez a grande - e triste - lição que o site nos trouxe é que seu objetivo é utópico demais, pois a maioria só quer helpdesk gratuito mesmo...

Comment: Nós precisamos de ferramentas melhores para barrar este tipo de conteúdo. Ou algo "automático". Talvez até mesmo algum incentivo por parte da SE.

Comment: @CypherPotato. Eu concordo que ferramentas de controle são importantes e nescessárias, mas também precisamos de mais usuários participando da moderação comunitária. O usuário que  ler esse comentário saiba que precisamos de mais votos positivos e negativos classificando sinceramente o conteúdo de acordo com a qualidade....

Comment: ... .Precisamos de mais comentários orientando os usuários a entenderem do que se trata o Stack Overflow e os orientando a usarem corretamente o site. Precisamos de mais sinalizações indicando problemas de uso e de conteúdo no site. Precisamos + votos de fechamento/reabertura orgânicos . Precisamos de mais atuação na filas de analise para dar celeridade nos processos de fechamento, melhoria e reabertura de perguntas. **Enfim não estou cobrando dos usuários que já fazem isso. Estou cobrando de você quem está lendo esse comentário e nunca, ou quase nunca, fez alguma dessas atividades**.