# Edição de pergunta reprovada, por que?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas, edições-sugeridas

Editei uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/564464/com-transformar-data-no-formato-mes-dia-ano-para-y-m-d-no-r) que tinha sido fechada por supostamente estar fora do escopo, aparentemente não tinha um exemplo reprodutível e não estava associada à "programação". Entendi, o problema e adicionei um pequeno exemplo reprodutível ao problema a fim de sanar o problema de fechamento e a comunidade pudesse contribuir com o tipo de problema.

Contudo a edição não foi aceita pelo revisor ao alegar que "esta edição descaracteriza o post para promover um produto ou serviço ou desfigura seu conteúdo".

Aqui vai algumas coisas importantes sobre essa pergunta:

1. O usuário era novo no site;
2. Aparentemente estava dando seus primeiros passos na linguagem R;
3. Problemas com datas é recorrente no R, o tipo de dado de entrada (Mes abreviado Dia, Ano) que o usuário se deparou não é muito comum em perguntas, pelo menos por aqui, mas mesmo assim R é capaz de trabalhar com esses dados, vide [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253492/where-to-find-locale-values-when-using-r-lubridate-package) e [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912171/how-can-i-explain-to-lubridate-which-locale-it-should-use).
4. A pergunta foi fechada, pois  não era de "problemas específicos, práticos ou conceituais sobre algoritmos, ferramentas e técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software."

O R é uma linguagem voltada para problemas estatísticos, não necessariamente para a construções de aplicações, embora tambem seja possível isso.

Por que esse tipo de pergunta não é aceita por aqui? A dúvida daquele usuário em questão se refere ao uso de comandos e algoritmos da linguagem R para processar um tipo de dado específico.

A edição promoveu algum tipo de produto mesmo? Onde?

Comment: A impressão que tenho, vendo sua sugestão de edição, é que vc inventou um código que vc **acha** que poderia ser o problema. Mesmo que seja um "bom palpite", ainda sim o correto é esperar a pessoa que perguntou adicionar o código (pois não temos como adivinhar). Quantas vezes já vi casos em que a pessoa descreve um problema, a gente imagina que o código é de um jeito e quando ela edita, a gente vê que não tinha nada a ver. Então isso é algo que somente quem perguntou pode nos informar. Tentativas de adivinhar o código não são edições válidas e devem ser rejeitadas sim

Comment: E sinceramente, se depois de 9 dias a pessoa não teve o interesse de adicionar o código, então não sei se vale a pena tentar salvar a pergunta. Tem ainda o detalhe que a pergunta está fechada, e ao editar ela vai para a fila de reabertura. Então se a edição não for boa o suficiente para reabri-la, nem vale o esforço (pois ao chegar na fila de reabertura, será rejeitada de qualquer forma, tomando tempo à toa dos revisores).

Comment: Por fim, vale lembrar que se a pessoa é iniciante ou tem anos de experiência, se está começando ou é especialista na linguagem, se o problema é recorrente ou raro, **nada disso faz diferença** com relação ao escopo. O que importa é que a pergunta [siga os critérios estabelecidos](/q/8496/112052), e só. Todo o resto que citou é irrelevante.

Comment: hkotsubo, na propria pergunta o usuario faz menção ao tipo de dado que entrada que possui uma string no formato "Mes, Dia Ano", além disso na própia formulação da pergunta contem um exemplo ao referenciar "May 31, 2013". Portanto a inclusão do exemplo não é uma adivinhação, mas algo mais clarificado do que o usuário tento expressar.

Comment: @hkotsubo, no que diz respeito ao "então não sei se vale a pena tentar salvar a pergunta." isso é um problema que outros usuário da linguagem podem enfrentar ao tentar converter uma string em datas

Comment: Como eu já disse, já vi **muitos** casos em que era "óbvio" o problema, mas quando a pessoa colocou o código, não tinha nada a ver. Mesmo que vc tenha "certeza", o certo é esperar a pessoa colocar o código. E se ela não o fizer, paciência. E se o problema é comum e recorrente, das duas uma: ou já tem algo no site (e aí a pergunta seria fechada como duplicada), ou que se faça uma pergunta dentro do escopo (seguindo os critérios que [já informei anteriormente](/q/8496/112052)).

Comment: O fato de ser um problema comum **não** é justificativa para postar algo que não atenda aos critérios do site. Tem que atendê-los, e aí tanto faz se o problema é comum ou raro.

Answer (score 6):

No motivo do fechamento **não** é dito que *não estava associada à "programação"*, está apenas descrito:

> **Apesar de ser sobre programação**, esta pergunta não parece atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento para um site de perguntas e respostas....

Antes de tentar fazer qualquer coisa em uma publicação fechada, é importante entender os motivos de [cada tipo de fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Sobre sua [**edição**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/406503), fui eu quem a reprovou, pois ela desfigurava a postagem, como é descrito no motivo, que é um texto padrão do sistema que vale para dois diferentes tipos de problemas:

> *Esta edição descaracteriza o post para promover um produto ou serviço ou desfigura seu conteúdo.*

Essa mensagem podem servir para:

a) para promover um produto
b) desfigura seu conteúdo

No caso a sua edição não promovia produto algum, o problema da sua edição é o "B", **desfigura seu conteúdo**

Você colocou um exemplo no corpo da pergunta que soava como uma tentativa de validar uma pergunta, que na verdade deveria depender de um posicionamento da autora, pois o que você acreditava ser um exemplo do problema, poderia não ser exatamente o que a autora precisaria.

Mesmo que você acredite que entendeu completamente o problema, não há como afirmar que de fato é isso o que a AP necessita, pois muitas perguntas, por falha dos APs, acabam sendo [**problemas XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635) (não deixe de ler o link), então mesmo que esteja convencido que seja aquilo, só a autora da postagem pode confirmar, até lá as edições devem ser sempre dentro das regras (que irei explicar a seguir)

## Edições conforme a [**central de ajuda do site**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

É esperado que as edições sejam substanciais e que deixem a publicação melhor do que foi encontrada. Os motivos mais comuns para fazer edições são:

- Corrigir erros de gramática e ortografia
- Esclarecer o significado da publicação (sem alterar esse significado)
- Incluir outras informações encontradas apenas nos comentários, de modo que todas as informações relevantes para a publicação estejam contidas em um único lugar
- Corrigir erros menores ou adicionar atualizações com o tempo
- Adicionar hyperlinks ou recursos relacionados

---

### O que acontece se alguém sugere uma edição errada?

Se um usuário sem privilégios de edição propuser uma edição que **não obedeça às orientações acima, ela será normalmente rejeitada no processo de análise**. Mesmo quando uma edição errada for aplicada a uma publicação, geralmente ela será corrigida por outros usuários. Os usuários com reputação suficiente podem optar por reverter a publicação para uma versão anterior (analisando o histórico de revisão da publicação e selecionando a versão desejada para exibição).

Em resumo, sua edição não obedeceu às orientações citadas na própria [**central de ajuda do site**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), então foi reprovada, se a autora confirmar via comentário, ou por outro meio que é exatamente aquilo o que ela está com dúvida, então você poderá mandar uma nova edição, informando aonde está a confirmação por parte da AP.

---

### Por que esse tipo de pergunta não é aceita por aqui?

Sobre sua pergunta, se perguntas sobre [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) são aceitas, e a resposta é sim, elas são aceitas, o problema não é se a pergunta é sobre [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), é sobre como a pergunta foi elaborada, o motivo do fechamento está no *caixa azul* no topo da pergunta que indica o fechamento, como expliquei aqui na postagem no começo, mas só para esclarecer os pontos, é importante entender o que é fechamento para que possa tirar um melhor proveito do site ou ajudar a comunidade:

> **Apesar de ser sobre programação**, esta pergunta **não parece atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade** e detalhamento para um
> site **de perguntas e respostas**. As perguntas aqui precisam **ser
> para problemas específicos, práticos ou conceituais sobre algoritmos,
> ferramentas e técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software**.
> *Melhore a pergunta*.

Note os pontos que destaquei acima, a mensagem possui todas orientações necessárias para que autores de perguntas fechadas possam melhorar suas publicações. Se a melhoria for feita de forma adequada, então a edição irá para [**fila de analise**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) e será reaberta a partir da avaliação dos membros experientes da comunidade.

Comment: Nao adivinhei o que o usuario quis perguntar, pois ele mesmo menciona no titulo o tipo de dado "Mes, Dia Ano", além disso na própria formulação da pergunta contem um exemplo do dado que ele possui uma string do tipo "May 31, 2013". Portanto que eu fiz foi acrescentar dados que textualmente ele apresentou, mas escritos por extenso.

Comment: Novamente afirmo a edição não promoveu nenhum produto ou serviço, tão pouco descaracterizou a pergunta original, pois me baseei no que o texto tentava transmitir

Comment: @wesleysc352 como disse na resposta, é algo que deve deixar para a autora da pergunta informar, pois isso pode ser algo que varie, não é questão de se adivinhou ou se interpretou algo... o que deve fazer é seguir as orientações da própria [Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). As mesmas regras são para todos, você, eu e qualquer outro membro do site que deseje editar alguma postagem. Todos podem editar, desde que sigam as normas. *Grato pela compreensão*.

Comment: @wesleysc352 como já expliquei, não é a parte da promoção de produto, o motivo do cancelamento é o *"desfigura a postagem"*. O resto já expliquei, é algo que não tem como sabermos, depende de uma posição da autora da postagem, e não de terceiros, fornecer o [**Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), não cabe a nenhum de nós supormos algo, só os autores das postagens podem confirmar detalhes mais específicos. ps: editei a resposta para deixar claro que isso não tem haver com "promoção de produto" de algo.

Comment: Entao o que seria "desfigurar"? Na minha concepção seria levar o problema para outra direção oposta ao seu objetivo. Neste caso, como a edição levou o problema para outra direção? O texto redigido pelo usuário, ainda com alguma dificuldade, deixa claro o problema ("May 31, 2013") e aonde gostaria de chegar (%Y-%M-%d). Obviamente faltaria por parte do autor o exemplo reprodutível dentro desse formato, foi o que eu tentei contribuir.

Comment: @wesleysc352 não podemos afirmar de fato o que a autora precisa, logo é desfigurar, mesmo que fosse aquilo que a autora precisa, ela não confirmou, então só adicionamos algo que mude muito a pergunta **se confirmado**, mas não é o caso, **já tivemos muitas edições acidentais** que pareciam ser o que os APs (autores de perguntas) desejavam, **mas acabavam por ser enganos**. Atenha-se as regras, elas são para todos nós, existem para evitar problemas. Assim que a autora lhe confirmar, via campo de comentários ou ela mesmo editar, então poderá mandar uma nova edição, desde que tenha a confirmação.

Comment: @wesleysc352 Vou repetir mais uma vez (desculpe ser repetitivo, mas parece que estamos andando em círculos mesmo, enfim): já vi muitos casos em que pela descrição, o problema era "óbvio" e a gente imaginava o código de um jeito, mas qdo a pessoa colocava o código, não tinha nada a ver. Mesmo que a chance de estar errado seja pequena, ainda sim o correto sempre é esperar a pessoa colocar o código.

Comment: concordo hkotsubo e Guilherme Nascimento o texto escrito pelo usuário pode ser uma coisa e na cabeça dele outra coisa. Mas a edição se limitou ao texto que estava lá postado. Se aplicássemos esse pensamento de que nem sempre o texto redigido é aquilo que autor da pergunta realmente quer, nunca poderíamos responder nada aqui, já que toda resposta postada estaria no campo da incerteza.  Quero deixar claro que a contribuição da edição se limitou ao texto e problema redigido pelo usuario, nunca foi sabotar nada por aqui.

Comment: @wesleysc352 muitas vezes o que os autores escrevem podem ser [**problemas XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635) (recomendo que leia esse link) ou simplesmente a pessoa não conseguem expressar 100% o que necessitam, então não adianta ficar supondo as coisas por uma única frase que leu na pergunta, não tem como nenhum de nós sabermos, só a autora pode confirmar, até lá limite-se a editar dentro das regras e do que foi confirmado (quando for confirmado), as regras são para todos.

Comment: @wesleysc352, o que os colegas estão colocando é que ao formular o exemplo você está colocando a sua compreensão do problema quando a compreensão do AP pode ser outra por exemplo reveja essa informação passada pelo AP *...Anteriormente eu fiz a mudança manualmente no bloco de notas...*. Isso sugere a possibilidade do autor da pergunta possuir além do problema evidente com a formatação de datas, também possuir problemas com importação e exportação de dados. Só um cenário dentro dos possíveis baseado no texto do pergunta. Em alterações mais invasivas o esclarecimento cabe ao autor da pergunta.

Comment: @wesleysc352 editei a resposta para responder a sua segunda pergunta *Por que esse tipo de pergunta não é aceita por aqui?*, sobre perguntas que sejam sobre a linguagem [tag:r].