# Resposta boa, só que fugindo do assunto perguntado

Tags: debate, comportamento

Talvez relacionada: [O que fazer com respostas que são boas mas não respondem o que foi perguntado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/491/o-que-fazer-com-respostas-que-s%C3%A3o-boas-mas-n%C3%A3o-respondem-o-que-foi-perguntado)

Essa pergunta: [Dúvida javascript function t(n,t,i,r)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175333/d%C3%BAvida-javascript-function-tn-t-i-r)

Todas respostas estão boas, porém [uma delas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175337/14262) foge do contexto perguntado, acredito até que o user que fez a pergunta entenda esses conceitos, e que o autor da resposta teve a mais boa das intenções, mas nesses casos não seria certo editar uma das respostas e acrescentar essas informações, caso o auto da outra resposta aprovasse, claro?

Confesso que acabei vendo certo oportunismo na resposta.....

Comment: Não estou vendo problemas, tem sua utilidade, não está errada, talvez não vá direto ao ponto, mas acho que há algum benefício nela. Tem algo específico que acha que tem de errado? É sempre bom ter mais respostas que tentam ajudar com conteúdo relevante. Eu mesmo estou pensando em responder algo lá que complementa o que já foi dito, nem espero votos, só para falar de algo que ninguém falou.

Comment: Isso não acaba abrindo certos precedentes de mal comportamento? Sei lá, só me surgiu essa dúvida mesmo rs, eu mesmo já fiz isso, de responder uma pergunta em uma linguagem, usando outra linguagem de programação, que poderia ajudar a elucidar na procura da resposta, e não foi muito bem aceito...

Comment: Eu acredito que não, me parece só trazer vantagens, a comunidade está livre para classificar a resposta como quiser, mas me parece ser uma resposta válida (não estou entrando no mérito da qualidade dela no contexto). Ali é a mesma linguagem. Mesmo em caso de outra linguagem não é bem aceito, mas é aceito :) Talvez não mereça positivos, mas também acho pouco provável que mereça negativos. Claro que cada caso é um caso. Pode ser porcaria, aí não importa onde está a resposta.

Comment: Me parece uma resposta bem util, certa vez fiz uma resposta que respondia a duvida e adicionei varios extras que de certa formam eram ligados a tecnologia, mas nao a duvida diretamente, graças a isso recebi um downvote e um comentario desagradavel de um usuario que nada tinha haver com as postagens, resumindo eu achei pertinente explicar a tecnoligia para complementar e tem gente que pensa que a resposta deve ser direta. Tem momentos que devemos ser o mais completos possiveis para ajudar o AP e futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 1):

Para desconcertar um pouco aquilo que foi dito nos comentários eu diria que ela é uma resposta aceitável.

Contúdo ela de fato nao responde á pergunta. Por esse motivo eu nao coloquei qualquer voto. Um outro problema que a resposta tem, embora nao seja nada de muito grave (eu diria até que é preciosismo) é que ela tem também uma informação incorreta. O autor da resposta diz o seguinte:

> ```
> Exemplo 1: Função com retorno void:
>
> <script>
> function hello(nome)
> {
>     alert("Hello, " + nome + "! Welcome!");
> }
> </script>
> ```

Contúdo em javascript todas as funçoes tem retorno. O retorno da funcao é `undefined` e nao `void`.

Tirando isso, como mencionei parece-me uma resposta aceitável, e especialmente relevante para iniciantes.

Comment: Posso estar totalmente errado mas digita `void(0);` no console do teu navegador e observe a saída, por favor me corrija se eu estiver enganado. Void significa vazio, então presumo que vazio não pode definir nada e por isto apresenta `undefined`, mas realmente não posso afirmar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O operadoor/funcao `void` avalia uma expressao e retorna `undefined`. Retornar `undefined` é diferente de nao retornar nada. Aquilo que quero dizer com isto é que em `javascript` nao há a mesma semantica de `void` como há em `Java` ou `C#` ou `C`.