# E quando uma boa resposta não responde a pergunta?

Tags: debate

Primeiramente, gostaria de deixar claro que, mesmo sendo remota, existe a possibilidade de eu não ter compreendido corretamente a resposta e julgado-a errada, embora há indícios que fortalecem minha tese.

Recentemente, questionei sobre o que são os parâmetros de caminho em uma URI:

[O que são Path Parameters em uma URI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228220/o-que-s%C3%A3o-path-parameters-em-uma-uri)

Apenas uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/232298/5878) apareceu e parece-me que não responde o questionado. O autor da resposta apresenta uma breve comparação entre *Path* e *Query* e cita os segmentos do caminho (*path segments*) como sendo *Parâmetros da URL*. Acredito que esta nomenclatura incorreta gerou confusão nos usuários, justificando os atuais 10 votos positivos na resposta. Não estou afirmando que a resposta não merece tais votos de forma geral, mas considerando o contexto, acho que não, pois não responde, de fato, a pergunta. É uma boa resposta que não responde a pergunta.

> **Nota:** no decorrer desta pergunta, outra resposta apareceu. Para evitar confusões, a resposta em questão é [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/232298/5878).

Os indícios que fortalecem minha visão de que a resposta não responde ao questionado são:

1. No final da resposta, ao responder o último questionamento, o autor da resposta escreve:

   > Essa pergunta fiquei um pouco confuso, Se a pergunta é se `/foo;v=1.0` é diferente de `/foo?v=1.0` a resposta é SIM, a primeira instrução seria inválida pela norma RFC3986 onde diz que os parametros path são hierárquicos e os query param são organizados após ?

   Claramente o autor julga ser inválida a sintaxe `/foo;v=1.0` mesmo sendo esta prevista na especificação citada e foco da pergunta.
2. Nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228220/o-que-s%C3%A3o-path-parameters-em-uma-uri#comment477473_232298) da resposta o autor da resposta diz:

   > @AndersonCarlosWoss cara procurei na referência e desconheço ; ponto e virgula na url, em qual seção está no rfc3986 está o ; ?desculpe a minha pergunta

   O que aponta que o autor, de fato, desconhece o foco da pergunta.

O que fazer nesse caso? São vários votos positivos em uma resposta que não responde a pergunta e, também, tendo a recompensa, se eu não dar a recompensa a outra resposta, esta ganhará metade, ao meu ver de forma não merecida.

Comment: O que acontece é que às vezes rola um efeito "maria-vai-com-as-outras", você dá um upvote só para suportar a ideia da maioria. Há casos em que uma resposta está melhor ou mais clara, mas foi respondida depois e acaba sendo votada negativamente ou não votada. 
Mas a questão é que de fato, pode haver multiplas perguntas e escolher qual é a mais certa é uma tarefa bem díficil.

Comment: Pra mim boa resposta é quando responde de fato o que foi perguntado, quando não responde é um equivoco apenas com textos aleatórios.

Comment: Acho que foi pena teres tirado a recompensa com 2 dias ainda. Podia haver outra resposta, agora que clarificaste a pergunta aqui também. E apesar da tua boa resposta.

Comment: @Sergio Pois é, acabei não cogitando essa hipótese, mas acho meio difícil, visto que só hoje que foi aparecer uma resposta correta. Acabei dando a recompensa justamente porque acredito que o usuário pesquisou bastante antes de efetuar a resposta.

Comment: [O que fazer com respostas que são boas mas não respondem o que foi perguntado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/491/91)

Comment: Eu quis dizer "Multiplas respostas" no meu comentário.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente é complicado, e acredito que a resposta que você se refere é a minha.
Mas deixa eu colocar o meu ponto de vista.

Quando você ou alguém faz uma pergunta no Stack não sabemos o nível de conhecimento da pessoa que pergunta, não sei se você conheçe 30% ou 90% sobre o assunto.

Outro fator é que, não existe um filtro de quem pode responder, ex: Somente pessoas com conhecimento > 60% poderão responder.

Sobre a pergunta, eu utilizo diariamente  Path Parameters em uma URI.

Sei 100% sobre o assunto? sinceramente duvido que eu saiba 100% de algo..rs.

Acredito que sei 70%, muito acima da média das pessoas, mas não um especialista que criará novas normas.

> Esse acho que é o grande problema, não existe uma relação que a pessoa
>   que responde a sua pergunta saiba mais ou menos que você, as vezes
>   precisamos ser mais detalhado na pergunta para mostrar que a resposta
>   que queremos é mais avançada.

Não digo que a culpa seja sua, mas minha resposta não é invalida ou incorreta, como o link apresentado pelo @RRay
[O que fazer com respostas que são boas mas não respondem o que foi perguntado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/491/91)

acho que minha resposta é boa, correta e por isso não creio que devo deleta-la, se responde 100% todas suas dúvidas? não sei; se é a melhor resposta? não sei.

**Update:** Realmente analisando a pergunta hoje e a minha resposta, vejo que ela não atende 100% a todas as perguntas inclusas na pergunta original.
Respondi sobre query, sobre parameters, diferenças entre elas..mas realmente faltou *"Isto é, /foo;v=1.0 é um recurso diferente de /foo?"*

Comment: A principal questão é que você considerou como *path parameters* um segmento de *path* que levará um valor de um parâmetro, mas são coisas completamente distintas; por isso disse que sua resposta não responde a pergunta. A resposta é boa comparando *path* com *query*, mas nada foi dito sobre os *path parameters*. Acho que isso ficou claro com as outras respostas.

Comment: Então quer dizer que se alguém me perguntar como funciona marchas de bicicletas normais e eu responder sobre marchas de moto eu estaria correto ainda e seria válido, mesmo que ambas esquemas de marcha não sejam tão semelhantes (quase nada)? Não estou lhe criticando negativamente, estou apenas achando que você ainda não entendeu por completo o problema (cc @AndersonCarlosWoss)

Comment: Não @GuilhermeNascimento o que eu quis dizer é que se ele perguntar sobre Marchas de bicicleta, eu iriei responder sobre marchas de bicicleta, porém as vezes não darei todos exemplos de câmbios disponíveis. Se eu responder uma resposta nada haver ai concordo que não tem sentido. veja que eu expliquei sobre query, sobre parameter, as diferenças, o que acho que faltou realmente foi o ponto-virgula no path que sinceramente nunca utilizei.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss por isso tinha colocado um comentário na sua pergunta, que se faltava algo, ou algum conceito da resposta, para você me avisar, assim saberia como conduzir a resposta, tentei colocar a forma mais genérica possível e que atendesse a todos. o que realmente faltou foi a parte do ponto-virgula, que no caso alguém deveria complementar a resposta, visto que realmente desconheço dessa parte.
Considero a resposta 50% respondido..rs

Comment: Mas a pergunta era somente sobre a parte do ponto-e-vírgula :D Eu tentei te avisar nos comentários e vi que você disse que não sabia esta parte, por isso vim questionar aqui o que fazer, pois a resposta falhava exatamente no tópico perguntado. Eu apenas fiquei preocupado com o número de votos em uma resposta que não respondia a pergunta. Isso pode gerar muita confusão achando que o que você respondeu é, de fato, sobre *path parameters*, mas não é. Por isso mantive meu voto negativo e fiz questão de oferecer a recompensa a outra resposta.

Comment: sim, por isso o correto é assinalizar com verde a resposta que lhe atende e não a mais votada, hj mecanismos de busca como Google, já aponta direto pra resposta marcado como correta.
Sinceramente, depois vou ver se consigo atualizar a minha resposta, porém não me sentiria a vontade de editar e adicionar partes que não domino.

Comment: alias acabo de ler a referencia e o ponto-virgula tem o mesmo efeito de =, com um detalhe, ponto-virgula dependendo do site e tecnolgia pode ocasionar um SQL injection..então não recomendo.

Comment: Perceba que as únicas coisas que pergunto são o que é o *path parameter*, que você não respondeu (você respondeu sobre segmentos do *path*), qual a função dos *path parameters*, que também não respondeu, e se o *path parameter* altera o recurso representado pelo segmento do *path*, que também não foi respondido. Em nenhum momento citei a *query*. Mas dada as outras duas respostas, acredito que não haverá mais confusão. Cabe a você se deseja manter a resposta ou não. Eu particularmente removeria.

Comment: Não consigo ver relação alguma com *path paremeters* e SQL injection, mas discussão sobre a solução é melhor lá na pergunta mesmo.

Comment: aspas simples e ponto e virgula são utilizados em SQL injection, ponto-virgula é usado para anexar novo parametro. http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: Mas isso é no SQL. Nada tem a ver com a formatação da URI.

Comment: Desculpe, mas acho que você ainda não entendeu o problema. Outra coisa SQL injection não é causado pelo `;`, isso é algo que chamamos de **"relativo"**, não vou entrar em detalhes porque acho que talvez você esteja um pouco perdido, mas esteja começando a encontrar aonde esta a raiz da questão aqui debatida nesta postagem do @AndersonCarlosWoss dentro do Meta.