# Como dar título a perguntas idênticas, onde só o que varia é a tecnologia?

Tags: debate, perguntas, título

Conforme discutido [nessa postagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289/215), se uma mesma pergunta busca respostas distintas conforme a tecnologia empregada, ela deve ser dividida em duas ou mais perguntas (uma para cada tecnologia). Entretanto, [esse outro post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297/215) fala que não se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título, pois a tag já cuida disso.

Hoje tentei criar a pergunta "Como fazer uma busca ignorando acentuação?", [para JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3994/215), sendo que já a havia feito [para Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/215). O sistema não deixou, dizendo que já existia uma pergunta com o mesmo título. Mudei para "Como fazer uma busca ignorando acentuação em JavaScript" e, por razões de coerência, alterei o título da pergunta sobre Python da mesma maneira.

O que fazer nessa situação? Me parece meio arbitrário ter que mudar a redação do título só para satisfazer a um "capricho" do sistema, por isso preferi a opção de colocar a linguagem no título. Isso está ok? Alguma sugestão de alternativa?

Comment: Seria um capricho do sistema ou nosso? Eu não vejo mal em títulos com "... em Lang-X". E sim, eu sei que as tags e o `<title>` já carregam essa informação.

Comment: @bfavaretto Me refiro ao fato do sistema rejeitar títulos idênticos, mas não um ligeiramente diferente ("Como ignorar a acentuação numa busca?", "Como buscar ignorando acentuação?" etc). Se eu estou **conscientemente** criando uma pergunta com título idêntico ao de outra, é responsabilidade minha garantir que ela não seja uma duplicata.

Comment: Acho que, no caso, a grande pergunta é se títulos genéricos demais são aceitáveis, já que podem ser utilizados várias vezes para diferente tecnologias, como exposto na pergunta do autor.

Answer (score 5):

Acho ruim colocar informação que não ajude a pergunta. Não sou contra colocar o nome da linguagem no título, mas acho que fica melhor quando ela realmente faz parte da pergunta. Colocar no título como se fosse tag, como alguns fazem, fica bem ruim e costumo retirar.

Já vi um caso que a pergunta ficou enorme porque o sujeito colocou e insistiu em colocar todas as tecnologias que eles estava falando. Curiosamente no corpo, ele não citou tão cuidadosamente.

Então não vejo problema em usar da forma proposta. E claro que a solução para os casos que conflito é esse mesmo.

Não acho obrigatório alterar o outro título que conflitou mas é claro que alterá-lo é algo coerente.

Não consigo pensar em nada melhor.

Comment: Concordo com tudo o que disse, em especial com o "não consigo pensar em nada melhor" :P Eu quis colocar essa pergunta aqui, mais pra ficar explícito, sobre como fazer quando há conflito entre duas *guidelines*.