# Perguntas e respostas que vão além da tecnologia nas tags

Tags: debate

Hoje vi uma pergunta sobre [como ofuscar código em Ruby](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40711/criptografar-c%C3%B3digo-fonte-ruby-on-rails).

No passado houve uma [pergunta semelhante para Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%c3%b3digo-fonte). Três das respostas foram formidáveis - elas explicam o assunto de uma forma que abrange não apenas Java, mas toda e qualquer tecnologia no passado, presente e futuro.

Por causa disso tive vontade de indicar a primeira pergunta como duplicata da segunda. Porém o fato de pertencerem a *tags* diferentes me deixou com um pé atrás. Seria legal fazer isso - ou bastaria indicar nos comentários que há pergunta semelhante para outra tecnologia, mas com respostas que valem para ambas?

Em tempo: vi esta pergunta: [Como dar título a perguntas idênticas, onde só o que varia é a tecnologia?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/745/como-dar-t%C3%ADtulo-a-perguntas-id%C3%AAnticas-onde-s%C3%B3-o-que-varia-%C3%A9-a-tecnologia) Achei relevante, uma vez que as perguntas que mencionei antes pedem a mesma técnica para tecnologias diferentes. Porém ainda acho que a resposta marcada como correta na pergunta sobre Java também responde a pergunta sobre Ruby neste caso.

Comment: Tem que olhar se as resposta satisfazem 100%. A pergunta só é duplicata se tudo o que ela pede está respondida em outra pergunta existente. Se realmente tudo está respondido, é duplicata. Mas pode ser que exista alguma especificidade para esta outra tecnologia e que no mínimo mereça um complemento. Aí talvez valha a indicação da outra pergunta apenas, sem fechar, pelo menos em um primeiro momento. Aí decidir se responde ou não vai de cada um. E o ideal é que esta análise seja feita por quem entenda da tecnologia da nova pergunta, senão corremos o risco dela ser fechada inadvertidamente.

Comment: Não conheço nada de Ruby mas me parece que é uma linguagem que tem mais facilidade para acessar o código e teria algumas forma para proteger um pouco mais o código que não faria sentido em Java que já tem algum nível de proteção. Talvez ele só queira saber como compilar para obter uma mínima proteção, ao contrário do outro que queria algo à prova de bala. Sei lá, já estou entrando no campo do chute.