# Gorila vs Tubarão

Tags: debate, perguntas

Quem ganharia em uma luta entre um **gorila** e um **tubarão**?

[image: Gorilla vs. Shark]

OK, talvez você esteja pensando que é uma pergunta ridícula. Talvez seja. Mas várias formas desta questão são perguntadas o tempo todo. Considere agora uma antiga pergunta do Stack Overflow intitulada Python vs Perl (já removida):

> Ok, então eu finalmente estou tentando mexer com linguagens de script e eu decidi focar em Python ou Perl. O problema é: eu não sei por onde começar.
>
> A minha experiência em programação primariamente é em C, Java e C++. Não há nenhuma tarefa específica que eu quero aprender com Python/Perl, só possivelmente aplicá-lo ao meu trabalho como desenvolvedor para facilitar a vida em geral.
>
> O que você acha ? Qual você usa? Uma é mais relevante na indústria do que outra?

Apenas substitua *Gorila* com **Perl** e *Tubarão* com **Python** e eu acho que você pode ver onde isso vai dar. Para ser justo, esta pergunta é mais uma curiosidade histórica do que qualquer outra coisa, foi perguntada nos primórdios da idade das trevas do final de 2008, quando ainda estávamos descobrindo esta coisa de perguntas e respostas. Ela já foi removida.

Esta questão, ou alguma parecida, seria imediatamente fechada como "principalmente baseadas em opiniões" se ela fosse perguntada no Stack Overflow de hoje.

> principalmente baseadas em opiniões
>
> Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.

Mas vamos aprofundar. *O que, especificamente, está errado em perguntar sobre gorila contra o tubarão?*

1. **Ninguém *precisa* saber a resposta a esta pergunta**.

   Você possui um gorila? Você possui um tubarão? Quando foi a última vez que você viu mesmo um gorila e tubarão duelando? Em outras palavras, qual é a seu papel nesta jogada em particular? Qual o problema específico, além de pura curiosidade, que uma resposta a esta pergunta satisfaria ou resolveria algo para você?
2. **Não é específico o suficiente**.

   Onde vai ser a luta, em que local? Subaquático, ou em terra? Quais são as regras da luta, para que possamos determinar um vencedor? Será que vai ser até a morte, ou sob algum tipo de sistema de pontos? Eles podem ser treinados especificamente para lutar pelos treinadores, ou estão completamente por conta própria? Sem qualquer tipo de escopo, cada resposta pode fazer suposições do que desejem - e serão seguramente centenas, todas diferentes.
3. **É difícil aprender com essas perguntas**.

   Vamos dizer que, hipoteticamente falando, tivéssemos o site animaltrainers.stackexchange.com, um local cheio de pessoas que têm experiência prática com ambos, gorilas e tubarões. E eles estiverem, hipoteticamente falando, dispostos a responder a essa pergunta com o melhor do seu conhecimento especializado. No processo, você pode aprender algumas coisas interessantes sobre os animais, tal como, que a força superior do corpo de um gorila adulto é seis vezes maior do que a de um ser humano adulto, ou então que a pele do tubarão é tão dura e áspera que antes da invenção da lixa, pele de tubarão era usada para polir madeira. Mas esse tipo de aprendizagem é, em grande parte das vezes, acidental na melhor das hipóteses, tal como um passeio aleatório através de uma enciclopédia. Pode ser prazeroso como um divertimento especulativo para comparar e contrastar estes dois animais muito diferentes em termos amplos. Mas, mesmo sob circunstâncias ideais, realmente não dá para haver uma resposta absoluta para essa pergunta diferente de "*depende, ambos os animais são adaptados ao seu ambiente particular e têm alguns pontos fortes e fracos*". Esta até que seria uma boa resposta, talvez até mesmo a resposta correta, mas ela não seria lá muito *útil*.
4. **Ela afasta especialistas**.

   Que especialista sério, treinador de animais se importaria com Gorila vs Tubarão em algum momento? Esse tipo de pergunta atrai o oposto de especialistas: pessoas que não são treinadores de animais sérios, mas estão dispostos a se envolver em especulações ociosas e discutir generalidades - ao invés de focar no mundo real, perguntas específicas, honestas e legítimas que todos enfrentam em seu trabalho do dia-a-dia. Qualquer especialista verdadeiro que chegue ao animaltrainers.stackexchange.com ficaria horrorizado ao ver uma pergunta como Gorila vs Tubarão aparecer na página inicial.

Isto é um pouco inventado, porque ninguém vai *defender* uma pergunta do Gorila vs Tubarão na rede Stack Exchange mais do que alguém, sei lá, assumir uma postura pró-racismo. É obviamente e claramente não construtivo fazer tais perguntas. Mas existem algumas sutilezas. Vamos examinar uma pergunta melhor, menos abstrata, mas com os mesmos problemas.

**Google+ vs Facebook?**

Este merece um pouquinho mais de crédito, tal como perguntar Gorila vs Humano. Incluindo dois concorrentes naturais significa que a questão já não cheira o absurdo e devaneio de Gorila vs Tubarão. Mas ainda falta definir qualquer escopo ou termos, e é, portanto, praticamente impossível responder razoavelmente. *Não construtivo ou só pode ser baseado em opiniões*.

**O que a UX do Facebook tem que fez mais sucesso do Google+?**

Ligeiramente melhor. Agora temos dois concorrentes naturais, e nós temos uma arena para lutar - mas é uma arena do tamanho da cidade de São Paulo. [UX é um tema extremamente amplo](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). É o formato? O preço? O desenho industrial? A interface de toque? Pode ser qualquer coisa. Impossível responder com outra coisa senão opiniões e palpites. *Não construtivo ou só pode ser baseado em opiniões*.

**Qual é o único aspecto da UX mais responsável pelo sucesso do Facebook contra o Google+?**

Tudo o que fizemos aqui é evitar que as respostas se tornem ensaios multi-pontos, e limitou-nos a reclamações esmagadoras (Eu *odeio* isso...), ou cartas de amor descaradas (eu *amo* isso...). Esta não é uma melhoria, é uma regressão. *Não construtivo ou só pode ser baseado em opiniões*.

**Círculos do Google+ constituem-se em uma melhor UX para compartilhar entre amigos do que os Grupos no Facebook?**

Ei, agora estamos realmente chegando a algum lugar! Nós temos escopo para um determinado recurso, sob a égide da UX.

Não é perfeito, mas é uma questão potencialmente aproveitável. O autor da questão deve contribuir também com um pouco mais de trabalho para além do título. Esperamos que seja feita uma pesquisa básica antes mesmo de perguntar. Você gasta tempo com ambos os recursos em ambos os sites? Você comparou e contrastou-os por conta própria? O que os outros estão a dizer? Partilhe a sua pesquisa! E o mais importante, dê-nos contexto. Explique por que você está olhando para isso, e o que você quer dizer com "melhor" - os cliques para compartilhar, facilidade de entendimento do uso, design, e assim por diante. **Coloque-se no lugar das pessoas que esperamos que venha a responder**. Você deu-lhes orientação e especificidades suficiente para que eles saibam como responder razoavelmente a sua pergunta, digamos, em 15 minutos?

Talvez esta seja uma distração. **Sinceramente, sinto que um monte de questões "este vs aquele" seria melhor expressas como exames dos conceitos subjacentes, sem todo o conflito disfarçado**. Mas se você *deve* comparar e contrastar duas coisas em uma pergunta no Stack Exchange - e não querem que a sua pergunta seja fechada imediatamente como principalmente baseadas em opiniões - tente manter Gorila vs Tubarão em mente.

---

Texto traduzido do original [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) escrito pelo Jeff Atwood, um dos fundadores do Stack Exchange.

Se você acha que algo não foi bem traduzido (e não foi mesmo), ajude a melhorar o texto.

Esta postagem serve não só para as pessoas entenderem o que não se pode, mas também o que se pode e como fazer para algo que parece ser ruim ser visto como bom. Praticamente qualquer coisa pode ser postada se a pessoa souber como escrever. Algumas dão muito trabalho, mas outras basta uma vontade mínima.

Comment: Bacco, se estiver lendo, pode fazer a localização dessa figura também? :) Just kidding.

Comment: Tou procurando um Mico-leão-dourado e um Boto cor-de-rosa pra por no lugar deles :P

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo que eu queria constatar, o perfil de pergunta do Stack, mas ainda assim não me esclarece, quanto a pergunta na qual a resposta esta no manual da linguagem.

Comment: Eu queria que aqui fosse mais seguido isto: **Coloque-se no lugar das pessoas que esperamos que venha a responder**. A gente ajuda e tem que ficar tendo trabalho de resolver os problemas de comunicação das pessoas.

Comment: Segundo alguns críticos, as perguntas que eu faço caem dentro desse conceito. De qualquer maneira +1 pela figura do tubarão contra o king kong

Answer (score 15):

***"Na terra o gorila ganha porque o tubarão seca, na água o tubarão ganha pois o gorila morre afogado!"*** 
Pronto.

O único problema em relação a essa pergunta é que ela não está relacionada a programação, então estaria melhor colocada no yahoo - respostas.

I - **Não vejo motivo em limitar perguntas** - se você procurava uma resposta e acabou achando uma *"pergunta ridícula"* se divirta com isso, dê uma boa gargalhada e então procure algo mais importante, afinal de contas, como você foi cair nessa página? talvez você mesmo estava procurando algo ridículo.

II - **A pior resposta é não ter reposta.** - Talvez os mais novos não saibam, mas antes do google éramos obrigados a ir em bibliotecas sanar as nossas dúvidas, podia levar uns 3 dias até conseguir aquela receita do bolo chocolate, e a receita as vezes era ruim também...

III - **As vezes as perguntas feitas por crianças ou "idiotas" nos levam a reflexões profundas.** - Certa empresa de empacotamento de vidros estava com problema na demora do empacotamento porque o empacotamento tinha que ser feito com jornais velhos e os funcionários se distraiam lendo os jornais. O chefe um dia fez uma reunião sugerindo soluções até que o "idiota" propôs "Por que não furamos os olhos dos empacotadores?". A proposta obviamente não foi aceita mas dela surgiu uma grande solução: A empresa passou a contratar deficientes cegos para esse setor.

Agora respondendo os pontos:
***1 - Ninguém precisa saber a resposta a esta pergunta.***
Pelo menos quem escreveu a pergunta quer saber a resposta. É muita presunção achar ninguém precisa dessa resposta. Você realmente sabe o que todos internautas do mundo pensam e precisam?
***2 - Não é específico o suficiente.***
E daí? Não quer responder não responde, coloca uma bandeirinha do lado dizendo "Pergunta ampla" mas deixa rolar.
***3 - É difícil aprender com essas perguntas.***
Difícil pra você que é um gênio. Pessoas não nerds aprendem muito com sites como wikipedia e yahoo respostas apesar dos PHDs por aí sempre dizerem pra não usar isso. Tá difícil de aprender com isso? Então vai ler outra pergunta que você gosta mais.
***4 - Ela afasta especialistas.***
 E a falta dela afasta todos que não são especialistas. Por exemplo: estudantes, onde o site poderia estar contribuindo socialmente na educação de crianças e aspirantes a programadores; e também administradores generalistas, que tem a necessidade de entender superficialmente várias tecnologias diferentes com o objetivo de arquitetar corretamente sistemas heterogêneos sabendo definir corretamente qual free-lancer contratar e qual tecnologia utilizar.

Comment: Nos comparar com o Yahoo respostas não é mt legal, já vi pessoa lá que responde "não sei" e recebe voto. Sobre limitar perguntas, é importante pois senão vira bagunça (tipo Yahoo Respostas), concordo que no geral é bom não pecar e ser extremamente específico, mas temos que tomar cuidado para que perguntas de baixa qualidade não se tornem maioria e afastem os especialistas. Ah, os especialistas, sem eles os não-nerds não teriam respostas úteis, e começariam inclusive a receber respostas do tipo "não sei". O que nos diferencia dos demais sites é justamente a moderação que mantém a qualidade.

Comment: Apesar das minha críticas eu não te negativei, existem alguns pontos que você citou que achei interessantes, porém também tem muita coisa que eu discordo, então tô indeciso por enquanto.

Comment: A única coisa que me chamou a atenção no que foi dito, foi a menção ao Yahoo! Respostas, pois é exatamente isso que está sendo proposto nos pontos respondidos. Entretanto, aqui não é o Yahoo! Respostas, justamente por não se aceitar este conceito de liberdade desgovernada.

Comment: Olá Math, acho a discussão bem válida, respondi aqui logo após que a minha primeira pergunta postada ontem (question 31762) ser classificada deste tipo, e suspensa. Não acho um bom cartão de visitas, para pessoas que contribuem voluntariamente, ter que estudar todas as regras do site para somente postar perguntas de alta qualidade. Sempre vi o stackoverflow em inglês como Yahoo Respostas da programação e ele me ajudou muito ao longo dos últimos 2 anos, qualquer dúvida que tenho é só procurar em inglês que tá lá rápido e fácil. Pensei que seria ótimo esse acesso em língua portuguesa também.

Comment: Mas até agora só estou achando as perguntas difíceis em português, as fáceis estão faltando. Mesmo que o SO Inglês pare de falar disso o acervo deles de perguntas fáceis está lá, e as crianças americanas sempre vão poder achar com uma simples consulta google.

Comment: É justamente esse o ponto Hamilton. Os milhões de programadores que diariamente acessam o SO em busca de respostas de qualidade e que funcionam (como fiz durante anos e ainda faço com o SOen), não querem encontrar um monte de gente "legal" batendo papo e postando coisas aleatórias. O fato de encontrarmos conteúdo bom no SO é justamente porque o conteúdo ruim foi "filtrado". Lógico que, infelizmente, algumas perguntas acabam ficando no meio e sendo fechadas sem necessidade, justamente por isso temos o meta, as edições, os comentários, etc.

Comment: Para além de parecer defender que o site aceite qualquer pergunta – e eu sou frontalmente contra isso –, você está simplificando demais a situação. Viu os exemplos abaixo dos pontos que você contestou? Não se trata de eliminar a pergunta X ou Y e seus autores, e sim trabalhar com eles para tornar a pergunta mais focada. Só isso. Se alguns fazem uma leitura radical dos motivos de fechamento (e há quem faça), isso precisa ser combatido (e vem sendo), porém abrir mão totalmente dos princípio que norteiam o site e a rede não me parece uma boa solução.

Comment: Salvaguardadas diversas comparações com o Y! Respostas, que seriam a morte do site rapidamente, ainda me pergunto se permitir algumas perguntas não seria benéfico ao site. A pergunta que originou o post original (Python vs Perl) permaneceu 3 anos no SOen, sem sequer ser fechada e teve um zilhão de votos (eu contei :D). O quanto essa e outras perguntas do mesmo tipo não permitiram que a comunidade crescesse e amadurecesse com o tempo? É justo esperar que a nossa absorva 5 anos de regras de uma só vez?

Comment: @Gabe do jeito que você menciona, dá a impressão que todos os usuários entraram no começo do SOzão e foram evoluindo juntos. Qualquer um que entre lá, absorve as regras todas de uma vez, não vejo o porque de aqui não ser assim. E com a vantagem que aqui o pessoal está na onda do #carinho e paparica até demais, então é bem mais fácil. Tanto que está todo mundo de prontidão para tentar dar suporte para fazer o usuário novo entender o que está acontecendo, mesmo ele tendo tido uma reação exagerada. Aliás, eu diria que os poucos desentendimentos do site foram justamente por falta de parâmetro.

Comment: O fato é que qualquer pergunta simples que tenho, tenho que  continuar fazendo em inglês? Porque em inglês eu acho, tá lá no SOen , mesmo que suspendam o google vai achar em cache ou o que for. Já a criança brasileira que não sabe inglês não vai achar.

Comment: @Bacco Discordo. O SOen tem uma enorme quantidade de usuários com diversos anos de experiência no site, que se dão muito bem. E uma **multidão** de pessoas que se dão mal no site. Afinal, "SE hates fun". E nossa onda de carinho passa muito mais por tentar ensinar as regras, o que é ótimo, e menos por discutir se as regras deveriam mesmo ser estas.

Comment: Hamilton, esse artigo não é contra perguntas simples, nem contra perguntas de crianças, nem contra perguntas de idiotas. Nessas categorias todas há perguntas ruins e boas, respondíveis e que geram mais ruído que informação. O artigo é uma tentativa de reduzir o ruído e ampliar a informação. Faça uma pergunta como Python vs Ruby hoje no SOen, e ela será fechada muito rapidamente.

Comment: @Gabe vale lembrar que já houve comum acordo no sentido de admitir-se que a pergunta feita pelo Hamilton foi fechada precipitadamente, e simplesmente é uma questão de ser ajustada. O resto eu vejo como um exagero por uma coisa que nem sequer é um problema, pois a solução proposta foi que ele repostasse uma versão repensada da pergunta, mas dessa vez levando em conta a documentação e orientações gerais sobre o site. Ele continua com essa opção e creio que será bem-vindo dentro de tudo o que que foi discutido. Não acho que o site tenha que fugir da expectativa geral para atender um caso isolado.

Comment: Por expectativa geral, entenda-se do perfil do SOpt, pelo feedback da comunidade, não necessariamente meu ou de qq outro individualmente. PS: Quanto ao "comum acordo" mencionado no comment anterior foi meu entendimento de toda a conversa. Pode não ser a opinião do resto.

Comment: @Bacco Também acho que não. Não me referi especificamente à pergunta dele, mas ao tipo de pergunta que originaram o tal do Gorilla vs Shark. Porque foram bem sucedidas por tanto tempo, e porque pararam de ser. E se foram bem sucedidas por tanto tempo no SOen, porque não poderiam ser aqui?

Comment: @Gabe aqui já tem bastante coisa genérica sendo mais bem sucedida do que eu imagino que deveria :) . Supondo que você tenha razão, também não acho que o momento de se discutir isto seja sempre quando há conflito. Inevitavelmente mistura com o caso específico. E eu não arriscaria mexer com um modelo que funciona. Aqui eu acho que a flexibilidade não foi positiva, mas ainda assim deixaria essa discussão (das linhas gerais) para outro momento do meta. Salvo você achar que o problema é mesmo o Gorilla x Shark. Eu já prefiro adotar o conhecimento de quem veio antes (os tais 5 anos).

Comment: O @Bacco colocou um ponto justo aqui: a discussão nestes comentários está começando a ser perder. Não é 100% sobre Gorilla vs Shark ou outra recomendação do site. Se vamos discutir o caso específico da pergunta do Hamilton, melhor abrir um debate separado sobre ela. Se vamos discutir fechamento precoce, é outro debate separado (já aberto, inclusive, mas podemos abrir outro). E tem outros casos. Seguir a discussão aqui vai ser um beco-sem-saída.

Comment: @Gabe, sugeriria o seguinte; que tal postar algo mais claro no meta sobre como seriam essas suas expectativas, para que a comunidade se orientasse mais claramente? Assim concentrariamos a discussão no lugar certo, e na sua ausência teriamos algumas orientações mais formais. O perigo destas conversas é que quem está lendo pode mudar o rumo, e quem não está, remar pro lado oposto. Dê uma pensada nisso, e pode deletar esse comment assim que ler. Eu preciso sair pq a faculdade me chama.

Comment: `A luta acontece num domo esférico preenchido com éter universal, ambos bichos podem respirar.` **Pronto**, avacalhei toda sua argumentação :P . . . E, numa nota mais séria, nos Metas mais grandes já vi muito recém chegado indignado com o formato, as regras, a moderação da comunidade, e sair propondo mudanças radicais. Bom... posso dizer que não dá muito certo. O melhor é estudar primeiro porquê as coisas são como são, participar do site por um tempo, e só então propor alguma mudança (depois de ter pesquisado o que já se discutiu sobre o assunto).

Comment: "Perl vs Python" Eu não respondo porque não conheço, já o "gorila vs. tubarão" eu conheço e pude responder algo que tava aí a meses sem resposta. Se o gorila e o tubarão podem respirar, venceria o que tem mais mobilidade nesse éter universal, Há que se lembrar que o gorila usa os braços além da mordida o que pode ser uma vantagem. Você não avacalhou apenas especificou melhor o situação.  Não propus nenhuma mudança, apenas respondi uma pergunta que, apesar de não ter votos positivos, continua sendo uma resposta. Essa resposta pode ajudar alguém que se depare com ela.

Comment: Eu tenho até medo de postar alguma coisa no Yahoo! Respostas depois que vi que, segundo eles, sua televisão 3D pode te engravidar. O_O

Comment: @Junior tens ampla razão, e tens os moderadores todos a saltarem-te em cima a pedir satisfações. Basta conta-los nos comentários para ver a atitude de "superioridade numérica".

Answer (score 1):

Que triste.... 

Me parece que tem muita gente com muita certeza e também muita gente com muita opinião. Ja solução. OU ainda Visão do problema...

**Cito entre tantos outros tópicos** GIGANTES sobre "como postar" o meu predileto "[Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas)", Eu mesma já fui devidamente apresentada a ele.

Doeu bastante.

Comment: Não entendi qual é ponto, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Bom na verdade eu acho que são vários pontos, e eu não sei bem se vou conseguir contribuir, já que sou bem novata... _-_ 
Mas talvez eu possa expor o ponto de vista JUSTAMENTE da novata..
por exemplo....  _-_ 

E de mais 4 pessoas pelo menos **(amigas e novatas como eu)** QUE não querem mais usar o stack.. _-_   

BOM, MINHA primeira pergunta então seria... **quem não "tem o minimo" deve ser posto pra fora?**

Comment: Neste momento acho que o primeiro ponto seria justamente, os participantes deste post, que "sabem" com resolver o problema de perguntas "estranhas", MAS me parece que: "quem faz estas perguntas" ou melhor a """""CAUSA destas perguntas OBSCENAS"""", não estão sendo devidamente "tratados"  e lendo um pouco os respectivos posts.. me pareceram estas pessoas são novatas... e ainda.. sabendo que amigos deixaram de usar o SO.. tenho mais certezas ainda...   OU SEJA  talvez a coisa seja um pouco diferente do que se trata aqui...

Comment: `quem não "tem o minimo" deve ser posto pra fora?` Não. Algumas pessoas ainda estão acostumadas com o formato de fórum ainda, então demora um pouco para entender o funcionamendo de um Q&A. Qualquer usuário pode fazer contribuições seja perguntas,  respostas edições etc mas primeiro se sugere que aprende o básico do site, como formatar uma pergunta e responder comentários. Lembre que no site existe um lugar mais livre que é o [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)

Comment: Qual o motivo para não o usar o SO?

Comment: Bom a partir de agora, falar sobre os outros complica, com certeza tem muita gente de opinião que vai "questionar ferrenhamente" ou ainda colocar seus "pensamentos" e ponto final. Então o máximo que posso fazer """""eh pensar em voz alta o que eu acho"""", duas amigas e um amigo simplesmente ""não me parecem a vontade"" para fazer perguntas no SO.  e por N motivos. Mas pelas minhas conversas eu poderia apostar que eles se sentem excluídos, de varias formas  diferentes.  Posso tentar reproduzir uma justificativa que uma menina me deu...

Comment: quando perguntei porque ela não fazia a pergunta aqui... "Você eh doida? quando fiz uma pergunta la, o cara me negativou e falou que eu não tinha sido clara, eu tentei consertar e ai choveu gente reclamando, ai ficava eu tentando falar que não sabia daquilo e que eu estava justamente querendo aprender aquilo e ele falando que eu tinha que ser clara...  poxa.. eu falei que não sabia..  nossa..  nossa  se eu soubesse não perguntava!!!!!!!!!!!  me senti um lixo...  não quero mais passar vergonha...  "

Comment: e alias isso aconteceu comigo também... mais de uma vez...  o clique foi rápido no negativar, DEPOIS não sei como, voltaram atras  e a pergunta ficou valida...  mas foi triste.. ALIAS exatamente como neste exato post. Você perguntou, MAS outros leram o titulo  ou primeira linha e NEG!!!!!... E acabou.  Eh assim mesmo que o SO funciona..

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto mas voltaram atrás e a pergunta ficou válida após alguma edição ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Sobre as "reclamações"  as pessoas que comentam são as mais interessadas em responder, normalmente usam um tom bem direto na escrita o que as vezes não é bem recebido/interpretado pelo autor da pergunta (Alguns levam a crítica para sí mas não devem. Se algo for críticado é o conetúdo e não a pessoa o mesmo vale para o downvote). Os votos do [meta tem um significado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1668/91). Apesar do primeiro contato com SO ter sido dos melhores, com o conhecimento do funcionamento e de não levar ao pé da letra os comentário que tal dar uma segunda chance para o SOpt?

Comment: Sobre esse post e o manual, ele são exemplos de que perguntas fechadas/negativadas podem se tornarm joias! basta refinar (delimitar o contexto, adicionar informações complementares etc) com algumas edições.

Comment: Percebo sua boa vontade em ajudar , explicar, exclarecer ... ate com exemplos.. MAS VEJA, o SO perdeu membros.. por anguns motivos ""toscos"".. que sao um pouco diferentes do que voce aborda...  essa falta de foco.. que os integrantes do SO (veteranos principalmente) tem  assusta.. (eu sofri disso....) quase sai... repito... uma pessoa MUITO chegada a mim desistiu pra sempre... um mago da informatica.. foi tratado como lixo... 
_=_ 
pena..
_=_ 
Mas eu nao sou ninguem pra falar nada aqui. Por favor  releia os posts.. ACHO voce vai ver que existe muita inconsistencia nas afirmacoes...

Comment: Voltando ao tópico deste post.. eu achoque tem maneiras muito melhores de atacar o problema...  pois a atual.. me parece afastar membros.... **mas repito. .eu "so acho".. sou novata... vocês eh que sabem o que eh melhor na casa de vocês**...

Comment: Camila, o que acontece é que quem está perguntando tem que saber no mínimo explicar qual é o problema que está tendo, caso contrário ninguém conseguirá responder, e tanto quem pergunta quanto quem está disposto a responder acabam se frustrando e perdendo tempo. Se você tem um problema e quer ajuda com alguma coisa, elabore uma pergunta, reveja ela, releia, e quando tiver certeza que explicou bem o problema e que colocou nela todas as informações relevantes, poste. Só não dá para postar qualquer coisa de qualquer jeito como muita gente aqui infelizmente faz.

Comment: Além disso, pode ser que um mago da informática como você diz, tenha perdido o SO. Já vi pessoas brilhantes e com alta capacidade que quando vem aqui tentar explicar o problema que tem, acabam escrevendo qualquer coisa de qualquer jeito, não conseguem se expressar e o resultado acaba sendo uma experiência ruim. Talvez a abordagem aqui tenha sido um pouco agressiva demais, mas a mensagem a se passar é apenas uma: "**se esforce em fazer uma boa pergunta, bem redigida, bem formatada e bem fundamentada**" - Quem fizer isso, com certeza terá sua pergunta bem recebida. Quem não fizer, não terá.

Comment: E outra coisa a se notar é que raras são as vezes onde os votos são para as pessoas. Quase sempre são para o conteúdo postado. Inclusive, votar com base na pessoa e não no conteúdo é considerado fraude de votos e passível de alguma atitude por parte dos moderadores. Isso significa que os votos que você recebe não são porque alguém gosta ou deixa de gostar de você, são porque gostaram ou não daquilo que você postou.

Comment: Quanto ao caso do "gorilla vs shark", o problema aqui é outro. São perguntas que podem ter centenas de respostas, onde cada um dá o seu pitaco e em muitas dessas respostas, não é possível se dizer qual é certa ou qual é errada. Ou seja, a pergunta degringola em uma conversa de boteco, e não é essa a finalidade aqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa bom.. desculpe mas não foi nada disso que tentei trazer a tona..  acho bom deixar esse papo pra la..  eh como eu disse...  eh difícil se comunicar. Tudo o que você disse esta certo. mas não me referi a nada disso. OBVIO que se você não ""pergunta"" não vai ter resposta... e OBVIO que que você não pergunta direito não vai ter resposta do mesmo jeito.   REPITO (tentando voltar ao tópico)  **eu achoque tem maneiras muito melhores de atacar o problema, pois a atual.. me parece afastar membros, mas repito, "so acho" sou novata... vocês eh que sabem o que eh melhor na casa de vocês**

Comment: A ideia do meta é  que todos (independente de ser veterano ou novato) possam dar ideias (novos recursos), debater problemas e melhorias para o SOpt etc. Poderia comentar quais são as suas ideias para atacar o problema? diferentes pontos de vista são bons para o debate.  O fato de ser novata não significa que não possa opinar sobre os assuntos da comunidade, muito pelo contrário, novas ideias são bem vindas.

Comment: Camila, acho que o que você está se referindo é de um problema que foi denominado de "no soup for you" - https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php - É isso?

Comment: 1) a ideia do meta eh maravilhosa, mas vamos e venhamos, não eh pra todos.... 2) O EXEMPLO da "sem sopra pra você" eh ótimo, mas acho que ainda tem umas coisa "**antes**" de **sequer**, "chegar no restaurante **pra comer**" _-_BOM caros, eu acho que, com "3 negativadas", essa resposta não esta bem aceita, LOGO, não eh melhor deixar pra la? As pessoas já sabem o que eh melhor pra elas! vamos deixar que sejam felizes !