# O que é uma pergunta baseada em opiniões?

Tags: debate, pergunta-subjetiva

A pergunta [Por que não devemos usar Singleton?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/101) provocou pelo menos 2 votos de fechamento por ser baseada em opiniões. Legal, eu fiz a pergunta para ver o que acontece e espera que isto fosse acontecer. Me faz pensar se realmente os usuários entendem o que é ser baseado em opiniões. No meu entendimento os usuários do SO não entende, parece haver muita confusão sobre isto no Programmers.SE e espero que aqui possamos ter um entendimento melhor.

Em [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101) eu traduzi o artigo do blog da SE que trata do assunto. Vamos analisar os itens colocados lá:

1. A pergunta claramente pede o porquê e o como.
2. Acho que a pergunta pede por algo que poderia ser longo. Certamente não pede um nome, um link, uma capa. E conseguiu.
3. A pergunta deixa tudo em aberto, não afirma nada se é bom ou ruim, apenas cita que pessoas acham isto, a pergunta tenta achar um motivo técnico real para entender a especulação. A pergunta não faz a especulação.
4. Embora não esteja claro na pergunta o pedido de experiências, também não dá nenhuma indicação que opiniões são aceitáveis ou desejáveis. E a resposta vai mais na linha da experiência do que da opinião. Claro que isto pode ser avaliado por cada um de um jeito diferente. A avaliação é uma opinião.
5. A pergunta não pede diretamente nada disto. Não quis tornar maçante, mas poderia ter insistido nisto. Será que precisamos de teses para comprovar tudo o que postamos aqui? Precisamos ser a Wikipedia que exige fontes para tudo? Ela exige nada, se disser que não tem fonte (tem *template* para indicar isto) a informação é aceitável assim mesmo. Claro que se algo é polêmico, alguém contesta, uma citação pode ser necessária. Mas vamos deixar este item como não contemplado.
6. Certamente há um motivo técnico para a pergunta e não é pura diversão.

Mesmo que um ou dois itens não sejam contemplados, é motivo para fechar como "baseado em opiniões"? E três ou quatro? Todos os itens têm o mesmo peso?

Particularmente eu vejo o 6o. item com um peso muito maior que todos os outros. Por isso que listas não costumam funcionar, que elas só podem dar certo se a pergunta for mais específica, for mais parecida com uma pergunta de recomendação, que não tenha o problema de [Gorila vs Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101). Listas falham facilmente em 5 itens, inclusive os piores. Listas não são *off-topic*, elas são ruins.

Perguntas em que os programadores podem ser ajudados de verdade, sem ilusão, mesmo que haja alguma polêmica, não podem sobreviver?

**Subjetivo e discussão sem sentido são coisas bem diferentes.**

Apesar de saber que a pergunta poderia ser fechada, além de ajudar quem não entende bem o problema, coloquei para testar, para provocar a discussão. E estou aqui defendendo ela. É isto que os usuários precisam fazer quando eles acreditam que suas postagens são boas.

Democracia é assim, ela não é perfeita, ela dá trabalho, ela beneficia quem consegue comunicar melhor seus argumentos e acumular apoio. Democracia não é atender os desejos individuais. Nós precisamos decidir se queremos democracia, anarquia, autoritarismo, algumas de suas variantes ou outra forma. Mas isto é assunto fora do contexto aqui.

É claro que não estou defendendo a minha pergunta, estou defendendo o melhor entendimento do que são perguntas baseadas em opinião. Mas se a comunidade não entender diferente do que eu entendo, vou ter que respeitar isto.

Eu acho esta avaliação muito boa, só precisamos afinar como usar, ou seja, ser **mais flexíveis que o SO** (que me parece ser o único site da rede que é tão rígido). Eu estou tentando deixar flexível sem deixar inútil. Não sei bem o que a SE pensa disto, em alguns momentos parece que estão jogando isto na lata do lixo. Pode até ser a intenção, mas seria bom ter um posicionamento oficial. Se for o caso, uma mudança tão importante mereceria um post no blog. Mas eu acho mesmo que não mudou nada e está havendo alguma confusão porque alguns usuários estão reclamando que não gostam deste posicionamento e a SE está tentando agradar todo mundo. Pena que não é possível.

**O objetivo aqui é conscientizar ou discutir se as diretrizes para este tipo de pergunta estão sendo aplicadas de forma a ajudar o site atingir sua melhor forma.**

Se alguns não entenderam, o objetivo do Good Subjective, Bad Subjective é mostrar **o que é o subjetivo bom**. Eles existem aos montes. Na maioria dos casos nem é difícil fazer esse tipo de pergunta de forma boa. Talvez o problema aconteça porque até mesmo perguntas objetivas são terrivelmente mal feitas em muitos casos.

Olhando de outra forma, que mal esta pergunta ou outras do mesmo gênero faz ao site?

Comment: O seu questionamento então foi feito em cima de um teste? Ou seja, foi para ver aonde a comunidade está errando ou acertando ?

Comment: Não só. Mas também. A comunidade não está necessariamente errando, mas talvez indo por um caminho que não ajuda o site. E pode ser casos mais isolados e não a comunidade.

Comment: Eu vou votar para fechar esta pergunta aqui no meta como principalmente baseada em opiniões :p Na verdade eu concordo contigo, também não vejo porque fechar a pergunta original. pra mim a pergunta é baseada em opiniões quando não pode ser respondida de forma, digamos, científica. E a pergunta original pode, sim, ser respondida com argumentos concretos.

Comment: Eu sempre achei o nome do motivo de fechamento meio estranho. Pra mim, não é a pergunta que é "baseada em opiniões", as *respostas* que ela pode gerar é que seriam baseadas em opiniões.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que o grande problema de questões do tipo, é o fato de grande parte acabar com respostas baseadas em achismo e/ou somente opiniões pessoais, sem uma fundamentação técnica, miníma que seja.

Isso vai de acordo com o 6º ponto que você levantou, se não têm como levantar nem um ponto técnico na tal pergunta, ela será somente baseada em opiniões, e acabará se tornando muito subjetiva (ruim).

O maior problema é que, não se têm uma resposta correta, e nem uma incorreta, são opiniões no final das contas, há uma grande chance de gerar discussão desnecessária, a pergunta em si não ser respondida, pois não há como ser respondida, encher respostas de comentários não relatados, e voltado para isso tudo, devemos lembrar que o foco principal do SO não é discutir sobre um tópico, é respondê-lo.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu o 6o. item, é o item onde essa pergunta passa mais longe de ser um problema. Eu até já vi uma resposta correta ali, não sei se será a melhor. Você viu alguma discussão lá no pergunta? Lembro que aqui é o SOpt, é diferente do SO. Eu também não quero achismos, mas achar que vai ter achismo é... achismo. Existe uma diretriz para avaliar o que é subjetivo bom justamente para não limar tudo que é subjetivo. Se você acha que a rede SE não permite nada subjetivo, você precisa pesquisar melhor. O que deve ser limado é o subjetivo ruim.

Comment: Eu entendi o ponto 6º, ao que parece eu que não expressei muito bem isso acima. E a sua pergunta se encaixa muito bem à ele, minha resposta foi de forma geral, principalmente à sua última indagação: ``[...] outras do mesmo gênero faz ao site?``